# IPv4 Integer Conversion Function

Tags: code-golf, conversion

Write the shortest function to convert an IP address into it's integer representation and output it as an integer.

To change an IPv4 address to it's integer representation, the following calculation is required:

- Break the IP address into it's four octets.
- `(Octet1 * 16777216) + (Octet2 * 65536) + (Octet3 * 256) + (Octet4)`

**Sample Input**

```
192.168.1.1           10.10.104.36           8.8.8.8
```

**Sample Output**

```
3232235777            168454180              134744072
```

Comment: I think this would be better if there was a restriction in place prohibiting a language's built-in functions.

Comment: @George - Yea, it would have been, but people had already done it before the I could put that in - I honestly didn't think about it.

Answer (score 11):

### PHP - 21 Characters

```
<?=ip2long($argv[1]);
```

Answer (score 8):

### MySQL - 20 Characters

```
SELECT INET_ATON(s);
```

Answer (score 8):

**C: 79 characters**

```
main(i,a)char**a;{i=i<<8|strtol(a[1],a+1,0);*a[1]++?main(i,a):printf("%u",i);}
```

EDIT: removed C++, would not compile without headers; with GCC, the `printf` and `strtol` function calls trigger built-in functions, hence headers can be skipped. Thx to @ugoren for the tips. This will compile as is without additional options to `gcc`.

EDIT2: `return` is actually redundant :)

Comment: very clever use of main() :) .. my version was 116bytes.

Comment: I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: @George, what is your input and how are you running it?

Comment: I'm running it with my UserScript through http://codepad.org

Comment: This won't work in C++, you can't call main recursively.

Comment: Very nice. Can save a few characters though: K&R style saves 6 with `main(i,a)char**a;{...`, and `&a[1]` is `a+1`.

Comment: @Bunnit, it will (may not be standards compliant), however the only difference is that `printf` and `strtol` are not built-in functions, so need to include two headers explicitly! I'll remove the c++ from the answer...

Comment: @ugoren, thx for the tips!

Comment: @Nim, it is illegal to call main() in C++, it is one of the differences between C and C++.  It's explicitly stated in the standard.  It might compile but it's UB.

Comment: Actually the question only asks for a function anyway so it doesn't even have to be main.  So you could save an extra six characters by using a single letter name.(Also now it should definitely not compile on any C++ compiler due to the default ints)

Answer (score 8):

## Ruby (no builtins/eval) - 47

```
s=->s{s.split(".").inject(0){|a,b|a<<8|b.to_i}}
```

Test:

```
s["192.168.1.1"]
3232235777
```

Answer (score 7):

### Befunge - 2x11 = 22 characters

So close, Befunge will win one day.

```
>&+~1+#v_.@
^*4*8*8<
```

#### Explanation

The biggest distinguishing feature of [Befunge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge) is that instead of being a linear set of instructions like most languages; it is a 2d grid of single character instructions, where control can flow in any direction.

```
>      v
^      <
```

These characters change the direction of control when they are hit, this makes the main loop.

```
 &+~1+
```

This inputs a number and pushes it onto the stack (`&`), pops the top two values off the stack, adds them and pushes them back onto the stack (`+`), inputs a single character and places its ascii value on the stack (`~`), then pushes 1 onto the stack and adds them (`1+`).

The interpreter I've been using returns -1 for end of input, some return 0 instead so the `1+` part could be removed for them.

```
      #v_.@
```

The `#` causes the next character to be skipped, then the `_` pops a value off the stack and if it is zero sends control right, otherwise sends it left.  If the value was zero `.` pops a value off the stack and outputs it as an integer and `@` stops the program.  Otherwise `v` sends control down to the return loop.

```
^*4*8*8<
```

This simply multiplies the top value of the stack by 256 and returns control to the start.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but should that be 19 chars? I understand why you say 2x11, but why does it work that way?

Comment: [Befunge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Befunge) is a 2d language, if you look for the `>v<^` that is actually the main loop in this program.  I guess in this case control doesn't actually pass through those last 3 spaces on the bottom, but I find it easiest to just count Befunge programs as the smallest bounding rectangle; and if you were to try and count control flow you get into trouble with self-modifying programs.

Answer (score 7):

### Golfscript -- 16 chars

```
{[~]2%256base}:f
```

As a standalone program, this is even shorter at 11.

```
~]2%256base
```

Extremely straightforward. Evaluates the input string (`~`) and puts it into an array `[]`. Since the `.`s in the string duplicate the top of the stack, we only take every other term in the array (`2%`). We now have an array which basically represents a base 256 number, so we use a built-in function to do the conversion. (`256base`).

Comment: very clever. i guess base256 is treated differently to say base10 or base16 then where 48=>0?

Comment: @gnibbler: I'm not sure what you're suggesting -- the base function handles all bases the same way, e.g. `{:B;{\B*+}*}:base` (although the real function is overloaded for conversions the other way). Interesting to note is that base conversion for strings is the same as arrays (as strings are just arrays without nesting, but with a different output format).

Comment: yeah i was thinking of base conversions of strings, so i didn't look closely enough at `base` for my answer

Comment: Very clever. Now do that for an IPv6 address. :)

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby (40)

```rb
q=->x{x.gsub(/(\d+)\.?/){'%02x'%$1}.hex}
```

->

```rb
q["192.168.1.1"]
=> 3232235777
```

Comment: Nice idea of using regexp.

Comment: Very clever!  Also you can write `to_i 16` as `hex` to save some characters.

Comment: thanks @chron that made both this and [link](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4907/implementing-a-firewall/4977#4977) 4 characters shorter

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby - 46 chars

```
require"ipaddr"
def f s;IPAddr.new(s).to_i;end
```

Comment: I think that constitutes cheating. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

## Bash - 46

#### Table of content

You will find 4 differently golfed version:

> ```
> echo $[_=32,`printf "%d<<(_-=8)|" ${1//./ }`0]                        # 46chr
> set -- ${1//./ };echo $[$1<<24|$2<<16|$3<<8|$4]                       # 47chr
> v=('|%d<<'{24,16,8,0});printf -vv "${v[*]}" ${1//./ };echo $[0$v]     # 65chr
> mapfile -td. i<<<$1;for((a=o=0;a<4;o+=i[a]<<(3-a++)*8)){ :;};echo $o  # 68chr
> ```

### New version! 2018-11-15 More golfed, 46 char

```
echo $[_=32,`printf "%d<<(_-=8)|" ${1//./ }`0]
```

#### Explanation

- I used `$_` for more golfing.
- Syntax `${1//./ }`will substitute every dots `.` by spaces .
- so `printf`will render something like `192<<(_-=8)|168<<(_-=8)|1<<(_-=8)|1<<(_-=8)|`
- then we will add a `0` after last **OR** `|` and
- preset `_` to **32**. [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) will read construct from left to right, so `$((_-=8))` make `24` at 1st *shift*, `16` on second, and so on.

in action:

```
set -- 192.168.1.1
echo $[_=32,`printf "%d<<(_-=8)|" ${1//./ }`0]
3232235777
```

For fun: trying to get `$_` content, after this:

> ```
> echo $_
> 3232235777
> ```
>
> ;-b
>
> ```
> set -- 192.168.1.1
> echo $_ $[_=32,`printf "%d<<(_-=8)|" ${1//./ }`0] $_
> 192.168.1.1 3232235777 0
> ```
>
> Ok, that's correct *`32 - 4 x 8 = 0`*

In a function:

```
ip2int() {
    echo $[_=32,`printf "%d<<(_-=8)|" ${1//./ }`0]
}
ip2int 192.168.1.1
3232235777
ip2int 255.255.255.255
4294967295
ip2int 0.0.0.0
0
```

#### or into a loop: -> 60

```
ip2int() {
    for i;do
        echo $[_=32,`printf "%d<<(_-=8)|" ${i//./ }`0]
    done
}

ip2int 192.168.1.1 10.10.104.36 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0
3232235777
168454180
134744072
16843009
4294967295
0
```

### bash (v4.1+): 47

***First post***

```
set -- ${1//./ };echo $[$1<<24|$2<<16|$3<<8|$4]
```

Explanation:

- Syntax `${1//./ }`will substitute every dots `.` by spaces .
- `set --` set *positional parameters* (`$@=($1 $2 $3...)`)
- So `set -- ${1//./ }` will split `$1` by dots and set `$1`, `$2`, `$3` and `$4` if string containg `3` dots (and no spaces).

in action:

```
set -- 192.168.1.1
set -- ${1//./ };echo $[$1<<24|$2<<16|$3<<8|$4]
3232235777
```

or in a function:

```
ip2int() {
    set -- ${1//./ }
    echo $[$1<<24|$2<<16|$3<<8|$4]
}
ip2int 192.168.1.1
3232235777
ip2int 0.0.0.0
0
```

#### or into a loop: -> 61

```
for i;do set -- ${i//./ };echo $[$1<<24|$2<<16|$3<<8|$4];done
```

in action:

```
ip2int() {
    for i;do
        set -- ${i//./ }
        echo $[$1<<24|$2<<16|$3<<8|$4]
    done
}

ip2int 192.168.1.1 10.10.104.36 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0
3232235777
168454180
134744072
16843009
0
```

### Another version differently golfed: 65

```
v=('|%d<<'{24,16,8,0});printf -vv "${v[*]}" ${1//./ };echo $[0$v]
```

Sample:

```
ip2int() {
    v=('|%d<<'{24,16,8,0});printf -vv "${v[*]}" ${1//./ };echo $[0$v]
}

ip2int 255.255.255.255
4294967295
ip2int 10.10.104.36
168454180
```

In a loop (+14): 82

```
ip2int() {
    for i;do
        v=('|%d<<'{24,16,8,0})
        printf -vv "${v[*]}" ${1//./ }
        echo $[0$v]
    done
}
```

*** or a little more ugly: 70***

```
v=('|%d<<'{24,16,8});printf -vv "${v[*]}" ${1//./ };echo $[0${v%<<2*}]
```

where `printf` give some string like `|192<<24 |168<<16 |1<<8|1<<24 |0<<16 |0<<8` we have to cut at last `<<2...`.

### golfed with `mapfile`, longer: 68

```
ip2int() {
    mapfile -td. i<<<$1;for((a=o=0;a<4;o+=i[a]<<(3-a++)*8)){ :;};echo $o
}
```

or with loop: 82

```
ip2int() {
    for a;do
      mapfile -td. i<<<$a;for((a=o=0;a<4;o+=i[a]<<(3-a++)*8)){ :;};echo $o
    done
}
```

Comment: could you add a brief explanation?  i've been trying to get into bash golfing and i don't follow what's happening with the `set --` part.  thanks.

Comment: @Jonah : `set -- foo bar` will populate `$@` with ***foo*** as `$1` and ***bar*** as `$2`.

Comment: @Jonah Added new version

Comment: New version! more golfed, -1 char!!

Comment: Fun: Try to look content of `$_` after running `echo $[_=32,\`printf "%d<<(_-=8)|" ${1//./ }\`0]` ;-)

Comment: Managed to [shave 19 characters off this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266546/70305). For your existing solution though, it could be shorter without meaningful refactoring; `set`, at least on my system, doesn't need the `--` argument when what follows can't be mistaken for other switches (and plain integers can't be), so you second shortest solution can easily shave three characters (a space + `--`) to get it down to `44`.

Answer (score 4):

## AWK in ~47 chars

First-timer here...  Um, not sure how to count this, but without the 'echo' it's 47 chars in AWK.  (Not exactly bogey golf, but it's in the hole.)

```
echo $addr | /bin/awk -F\. '{print $1*16777216+$2*65536+$3*256+$4}'
```

Full day early for #tbt, too, so I actually met a schedule!!!  *8-)

Banner day.

Comment: Welcome!  You'd only count the body of what you'd put into an awk script.  See [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37217/rosetta-stone-challenge-whats-average-anyways/37239#37239).  In your case you'd count only `{print $1*16777216+$2*65536+$3*256+$4}`.  Of course you'd have to move the field separator into the program, rather than specifying it as a flag.

Answer (score 3):

### Golfscript - 21 chars

```
{'.'/{~}%{\256*+}*}:f
```

Comment: +1 Good solid solution. Don't you wish GolfScript provides bit-shifting operators? ;-) (Though, darned if I know which symbols they should be bound to.)

Answer (score 3):

### Python <strike>56</strike> 45

```
c=lambda x:eval('((('+x.replace('.','<<8)+'))
```

Answer (score 3):

### C++ - lots of chars

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
uint f(std::string p)
{
        std::vector<std::string> x;
        boost::split(x,p,boost::is_any_of("."));
        uint r=0;
        for (uint i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
                r=r*256+atoi(x[i].c_str());
        return r;
}
```

Comment: @George Edison: using boost helps to get down with the numbers of chars? :)

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell <s>66</s> 61

Variation on Joey's answer:

```
filter I{([ipaddress](($_-split'\.')[3..0]-join'.')).address}

PS C:\> '192.168.1.1' | I
3232235777
PS C:\> '10.10.104.36' | I
168454180
PS C:\> '8.8.8.8' | I
134744072
```

Comment: Argh, I must have been stupid to have missed that ...

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, <s>47</s> 43 bytes

```powershell
$args-split'\.'|%{$r=([long]$r-shl8)+$_};$r
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

$args-split'\.'|%{$r=([long]$r-shl8)+$_};$r

}

@(
    ,("192.168.1.1",3232235777)
    ,("10.10.104.36",168454180)
    ,("8.8.8.8",134744072)
) | % {
    $s,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $s
    "$($result-eq$expected): $result"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: 3232235777
True: 168454180
True: 134744072
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Windows PowerShell, 70

Naïve approach:

```
filter I{[int[]]$x=$_-split'\.'
$x[0]*16MB+$x[1]*64KB+$x[2]*256+$x[3]}
```

With using System.Net.IPAddress: **76**

```
filter I{([ipaddress]($_-replace('(.+)\.'*3+'(.+)'),'$4.$3.$2.$1')).address}
```

Test:

```
> '192.168.1.1'|I
3232235777
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (45 characters)

Requires support for the `.reduce()` Array method introduced in ES5 and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions).

```
f=(x)=>x.split('.').reduce((p,c)=>p<<8|c)>>>0
```

Comment: Huh... I didn't know >>> worked like that (converting to unsigned 32 bit integer)

Answer (score 2):

### Befunge-93 - 36 characters

```
&"~"2+::8****&884**:**&884***&++++.@
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl : DIY ( for oneliners. )(40)

```
$j=3;$i+=($_<<($j--*8))for split/\./,$x;
```

# Use value in $i

## DIY Function(65):

```
sub atoi{my($i,$j)=(0,3);$i+=($_<<($j--*8))for split'.',shift;$i}
```

Comment: You can split by a string, so you save a character by using `split'.'` rather than `split/\./`

Comment: With the function version, yes, but the inline version no, because you'd need `split q{.}` to get around the need to escape shell quotes :/

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell - 14 chars

```
(.) a=(256*a+)
```

usage in GHCi:

```
Prelude> let (.) a=(256*a+)
Prelude> 192. 168. 0. 1
3232235521
```

The only problem is that you have to put spaces left or right of the dot, otherwise the numbers will be interpreted as floating point.

Comment: mind adding a brief explanation?

Comment: the dot infix operator is redefined to do the computation, very smart indeed!

Comment: This is very clever, but it doesn't use the correct input format (because of the spaces)

Answer (score 2):

### C# – 77 chars

```
Func<string,uint>F=s=>s.Split('.').Aggregate(0u,(c,b)=>(c<<8)+uint.Parse(b));
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
'.¡₁β
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fXe/QwkdNjec2/f9vaKAHRiZ6xmYA)

Comment: dude people are such ninjas

Answer (score 1):

**C# - 120 Characters**

```
float s(string i){var o=i.Split('.').Select(n=>float.Parse(n)).ToList();return 16777216*o[0]+65536*o[1]+256*o[2]+o[3];}
```

My first code golf - be gentle ;)

Comment: You can remove the spaces around your first '='. However, your main problem is int overflow ;). Remember, an IP address takes up 4 full bytes.

Comment: @Nellius - quite right. I didn't even think of checking that, basically checked on compile. Thanks, will fix now.

Answer (score 1):

## D: 84 Characters

```
uint f(S)(S s)
{
    uint n;
    int i = 4;

    foreach(o; s.split("."))
        n += to!uint(o) << 8 * --i;

    return n;
}
```

Comment: i don't know D so forgive me if it's whitespace sensitive like python, but this doesn't look golfed.  can you remove the double line breaks or the line breaks between semi-colon terminated statements?

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.2 (69)

```
sum((int(j)*4**(4*i)) for i,j in enumerate(input().split('.')[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP (no builtins/eval) - 54

```
<foreach(explode(".",$argv[1])as$b)$a=@$a<<8|$b;echo$a;
```

Comment: Shouldn't this open with `<?php`, not just `<`?

Comment: @TRiG, I believe you can change the PHP opening delimiter in the config file. Useful in this case.

Comment: @Xeoncross. Ah. Neat. I might try that one day, just to mess with my workmates' heads.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 14 characters:

```
sub _{unpack'L>',pop}

# Example usage
print _(10.10.104.36) # prints 168454180
```

Comment: How do you make that 14 characters? I count 21.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
üL▼ü╛tΓi╨
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=814c1f81be74e269d0&i=192.168.1.1%0A10.10.104.36%0A8.8.8.8&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 16 bytes

```perl6
{:256[m:g/\d+/]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2srI1Cw61ypdPyZFWz@29n9xYqVCmoZKvKZCWn6Rgo2hpZGeoZmFnqGeoYKhgR4YmegZmylY6IGh3X8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) `-m32` / POSIX, 33 bytes

```c
f(a){inet_aton(a,&a);a=ntohl(a);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3NCoMwEITP@hSL0JL4kzZaxGJ9EislBKMBTYqml0pevWkqZfewMzt8w7OBc@cEYniTqjcPZrRCLD0yXLNGGT1O/lVbNzOpEIYtDPjIFohN20EDG0T0mhNaVoQSGqVensm@F1KUP12RfSKwdRgIvQCSyoBszjXI2yrfvRbI4NP/ig32fpLsRcFz8VmBosPrrjzLB1vZYexBNrTuw8XEhtVlc5F/AQ)

On a big-endian platform, you could simply define a macro with `-Df=inet_aton` for **13 bytes**.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ṣ”.Vḅ⁹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsWPGubqhT3c0fqocef///8NLY30DM0s9Az1DAE)

#### How it works

```
ṣ”.Vḅ⁹  Main link (monad). Input: string
ṣ”.     Split at dots
   V    Convert to numbers
    ḅ⁹  Convert base 256 to integer
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 27 bytes

```bash
echo $[${1//./<<32-++i*8|}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BJVql2lBfX0/fxsbYSFdbO1PLoqY29v///4aWRnqGZhZ6hnqGAA)

At the cost of 1 character, this can avoid depending on the state of `i`:

```bash
echo $[i=4,${1//./<<--i*8|}]
```

Dramatic improvement on existing [`bash` solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48169/70305) (46 characters at time of writing).

Comment: Well seen and clever! By using integer: `declare -i i;i="i=4,${1//./<<--i*8|}"` will assign integer value to `$i`! Nice!

Comment: Not shorter variant: `echo $[i=3,${1//./<<i--*8|}]`

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 10 bytes

```
256/.'"."\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxVT81ugzAYu+cpomhStwMJ+YFQ8gQ97bBjh1SUJRSVJgxCRTVtzz4WbS3z951sy7JtybKc4A3C6BWAUH487K9fQ2khhLM6+JN6PNi67dSsrmp4qj4Xzx7RLcM0LzDFFCnOOGM8k1JWUUtxfIF5jtTiEpmgRRq1AsdbaC6kEKlkFQAEHEPox5IQ7d9M4zuLx1Drk5n1sXaNwdqfyftkxtB6NxKeb0nbX0TSumAaMyTau4sZxkVM7OT0jwuAl/rcdwbuXD8FAFZ94R3rpiv6t+Qt43kKMeS+E65D/gbCf7gNBN9R5llf)

- `"."\` split string input on `.`'s
- `.'` convert each string to its integer
- `256/` convert from base-256

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell - 53

Variation on Ty Auvil's answer, which is a variation on Joey's answer:

`%{([ipaddress]($_.split('.')[3..0]-join'.')).address}`

```
PS C:\> '192.168.1.1' | %{([ipaddress]($_.split('.')[3..0]-join'.')).address}
3232235777
PS C:\> '10.10.104.36' | %{([ipaddress]($_.split('.')[3..0]-join'.')).address}
168454180
PS C:\> '8.8.8.8' | %{([ipaddress]($_.split('.')[3..0]-join'.')).address}
134744072
```

I would have just made a suggestion in the comments, but not enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

**ASM - 98 byte executable (WinXP command shell), about 485 characters**

Assemble using A86. Badly formed IP addresses generate undefined output.

```
    mov si,82h
    mov di,10
    mov bp,l3
    fldz
    push l2
    push l0
    push l0
    push l0
 l0:xor ax,ax
    xor cx,cx
 l1:add ax,cx
    mov [bp+di],ax
    mul di
    mov cx,ax
    lodsb
    sub al,'0'
    jnc l1
    fild w[bp]
    fmulp
    fild w[bp+di]
    faddp  
    ret
 l2:fbstp [si]
    mov bx,di
    mov di,bp
 l4:dec bx
    jz l5
    mov al,[si+bx-1]
    aam 16
    add ax,'00'
    xchg al,ah
    stosw
    jmp l4
 l5:mov al,'$'
    stosb
    lea di,[bp-1]
 l6:inc di
    cmp b[di],'0'
    je l6
 l7:cmp b[di],al
    jne l8
    dec di
 l8:mov dx,di
    mov ah,9
    int 21h
    ret
 l3:dw 256
```

Answer (score 0):

### C (91)

Not going to win anyway, so I tried to be a bit creative.
Tested on 32-bit GCC 4.4.3.

```
main(a,c,b)char**c,*b;{c=c[1];for(b=&a+1;c=strtok(c,".");c=0)*--b=atoi(c);printf("%u",a);}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Scala 59 chars:

```
def f(i:String)=(0L/:i.split("\\.").map(_.toInt))(_*256+_)
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Perl with builtins (35):**

```
unpack"N",pack"C4",split/\./,shift;
```

### Perl without builtins (42):

```
split/\./,shift;$s+=$_<<@_*8while$_=shift;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python (No eval) - 67

```
c=lambda x:long(''.join(["%02X"%long(i) for i in x.split('.')]),16)
```

Comment: can you not shorten it a few more characters by using int() instead of long()?

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 53 chars

```
f=FromDigits;f[f/@StringSplit[InputString[],"."],256]
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, 21 bytes

```
[:256&#.[:".;._1'.'&,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7BCsIwEETv/YpBoWkhLs0mbWpipSB48uS1iJTSIl4U6s2Pj2lldhnYNyzzDBsSExoHAYkCLu6OcLpezqFzXFbpljq3IU93JUikMuTJZ@jncUZDEGrPpKqaFCnhoVkz69JaCx9ZQesY0lWEMWZKo@piYTWtWs7aWGMKy8m7n9enU3tsv4QG0VwyDo8XMpaOc2Q3eWiXWO5J418j/AA)

### explanation

```
[: 256&#. [: ".;._1 '.'&,          
[: 256&#.                   NB. assuming a base 256 list, 
                            NB. convert the following to decimal:
                    '.'&,   NB. the input with a dot appended
          [: ".;._1         NB. split at dots and converted to ints
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
4Ḷ⁹*U
ṣ”.V×¢S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/k4Y5tjxp3aoVyPdy5@FHDXL2ww9MPLQr@//@/hR4YAgA)

I don't think Jelly has a builtin for this. At least, I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 16 chars, 32 bytes

```
{256⊥⍎¨⍵⊂⍨⍵≠'.'}
```

test

```
  f←{256⊥⍎¨⍵⊂⍨⍵≠'.'}
  f¨'192.168.1.1' '10.10.104.36' '8.8.8.8'
3232235777 168454180 134744072
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 83 bytes

`i->{long u=0;for(int j=0;j<4;)u+=new Long(i.split("\\.")[j])<<(24-8*j++);return u;}`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY9Na8MwDIbv@RUiJ3shZilltDgZ9L6demx78FK3yEvs4I@OEvLbMyXUByGkB72PjXqo0g3amuvvjP3gfARDM5EiduLgvXoGmWVtp0KAb4U2GzMAtFH7m2o1HGAEGtDrnL2DS5Edo0dqkctlM2VUQlQRW4IRmhnLz3GFU/Mub84zugaGelNvJU9FY/UffBHAUIShw8jy81nk/GQuvK7ZZlvu3kxRcOl1TN5CktMsl5Qh/XSU8gp7OLxCT8YvodMFlL8HTuC4Gh@fIepekLIYCIgUt@jn1X4jqo@dqESVcy7XP0zzPw)

Could have saved 10 bytes by moving the initialisation of `u` and `j` "up" a level but I'm not entirely sure that's allowed so I went for the safe version of my solution.

Answer (score 0):

### Burlesque - 11 bytes

```
'.;;ri256ug

'.;;           split by `.`
    ri         read integer
      256ug    undigits base 256
```

[Try it online.](http://cheap.int-e.eu/~burlesque/burlesque.cgi?q=%22192.168.1.1%22%27.%3B%3Bri256ug)

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, <s>10</s> 4 bytes

```
nG²o
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=bkeybw==&input=IjE5Mi4xNjguMS4xIg==)

```
 G       :16
  ²      :Squared
   o     :Range [0,G²)
n        :Convert input string from that base to base-10 integer
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 50 bytes

```
{it.split(".").fold(0L){a,v->v.toInt()+(a shl 8)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BDoIwEADvvGLT026UxnowSAKeTbj5giZQ3Fi3DVQuhLdXdK6TzLxC8ix5sR5cDfhIE8tIULbQBRmhySsnPUfPCZVWpF3wPZ46Wu1xKdtFp3CXhHRAC/PTQ0Xblt1H4G1ZkGAtYOdX5wgNTIPtO5ZhN7calPrbuC8TOuRIVGzZXM/aXCpttPkC)

Answer (score 0):

## [min](https://min-lang.org), 53 bytes

```
"." split 3 :a (int 256 a pow * a 1 - @a int) map sum
```

Takes IP address as string on stack. Leaves the converted number on top of stack.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 58 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = 58 bytes.

- Filename (escaped): `._\377\001.+.c.c.!.!.!.i.s._\377\001.+.c.!.!.+.i.s._\377\001.+.!.+.i.s._.+.n`
- Content: empty

Problem is that my implementation of Pxem supports literal value up to 255; needed to make greatee values by myself.

### Usage

Via stdin/stdout. Accepts only one input at once.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lRhrV9u48nt/heLNQ4rtyM4DQhSFhUC72YWUBdpLm7gckzjEYJyHHQgN7l/fO5IdJ9A9596eHCxpnprRzGjEfTD@5zdk39iGM6jXzd2b2nCnYtZhrJcrO2VnUDPM2l6tNhruGPXKu8AJke4s2OLBDu6RYZTLzFlOJ/MQnbSvD05OeJvh8HnqoFsnHEz8UT4vV4PJw4PtD0mLDp1H6i88D5VbeTOfT5jPDi7/4EoWJ3RIn64FSNTLy3Tu@uEI5YJ@30dKVgAVkl2JUW1E8USPlPVmPnU7V9cXl0e8bBiVNfDs40Xn6uTLdfvj@flx@5KbrId0IW11eHDxx/Xn4/OLzsduA8QgK59fIWnrBE0ngbtkYqEesijl@fpvLM7DwrNDBwVjwTCZhjB7msyHwdRzQ2Z7rh0g/RYVsitTVbK/K1GBF8RYYN1PJyft0yPeABW4Bwqw0DhkwdgdhVL7EAnKBOAMxhOU/Y0oiCMTWS8vOIOcR9tDSgaNbC9wFELyeQEUhMG4PPGGrXyZMClaApcvgTNEhYAu6TNlAXy@04IU@H0tUPI6w5QZDPIe@d4eg3Oaup6DCR5xgw3swAGxpoJcH@FRkaAROJc5gT1gdvAgDnYCZ3rgI/0xXJgv4Rzp7QAVeoa@ZxVg7PtFq/ByO3emqPRiP92jwuHxh0531e5VKhaD74787opvVUKqNfHdg@9oMsfMbZZ3mKtyU824KnY5r5FiWU7qpFiByQ@l1KvtWeCVi57H2z1X3alZqhj3di0rWgFUVS2eNZg7wrDQyxbn1Z18PmsIo9pk5em8zE4wYXEoKrlB31c0Q80aUXTcPVoBKhot/EHoTnwEixUI8sgqofYU9jQWHvNIAkEKuujpumfFAtFVFBWk7fojmoDLpK8VsTrkhVLvafn83UJPdIJKdkFA27wwsEM4FnCg0cK@ymlMRHVq00SxUrLRYRUl7MpLG3LBDZEZZQ2wFeGYxbbovoJ@hx35KvA2rgjTJ0U6pMKGjE8kj8EW3NfNxAy/tZAWQpZ6ru80uZFoRIcbJW/2FMVbshNNpnQbyPA3rEpskrKWEEFAsje5DxGlrB0VgKOEK2NvNcuxIOY7yzAKimDedOIPgsd5aNEitpsmUWlPzWRzerwuE7KStHRKVzZEcsDNKGiaDP5ixBgmYzAjpEU7WgU8Q3sjJ/EZs4V97rVFVeqBvO57HRRgu2UQUD0Am3sTPwDVABwLIH2gOqBNmK13EZmxLWsLKtsWKIXVGUSoIeNyysVc1U0rmmZ@QEAlO/eoIBLxOkXvL1CwuAnCOc4aWoWwMwgw1@JXkdnEXS6LEJ5qtvb@QlQH2OIKyLGSVQCC7F7X0mJRhA0dz4E6FguIus0KkAdCUywwlRxvVKCkJNT7hiwV5F2lktI9dFtlqEjCcrAb6gvtZXMWzeeF3iJ8wDI4jiUXa/bMY4hIx2XzmSxV/qzjZ76E/OMim0Ta30FG3jWBjJFpbL3du4M0ZtsOAW9i2lfp/lJ9bsCZ7C91GDMwFmHMwZh7bkAJfGuzCM5YiQFKXBbnLWCFBkhVWTzNgH7LUudhGj7TwrqeQnyXillK04qWwGMyykJGv3kIPEapqLvCZUV6hvOE0VtYIwrDDVwDgQxf9xoCeOTMwwdwFpQfwR@s0ypORgCTVQyHLIsnQwoXi7xIRskdAZetqOcFkVrYIIWXl3g9BKFzJ1zMfUi2QiIf6sBwmGrTaXATpqsMhVsuXfWzdOg@psscfZhsGEtF@p/L91jJKwApvLzZD059SON6f9G75xDtkIcyVBVFG2tKQ/CybECzYFuBQORs2NKC6@BDsrpXVQYiLA4fETvi@A5B2mFTQNmhqkL1v9cOEwKYrAXDjoVsQlgwH/Dk9gnm0IrgYLhV18/wERG71P7CxOJHUpuqbvDHUPdjX2b@2r4P/kzhCOAtc4P5a4MRwjaIy1cIoVCkfoq@wudkdc6BSm5C15MzROcbmgVuJ6UV62aznc@3m@XaDtlvNxRlQ/VBSII0W/g/aIkKoQufLXyuKBuRySSp9i1jP2s09C0rPglNwNPegA7w6foSOmgo2qms7ciU1T0GZ9IynzJNweg4pjPgSrLAV/DdoCfxtfqvOB93tJl2pHkbktWMAw3zuOf4t@EYz4gMiQ40J50m91gHAmKB8RFPiuZM62gmIT8U2Zgo@0dqtd6o1ki00eLCDs7wh1ear/Gp1ta@al/I6pQrpesG6k5CUXecW2eusDYHcvYVlMpWhcn9VXfj86jVyc3cse9FnWv/UL5Ve5WalVXI6iuvVvV2wixJIiDB9ZjNrMKd0ua8Im6wmAaa5dD1F04kHC9p281qXZC1aruECGi8gY3qWDr5wr8g3NaBmIlzZGf4a/HLln2DLa@f4ctXtgdbuKvtiH@E47jTPhNZQ8HlBmnecRnE4Ps7cMJnkYRax2JyEM2XmNzF6ztdt/jnLb/Pt/SIyRy68onvPefzsB/RfRxgpTRvIJgqwgIR8zJ9SVGEyfYRPm0SC6RBOQGCDEjYUCzx39os1geJSxJik/0twykOqgT4d3O24Xv@Bb7WjG0Yv6dbwjHrelfx3lO6cMsLY1HoXrn8Icbei4Z1DCclKLbQQ3Ei2xTJfSfI2D0UkPSkWndcFsyOqJsqFFI4niJce8W43JH4oLhEwgluVMg7Q2j4U4YK7E59naTiGumkFJBJoA8odEHVNPb1TqOzfVTynnklr/hanrh5ZknK/5mEBpaOhhbMkyNPgiPbQAaQp9Exa3n7M@o1PDp7FR7i@vo/Rea2REpxORCXm4E0cff@8757cHoMvft1v7K72zcMs6SWBvDLyJ9bCt5gBFT9CZ7CYPQL79ofu5fH3UteKCTyQdObBlnCFdl1iPs4l6O30EWvGX@mTzDKptVOZSTvPDTaYNbUKW7w7i3X0wDpAyj0735m@gmV@n0EJ51ubYvjV1@O8LLpnovGL2tARybe/fo9Mv25Zq77sG@lIurjUrFPstB29U3RmpBImB8MuWya9AGS/6hYiBIyeRC9CgDnPwE3extWkd6tviKAHJ7Ca/9ggqbuUHNC98HRpoPpQnsMvrOhHTpk27bq/7AttF0P6X61vLYC9o9L/VW9Hwk7@iZlsiPSy2Z1t1qv7FTrKjQ3GdHdqP0@NF83A7DwF70pnljCJ8FQPLKgN0pfXjPel8/Qj@cXfP1cFwXEhX7LFW0GPMdVMuhB6x/Eh4qVfj83UTQXWq2MfFoGSU89Q@cX8PQykr4gbgri5iDqnudqBudm8kQMkLIOETQDHsEaJbhBL2tY60fltmzRrY@RHvxj7pVL5k69ZJbM/wI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pinecone](https://github.com/wmww/Pinecone), 266 bytes

```
u:IntArray:4;s:"".input;k:IntArray:s.len;k.set:0,-1;n:1
i:0|i<s.len|i:i+1@((s.sub:i,i+1)="."?(k.set:n,i;n:n+1))k.set:n,s.len;i:1|i<n+1|i:i+1@(j:s.sub:((k.get:i-1)+1),(k.get:i)u.set:(i-1),(j.Int))print:((u.get:0)*16777216)+((u.get:1)*65536)+((u.get:2)*256)+(u.get:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
'./ɠḋ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPScuJTJGJUM5JUEwJUUxJUI4JThCJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MTkyLjE2OC4xLjEmZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
'./ɠḋ  '# Implicit input
'./    '# Split it on "."s
   ɠḋ   # Convert from base-256
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3.11+](https://www.python.org) (no `eval`/built-in libraries), 47 bytes

```python
c=lambda x:0 .from_bytes(map(int,x.split('.')))
```

As of 3.11, `int.from_bytes` implicitly uses big-endian byte order. `0. from_bytes` is shorter than `int.from_bytes`, and works just fine (since `from_bytes` is a class method, it works the same when called on an instance; the space is needed to avoid `0.` being interpreted as a `float`).

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY39ZNtcxJzk1ISFSqsDBT00oryc-OTKktSizVyEws0MvNKdCr0igtyMks01PXUNTU1odqi0vKLFDILFDLzFNQNLY30DM0s9Az1DBUQwNBAD4xM9IzNkIQt9MBQHWqophUXSLSgCGiTRrJGZgHMBpgDAQ)