# Line numbering - implement nl

Tags: code-golf, string, counting

Your task is to implement a program similar to the `nl` command-line tool from the GNU core utilities.

[Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/16402) are banned.

You may not use any built-in or external function, program or utility for numbering the lines of a file or string, such as `nl` itself or the `=` command in GNU sed.

## Specification

### Input

The program accepts filenames as arguments. Your code does not have to be cross-platform; the filename format of the OS running the code should be used, i.e. if you happen to be on Windows, the directory separator can be `\` or `/`.

You must be able to take 64 input files, including `-` if it is specified. If over 64 are given, only handle the first 64.

In the list of filenames, `-` represents standard input.

If filenames are given, read from the files in the order that they are given and concatenate their contents, inserting a new line between each one and at the end. If you cannot read from one or more of the filenames (because the file does not exist or you do not have read permissions for it), ignore them. If all filenames specified are invalid, output nothing.

If no filenames are given, read from standard input. Only read from standard input if no filenames are given or if `-` is given.

### Output

The program will output, to standard output, the input with lines numbered thus (You may assume that the input has `\n`, `\r\n` or `\r` line endings; pick whichever is convenient for you, but specify which one):

```
<5 spaces>1<tab><content of line 1 of input>
<5 spaces>2<tab><content of line 2 of input>
...
<4 spaces>10<tab><content of line 10 of input>
...
<3 spaces>100<tab><content of line 100 of input>
...
...
```

6 characters of space are allocated for the line number, and it is inserted at the end of these characters; the rest become spaces (e.g. `1` will have 5 leading spaces, `22` will have 4 leading spaces, ...). If the input is sufficiently long, you will eventually run out of space for the line number, at line `999999`. You must not output anything after line 999999.

If the input is empty, output nothing.

### Exit status

The lower numbers take priority: if errors 1 and 2 were encountered, exit with status 1.

Exit with status 0 if the input was successfully received, and the lines successfully numbered and output.

Exit with status 1 if one or more of the files specified on the command line were not found or could not be read from.

Exit with status 2 if too many files (more than 64) were given.

Exit with status 3 if the input was too long (more than 999999 lines).\

### Scoring

This is code-golf - shortest program wins!

I may add bonuses later for implementing certain options that `nl` has. There are no bonuses at the moment.

Comment: Is the line-numbering continuous or short it "reset" itself for each individual file?

Comment: @britishtea It is continuous

Comment: So is it necessary to use node if we want to submit something in js? Or can we use function args or `prompt()` to emulate program args and stdin?

Comment: Binary files? Encoding? Unicode markers?

Answer (score 6):

### Bash, 121

```shell
s=$[2*($#>64)]
for f in "$@";{ [ -f $f ]||s=1;}
((s))&&exit $s
awk '{if(NR>=10**6){exit 3}printf("%6d\t%s\n",NR,$0)}' $@
```

Comment: You can make your `if` expressions quite a bit shorter if you use arithmetic expressions, e.g. `(($#>64))&&s=2`

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I learned a thing!

Comment: You can replace `s=0;(($#>64))&&s=2` with `s=$[2*($#>64)]`, `(($s==0))||` with `((s))&&` and the `if` statement with `[ -f "$f" ]||s=1`.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25802/11259

Comment: `awk` will also concatenate if passed multiple files, so this officially counts as a [useless use of cat](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html) ;-).  Instead I think this will work: `awk '...' $@`

Comment: You may be able to use the fact that when undefined variables appear in arithmetic expansions, they will expand to 0, to get rid of the `s=0` line.

Comment: @Sammitch Change your third line to `for f in "$@";{ [ -f "$f" ]||s=1;}` - saves a lot of chars. I think the quotes around $f are necessary in case your filename has spaces in it

Comment: @Sammitch I've tested this, but it doesn't seem to handle `-` for STDIN correctly

Comment: The spec says you should handle the first 64 inputs if given more than 64, rather than just giving up at the beginning. I think it also suggests that you should output all the readable files if only some of them are readable.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 195

```ruby
o,l=$*[64]?[2]:[],999999
($*==[]?[?-]:$*).each{|n|f=n==?-?STDIN: open(n)rescue o<<1&&next
s=f.read.lines
s[l]?o<<3:1
puts s[0..l].map.with_index(1){|l,i|i.to_s.rjust(6)+?\t+l}}
exit !o[0]?0:o.min
```

Comment: I think `STDIN` is aliased to `$<`.

Comment: It's an alias for `ARGF`, which will read from the rest of the files given as arguments as well. I think this can be golfed down further using `ARGF` somehow (it even seems to recognize `"-"` as being stdin).

Comment: britishteanl:4:in `block in <main>': undefined method `[]'   for #<Enumerator:0x000006002980c8> (NoMethodError)  
        from britishteanl:2:in `each'  
        from britishteanl:2:in `<main>' - what's wrong? I ran it as `ruby britishteanl folder/filename`

Comment: I suspect it's a difference in Ruby version. I've run the sample on both Ruby 2.0.0 and Ruby 2.1.2 without problems. What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

#### python 173

```
import os,sys
c=0
l=1
for f in sys.argv[1:]:
    if c>64:exit(2)
    if not os.path.isfile(f):exit(1)
    c+=1
    for x in open(f):
        if l>=10**6:exit(3)
        print '%6d\t%s'%(l,x),;l+=1
```

Comment: I think your code is currently missing the `-` for `sys.stdin`. A possible solution might be something like `fh=sys.stdin if f=='-' else open(f)` and then go with `x=fh.readline()`?! Unfortunately it does not make it any shorter though. :)

Answer (score 1):

### J (162)

```
exit(((2*64<#)[exit@3:`(stdout@(,&LF)@;@(,&TAB@(6&":)&.>@>:@i.@#,&.>]))@.(1e6>#)@(<;.2)@(1!:1)@(<`3:@.('-'-:]))&.>@;@{.@(_64&(<\))) ::1:)]`(]&<&'-')@.(0=#)2}.ARGV
```

Explanation:

- `` ]`(]&<&'-')@.(0=#)2}.ARGV ``: Get the command line arguments, and remove the first two (because those are the interpreter and the script file name). If the resulting list is empty, return `['-']` (i.e., as if the user had passed only `-`), otherwise return the list unchanged.
- `(` ... `::1:)`: if the inner function fails, return `1`, otherwise return whatever the inner function returned.
- `((2*64<#)[`...`)`: evaluate the inner function and throw the result away. Then, if the length of the passed list was not higher than `64`, return `0`, otherwise return `2`.
- `&.>@;@{.@(_64&(<\))`: get at most `64` elements from the list, and for each of them run the following function:

  - `` (1!:1)@(<`3:@.('-'-:])) ``: if the element was `-`, read the contents of file descriptor `3` (stdin), otherwise read the contents of the file named by that element. If this fails (i.e. file doesn't exist), the code above will catch it and return `1`.
  - `` exit@3:`( ``...`)@.(1e6>#)@(<;.2)`: split the string on its line endings. If there are 1.000.000 or more lines, exit with status `3`. Otherwise:

    - `,&TAB@(6&":)&.>@>:@i.@#`: generate the numbers for each line, format them in a 6-digit column, and add a `TAB` to the end of each string,
    - `,&.>]`: add each number to the front  of each line.
    - `stdout@(,&LF)@;`: then output the whole thing, followed by an extra `LF`.
- `exit`: exit with the return value of that function

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 76 bytes

One byte for the `p` flag. Run with `ruby -p nl.rb`.

```
BEGIN{x=$*.size-65}
exit 2if$*.size==x
exit 3if$.>999999
$_="%6d"%$.+?\t+$_
```

stdin or file arguments are handled automatically by Ruby. It already exits with code 1 if a file argument doesn't exist. `$.` is the number of lines that have been read. `$*` is the command line arguments, and the files are popped off as the files are read. The `p` flag executes the `BEGIN` block and wraps the rest of the program inside a while-gets-print loop, using `$_` as the input/output.

Comment: The spec says you should handle the first 64 inputs if given more than 64, rather than just giving up at the beginning.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>125</s> 122 bytes

```
@a=@ARGV;for(@a){$i++>63&&exit 2;($_ eq '-'or-e$_)or next;@ARGV=$_;while(<>){$c>1E6-2&&exit 3;printf"%5d\t%s",++$c,$_}say}
```

Comment: This does not satisfy the specification regarding the 64 argument maximum and the exit status.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 84 + 2 (`-pl`) = 86 bytes

```
perl -ple'BEGIN{map{-r||exit 1}@ARGV;@ARGV>63&&exit 2}$.>=1e6&&exit 3;$_=printf"%5d\t%s",$.,$_'
```

Deparsed:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -ple'BEGIN{map{-r||exit 1}@ARGV;@ARGV>63&&exit 2}$.>=1e6&&exit 3;$_=printf"%5d\t%s",$.,$_' output.txt; echo $?

BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
sub BEGIN {
    map {exit 1 unless -r $_;} @ARGV;
    exit 2 if @ARGV > 63;
}
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    exit 3 if $. >= 1000000;
    $_ = printf("%5d\t%s", $., $_);
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Important to know:

- `-p` wraps the program given with `-e` in the `while`/`continue` loop
- `BEGIN` code will be executed before the (implicit) main part
- file test `-r` also fails if file doesn't exist `!-e` and defaults to testing `$_`, implicitly given in `map { ... } @ARGV`
- `$.` holds the current line number
- rest should be self-explanatory ;)

Comment: Great answer, and welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! Perhaps you could edit to add an explanation of how your code works.

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>362</s> 359

Just for the fun of it. ;-) Works with LF or CR/LF linefeeds.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define R return
#define P printf(
e,t,l;void*f;r(){P"% 6d\t",++l);for(;(t=fgetc(f))^-1&&l<1000000;){if(ferror(f))R 1;P"%c",t);if(t==10)P"% 6d\t",++l);}P"\n");R l<1000000?0:3;}main(int c,char**v){e=c>65?2:0;for(++v;*v||c<2;++v){t=c<2||!strcmp(*v,"-")?f=stdin,0:!(f=fopen(*v,"rb"));if(t||(t=r()))e=!e|(e>t)?t:e;if(f&&f!=stdin)fclose(f);}R e;}
```