# Pixel-art, episode 1: display Super Mario

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output

it's a-me!

Today's task is simple: write a program, or a function that displays the idle small Mario sprite, from Super Mario Bros, on NES, over a blue background.

Any kind of entry is valid as long as it displays those 12 * 16 pixels anywhere on the screen / window / browser.

(EDIT: the displayed image can be scaled up if your language can't do pixel art. You can also output ASCII art or HTML art, but using the right colors.)

Image (zoomed 400%):

[image]

You must use the following colors:

- blue: #6B8CFF
- red: #B13425
- green/brown: #6A6B04
- orange: #E39D25

Shortest program (in number of characters) wins!

Standard loopholes apply (especially, no network connexion allowed), but hardcoding and displaying an image file in your program is allowed. (entries using this trick will be rank separately)

Here we go!

---

## Current Leaderboard

**Shortest answer using code only:**

- Mathematica, 141. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39916/10732 (by Martin Büttner)
- Bash, 158. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40002/10732 (by hpsMouse)
- ...

**Shortest answer using some kind of hardcoded image:**

- HTML, 102b. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39923/10732 (by xem and NiettheDarkAbsol)
- PHP, 131b. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39926/10732 (by NiettheDarkAbsol)
- ...

Comment: Also, creating a file is not allowed? It has to be displayed?

Comment: I don't see any pattern in that image. So it all comes down to the best compression one can use in a language.

Comment: @Optimizer Looks like RLE could work well.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, I fixed them and added a zoomed version of the image. @MartinBüttner you can create a file but your program must display it. And yeah, it's a basic compression challenge.

Comment: @Optimizer no pattern, but there's a lot of symmetry in the lower half on the image

Comment: @xem damn, no CJam then ;)

Comment: why, CJam is afraid of symmetry?

Comment: @xem no color output in CJam. Only text in one color

Comment: @Optimizer or an image ;)

Comment: Nitpicking: That's Mario, not Super Mario.

Comment: It's Mario Mario actually. But Super Mario is more popular :P

Comment: I would like to see someone do this in .NET

Comment: As a random added thing, the number of character changes required to convert from normal Red-outfit Mario to Fireball-launching White-outfit Mario. Haha :P

Comment: What a fun idea...Here's an idea for a sequel challenge: Take the Mario image (Any format) and turn it into an image of Luigi!

Comment: Can we make a piet program that looks like him?

Comment: Can output be to the terminal (i.e colorama in Python)?

Comment: sure, no prob...

Comment: Q. Regaring the category "code only"... does using a single HTML element only for the purpose of injecting JS output disqualify an entry in that category?

Comment: Q. Regarding HTML output... instead of line breaks to denote rows in the grid, is it within the rules to rely on the browser window being sized particularly so its contents wrap automatically to produce the same effect?

Comment: @bumpy yep, you're free to use a single HTML element and rely on resizing

Comment: @xem, you would not happen to have any copies of the original images, would you? The posted links are showing `410: Gone` Errors

Comment: @TaylorScott thanks for the notification! fixed.

Answer (score 36):

## HTML/JS, <s>206</s> <s>158</s> <s>153</s> 102

**102**

Trick used: save the compressed GIF file as an HTML file, and add <img src=#> at the end

Thanks to this entry: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39926/10732 by @NiettheDarkAbsol

```
GIF87a  ¡ kŒÿã%jk±4%,       6„‡héj„Af-ÕdÎy\%    …R˜0”ŒÈJ­³I©±²û“ú=ª$±p%i¸•¤ <img src=#>
```

Demo: http://meuziere.free.fr/mario/gif.html

Older versions:

**153**

Trick used: save the compressed PNG file as an HTML file, and add <img src=#> at the end

```
‰PNG


IHDR         _v”   PLTEjkkŒÿ±4%ã%ó’V   IIDAT×c[Êµj%C€ÍUŸ?|ìíœÿ02„ÿÿÊÐÊàÐÄÈÀ°ŠáÓë~†«ö3üZµž!jÚR‡P x( s6ïåÇ<img src=#>
```

**158**

Trick used: setting the trimmed dataURI of a compressed PNG as the SRC of an IMG tag and packing the whole thing in Unicode chars.

Execute that in your JS console:

```
document.write(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))
```

**206**

Unpacked (206b):

```
<img src=data:image;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAQAgMAAABfD3aUAAAADFBMVEVqawRrjP+xNCXjnSXzkghWAAAASUlEQVQI12MIWxXKELVqJUOAzVUGnz9/GXzs7Rmc/zAyhP//yhDQEMrg0MTIwLCKgeHT636Gf6v2M/xatZ4hatpSBodQoHgoAw>
```

[Demo](http://xem.github.io/miniCodeEditor/1.1/#%7F%7F%3Cimg%20src%3Ddata%3Aimage%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAQAgMAAABfD3aUAAAADFBMVEVqawRrjP+xNCXjnSXzkghWAAAASUlEQVQI12MIWxXKELVqJUOAzVUGnz9/GXzs7Rmc/zAyhP//yhDQEMrg0MTIwLCKgeHT636Gf6v2M/xatZ4hatpSBodQoHgoAw%3E1)

Tools used:

- https://tinypng.com/
- http://xem.github.io/miniURI/input.html
- http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/

Comment: You don't need the tags. Just use the chrome's data uri and enter it in your url bar. 200 characters

Comment: Hm... I considered that dataURI isn't a valid "program". But you're right. All browsers allow dataURIs in the addressbar.

Comment: Now you're using a loophole yourself as the OP ;). You're offloading all work to the external/built-in compression of the GIF format. If that's cool we should all go hunting for obscure image formats with the best compression rate now, and I could have saved myself a lot of work writing my own compression. ;)

Comment: I edited the OP: there will be a ranking for hardcoded images and a ranking for ... not. ;)

Comment: @xem Well, your challenge, your call. But it seems a bit pointless if we're now just looking for the most compressed existing file format. ;)

Comment: Let's see that as a "side challenge". also, posting an image file is not valid: it has to be a program. HTML can't display much formats (bmp, png, gif, jpg, ...that's about it). And if another language than HTML can contain hardcoded images, I'm interested to see that. :)

Comment: Could you provide the HTML files Base64-encoded? Your external hosting seems to be down, and the in-answer text isn't copy-pasteable.

Comment: I provided a working url for the 102b file ;)

Comment: Does not display in MSIE 11.0.13

Comment: Yeah, saving an image file as HTML is a hack that IE doesn't understand (yet). But ... IE ... let's don't care about it :p

Comment: It appears the rawgit link is dead.

Answer (score 28):

### Mathematica, <s>412</s> <s>292</s> <s>252</s> <s>212</s> <s>163</s> <s>148</s> <s>143</s> 141 characters

```
f=FromDigits[ToCharacterCode@#,2^16]~IntegerDigits~#2&;Image@Partition[f["넴╫賿橫ӣ鴥",256][[3#+1;;3#+3]]/256&/@"吀啐^A媾핮﻽溿뽫ﺩ埿⩕樨ꦪª⿼?ཐᐅ橕ꦪ喪"~f~4,12]
```

This uses caret notation `^A` for the control character at code point `1`. In Mathematica, I can actually embed the character literally, although that leads to all sorts of ugliness when copying things around. Anyway, the above is 2 characters shorter than my former version, and I got those to characters from using base-4 instead of base-5 to encode the colour palette indices. Right now I cannot be bothered to fix the explanation and screenshot below, so I'm leaving you here with the original base-5 version of my answer:

---

```
f=FromDigits[ToCharacterCode@#,2^16]~IntegerDigits~#2&;Image@Partition[f["넴╫賿橫ӣ鴥",256][[3#-2;;3#]]/256&/@"ᯱ曎㌟뱮䚻륏Σ襺ﺦ您汜豈塘ᙉ雬儥衰ꐰꃾ纔ㆯ쭴뫋澖ᕿ蓉"~f~5,12]
```

I'm encoding the pixels in Unicode characters (yay for counting by characters!).

Here is what it looks like in Mathematica:

[image]

Here's how it works:

First we define a function `f` that turns Unicode strings (passed in as the first argument `#`) into lists of integers. First we obtain the character codes. Those can be interpreted as digits of a base 65536 number. And then we convert that number to another base, passed in as the second argument `#2`.

Now let's do that for the longer Unicode string. `ToCharacterCode` yields this list:

```
{7153, 26318, 13087, 48238, 18107, 47439, 931, 35194, 62191, 65190, \
 24744, 57782, 27740, 35912, 22616, 5705, 38636, 20773, 34928, 42032, \
 41214, 32404, 12719, 52084, 47819, 28566, 5503, 33993}
```

Treating this as base 65536:

```
7933607912575313477287527915733176998797205587959732019781370103381...
4831246938139171755469819519515972565671101475553962564506286523593
```

And converting to base 5:

```
{2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \
 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, \
 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, \
 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, \
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, \
 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, \
 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, \
 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, \
 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}
```

Those are the colour indices of the pixels, in order blue, red, green, orange. We use those to index into that list of numbers, which is the colour palette.

Now for the colour palette. That's `"넴╫賿橫ӣ鴥"`. We use the above indices to select the correct string. Then we apply our function again, but using base 256. That yields a list of 12 integers:

```
{177, 52, 37, 107, 140, 255, 106, 107, 4, 227, 157, 37}
```

We use `;;` range indexing to pull out the relevant slice for the current colour.

Lastly, we just use `Partition` to split this into rows of `12` and feed it to `Image`. Voilà!

**Edit:** With the Unicode packing the RLE was no longer worth it. Removing it saved 50 characters.

**Edit:** Of course, without RLE, there's also no need to go to base 16.

**Edit:** And while we're at it, why not Unicode-pack the colour palette, too? (I have a hunch that I can save a little bit more by make the entire colour palette also a single string and using `Partition` there too. I'll try that later.)

**Edit:** Yes, that did shave off another 5 bytes.

Comment: would you mind adding a screenshot of the result? (not that I don't trust your code, but curious about how it's displayed: in a window? a browser? else?)

Comment: @xem Will do. It's a REPL environment capable of graphical in- and output.

Comment: Not sure, but are you mirroring the lower portion of the image ?

Comment: @Optimizer No, I doubt I'd be able to do that in less characters than I'd be saving.

Comment: When I look in the Mathematica documentation I don't see any usage on tilde but it appears here that you're using it to feed the result of one function into another and then apply an additional argument to that second function (IntegerDigits)? Also, the color palette: looking at the image, it appears there are only four colors, but your color palette seems to include more than that: {177, 52, 37, 107, 140, 255, 106, 107, 4, 227, 157, 37}. Looking at the documentation for Image, it looks like it prints out grayscale unless additional options like ColorScale --> RGB is provided.

Comment: Man, the unicode encoding is just a joy to read. This is good.

Comment: @JavaNovice14085 The tilde is syntactic sugar to use infix notation. I.e. `a~f~b` is the same as `f[a,b]`. Precedence is  a bit tricky. It's left associative so `a~f~b~g~c` is `g[f[a,b],c]` and has lower precedence than `@` (`f@a` is syntactic sugar for `f[a]`) but higher precedence than the `Map` and `Apply` short forms. The colour palette really is `{{177, 52, 37}, {107, 140, 255}, {106, 107, 4}, {227, 157, 37}}`, but I'm using an unrolled array and `[[3#+1;;3#+3]]` accesses a slice of three consecutive elements.

Answer (score 20):

## Java : <s>398</s> 377

```java
void s(){new java.awt.Frame(){public void paint(java.awt.Graphics g){int i=0,x,m[]={12226,44085194,467839834,0x5abea55a,0x5bbd5d50,0x5ffe9540,0x5ffe9540,0x5aee5d50,531408218,334277466,333492170,0xc02fc2},c[]={7048447,0xB13425,6974212,0xE39D25};for(setSize(99,99);i<192;g.setColor(new java.awt.Color(c[m[x]&3])),m[x]/=4,g.drawLine(x+40,60-i%16,x+40,60-i++%16))x=i/16;}}.show();}
```

Simply draws the sprite by unpacking an int for each column. Shown in a full program:

```java
class P{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        new P().s();
    }

    void s(){
        new java.awt.Frame(){           
            public void paint(java.awt.Graphics g){
                int i=0,x,m[]={12226,44085194,467839834,0x5abea55a,0x5bbd5d50,0x5ffe9540,
                               0x5ffe9540,0x5aee5d50,531408218,334277466,333492170,0xc02fc2},
                          c[]={7048447,0xB13425,6974212,0xE39D25};
                for(setSize(99,99);i<192;
                    g.setColor(new java.awt.Color(c[m[x]&3])),m[x]/=4,
                    g.drawLine(x+40,60-i%16,x+40,60-i++%16)
                )x=i/16;
            }
        }.show();
    }
}
```

Obligatory screenshot:

[image: it's me, mario]

Comment: You can save 9 bytes by using an `import java.awt.*`.

Answer (score 15):

## x86 Machine Code, 102 bytes

How it works: The image is stored as a 2-bit image using a palette. Each row of the image is stored as 3 bytes, followed by one 1 byte of the color palette. This allows the data to be loaded as a single DWORD. The twelve pixels are output by masking off the lowest 2 bits of the value, writing them to video memory, and then right-shifting the entire value two bits. Once the pixels for the row have been outputted, the palette byte is written to the VGA palette. When the image is finished drawing, the program enters an infinite loop.

Assembly code to generate the binary:

```
org 100h
mov al,13h
int 10h
les ax,[bx]

mov si,image_data
draw:
add di,320-12
lodsd
xchg eax,ebx
mov cl,12
row:
mov ax,bx
and al,3
stosb
shr ebx,2
loop row
xchg ax,bx
mov dx,0x3c9
out dx,al
test al,al
jnz draw

image_data: db 21,0,85,0xb1/4, \
5,0,64,0x34/4,            \
165,190,87,0x25/4,        \
185,191,127,0x6b/4,       \
185,254,254,0x8c/4,       \
233,191,106,0xff/4,       \
213,255,95,0x6a/4,        \
165,168,85,0x6b/4,        \
169,40,106,0x4/4,         \
170,0,170,0xe3/4,         \
47,195,248,0x9d/4,        \
63,0,252,0x25/4,          \
15,0,240,111,             \
5,20,80,111,              \
169,85,106,111,           \  
170,85,170
```

Base-64 encoded binary, save it as Mario.com to run it:
sBPNEMQHvigBgcc0AWatZpOxDInYJAOqZsHrAuL1k7rJA+6EwHXiwxUAVSwFAEANpb5XCbm/fxq5/v4j6b9qP9X/XxqlqFUaqShqAaoAqjgvw/gnPwD8CQ8A8G8FFFBvqVVqb6pVqg==

Sample output:
[image]

Answer (score 11):

## [Octo/XO-Chip](http://johnearnest.github.io/Octo/), 70 bytes

Octo is a high level assembly language that compiles down into bytecoded instructions for the [CHIP-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHIP-8) virtual machine. Octo provides some custom extensions called "XO-Chip" to the basic CHIP-8 bytecode, including the ability to draw 4-color bitmaps via overlaid bitplanes.

The compiled bytes are as follows:

```
0xA2 0x08 0xF3 0x01 0xD0 0x00 0x1F 0x00 0x3F 0xC0 0x39 0x00 0x51 0x00 0x58 0x80
0x21 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x3F 0x00 0x7F 0xE0 0xFF 0xF0 0x36 0xC0 0x1F 0x80 0x3F 0xC0
0x39 0xC0 0x70 0xE0 0xF0 0xF0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x3F 0x80 0x7F 0xE0 0x7F 0xF0
0x3F 0xE0 0x1F 0xC0 0x37 0x00 0x76 0xE0 0xF0 0xF0 0xE9 0x70 0xE0 0x70 0xC0 0x30
0x00 0x00 0x70 0xE0 0xF0 0xF0
```

[image: mario]

Run it here in your browser: http://johnearnest.github.io/Octo/index.html?gist=33aa37d4717a425ccd4f

It is probably more illuminating to see the Octo assembly language which produces that bytecode:

```
: main
    i := mario
    plane 3
    sprite v0 v0 0

: mario
    0x1F 0x00 0x3F 0xC0 0x39 0x00 0x51 0x00 
    0x58 0x80 0x21 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x3F 0x00 
    0x7F 0xE0 0xFF 0xF0 0x36 0xC0 0x1F 0x80 
    0x3F 0xC0 0x39 0xC0 0x70 0xE0 0xF0 0xF0 
    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x3F 0x80 0x7F 0xE0 
    0x7F 0xF0 0x3F 0xE0 0x1F 0xC0 0x37 0x00 
    0x76 0xE0 0xF0 0xF0 0xE9 0x70 0xE0 0x70 
    0xC0 0x30 0x00 0x00 0x70 0xE0 0xF0 0xF0
```

The main program is three two-byte instructions. Set the memory index register `i` to the beginning of the data segment, select drawing plane 3 (3 is a bitmask; this indicates you wish to draw in 4 color mode with both bitplanes) and then draw a sprite at an x and y position given by register `v0` (initialized to zero). The final 0 provides the size of the sprite, which in the SuperChip and XO-Chip instruction sets will draw a 16x16 sprite. In 4 color mode, a bitmap for the first plane is followed immediately by a bitmap for the second plane.

To see how the planes work, consider this modified program which scrolls one plane to the right after drawing mario:

[image: mario2]

```
: main
    i := mario
    plane 3
    sprite v0 v0 0
    plane 2
    scroll-right
    scroll-right
    scroll-right
    scroll-right

: mario
    0x1F 0x00 0x3F 0xC0 0x39 0x00 0x51 0x00 
    0x58 0x80 0x21 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x3F 0x00 
    0x7F 0xE0 0xFF 0xF0 0x36 0xC0 0x1F 0x80 
    0x3F 0xC0 0x39 0xC0 0x70 0xE0 0xF0 0xF0 
    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x3F 0x80 0x7F 0xE0 
    0x7F 0xF0 0x3F 0xE0 0x1F 0xC0 0x37 0x00 
    0x76 0xE0 0xF0 0xF0 0xE9 0x70 0xE0 0x70 
    0xC0 0x30 0x00 0x00 0x70 0xE0 0xF0 0xF0
```

If you enjoy this you might like one of my [other solutions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/52547/minimal-nethack/52556#52556) written with Octo. There's actually a [game jam](http://octojam.com) going on for the month of October based around this tool.

Answer (score 10):

## Bash + ImageMagick: <s>350</s> <s>331</s> 321 characters

(Palette shamelessly stolen from [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%c3%bcttner)'s [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39916).)

```bash
p=(B13425 6B8CFF 6A6B04 E39D25)
for c in 21 0 85 5 0 64 165 190 87 1{85,91,27,85} 254{,} 233 191 106 213 255 95 165 168 85 169 40 106 170 0 170 47 195 248 63 0 252 15 0 240 5 20 80 169 85 106 170 85 170;{
for j in 0 2 4 6;{
d+=(-fill \#${p[c>>j&3]} -draw point\ $[i%12],$[i++/12])
}
}
convert -size 12x16 xc: "${d[@]}" x:
```

Sample output:

[image: Mario]

To inspect it easily add `-scale 120` to `convert`'s parameters to get a 10x scaled version:

[image: Mario scaled 10]

Comment: `s/185 191 127 185 254 254/1{85,91,27,85} 254{,}/`; `s/do/{/`; `s/done/}/`

Comment: Doh. I even upvoted [DigitalTrauma](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digitaltrauma)'s related [tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25802), but I keep forgetting that `{`..`}`. Thank you, @grawity.

Answer (score 10):

## GIF - 93 bytes

Hardcoding the image is apparently okay now, so... yay? :D

```
GIF87a  ¡ kŒÿã%jk±4%,       6„‡héj„Af-ÕdÎy\%    …R˜0”ŒÈJ­³I©±²û“ú=ª$±p%i¸•¤  ;
```

As seen in Notepad++

[image: screenshot in NP++]

## As PHP - 131 bytes

```
<? header("Content-Type:image/gif");?>GIF87a  ¡ kŒÿã%jk±4%,       6„‡héj„Af-ÕdÎy\%  …R˜0”ŒÈJ­³I©±²û“ú=ª$±p%i¸•¤  ;
```

Comment: can you please upload your gif somewhere (ctrlv.in for example)? I'd like to use it in my entry instead of PNG :)

Comment: @xem http://adamhaskell.net/img/mario.gif

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I'm not sure how you counted the size of that, but I count 150 bytes. Regardless, scoring is by characters, and it seems to be 114 characters.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I'm using the windows-1252 character set, so things like ÿ are a single byte (0xff here) whereas they wouldn't be "normally". NP++ gives the length in characters and shows 93, and the file saved on my computer is also showing 93 bytes.

Comment: I see. I guess in that case your score for PHP would be 131 both in bytes and characters.

Comment: I think hardcoding is fine for kolmogorov complexity challenges, because they do require you to output a fixed image. I think the relevant loophole here is more like "using built-in functionality to do the work"... which in this case is the compression/decompression built into the browser rendering your compressed GIF.

Comment: I made a 102b html answer using this gif. thanks :D

Comment: PS: I also trimmed the last 2 bytes of the GIF. It seemed to work fine without them.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I just noticed that the OP explicitly lifted this loophole, so if you make an edit to the post I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Edit made =3

Comment: Yup, the PHP snippet is fine for me (even if you could remove the last 2 bytes). But the raw gif snippet isn't a program.

Comment: @xem: If the browser is considered an "interpreter" for HTML/javascript/etc, and feeding it the raw gif snippet via the same mechanism results in the desired output... the difference becomes small

Comment: @MooingDuck indeed.

Comment: In two places it says that your GIF is actually 78 bytes long...

Comment: @BetaDecay Where does it say that?

Comment: [Here](http://www.lettercount.com), [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/charcount.shtml) and [here](https://www.charactercountonline.com).

Comment: @BetaDecay Have you considered that those counters expect *text*, not binary data? I provided the Notepad++ screenshot which clearly shows `length : 93`

Answer (score 6):

## Groovy <strike>417</strike> 386

Fun as hell, but with a terrible char count. [GroovyFX](http://groovyfx.org/) needed

```
m=[b:'6B8CFF',r:'B13425',g:'6A6B04',o:'E39D25'];groovyx.javafx.GroovyFX.start{stage(visible:!0){scene(width:60,height:80){flowPane{"3b5r4b2b9r1b2b3g2o1g1o3b1b1g1o1g3o1g3o1b1b1g1o2g3o1g3o1b2g4o4g1b3b7o2b2b2g1r3g4b1b3g1r2g1r3g1b4g4r4g2o1g1r1o2r1o1r1g2o3o6r3o2o8r2o2b3r2b3r2b1b3g4b3g1b4g4b4g".toList().collate 2 each{l->(l[0]as int).times{rectangle(width:5,height:5,fill:"#"+m[l[1]])}}}}}}
```

ungolfed:

```
m=[b:'6B8CFF',
   r:'B13425',
   g:'6A6B04',
   o:'E39D25']           

s=5

groovyx.javafx.GroovyFX.start {bd->
  stage(visible: !0) {
    scene(width:s*12, height:s*16) {
      flowPane {
        "3b5r4b 2b9r1b 2b3g2o1g1o3b 1b1g1o1g3o1g3o1b 1b1g1o2g3o1g3o 1b2g4o4g1b 3b7o2b 2b2g1r3g4b 1b3g1r2g1r3g1b 4g4r4g 2o1g1r1o2r1o1r1g2o 3o6r3o 2o8r2o 2b3r2b3r2b 1b3g4b3g1b 4g4b4g"
          .replaceAll(" ", "")
          .toList()
          .collate(2) 
          .each { l->
            t=l[0] as int
            cr=m[l[1]]
            t.times {
              rectangle(width:s, height:s, fill:"#"+cr) 
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `grep()` instead of `toList()`

Answer (score 5):

## HTML/JS, <s>427</s> <s>408</s> <s>264</s> <s>256</s> <s>239</s> 226 chars

#### Obfuscatweet, <s>271</s> <s>270</s> <s>264</s> <s>256</s> <s>239</s> 226 chars

Using obfuscatweet, managed to shorten this down to < 250 :D

```
document.write(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))
```

Code below is what this consists of.

Trick used: converted image to base4 String of color tiles, converted this into a hexadecimal String. Index of the base 4 denotes color (0=blue, 1=RED, etc.) CSS with an inline p is used to because divs need content to expand (also p is shorter). Because CSS needs to begin with a letter, 'A' is prepended before the CSS tags.

Padding from the CSS gives pixels. None of this uses Unicode characters, which I'm not too familiar with anyways, though it'd probably go sub-300 in that case. The relative advantage to using the padding is that you can, as in this case, blow up the image to whatever size you want each pixel to be. I've used 9 pixels, but if you spend an extra character, you can get up to 99 pixels per represented pixel.

#### CSS, <s>127</s> <s>119</s> <s>118</s> <s>114</s> <s>100</s> <s>13</s> 0 chars

Switching from `p` to `rp` removes the need for `display:inline`, cost +1 char, -15! chars!

Removed all the colors and put it into an array in JS -87 chars. Then I just removed all the css

#### JS, <s>300</s> <s>289</s> <s>280</s> <s>275</s> <s>329</s> 325 chars

```
c=["6B8CFF","B13425","6A6B04","E39D25"];a='0155000555540ABEC02EFEFC2EBFBF2BFEA803FFF00A6A002A69A8AA55AAF9D76FFD557FF5555F0541502A00A8AA00AA';with(document)for(i=0;i<96;write('<br>')){h=('000'+parseInt(a.slice(i,i+=6),16).toString(4)).slice(-12);for(j=0;j<12;write('<rp style="padding:1 8;background:#'+c[h[j++]]+'"></rp>'));}
```

I tried to cut as much as I could out of this plain JS processing a hex string, but given as it's my first try, this is how far I got using only what I know. The HTML writing has been shortened by a function that adds tags, and the classes use the base 4 value to determine the color to display.

Using additional shortening, replaced charAt with [] brackets, and removed the A0 class and set blue as default color for p, saving additional 10 characters. The additional cost to use `rp` tags is offset by a huge loss in CSS.

Additional offset from removing the while loop pad to just adding '000' for the use case and slicing -12 from it.

Added additional JS for colors, then put the padding in there. Noticed a bug with the padding that requires 2 extra characters to fix. Compacted a bunch of loops

#### HTML File, <s>430</s> <s>429</s> <s>419</s> <s>399</s> <s>366</s> 342 chars

[Demo](http://c99.nl/f/513968.html)

```
<script>c=["6B8CFF","B13425","6A6B04","E39D25"];a='0155000555540ABEC02EFEFC2EBFBF2BFEA803FFF00A6A002A69A8AA55AAF9D76FFD557FF5555F0541502A00A8AA00AA';with(document)for(i=0;i<96;write('<br>')){h=('000'+parseInt(a.slice(i,i+=6),16).toString(4)).slice(-12);for(j=0;j<12;write('<rp style="padding:1 8;background:#'+c[h[j++]]+'"></rp>'));}</script>
```

Comment: Nice! I'd advise you to remove all the line breaks in your code, and provide a link for a demo ( http://c99.nl ). As a bonus, you could pack your entry in Unicode chars using http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/. That will improve your score.

Comment: also, you can remove your &lt;html> tags, place the &lt;style> tag at the end, and remove the /style and the trailing "}" of the last CSS rule.

Comment: @xem OK I cut out all the lines out and squished everything. I'll try and figure out an optimal way to split the JS for obfuscatweet.

Comment: obfuscatweet accepts any js code (so you can put your 289 js chars there), or any html code (so you can copy your html file here). The output of obfuscatweet can be executed in a browser's console or in a HTML file using the right charset meta tag.

Comment: psst, you forgot to remove the last "}" of the CSS part. It works without it.

Comment: So many rules being broken to shorten this down! `rp` tag removes display:inline and helped greatly in getting sub-400 in the HTML O_o

Answer (score 5):

## MATLAB, <strike>194</strike> 193 bytes

The code:

```
imagesc(dec2base(base2dec(reshape('5FVQL5VVVT50A4L4HA594GAHA45A015DAL551G2L41GO101VO0A7FMAANVVAAVVVQ5VLVL40L8100L80',5,[])',32),4)-48);colormap([106 107 4;107 140 255;227 157 37;177 52 37]/255)
```

And the output:

[image: Mario]

Basically I converted the Mario image so that each pixel is a 2 bit number. I then encoded that in base 32 which is the string shown in the code. This string is first reshaped to be 5 x 16 (each row (12px) of 2bit numbers was encoded into base 32), then converted back into base 10. The result is converted once again, this time into base 4 yielding a 12x16 array of 2 bit numbers. These numbers are plotted using `imagesc()`. Then the colours are assigned using `colormap()` with a custom colour map of the required hex values.

Amusingly, a third of the number of bytes used are just to get MATLAB to set the correct colours *after* it has been plotted. The colour code is almost the same number of bytes as the entire base32 string!.

Without correcting the colour (remove the `colormap()` call), it is **135** bytes, and this is the output for the default colour map on MATLAB R2013a:

[image: Mario, no mapping]

Answer (score 5):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>310</s> <s>307</s></sub> 295 Bytes

Anonymous VBE Immediates Window function that outputs a Mario to the Activesheet object at cells `A1:L16`

```vb
o=2465251:Cells.RowHeight=48:a[A1:L16],-29589:a[C4:K5,D3:I7,J7,L5,A11:L13],o:a[C3:E3,H3:H4,B4:B6,C6,D4:D5,E5,I5,H6:K6,C8:H8,B9:K10,A10:L10,C11,J11,B15:D16,A16,I15:K16,L16],289642:a[D1:H1,C2:K2,E8:E10,F10:H10,H9,D11:I13,C13:E14,H13:J14],2438321:a[E11,H11],o
```

Helper `Sub`Routine a

```vb
Sub a(r,c):r.Interior.Color=c:End Sub
```

**Ungolfed Version**

```vb
Public Sub b()
    o = 2465251
    Cells.RowHeight = 48
    a [A1:L16], -29589
    a [C4:K5,D3:I7,J7,L5,A11:L13], o
    a [C3:E3,H3:H4,B4:B6,C6,D4:D5,E5,I5,H6:K6,C8:H8,B9:K10,A10:L10,C11,J11,B15:D16,A16,I15:K16,L16], 289642
    a [D1:H1,C2:K2,E8:E10,F10:H10,H9,D11:I13,C13:E14,H13:J14], 2438321
    a [E11,H11], o
End Sub


Private Sub a(ByRef r As Range, ByVal c As Integer)
    r.Interior.Color = c
End Sub
```

-3 bytes for removing whitespace
-12 bytes for using `[...]` notation over `Range(...)` notation; changing over from hex colors to int colors

### Output

[image: It'sa Me]

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript/<s>CSS</s>/HTML <s>446</s> <s>430</s> <s>407</s> <s>353</s> <s>328</s> 316

I golfed as much as I could and ended up with some dirty HTML/JS, but whatever...it works.

**Edit**:
This is it...I'm done.

**Edit**
Seriously done this time.

### JavaScript

```
for(i=0;i<192;)document.body.innerHTML+=(i%12?"":"<br>")+"<font color=#"+["6B8CFF","B13425","6A6B04","E39D25"]["000111110000001111111110002223323000023233323330023223332333022333322220000333333300002212220000022212212220222211112222332131131233333111111333331111111133001110011100022200002220222200002222"[i++]]+">█"
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcfnojv4/21/)

Comment: The linked JSFiddle doesn't contain the same version as posted here and doesn't work (at least not for me in Firefox). By the way, for nicer output a `*{line-height:1}` would help.

Comment: @manatwork Try again.

Comment: Nice. But why the div? Just for my curiosity, I tried an ECMAScript version. Got 372 characters: http://jsfiddle.net/768h7brb/

Comment: because `<div></div>` is shorter than `document.createElement('div')`. And JSFiddle doesn't like `document.write`

Comment: I mean why `p=document.body.children[0]` then `p.innerHTML+=…`, when you can directly `document.body.innerHTML+=…`. You are not styling the div itself anyway.

Comment: I keep working on it. It's about to get smaller again

Comment: Ok. I'm curious about its evolution. In meantime, do you know that strings support subscripting? I mean `abcde[2]` is letter at position 2, “c”.

Comment: Reverse the ternary operator's condition to get rid of comparison's right side: `i%12?"":"<br>"`.

Comment: You can remove the spaces between the CSS selectors and the final closing bracket.

Comment: You can use a single “#” character instead of 4: `…yle=color:#"+["6B8CFF","B13…`. The space in front of `document.body.` and the `;` at the end can be removed. And a horribly ugly thing: the closing “</a>” tag can also be removed.

Comment: @manatwork yea...I removed the closing a...but it just felt dirty so i put it back.

Comment: Interesting. Removing the closing “</a>” tag has no visible side effect in Firefox and Chrome… (If using Explorer, try an even dirtier trick which worked in Explorer 3: use just “</>” for closing tag.)

Comment: @manatwork How's that for dirty?

Answer (score 4):

### Matlab - <s>449 / 332</s> 305 bytes

partial compression + Using the lower image symetry:

```
a=[0,0];b=[2,2];c=[3,3];d=[a,0];f=[b,2];g=[c,3];h=[b,b];i=[a,a];k=[1,1];l=[0,f,1,2;h,k;c,2,1,3,1;g,k,1;c,k,k;a,k,1,0;0,f,a;h,a];imshow(uint8([d,k,1,k,i;a,k,k,k,k,1,0;a,f,c,2,3,d;0,2,3,2,g,2,g,0;0,2,3,b,g,2,g;0,b,c,c,h,0;d,g,g,3,a;a,b,1,f,i;[l fliplr(l)]]),[107 140 255;177 52 37;106 107 4;227 157 37]/255)
```

--
Partially compressed version (332 bytes):

```
a=[0,0]
b=[2,2]
c=[3,3]
d=[a,0]
e=[1,1,1]
f=[b,2]
g=[c,3]
h=[b,b]
i=[a,a]
imshow(uint8([d,e,1,1,i;a,e,e,e,0;a,f,c,2,3,d;0,2,3,2,g,2,g,0;0,2,3,b,g,2,g;0,b,c,c,h,0;d,g,g,3,a;a,b,1,f,i;0,f,1,b,1,f,0;h,e,1,h;c,2,1,3,1,1,3,1,2,c;g,e,e,g;c,e,e,1,1,c;a,e,a,e,a;0,b,2,i,f,0;h,i,h]),[107 140 255;177 52 37;106 107 4;227 157 37]/255)
```

---

Fully uncompressed version (449 bytes):

```
imshow(uint8([0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0;0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0;0,0,2,2,2,3,3,2,3,0,0,0;0,2,3,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,0;0,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,3;0,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,0;0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0;0,0,2,2,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,0;0,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,0;2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2;3,3,2,1,3,1,1,3,1,2,3,3;3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3;3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3;0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0;0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0;2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2]),[107 140 255;177 52 37;106 107 4;227 157 37]/255)
```

---

Output in both cases (magnified on screen obviously, the real one is 12x16pix):
[image: MarioMagnified]

Comment: Hey I wondered if anyone would exploit the symmetry somehow.   I couldn't fnd a way with the method I finally went with.

Answer (score 4):

## C, 4999 bytes

This absolutely cannot compete with some of the answers here, but I thought I'd give a C answer a shot. The code is one single long line, so [here](http://pastebin.com/RPQ9sY8A) is a pastebin link. If you'd prefer, here is a base64 encoding of the gzipped code:

`H4sICAzFGFYCA21hcmlvLmMA3Zc9DsIwDIXv0qndUqchkXwUurAgdYiFEEyIu4NYaZBI7PzNT3Lsz4mf408bjdPjct3odh6HVeujdgg4K4vzohCM8esdjHOpkrVoALUtIrBX8y1R04DKNCGZmTp85CVdAHifYuxO3mElIlju6xaRICOgCo4pD64PoiTzHnkZcHYnRhAYcEEpFznxB1mXP4TdS/KeVGYPZbmVaQHlnRVZFi65OkhoGodq+RHrby4xsTj8i6RmapXrPvfa0Q8ZWZY1/UPbSiC7Z2bYA7r0zla57Xmo8sOEzxdNYIXFhxMAAA==`

Notable in that it requires no external libraries to run.

Requires xterm, Konsole, or GNOME terminal, because it uses the RGB expansion to the ANSI color escape codes to output the correct colors (ANSI doesn't define orange). For obvious reasons, ideone won't work. It can be run in Windows under Cygwin, which uses xterm (in fact, that's how I tested it). MSYS might work; I'm not sure.

Output on my machine (xterm):

[image: it's a me, mario!]

Comment: -1 is not a multiple of 10

Comment: Sorry, it was in reference to the score

Answer (score 3):

**Bash 346**

*pure bash with VT100 like escape sequences ( sorry no orange in that palette )*

```
C="  "
B="\033[44m$C"
R="\033[41m$C"
G="\033[42m$C"
O="\033[43m$C"
N="\033[00m\n"
A="BBBRRRRRBBBBNBBRRRRRRRRRBNBBGGGOOGOBBBNBGOGOOOGOOOBNBGOGGOOOGOOONBGGOOOOGGGGBNBBBOOOOOOOBBNBBGGRGGGBBBBNBGGGRGGRGGGBNGGGGRRRRGGGGNOOGRORRORGOONOOORRRRRROOONOORRRRRRRROONBBRRRBBRRRBBNBGGGBBBBGGGBNGGGGBBBBGGGGN"
while read -n1 v
do
  printf "${!v}"
done <<< "$A"
```

Comment: You could reduce it by using an array for the palette instead of separate characters. As declaring associative arrays is long, better recode it to integers. A 295 character version of your code: http://pastebin.com/d0LW0HM1

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 83 bytes

Disclaimer: This isn't a winning candidate, because some of the language features were created after posting the question.

```
.wc16@Lc4CM"±4%kÿjkã%"jC"T\0UP\0Z¾Õnþýn¿¿kþ©WÿõZ*Uj(©ª\0ªøÃ/ü\0?ð\0PjU©ªUª"4
```

Here's a hex-dump:

```
00000000   2E 77 63 31  36 40 4C 63  34 43 4D 22  B1 34 25 6B  .wc16@Lc4CM".4%k
00000010   8C FF 6A 6B  04 E3 9D 25  22 6A 43 22  54 5C 30 55  ..jk...%"jC"T\0U
00000020   50 5C 30 01  5A BE D5 6E  FE FD 6E BF  BF 6B FE A9  P\0.Z..n..n..k..
00000030   57 FF F5 5A  2A 55 6A 28  A9 AA 5C 30  AA F8 C3 2F  W..Z*Uj(..\0.../
00000040   FC 5C 30 3F  F0 5C 30 0F  50 14 05 6A  55 A9 AA 55  .\0?.\0.P..jU..U
00000050   AA 22 34                                            ."4
```

You can also download the program [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65361302/mario.pyth) and run it with

```
python3 pyth.py mario.pyth
```

This creates a file `o.png`:

[image: Mario]

#### Explanation:

There are only 4 different colors, therefore I only need 2 bits to save the color of each pixel.

```
.wc16@Lc4CM"..."jC"..."4
                  "..."   the colors of the image, 2 bit per pixel
                 C        convert these bytes to a number
                j      4  and convert it to base 4 (extracting the colors)
           "..."          the hexcodes of the 4 colors (3 byte per color)
         CM               convert each byte into its number
       c4                 split into 4 lists
     @L                   for each pixel, pick the correct list of color-list
  c16                     split into 16 rows
.w                        save it as "o.png"
```

Comment: Does this work in the last version of Pyth before the challenge was posted?

Comment: @ThomasKwa Yeah, forgot. I'll edit a info.

Answer (score 2):

## Processing 2 - 359 characters

I saw this challenge and immediately thought of Processing's pixel[] function.  I was hoping it would be shorter but i'm still fairly happy with the result considering this is my first attempt at code golf.

```
int i,l;i=l=0;size(12,16);loadPixels();for(char c:"3b5r6b9r3b3g2o1g1o4b1g1o1g3o1g3o2b1g1o2g3o1g3o1b2g4o4g4b7o4b2g1r3g5b3g1r2g1r3g1b4g4r4g2o1g1r1o2r1o1r1g5o6r5o8r2o2b3r2b3r3b3g4b3g1b4g4b4g".toCharArray()){while(l>0){pixels[i]=#6B8CFF;if(c=='r')pixels[i]=#B13425;if(c=='g')pixels[i]=#6A6B04;if(c=='o')pixels[i]=#E39D25;i++;l--;}if(c<58){l=c-48;}}updatePixels();
```

ungolfed:

```
int i,l;i=l=0;
size(12,16);
loadPixels();
for(char c:"3b5r6b9r3b3g2o1g1o4b1g1o1g3o1g3o2b1g1o2g3o1g3o1b2g4o4g4b7o4b2g1r3g5b3g1r2g1r3g1b4g4r4g2o1g1r1o2r1o1r1g5o6r5o8r2o2b3r2b3r3b3g4b3g1b4g4b4g".toCharArray())
{
    while(l>0)
    {
        pixels[i]=#6B8CFF;
        if(c=='r')pixels[i]=#B13425;
        if(c=='g')pixels[i]=#6A6B04;
        if(c=='o')pixels[i]=#E39D25;
        i++;
        l--;
    }
    if(c<58){l=c-48;}
}
updatePixels();
```

you can download processing [here](https://www.processing.org/download/?processing)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript 515

```
str='';
"000111110000|001111111110|002223323000|023233323330|023223332333|022333322220|000333333300|002212220000|022212212220|222211112222|332131131233|333111111333|331111111133|001110011100|022200002220|222200002222"
.split("|").forEach(function(ov, ok) {
str += '<div>'
    ov.split("").forEach(function(iv, ik) {
    str += '<div style="width:1px;height:1px;background-color:' + ['#6B8CFF','#B13425','#6A6B04','#E39D25'][iv] + ';display:inline-block"></div>';
    });
    str+= '</div>';
});
document.write(str);
```

just got it working, still have to go in and golf it up

Comment: You can replace the `div`s that make up the rows with a tag that is inline by default. I haven't tested it, but using `a` should work. You can also use `background` instead of `background-color`.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl - Ungolfed 927

I'll have to golf this later. First time trying out `Image::Magick`.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Image::Magick;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @p = (
[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
[0,0,2,2,2,3,3,2,3,0,0,0],
[0,2,3,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,0],
[0,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,3],
[0,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,0],
[0,0,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0],
[0,0,2,2,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,0],
[0,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,0],
[2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
[3,3,2,1,3,1,1,3,1,2,3,3],
[3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3],
[3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3],
[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0],
[0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0],
[2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2],
);
my $image = Image::Magick->new;
$image->Set(size=>'12x16');
$image->ReadImage('canvas:white');
for my $i (0..$#p) {
    for (0..(@{$p[$i]} - 1)) {
        my $color;
        $color = ($p[$i][$_] < 1 ? "#6B8CFF" : $p[$i][$_] < 2 ? "#B13425" : $p[$i][$_] < 3 ? "#6A6B04" : "#E39D25");
        print "$i : $_ : $color \n";
       $image->Set("pixel[$_,$i]"=> $color);
    }
}
#$image->Write("mario.png");
$image->Display();
```

I'm sure we have plenty of these but here's mine: [image: Mario!]

Answer (score 2):

## Bash Printable: <del>179</del> 158 Bytes

Inspired by [user2485710's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39969/18017).

You need to tune your terminal to match colors exactly.

```
eval "$(base64 -d<<</AD/8AAD9Wm/2amr2Wpq1qlX/qqv9RX/1RRXVQBVpIIaqAAqoAAK8DwP1f9XVf9V|xxd -b -c3 -g0|cut -c10-33|sed $'s/../\e[4$[2#&+1]m \e[0m/g;s/^/echo /')"
```

Comment: [this is what i see](http://i.imgur.com/BlwQjVl.png). am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @ardnew: [BSD base64](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/base64.1.html) uses `-D` for *decode* and `-d` for *debug*.

Answer (score 2):

## Tcl 298

```
package require base64
set d [base64::decode AVUABVVUCr7ALv78Lr+/K/6oA//wCmoAKmmoqlWq+ddv/VV/9VVfBUFQKgCoqgCq]
binary scan $d B* z
set i 0
foreach {a b} [split $z ""] {
if {$i % 12 == 0} {puts "\033\[0m"}
puts -nonewline "\033\[4[string map {00 4 01 1 10 2 11 3} $a$b];m  "
incr i
}
puts "\033\[0m"
```

It's a 2 bits per pixel image in base 64.  Pixels are mapped to ansi escape codes.

[image]

Comment: Without even trying, your code seems a little bit golfable: https://tio.run/##Rcy7boMwAIXhnac4QnRpVNkElLSpMgBSF7J0wB2AwYCDrIINhiRqEM9OL2lVne0/0jeWzbJ0vHzntYAR/UkagYIPYuNbhVTcfGAouUJ6a7tdJUpdCQQsCULGkshsg8N5@3gwKxKTjQ4IuUStDuK21X3z1q@q6kwYI0@MHcPk5TWuI93XUZ8jvMfVGsQICWo1Le/AMxRIh66RI5wrbDvHJI@YHHnnrvd7OmPqTuMAO6Oel6W0tWfrJzworcSlkUr8fX46jEaqGt/uRCl8UBdfo1jDdeHNcLhT5M8tYFtSlQbyF/vXl@UT

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript - 256 characters (161 obfusc-a-tweeted)

```js
d=v=>{for(i=v&15;i--;)O.innerHTML+=`<i style="color:#${'6B8CFF6A6B04B13425E39D25'.substr(x%4*6,6)}">█</i>`+(++f%12?'':'<br>');x++},f=x=0,[..."fhilsswsssuss££cgÓdcddc¤g£stcucds³c¹cefefcc¤c§"].map(v=>(d(v=v.charCodeAt(0)-99),d(v>>4)))
```

```html
<p id=O>
```

[image]

#### Method:

1. Using bitmasking, a 63x8-bit string provides a 126x4-bit value array consisting of numbers in the range 0-9.  (Frustratingly... saved 63 characters by going 4-bit, but spent 50 characters unpacking the bits again lol.  Still, 13 chars is 13 chars! :-)
2. The 4 paint colours are cycled in the order: B, G, R, O.  At each iteration, 0-9 divs are rendered for the current color (with a line break every 12th)

To determine the optimal order for the color cycle, I ran the compression algorithm against the raw data for each of 24 permutations of [R, G, B, O] and selected the one yielding the shortest output (126 was best, least optimal was around 150-something)

ETA discovered this only after reading the other answers using obfusca-tweet...

```
eval(unescape(escape`ﶈ�`.replace(/u../g,'')))
```

Further ideas.
- Try 3-bit data range 0-6, with the rare 7,8,9 gaining 4 extra each: 60000N.
- check color cycle permutations in all  directions and speeds other than horizontally one pixel at a time.
- try multiple render passes so colors can be layered.

Comment: D'oh it just dawned that this is about chars not byes, so could probably have halved the data again using the 16-bit chars.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6 (HTML + CSS), 199 <strike>307</strike> <strike>3195</strike> <strike>3630</strike>

Using [Obfusc-a-tweet](http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/):

```
eval(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))
```

This displays the sprite without using any images or multiple elements; it just misuses the CSS `box-shadow` property to create each pixel. Try it at http://jsbin.com/pozohiyezo/. This unobfuscated version is **307 characters**:

```
s=[]
'39zrp34dfl3jgt14bwu54bkcf47p2h3flyt3inh1454896msoa9pfe79tz5r9d4b334hdx45d496n9gq'.match(/.{5}/g).some((n,i)=>[...parseInt(n,36).toString(4)].forEach((m,j)=>s.push(j+1+'px '+(+i+1)+'px #'+['B13425','6B8CFF','6A6B04','E39D25'][+m])))
document.write('<p style="width:1px;height:1px;box-shadow:'+s+'"')
```

This is the original, plain-vanilla HTML version. See it in action at http://jsfiddle.net/gfeLn1ey/1/.

```
<p style="width:1px;height:1px;box-shadow:4px 1px 0 #B13425,5px 1px 0 #B13425,6px 1px 0 #B13425,7px 1px 0 #B13425,8px 1px 0 #B13425,12px 1px 0 #6B8CFF,3px 2px 0 #B13425,4px 2px 0 #B13425,5px 2px 0 #B13425,6px 2px 0 #B13425,7px 2px 0 #B13425,8px 2px 0 #B13425,9px 2px 0 #B13425,10px 2px 0 #B13425,11px 2px 0 #B13425,12px 2px 0 #6B8CFF,3px 3px 0 #6A6B04,4px 3px 0 #6A6B04,5px 3px 0 #6A6B04,6px 3px 0 #E39D25,7px 3px 0 #E39D25,8px 3px 0 #6A6B04,9px 3px 0 #E39D25,12px 3px 0 #6B8CFF,2px 4px 0 #6A6B04,3px 4px 0 #E39D25,4px 4px 0 #6A6B04,5px 4px 0 #E39D25,6px 4px 0 #E39D25,7px 4px 0 #E39D25,8px 4px 0 #6A6B04,9px 4px 0 #E39D25,10px 4px 0 #E39D25,11px 4px 0 #E39D25,12px 4px 0 #6B8CFF,2px 5px 0 #6A6B04,3px 5px 0 #E39D25,4px 5px 0 #6A6B04,5px 5px 0 #6A6B04,6px 5px 0 #E39D25,7px 5px 0 #E39D25,8px 5px 0 #E39D25,9px 5px 0 #6A6B04,10px 5px 0 #E39D25,11px 5px 0 #E39D25,12px 5px 0 #E39D25,2px 6px 0 #6A6B04,3px 6px 0 #6A6B04,4px 6px 0 #E39D25,5px 6px 0 #E39D25,6px 6px 0 #E39D25,7px 6px 0 #E39D25,8px 6px 0 #6A6B04,9px 6px 0 #6A6B04,10px 6px 0 #6A6B04,11px 6px 0 #6A6B04,12px 6px 0 #6B8CFF,4px 7px 0 #E39D25,5px 7px 0 #E39D25,6px 7px 0 #E39D25,7px 7px 0 #E39D25,8px 7px 0 #E39D25,9px 7px 0 #E39D25,10px 7px 0 #E39D25,12px 7px 0 #6B8CFF,3px 8px 0 #6A6B04,4px 8px 0 #6A6B04,5px 8px 0 #B13425,6px 8px 0 #6A6B04,7px 8px 0 #6A6B04,8px 8px 0 #6A6B04,12px 8px 0 #6B8CFF,2px 9px 0 #6A6B04,3px 9px 0 #6A6B04,4px 9px 0 #6A6B04,5px 9px 0 #B13425,6px 9px 0 #6A6B04,7px 9px 0 #6A6B04,8px 9px 0 #B13425,9px 9px 0 #6A6B04,10px 9px 0 #6A6B04,11px 9px 0 #6A6B04,12px 9px 0 #6B8CFF,1px 10px 0 #6A6B04,2px 10px 0 #6A6B04,3px 10px 0 #6A6B04,4px 10px 0 #6A6B04,5px 10px 0 #B13425,6px 10px 0 #B13425,7px 10px 0 #B13425,8px 10px 0 #B13425,9px 10px 0 #6A6B04,10px 10px 0 #6A6B04,11px 10px 0 #6A6B04,12px 10px 0 #6A6B04,1px 11px 0 #E39D25,2px 11px 0 #E39D25,3px 11px 0 #6A6B04,4px 11px 0 #B13425,5px 11px 0 #E39D25,6px 11px 0 #B13425,7px 11px 0 #B13425,8px 11px 0 #E39D25,9px 11px 0 #B13425,10px 11px 0 #6A6B04,11px 11px 0 #E39D25,12px 11px 0 #E39D25,1px 12px 0 #E39D25,2px 12px 0 #E39D25,3px 12px 0 #E39D25,4px 12px 0 #B13425,5px 12px 0 #B13425,6px 12px 0 #B13425,7px 12px 0 #B13425,8px 12px 0 #B13425,9px 12px 0 #B13425,10px 12px 0 #E39D25,11px 12px 0 #E39D25,12px 12px 0 #E39D25,1px 13px 0 #E39D25,2px 13px 0 #E39D25,3px 13px 0 #B13425,4px 13px 0 #B13425,5px 13px 0 #B13425,6px 13px 0 #B13425,7px 13px 0 #B13425,8px 13px 0 #B13425,9px 13px 0 #B13425,10px 13px 0 #B13425,11px 13px 0 #E39D25,12px 13px 0 #E39D25,1px 14px 0 #6B8CFF,2px 14px 0 #6B8CFF,3px 14px 0 #B13425,4px 14px 0 #B13425,5px 14px 0 #B13425,6px 14px 0 #6B8CFF,7px 14px 0 #6B8CFF,8px 14px 0 #B13425,9px 14px 0 #B13425,10px 14px 0 #B13425,11px 14px 0 #6B8CFF,12px 14px 0 #6B8CFF,1px 15px 0 #6B8CFF,2px 15px 0 #6A6B04,3px 15px 0 #6A6B04,4px 15px 0 #6A6B04,5px 15px 0 #6B8CFF,6px 15px 0 #6B8CFF,7px 15px 0 #6B8CFF,8px 15px 0 #6B8CFF,9px 15px 0 #6A6B04,10px 15px 0 #6A6B04,11px 15px 0 #6A6B04,12px 15px 0 #6B8CFF,1px 16px 0 #6A6B04,2px 16px 0 #6A6B04,3px 16px 0 #6A6B04,4px 16px 0 #6A6B04,5px 16px 0 #6B8CFF,6px 16px 0 #6B8CFF,7px 16px 0 #6B8CFF,8px 16px 0 #6B8CFF,9px 16px 0 #6A6B04,10px 16px 0 #6A6B04,11px 16px 0 #6A6B04,12px 16px 0 #6A6B04,6px 6px 0 5px #6B8CFF"
```

Comment: TIL, you can not close a <p tag :)

Comment: this code can have a very good compression in a tool like regpack. Here's an example in 729b (JS is used to write the HTML, though): http://goo.gl/7fF7kx

Comment: @xem I had actually not even considered generating the code with JS, but I was able to make it much shorter buy following the code's pattern.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, <s>253</s> <s>240</s> <s>238</s> 236

### [Obfuscatweet](http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/)ed source - <s>253</s> <s>240</s> <s>238</s> 236

```javascript
document.write(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))
```

### Unobfuscated - <s>395</s> <s>370</s> <s>365</s> 361

```html
<script>"5m2o9mh3097log9101pk9zp7u9vtxw93qu8986ww9uogk93csph96jmje96plnu96v7y29m5809thzo93bec5".split(9).forEach(function(c){d=document;c=parseInt(c,36).toString(4);while(c.length<12)c="0"+c;c.split("").forEach(function(v){d.write("<p style='display:inline;padding:9;background:#"+["6B8CFF","6A6B04","E39D25","B13425"][+v]+"'></p>")});d.write("<br>")})</script>
```

Thanks to @compass for the `<p>` tag tricks, and @xem for 2(5) chars.

[Demo](http://c99.nl/f/913861.html)

It converts data from base 36, and converts to base 4.

Comment: I can't test it, but I don't think `padding:9` Does anything without a unit after it. You could also use a single-letter element like `a` or `q` that is implicitly inline, instead of `p`.

Comment: @hsl I've updated demo link, and it works well at least my Chrome, Firefox and Safari on Mac.

Comment: -2 bytes: replace "|" by 9 in the string and the split. Also, you use 3 times "document.write", you should put it in a var to save, like, 24b)

Comment: @xem Thanks for reminding me the number split trick. And since we can't assign `document.write` to variable (we should use `document.write.bind(document)`), my best was assigning `document` to variable.

Comment: or, you can do this the first time: (d=document)[w="write"](/* things to write */), and just do that after: d[w]("Hi")

Comment: @xem Thanks, I've learned another good trick.

Comment: @hsl it appears all major browsers handle unitless `9` as px even though they're not technically supposed to. The CSS is malformed, but if we're going for good form, pretty much every golfed JS here is likely getting an F.

Comment: @Snack I've updated my solution. You can use `rp` instead of `p` and remove `display:inline`!

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, <s>256 or 245</s> 252 or 241

**256**

```
document.write("k6n56kcraqlaqasasjaqbsasibtdlstlb2cmc2b2cid5dra2q3q2au7u55rj4j4kclcidld".replace(/./g,function(x){return new Array((x=parseInt(x,36))&7).join("<li style=padding:4%;float:left;background:#"+['B13425','6A6B04','6B8CFF','E39D25'][x>>3]+">")}))
```

It's sad to override 256, but **245** is possible if use nonprintable characters:

```
document.write(btoa(">§ç©­ª¥j¦¬jÈÚ©»²&ív[-½ÍÙÈåÚÚÚ­êÙ«»»køÉ\\Ù]").replace(/./g,function(x){return new Array((x=parseInt(x,36))&7).join("<li style=padding:4%;float:left;background:#"+["B13425","6A6B04","6B8CFF","E39D25"][x>>3]+">")}))
```

There is some problem with submitting solution with nonprintable characters. The argument of `btoa` have to be the result of `atob("ij6n56kcraqlaqasasjaqbsasibtdlstlb2cmc2b2cid5dra2q3q2au7u55rj4j4kclcidld")` with 1 symbol of length added for escaping backslash.

Shorten both solutions by 4 symbols: we don't need new for array creation.

**252**

```
document.write("k6n56kcraqlaqasasjaqbsasibtdlstlb2cmc2b2cid5dra2q3q2au7u55rj4j4kclcidld".replace(/./g,function(x){return Array((x=parseInt(x,36))&7).join("<li style=padding:4%;float:left;background:#"+['B13425','6A6B04','6B8CFF','E39D25'][x>>3]+">")}))
```

**241**

```
document.write(btoa("©ùêG+j©Z©«²6ªnÆ¬»]Ëeog&sför'yv¶¶«z¶jîîçãâ>$rVÚÙ]").replace(/./g,function(x){return Array((x=parseInt(x,36))&7).join("<li style=padding:4%;float:left;background:#"+['B13425','6A6B04','6B8CFF','E39D25'][x>>3]+">")}))
```

No escaping is needed in this version. The `btoa`'s argument is result of `atob("k6n56kcraqlaqasasjaqbsasibtdlstlb2cmc2b2cid5dra2q3q2au7u55rj4j4kclbaidld")`

Comment: I noticed the non-printable problem on this and my last challenge too.  I thought it was only chars 8, 9 & 13 if that helps (though I could easily be mistaken)

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, <strike>266</strike> <strike>260</strike> <strike>257</strike> <strike>249</strike> 245 bytes

```
$_="444111114444441111111114442223323444423233323334423223332333422333322224444333333344442212224444422212212224222211112222332131131233333111111333331111111133441114411144422244442224222244442222";s/\d/\033[4$&m  /g;s/.{84}/$&\033[00m\n/g;print
```

Uses approach similar to user2485710's bash solution to write a VT100 style output.  Strips the explicit N for newline by inserting a newline every 12 "vt100 pixels", 12 * 7 = 84.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, <s>147</s> 136 characters

```
P$="xxxxxxxx
FOR I=0TO 191C=ASC("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"[I/8])>>I MOD 8*2AND 3GPSET I/16,15AND I,ASC(P$[C*2])<<16OR ASC(P$[C*2+1])NEXT
```

Output (cropped): [image: screenshot]

I replaced all the characters in the data strings with `x`'s, here are the character codes (in UCS-2):
`P$` (Palette): `FF6B,8CFF,FFB1,3425,FF6A,6B04,FFE3,D925`
Image data: `0000,83F8,0A80,A3FA,8BE4,A5EA,BEA5,A55A,7EE5,0575,BFF5,0156,BFF5,0156,BBA5,0575,3AF4,A55A,3BC4,A5EA,0BC4,A3FA,0300,83F8`

The palette is stored in a string, each color (32 bits) is stored in two characters (16 bits each). The image data (2 bits per pixel) is stored in another string (8 pixels per character)
Luckily, the challenge is scored in characters, since this file is significantly larger if saved in UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 87 bytes (Non-competing)

```
•8,vkJíÝ1¢tt6,9XÂck$XSãõO©Ú"›qf®¸Ì#}„K0ÝCìxý}É~ð_áú•4BSvy•3«WKyÛòèz*Ðeb•16B6ôè'#ì})12ô»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#AYIAff//4oCiOCx2a0rDrcOdMcKidHQ2LDlYw4JjayRYU8Ojw7VPwqnDmiLigLpxZsKuwrjDjCN94oCeSzDDnUPDrHjDvX3DiX7DsF/DocO64oCiNEJTdnnigKIzwqtXS3nDm8Oyw6h6KsOQZWLigKIxNkI2w7TDqCcjw6x9KTEyw7TCu///)

Outputs:

```
#B13425 #B13425 #B13425 #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #B13425 #B13425 #B13425 #B13425
#B13425 #B13425 #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #B13425
#B13425 #B13425 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #E39D25 #E39D25 #6A6B04 #E39D25 #B13425 #B13425 #B13425
#B13425 #6A6B04 #E39D25 #6A6B04 #E39D25 #E39D25 #E39D25 #6A6B04 #E39D25 #E39D25 #E39D25 #B13425
#B13425 #6A6B04 #E39D25 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #E39D25 #E39D25 #E39D25 #6A6B04 #E39D25 #E39D25 #E39D25
#B13425 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #E39D25 #E39D25 #E39D25 #E39D25 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #B13425
#B13425 #B13425 #B13425 #E39D25 #E39D25 #E39D25 #E39D25 #E39D25 #E39D25 #E39D25 #B13425 #B13425
#B13425 #B13425 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6B8CFF #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #B13425 #B13425 #B13425 #B13425
#B13425 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6B8CFF #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6B8CFF #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #B13425
#6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04
#E39D25 #E39D25 #6A6B04 #6B8CFF #E39D25 #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #E39D25 #6B8CFF #6A6B04 #E39D25 #E39D25
#6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04
#6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6A6B04 #6A6B04
#B13425 #B13425 #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #B13425 #B13425 #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #6B8CFF #B13425 #B13425
#B13425 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #B13425 #B13425 #B13425 #B13425 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #B13425
#6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #B13425 #B13425 #B13425 #B13425 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04 #6A6B04
```

Because 05AB1E can't do colors, or graphics of any kind... If this isn't acceptable I'll delete it.

Comment: You could write a Bash wrapper and say your solution is `Bash + 05AB1E`

Comment: @Pavel I was thinking of doing that, guess I'll go mate this solution with someone else's ;P.

Comment: I can't say it "wins" but please keep it, as it's a great compression score :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 113 bytes (filename).

Here is filename (some characters as backslash with its code point in three-digit octal):

```
xHJG\071\070b\015\001\021\001\242\005\001l\215\400\344\236&kl\005\262\065&-\001\001\001\001\015\001\021\001\001\003\067\205\210i\014\352k\205\015B\005g.\326\030e\317z]&\012\015\206S\231\061\225\215\311K\256\005\264J\252\262\002\263\220\374\224\373>\007\253\007%\262q&j\271\226\245\001\001<.w\001.-.o.c.c.z.d.aX.a
```

Outputs as GIF.

### How it works

Just as [@nietthedarkabsol's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39926/100411), but had to add one to every byte, as the original GIF contains null chacters, which is illegal for filename. Then I just decrement each of them to output them. If I had an implementation whose `.w` breaks from the loop when stack is empty (nk. actually specified on the original page but no one has ever complied with it, including himself), then the final part could be golfed to: `.w.o.c.a`.

Answer (score 0):

## Sinclair BASIC - 573 bytes

OK, so the Spectrum can't show RGB colours as specified, so have used the closest possible.

```
10 let x=0:let y=0:let i=0
20 let a$="1c2e1f2i1c4c6b461d4646c46c1b464b6c46c14b6d4d1d6g1d4b24c1e4c24b24c14d2d4d6b4262b6246e2f6e2c1b2c6b1b2c1b2c1c4c1d4c14d1d4d"
30 let l=len a$
40 let i=i+1:let c=1:let p=0:let k=val a$(i)
50 if a$(i+1)>="a" then let c=code a$(i+1)-96:let i=i+1
60 print at y,x;ink k;"\::":let p=p+1:let x=x+1:if x=12 then let x=0:let y=y+1
70 if p<c then goto 60
80 if i<l then goto 40
```

The string is the colour (1=blue, 2=red etc) followed by a letter to represent how many times that block repeats (by taking the ASCII value minus 96 to become 1,2,3 etc). A number without a letter after it just draws one block.

`"\::"` in line 60 is how to enter graphics in a text editor before turning into a TAP file to load into Fuse emulator. (Shows as a solid block graphic on screen).

Each keyword is one byte in Sinclair BASIC, have included a count from a PEEK command after it was generated.

[image: It's-a Mario]

Answer (score 0):

### Perl - <strike>399</strike> 171 bytes

```
use MIME::Base64;$_='R0lGODdhDAAQAKEEAGuM/+OdJWprBLE0JSwAAAAADAAQAAACNoSHaAvpaoQMQQRmLdUXZM55XCUJDIVSmDCUjMhKrQSzSamxAbKP+5P6PQaqBiSxcCVpuJWkAAA7';
print decode_base64($_)
```

Writes the gif file to stdout.