# Pixel art, episode 2: Display the map 1-1 of Super Mario Bros

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output

Last challenge ([Pixel-art, episode 1: display Super Mario](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39915/pixel-art-display-super-mario/)) was just a training... (and you completed it in amazing ways, thanks!)

This time, you have to work a little bit more. You have to display all the first overworld map of Super Mario bros on NES, without enemies, and without Mario.

Your program or function must display all the pixels of the following image OR produce an image file similar to it (BMP, PNG, or GIF).

Your program must not access the internet in any way.

The output can be zoomed if you want, and the pixels can be ASCII or HTML elements if you want, as long as they have the right color.

Here's the model you have to follow:

- The whole image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kfVc.png
  [image]
- The tileset (if you need it): http://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/10/19/5443f44c7eb78.png
  [image: tileset]

  You can produce your own tileset, subset or superset of this one.

  You can use your tileset as a separate image file or include it in your code (for example, in base64). If it's separate, add its size in bytes to your score.
- The map with coordinates: http://goo.gl/c8xJIx or http://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/10/19/544373adc9f64.png
  [image: map]
- The colors:

```
Sky blue: #5C94FC
Black: #000000
Pink: #FCBCB0 (for the blocks and the castle)
Brown: #C84C0C (for the blocks and the castle)
Orange: #FC9838 (for the "?" block)
Light green: #80D010 (for bushes, mountains, flagpole, warp)
Dark green: #00A800 (for bushes, mountains, flagpole, warp)
White: #FCFCFC (clouds)
Light blue: #3CBCFC (clouds)
```

Shortest answer wins.

EDIT: There will be two score boards, one where scores are counted in bytes and one where they are counted in characters.

Good luck!

P.S: Here are some notes that could help you optimizing your program:

- Clouds, bushes and mountains have a repeating pattern (every 48 columns)
- Flying blocks are only present on lines 4 and 8
- Each tile or sprite of the map uses at most 4 colors (including blue or transparent, depending on how you see it)
- Bushes are just "top of clouds" with a diferent color palette
- Single, double and triple bushes/clouds can easily be formed using the same mini set of 16x16px pieces. This is also true for the single and triple mountains

Comment: Is episode N going to be making playable 1-1?

Comment: hey, stop spoiling! :D (btw: no)

Comment: You might want to specify that you can't just download the image and show it.

Comment: @BetaDecay I could but... the frontier is very thin between including an image and producing a similar image programatically. Also, I'm curious to see someone else make another hardcoded solution in less than 4012 chars. Theoretically, the hardcoded image could fit in less than 2400 Unicode characters.

Comment: FYI I added lots of information in the OP (map, palette, tileset)

Comment: I never realised the bushes were the tops of the clouds... Well well well!

Comment: @BetaDecay NES developpers were the code-golfers of the 80's ;) All the SMB game (dozens of sprites, palettes, sounds, musics, physics engine, game engine, AI, ...) fits in 32kb. It blows my mind. This challenge is a tribute to it, btw.

Comment: @xem: There's one tile missing in your tileset: complete dark green (for the hills), f.e. in the large map at (2, 11). I'd suggest to replace the redundant complete blue tile above the hill in the tilemap, like this: http://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/10/19/54439ba9d530d.png

Comment: @xem: Another one: The castle has complete brick blocks (f.e. at (202,10)) that differs from the other brick blocks (f.e. at (168,8)) which have orange lines at the top. Updated tileset: http://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/10/19/5443f44c7eb78.png

Comment: thanks again and sorry for not noticing that earlier

Comment: @xem it would probably be a good idea to put the images on the i.stack.imgur.com server (use the upload image tool) so they don't magically disappear.

Comment: Done. I also added info on how to use and count the score of the tileset.

Comment: Is PPM out ok, and is it ok to expect a data file to be written in over stdin?  I can try and do the UTF-8 string in an eval instead of a separate file, but things will be much more readable if I just put the gzipped data file separately.

Comment: @Will Sorry, I don't know what PPM means, but basically, yeah, your program can use any file, gzipped or not, passed in argument or used directly using its path. Your score will be the size of your program (in chars) + the size of your files (in bytes)

Comment: PPM is an image format: [Portable PixMap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format).

Comment: The reference image is incorrect, the right-most hill spot is in the wrong location, and the bushes are not repeated correctly. You can compare it to your grid image, or http://www.mariomayhem.com/downloads/mario_game_maps/super_mario_bros_maps/SuperMarioBros-World1-Area1.png

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't spot the error you're talking about. Is it the mountain on the right of the map? where should it be if instead?

Comment: Look at the spots on the mountain on the gridded version (grid 3,11) verses your reference image - the spots should be on the left of the tile, not the right. Your bushes look like they are shifted to the right one pixel, this causes part of the black outline to be cut off when they repeat.

Comment: Its a real shame that it comes down to whether you can compress the source code as well as the data; rather than going the unicode eval route which makes for an ugly entry, can't we just count the lzma size of the python sourcecode?

Comment: @Will Sorry for this rule that doesn't please everyone. To fix it, I'll make two leaderboards, ine where scores are in bytes and one where scores are in characters. So go ahead, and don't worry about Unicode or lzma.

Comment: @xem no no no, its not that bad a case of sour grapes ;)  Keep things as they are; python too can do the eval trick although perhaps statically-typed languages can't follow.

Answer (score 15):

## x86 Machine Code, <strike>1729</strike> <strike>1619</strike> <strike>1468</strike> 1382 Bytes

How it works: Tiles are generated by a combination of RLE compression, 2bit images, and procedural code. Once the tiles are generated in memory, the program then creates a matrix of tile indexes. This is first loaded with the repeating background. After that, the pipes, floating blocks, pyramids, and the flag pole are drawn procedurally. The pipes, hills, bushes, and pyramids can extend below the ground, but are covered up when the rock tiles get written next. Finally, the castle tile values are simply copied into the correct location.
To generate the image file, the BMP header and palette is stored in the file as data, and is written first. The program then runs through the matrix, writing the appropriate row from the corresponding tile for each position.

Usage: Run mario.com, it will generate "m.bmp", a standard BMP image file. The file is created as a hidden file, since that ended up being less bytes.

[Download a ZIP file containing the source code and binary, plus output.](http://lags.leetcode.net/mario.zip)

[image]

Assembly code to generate the executable file:

```
org 100h
code_start:

;xor    cx,cx
mov    cx,12+14+256*3
mov    dx,filename
mov    ah,0x3c
int    21h
mov    bx,ax
push   ax


;mov    dx,BITMAPFILEHEADER
inc    dx
inc    dx
mov    ah,0x40
int    21h


mov di,tiles
xor ax,ax
mov ch,48
rep stosw

cwd             ; load the cloud sprite
mov si,cloud
call    DrawSprite
call    DrawHill

mov dx,14*256+12*16
PipeTileLoop:                ;Pipe
mov si,pipe0
call    DrawSprite
sub dh,2
jns PipeTileLoop

mov dx,32+12*16
call    DrawSprite
mov dh,13
;mov     si,pipe2
call    DrawSprite

cwd
xor ax,ax                ; move to the tile array
mov cl,6
MoveTileLoop:
call    MoveTile
loop    MoveTileLoop
mov word [BITMAPFILEHEADER+5+2],0x607     ; bushes
sub dl,3*16
mov cl,13
jnc MoveTileLoop

mov dx,0x1004
mov si,ball
call    DrawSprite
mov dl,0
call    MoveTile

xor bx,bx       ; pole
pole:
mov word[bx+tiles+22*256+7],0x707
add bl,16;
jnc pole

mov word [BITMAPFILEHEADER+5+2],0x805      ; qbrick
mov si,qbrick
call    DrawSprite
call    MoveTile

mov byte[BITMAPFILEHEADER+5+3],4

mov al,1            ; bricks & castle
call    Clear
mov al,23
call    MoveTile        ; black door
mov dx,0x800+64
BrickLoop:
xor dh,8
mov si,bricks
call    DrawSprite
sub dl,dh
jg  BrickLoop

cwd
call    MoveTile         ; left window
call    MoveTile         ; castle brick
mov al,3
mov di,image+15*256+16
mov cl,16
rep stosb
mov al,26
mov dl,16
call    MoveTile         ; reg brick

;mov     dl,32
;mov     si,door
call    DrawSprite
;mov     dl,32
call    MoveTile        ; door top
mov dx,48 +8*256
;mov     si,cren
call    DrawSprite
push    si

mov dh,0
call    MoveTile        ; crenulation 1
mov si,image+48+256  +4
mov di,image+48+256*9+4
mov bl,7
CrenLoop:
mov cl,7
rep movsb
mov dl,256-7
add si,dx
add di,dx
dec bx
jnz CrenLoop
mov dl,3*16
call    MoveTile        ; crenulation 2

pop si
mov cl,3
jmp skip
LastLoop:
;call    MoveTile        ; right window
                 ; block
                 ; rocks
call    DrawSprite
skip:
call    MoveTile
loop    LastLoop



xor ax,ax              ; Begin drawing world using the tiles
call    Clear
mov bl,48*4
BackgroundLoop:
lea di,[bx+image+2*256]
SmallHill:
mov al,10
mov cl,5
HillRow0:
stosb
inc ax
loop    HillRow0
mov dword [di+256-4],10+11*256+256*256*14
mov byte [di+512-3],15
sub di,256-10
cmp di,image +256
ja  SmallHill

mov si,fluff         ; draw clouds, bushes
FluffDrawLoop:
lodsw
add ax,bx
add ax,image
xchg    ax,di
lodsb
aam
mov cl,ah
;call    DrawFluff;

mov ah,1
FluffLayer2:
stosb
inc ax
push    cx
rep stosb
inc ax
stosb
pop cx
add di,256-2
sub di,cx
inc ax
dec ah
jns FluffLayer2

cmp si,pa
jl  FluffDrawLoop

sub bl,48
jnc BackgroundLoop

;mov     si,pa
mov cl,6
PipePlace:
lodsw
xchg    bx,ax
mov di,image
mov word [bx+di],18+19*256
PipeLoop:
dec bh
mov word[bx+di],16+17*256
jnz PipeLoop
loop    PipePlace

;mov     si,dba          ; draw the various floating blocks
mov cl,4
DrawBlockLoop:
lodsw
xchg    ax,bx
mov ah,bl

cwd
lodsb
BlockLoop:
mov bl,al
mov byte [bx+di],ah
lodsb
cmp al,dh
mov dh,al
ja  BlockLoop

dec si
loop    DrawBlockLoop

mov bx,198+256*12
FlagPole:             ; Draw flag pole
mov byte [bx+di],22
dec bh
jg  FlagPole
inc si
;mov     si,pyr            ; pyramid blocks
mov cl,8
PyrMainLoop:
lodsw
shr ah,1
cwd
inc dx
jnc NoNeg
neg dx
NoNeg:
mov bx,ax
PyrDrawLoop:
mov byte [bx+di],32
dec bh
jnz PyrDrawLoop
add ax,dx
dec ah
jnz NoNeg
loop    PyrMainLoop


;mov     si,ground        ; ground blocks
;mov     di,image
mov bl,4
push    di
GroundLoop:
lodsb
xchg    ax,cx
mov al,33
rep stosb
lodsb
add di,ax
dec bx
jnz GroundLoop
push    si
inc ch
mov si,di
sub si,cx
rep movsb

pop si
pop di
;push    di
;mov     si,copy         ; Draw Castle, flag ball
mov  dl,6
CopyLoop:
lodsw
mov cx,ax
shr cx,12
and ah,15
xchg    bx,ax
CopyRun:
lodsb
mov [bx+di],al
inc bx
loop    CopyRun
dec dx
jnz CopyLoop;

xor ax,ax
xor bx,bx ; image y        ; write the image to file
pop dx
WriteTileStep:
WriteRowStep:
mov bl,0 ; image x
WriteStep:
pusha
mov ah,[bx+di]
mov bx,dx
add ax,tiles
xchg    ax,dx
mov cl,16
mov ah,0x40
int 21h
popa
inc bx
cmp bl,212
jb  WriteStep
add al,16
jnz WriteRowStep
inc bh
cmp bh,14
jl  WriteTileStep
;pop     bx
;mov     ah,0x3e
;int     21h

;ret


DrawSprite: ; dx=x,y, si=data
pusha
mov bp,dx
;cwd
mov di,temp
push    di
lodsw              ; w, h*2+flag
mov dl,al
shr ah,1
pushf
mul ah
xchg    bx,ax
popf
jc  BitMapped
RunLoop:
lodsb
mov cl,al
shr cx,2
sub bx,cx
rep stosb
jnz RunLoop
jmp MoveData
BitMapped:
BitMappedLoop:
lodsb
mov cl,4
BitMappedQuad:
stosb
shr ax,2
loop    BitMappedQuad
sub bx,4
jg  BitMappedLoop
MoveData:
mov bx,sp
mov [bx+4],si
pop si
mov bx,di
lea di,[bp+image]
mov dh,-1
MoveLoop:
mov cl,dl
rep movsb
sub di,dx
cmp si,bx
jl  MoveLoop
popa
ret

MoveTile: ; dx =x,y, bx=y,ax=t-1
inc ax
pusha
mov si,dx

xchg    al,ah
xchg    di,ax
mov ax,16
TileLoop:
mov cl,16
TileTrans:
mov bx,[si+image]
inc si
and bx,3
mov bl,[bx+BITMAPFILEHEADER+5]
mov [di+tiles],bl
inc di
loop    TileTrans
add si,256-16
dec ax
jnz TileLoop
popa
add dl,16
ret

Clear: ; al = value
mov di,image
mov ch,48
rep stosb
ret;

DrawHill:
pusha
xor bx,bx
mov al,3
HillLoop:
lea di,[bx+image+6*16]
inc byte [di]
inc di
mov cl,16*5-2
sub cl,bl
sub cl,bl
rep stosb
inc byte [di]
inc bx
inc bh
cmp bl,16
jl  HillLoop

mov si,spot
push    si
mov dx,32-7+256*8 + 6*16
call    DrawSprite
mov dl,32+17    + 6*16
pop si
call    DrawSprite
mov dx,5*16      + 6*16
call    DrawSprite
popa
ret

filename: db 'm','.'
BITMAPFILEHEADER: db 66,77,'P',0,12,0,1,2,3,0,26,3,0,0
BITMAPCOREHEADER: db 12,0,0,0,64,13,224,0,1,0,8,0
colors: db 252,148,92,0,0,0,252,252,252,252,188,60,176,188,252,12,76,200,0,168,0,16,208,128,56,152,252

;pal: db 0,1,2,3
cloud: db 88,32,224,5,114,5,228,5,122,5,224,5,122,5,228,9,106,5,6,5,240,102,5,4,5,240,5,86,5,10,5,252,5,78,5,4,5,6,5,252,4,13,66,5,8,5,92,13,16,17,136,5,14,7,42,5,100,9,14,5,4,9,18,9,4,9,120,5,14,11,14,7,18,5,96,5,26,5,34,5,10,9,116,5,26,7,22,5,84,13,18,11,18,15,34,9,108,5,38,5,6,5,84,5,22,27,6,23,38,108,5,34,5,4,5,88,5,10,19,14,19,18,7,34,5,108,9,26,5,92,5,10,7,10,7,26,7,54,5,120,5,18,5,92,5,10,7,46,7,46,5,128,17,56
spot: db 6,17,245,95,255,245,93,87,127,245,87,127,245,223
hilltop: db 16,3*2,0x9, 0x33, 0x9, 0x8, 0xD, 0x1B, 0xD, 0x1C, 0x19, 0x14
ball: db 8,17,80,5,244,31,253,127,253,127,249,127,249,127,228,31,80,5
pipe0: db 64,5,0x90,0xFA,0xAA,0xAE,0xFF,0xFF,0xBB,0x06,0xA9,0xAF,0xAA,0xEB,0xFF,0xFF,0xBB,0x6B,0x90,0xFA,0xAA,0xAE,0xFF,0xFF,0xAE,0x06,0xA9,0xAF,0xAA,0xEB,0xFF,0xFF,0xEF,0x6A
pipe1:db 32,4,8,113,8,129
pipe2:db 32,12,5,23,26,79,9,122,133
qbrick: db 16,33,85,85,85,85,254,255,255,127,222,255,245,119,254,191,246,127,254,191,254,127,254,255,245,127,254,191,246,127,254,191,86,127,254,215,106,127,254,218,107,127,254,218,107,127,254,90,233,127,254,171,250,127,222,255,255,119,254,255,255,127,168,170,170,42
bricks: db 8,16,33,14,5,30,5,30,5,18,33,30,5,30,5,30,5
door: db 16,32,0xFD, 0xFD, 0x89, 0x6, 0x39, 0xA, 0x39, 0x6, 0x41, 0xA, 0x31, 0x6, 0x5, 0xE, 0x29, 0xA, 0x5, 0x16, 0x19, 0x12, 0x5
cren: db 16,17,213,255,255,85,234,0,192,170,234,0,192,170,234,0,192,170,234,0,192,170,234,0,192,170,234,0,192,170,255,0,192,255
block: db 16,32,61,6,7,53,6,5,11,45,6,9,15,37,6,13,19,34,17,19,34,17,19,34,17,19,34,17,19,34,17,19,34,17,19,34,17,19,34,17,15,6,35,17,11,6,43,13,7,6,51,9,6,59,5
rocks: db 16,33,86,149,87,149,171,106,171,90,171,127,171,106,251,85,171,106,95,170,173,106,165,170,173,106,171,170,182,106,171,170,182,106,171,170,182,106,171,170,246,127,171,170,102,149,171,170,118,106,171,170,182,106,171,170,182,106,171,170,182,106,254,255,231,191
fluff: db 8,10,11,     19,11,11,       27,10,31,       36,11,21,    11,1,34,    23,1,14,       41,1,24
pa: db 28,3,38,4,46,5,57,5,163,3,179,3
dba:db 21,5
qb: db 16,21,23,78,106,109,112,170, 21,9
qb2: db 22,94,109,129,130, 27,5
ba: db 20,22,24,77,79,94,100,101,118,129,130,168,169,171  , 27,9
ba2: db 80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,91,92,93,121,122,123,128,131,0
pyr: db 137,5*2+1,140,5*2,151,5*2+1,152,5*2+1,155,5*2,188,9*2+1,189,9*2+1,198,4
ground: db 69,2,86-69-2,3,153-86-3,2,256-153-2,0
copy: db 202,2+5*16,26,26,24,26,26,   202,3+5*16,26,26,28,26,26,    202,4+5*16,29,30,30,30,29,   203,5+3*16,31,26,25,  203,6+3*16,29,29,29, 198,12+16,20
temp: rb 256*48
tiles: rb 34*16*16
image:
```

Comment: Incredible! There are still people out there writing assembly :D

Comment: +1000 Easily the best entry!  So, no standard libraries at all eh?  That's really simply leagues ahead smaller than the HLL entries :D

Answer (score 13):

## Javascript minified (*): <strike>1285 1258 1253 1205 1186</strike> 1171 characters

(*) Minified using Closure, RegPack and ObfuscaTweet, as suggested by xem

Unicode version is 4549 bytes in size, without ObfuscaTweet (Closure and Regpack only), size is 2251 bytes.

History:

1285 -> 1258: variable `A` for 48 (thx @hsl), merged some of the `for` loops, merged `mt()` and `mu()`, using tile indices instead of tile strings, optimized png with [PNGOUT](http://advsys.net/ken/utils.htm)

1258 -> 1253: merged some more `for` loops; renamed `mt()` to `r()`; removed unnecessary braces; variable `B` for 16; defining 16 unused CSS sprites (replaces 32 with `A`); showing 1 unused row (replaces 14 with `B`); removed function `e()`; shortened `t()`, `g()`, `c()`; using `for(i=0;i<n;)f(i++)` instead of `for(i=0;i<n;i++)f(i)` where possible

1253 -> 1205: moved body style to CSS part instead of `<body style=...>`; replaced some `for` loops with `f` calls; optimized functions `r`,`q`; `</head><body>` seems to be unnecessary, `<html><head>` too; function `t(i)` for CSS mapping removed; CSS names `b0`..`b31` instead of `a`..`z`,`aa`..`ff`

1205 -> 1186: function `n` renamed to `N`; new function `n` that operates on an array with delta coding

1186 -> 1171: hills and warps can be drawn "big" anytime, the lower parts get overdrawn by stone blocks; use `d` for both clouds and bushes; removed some unnecessary semicolons

This is a procedural attempt. There are patterns everywhere, one of the magic numbers is 48 (tile gap between clouds, bushes and mountains). The tileset is encoded as Base64 data url string and used as a CSS stylesheet. In Javascript, the 212x14 array `m` is filled with tile indices. See the commented unminified version for more details.

Works in Chrome 38 (Ctrl+T for new tab, Ctrl+Shift+J for javascript console, paste code there) and Firefox 33 (if wrapped with HTML javascript tags). There's a [JS bin version](http://jsbin.com/bafabaneja/edit), too.

There's still some room for optimizations, I'll post updates and it would be nice if some JS/CSS/HTML people could suggest optimizations/corrections.

Minified:

```
eval(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))
```

Unminified and commented:

```
// map width
W=212;
// helper constants
A=48;B=16;
// array containing the map, generated at runtime
m=[];
function w(s){document.write(s)}
// set a map tile
function N(i,s){m[i]="b"+s.toString()}
function n(i,s){z=0;for($ in i){z+=i[$];N(z,s)}}
// set a row of map tiles (index a..a+b)
function f(a,b,s){for(k=a;k<=a+b;)N(k++,s);}
// set a block of map tiles (index a and b define upper left and lower right corner)
function g(i,j,s){for(x=i%W;x<=j%W;x++)for(y=i/W|0;y<j/W|0;)N(y++*W+x,s)}
// helper for clouds and bushes - j=1..3 sets map tiles to XYZ, XYYZ or XYYYZ
function c(i,j,a){N(i,a);f(i+1,j-1,a+1);N(i+j+1,a+2)}
// clouds/bushes
function d(i,j,a){c(i,j,a);c(i+W,j,a+16)}
// hill
function p(i){N(i+2,8);n([i+213,211],23);n([i+214,211,2],24);n([i+215,213],25);N(i+426,9)}
// warps
function q(i){N(i,10);N(i+1,11);l(i+W,3,26);l(i+213,3,27)}
// stairs - d=1 for upwards, d=0 for downwards
function r(i,d){for(j=0;j<4;j++)f(i+d*(3-j)+j*W,j,0);}
// set a column of map tiles (index i, height j)
function l(i,j,s){for(k=0;k<j;k++)N(i+k*W,s);}
// fill map with sky tiles
f(0,2967,7);
// clouds and bushes - some of the bushes will be overdrawn by blocks and the castle, so draw them first
for(i=0;i<4;i++){d(231+i*A,1,4);d(248+i*A,2,4);d(451+i*A,3,4);d(432+i*A,1,4);d(2343+i*A,3,17);d(2355+i*A,1,17);d(2373+i*A,2,17)}d(624,1,4);N(2539,19)
// '?' blocks
n([870,72,15,20,1,734,5,2,55,28,3,3,58],3)
// brick blocks and castle
f(928,7,2);f(939,2,2);f(969,2,2);n([976,3,737,2,2,53,2,15,6,18,11,1,38,1,2],2);N(1900,B);g(2322,2535,B);g(2325,2538,B);f(1687,2,13);N(1899,29);N(1901,31);f(2110,4,13);f(2111,2,15);N(2324,14);N(2536,30)
// big and small hills - one of the big hills will be overdrawn by the stairs, the small hills are big hills overdrawn by stone blocks
for(i=0;i<5;i++){p(1908+i*A);p(2135+i*A)}
// warps (often overdrawn by stone blocks), stairs and block below pole
q(1742);q(1753);q(1946);q(2148);q(2283);q(2299);r(1830,1);r(1844,1);r(1877,1);r(1033,1);r(1836,0);r(1851,0);g(1881,2520,0);l(1037,4,0);l(1848,4,0);l(1885,4,0)
// pole
N(410,12);l(622,9,28);N(2530,0)
// lower row of stone blocks
f(2544,423,1);
// gaps in stone blocks
g(2613,2826,7);g(2630,2844,7);g(2697,2910,7)
// HTML start and CSS spritesheet base (tileset PNG encoded as base64)
w("<style>body{width:3400px}div{background:url(data:image/png;base64,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)}")
// generate CSS classes 'b0'..'b31' for the 32 used tiles
// this actually generates 16 additional unused classes to reuse the constant A and save 1 byte
for(i=0;i<A;i++){j=(i%B)*-B;k=i>15?-B:0;w(".b"+i.toString()+"{background-position:"+j+"px "+k+"px;width:16px;height:16px;float:left;}")}
// some more HTML
w("</style>")
// body of HTML contains all tiles as <div> elements arranged in <span> columns
for(x=0;x<W;x++){w("<span class=b0>");for(y=0;y<B;){w("<div class="+m[y++*W+x]+"></div>")}w("</span>")}
```

Comment: Very impressive for a first draft, and thanks for putting so many efforts into it. Here are a few optimizations you could use: remove <html>, <head>, <body> tags, type="text/javascript", (or text/css) attribute, minify your JS code (use http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), then pack it ( use http://siorki.github.io/regPack.html) then obfuscate it in Unicode chars (use http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/). But please, if you do so, keep the "unminified" version in your answer so thah people can read it. To count your score in number of chars, use https://mothereff.in/byte-counter. ;)

Comment: Also, no need to document.write closing tags alone (you can remove 'w("</span>")'), no need to put quotes around the values of your style and class attributes. You can remove all the style of your "new" body element, excemt its width. Then, on the JS side: no space after "for", no ";" before "}", no line-breaks, ... (but any JS minifier will remove those extra bytes for you)

Comment: also, try hosting your code on http://c99.nl, it may fix your graphical issue with bushes and clouds

Comment: Semicolons are automatically inserted at the end of lines, so you can safely remove those.

Comment: @hsl, I guess you suggest removing trailing semicolons. I'd rather suggest removing line breaks, i.e. pass that code through a minifier :)

Comment: @xem I prefer line breaks because they make the code look neater and cut down on horizontal scrolling, but removing newlines works too and has the same char count.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice, as you can see, most of it worked :) The graphical issues were already resolved in the second version.

Comment: You could shave off a few characters by storing 48 as a variable and using that in all the `for` loops.

Comment: That's unminified!?!?!?!?

Comment: @AnubianNoob: Yep :D. It's still golfed, though. Perhaps I'll post more info on what the code does later.

Comment: You may want to replace your <div>s with <p>s (it's shorter, plus, you don't have to close <p> tags.) As mentioned before, document.write closing tags alone is unnecessary. So, I think you can remove 'w("</span>")'

Comment: @xem: If there is content inside the tag, you have to use closing tags. Both replacing `<div>` and removing `</span>` won't work, see http://jsbin.com/jovexaqezu/edit (`<p></p>` instead of `<div></div>`), http://jsbin.com/kameqohegi/edit (no `</p>`) and http://jsbin.com/zesudeyaxa/edit (no `</span>`)

Comment: `function l(i,j,s){for(k=0;k<j;k++)n(i+k*W,s);}` can be shortened by extracting k++ to the function, I think? So can the next line with j.

Comment: @schnaader sorry, I mixed up document.write("...") and document.body.innerHTML += "...". With the latter, closing tags is not necessary. But it doesn't matter very much.

Comment: (How many bytes is this?)

Comment: @Will: As stated in the answer, the score is 1171 characters (Unicode) or 2251 bytes (ASCII). The ASCII byte score can be reproduced by running Closure and RegPack on the unminified and commented code.

Answer (score 8):

## Javascript, <s>1069</s> <s>1072</s> 1024 characters (1957 bytes)

### [RegPacked](http://siorki.github.io/regPack.html) and [Obfuscatweeted](http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/)

```js
eval(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))
```

### Unobfuscated code

I hid this code because there's ungolfed code below.

```js
function R(s,t){return new Array(t+1).join(s)}
function b(n){return"<div style='background: url(data:;base64,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)-"+(n%16)*16+"px -"+(n/16|0)*16+"px;width:16px;height:16px;float:left}'></div>"}
function M(s){m="";for(_ in s)m+=b(parseInt(s[_],32));return m}
function C(s,a){c="";for($ in a)c+=$%2?M(a[$]):R(s,a[$]);return c}
O="<body style='width:3392px'>";
O+=R(s=b(7),212);
O+=R(C(s,[19,"456",14,"4556",8]),4);
O+=C(s,[6,"c",13]);
O+=R(C(s,[8,"456",8,"klm77777455567777kllm",8]),4);
O+=C(s,[6,"s7456",9]);
O+=R(C(s,[8,"klm",16,"klllm",16]),4);
O+=C(s,[6,"s7klm",31,"3",57,"222222227772223",14,"3",11,"22277772332",56,"00",8,"s",200,"000",8,"s",199,"0000",8,"s",198,"00000",8,"s7777ddd",22,"377723232",21,"ab",9,"ab",18,"232",14,"2777772777773773773777772",10,"22",6,"0770",10,"00770",12,"2232",12,"000000",8,"s7777tgv",8,"8",35,"ab",6,"qr778",6,"qr",39,"8",37,"007700777787770007700",26,"000000077778777s777dfffd",6,"nop",13,"8",10,"ab",8,"qr",6,"qr7nop",5,"qr",6,"8",31,"nop",13,"8",21,"0007700077nop700007700077787ab",14,"ab700000000777nop77s777ggegg77877no9op",6,"hiiijnop7777hij77qr",8,"qr7hiij7qrno9op7777qrhiiijnop7777hij",15,"hiij777no9op",6,"hiiijnop",4,"hij",12,"0000ii0000no9o00000770000jnopqr77hij",9,"qr00000000077no9op70777gguggjnop7"]);
O+=R(C(b(1),[69,"77",15,"777",64,"77",57]),2);
document.write(O);
```

### Ungolfed code

```js
function repeat(s, t) { var S=s; while(t-- > 1) S += s; return S; }
function block(n) { return "<div style='background: url(data:;base64,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)-" + (n%16) * 16 + "px -" + (n/16|0) * 16 + "px; width: 16px; height: 16px; float: left; }'></div>"; }
function blocks(s) { var S=""; for(var i in s) S += block(parseInt(s[i], 32)); return S; }
var output = "<body style=width:3392px>";
output += repeat(block(7), 212);
output += repeat(blocks("777777777777777777745677777777777777455677777777"), 4);
output += blocks("777777c7777777777777");
output += repeat(blocks("7777777745677777777klm77777455567777kllm77777777"), 4);
output += blocks("777777s7456777777777");
output += repeat(blocks("77777777klm7777777777777777klllm7777777777777777"), 4);
output += blocks("777777s7klm777777777");
output += blocks("777777777777777777777737777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777772222222277722237777777777777737777777777722277772332777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777770077777777s7777777777777");
output += blocks("777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777700077777777s7777777777777");
output += blocks("777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777000077777777s7777777777777");
output += blocks("777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777770000077777777s7777ddd777777");
output += blocks("7777777777777777377723232777777777777777777777ab777777777ab7777777777777777772327777777777777727777727777737737737777727777777777227777770770777777777700770777777777777223277777777777700000077777777s7777tgv777777");
output += blocks("77877777777777777777777777777777777777ab777777qr778777777qr7777777777777777777777777777777777777778777777777777777777777777777777777777700770077778777000770077777777777777777777777777000000077778777s777dfffd77777");
output += blocks("7nop777777777777787777777777ab77777777qr777777qr7nop77777qr77777787777777777777777777777777777777nop777777777777787777777777777777777770007700077nop700007700077787ab77777777777777ab700000000777nop77s777ggegg77877");
output += blocks("no9op777777hiiijnop7777hij77qr77777777qr7hiij7qrno9op7777qrhiiijnop7777hij777777777777777hiij777no9op777777hiiijnop7777hij7777777777770000ii0000no9o00000770000jnopqr77hij777777777qr00000000077no9op70777gguggjnop7");
output += repeat( repeat(block(1), 69) + blocks("77") + repeat(block(1), 15) + blocks("777") + repeat(block(1), 64) + blocks("77") + repeat(block(1), 57), 2);
document.write(output);
```

I first made tiles into sprites with @schnaader's minified data URI. `0 ~ v` (which is 0 ~ 31 in base 31) represents each tile.

And I converted map to tiles by hand. This data has 212 characters per row.

Then I replaced repeating character (like `7`(sky) and `1`(ground)) with `repeat()`.

I found `7`s and some blocks, and another `7` pattern is repeated. So I made another function to make it compact. You can see it at unobfuscated source code.

Finally I RegPacked, and Obfuscatweeted my 2341 bytes golfed code.

It was very funny challenge. Thanks! And thanks to @xem for more tricks.

Comment: Let's get dirty. Here are some tips to lose a few dozen chars: you can remove the quotes in <body style='width:3392px'> and in <div class='...'>. You can write your <style> element at the end of your <body>. You can omit </style> and </body>. You can remove the leading "image/png" and the trailing "ggg==" in your base64. You can omit the <style> element altogether, and get rid of the longhand notation "background-position" and the div classes, by setting an inline style to each div, like this: <div style='background:url(data:;base64,...)-Mpx -Npx;width:16px;height:16px;float:left'>

Comment: Good work! I thought my procedural attempt would beat coding the map, now I have something to catch up with ;)

Answer (score 7):

## Python3 <s>1638</s> <s>1576</s> <s>1616</s> 1513 bytes

### 581 code + 932 data

[image]

↑ This top is the original level.  In the middle is the PPM generated by this script.  At the bottom is a diff, and this shows that the palette and the map do not agree exactly!  I put this down to data glitch and not my script ;)

```python
# 759808 is 212*14 tiles at 16*16 each - the size of the map
import lzma;B,E,R,X=bytearray,759808,range,16
D=B(lzma.decompress(open("i","rb").read())+B(E)) # put canvas on end of data array
i,P=8218,lambda x,y:8622+y*54272+x*X # 8622 is length of decompressed data
def Q(s,n,d): # copies a 16x16 tile from s to d
 # n is the stride for the source s, which is different for put and copy
 for m in R(0,256,X):e=d+m*212;D[e:e+X]=D[s+m*n:s+m*n+X]
for j in R(4): # there are 4 command sections
 j&=1;i+=1+j;r=D[i-1]<<8 # j is now truthy if this is a copy buffer
 for k in R(D[i]): # this many commands
  a,b,w,h,c,d=D[i+1:i+7];q=h>32 # unpack it; put doesn't use all these
  # do the put/copy
  for z in R(((a,h-32)[q],w*h)[j]):Q((D[(i+4+z,i+5)[q]]<<8,P(a+z%w,b+z//w))[j],1+211*j,
      (P(b+z,w),P(c+(z%w,w-z%w-4)[r&1],d+z//w))[j])
  i+=((3+a,5)[q],6)[j&1];r>>=1 # move i to next command
for y in R(2,11):Q(28<<8,1,P(198,y)) # special case flagpole
o=open("o","wb");o.write(b"P6 3392 224 255 ") # header for PPM
for c in D[8622:]:o.write(D[8192+c*3:][:3]) # decompress palette to RGB
```

(bytes counted without comments, line-unwrapped and second level indent being `\t`)

Data (base64-encoded to be pasted; decode and save as a file named "i"):

```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```

The data file is a custom format I made for this problem and is stored as LZMA.

First all 32 tiles are serialized.  There are 9 colours in the palette, and this takes 8219 bytes uncompressed.  (I found that trying to compress the tiles at 4-bits-per-pixel didn't help compression at all.  I did not try and brute-force the best ordering of the tiles, and I probably lose a few points here.)

There are 212x14=2968 blocks making up the map.

Then the instructions to recreate the map are now encoded.

First comes a section of "put" commands that place some sequence of tiles from the tile-palette on the map at a particular x,y.  As there are 32 tiles, I specify a run of the same tile using a number bigger than 32 rather than the tile index.

Then comes a section of "copy" commands that copy some rectangle of the current map to some other place.  There is a special bit-mask that marks if the copy should be mirrored.

A short example command buffer:

```python
16, # there are 16 put commands
3, # place 3 tiles
8,2, # dest x, y
4,5,6, # these three tiles
3, # place 3 tiles
8,3, # dest x, y
20,21,22, # these three tiles
5, # place 4 tiles
27,2, # dest x, y
4,5,5,5,6, # these five
...,
8, # bits set if copy reversed (high 8 bits of a uint16 mask)
14, # there are 14 copy commands
8,2, # src x, y
3,2, # w, h to copy
19,1, # dest x, y
1,9, # src x, y
3,2, # w, h to copy
16,10, # dest x, y
...,
13, # there are 13 put commands
...
7, # bits set if copy reversed (high 8 bits of a uint16 mask)
15, # there are 15 copy commands
...
```

(I said *short*, but that's actually nearly half the total command buffer needed to make the whole map; the vast majority of the bytes in the data are the 32 source tiles themselves)

Then comes a second section of "put" commands and finally another section of "copy" commands.

Because these can overwrite each other, I can build copy parts that I later erase or change.

I can doubtless shave a few more bytes off it by - for example - turning *puts* into small *copies* and by doing the `eval` trick on a gzipped source-code, or playing with PNG (which is DEFLATE with image-specific filters) too.  But I like things verbose as they are.

Comment: Great work! About the diff, if the images of the OP are wrong (which is totally possible, I made that with paint), can you please provide better images for the map (or better values for the palette, idk). Thanks :)

Comment: Also, all the clouds and bushes appear in the diff. Do you think it's because of colors or because of an offset of 1-2 pixels between the two images? Looks like an offset to me

Comment: @xem I don't think the problem is so bad and I don't think it needs urgent fixing.  In your map the tile at `3,11` seems to be missing from the palette.  There seems to be some noise in the map around `20,12` and the general outline of trees and clouds may be an off-by-one alignment glitch in the palette?  There's only 9 colours, so it can't be any kind of blending artifact.

Comment: the bricks are totally my fault yeah :D. I tried to hide a goomba and made a 1px offset. I didn't touch bushes and clouds at all though. But I think your image is righter than mine, so I take it :p

Comment: I also failed hiding mario and all the other goombas in front of mountains, actually, d'uh. Thanks!

Comment: using your correct image in my hardcoded entry (http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40010/10732) helped a lot! Almost 100 chars less :)

Comment: I updated the OP with your correct image, you can remove your diff ... or update it to show that your image is equal to ...your image :)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript: <strike>3620 *(ouch)*</strike> <strike>3429</strike> 3411

### Updates

- **Update #1:** Removed `var` definitions and put the variable declarations inside brackets of first use. Removed `getElementById()` as it is also available on load as a varaible by ID. Using `cloneNode()` instead of `createElement('CANVAS')`. Renamed *main* from `xMx` to `M`. Removed the scaling feature :(, *(still available in the example.*)

  Added some comments to the expanded code. (That code is not updated with the removals. The line below, *("Mini code")*, is.)
- **Update #2:** Removed the main function `M()` as a whole and let the code run at *root*. This would require the code be placed inside a load wrapper or at end of document.
- **Update #3:** Added statistics.

***Mini code:***

```
K=126,f=['#000','#c84c0c','#fc9838','#00a800','#80d010','#fcbcb0','#3cbcfc','#fcfcfc'],X='Å=!15d>KIRiE%>?D^?C^FVNBTJ@M^>>]ANtN?ZCW]@QM4Gb1>EVWEZAEZN@VfMI?MPckVAwNEZWNV>Q]@YT2n6d@%vN4Gb@MABMALT>JTABM>Qz@FCTI`ZEE@L?E@CDD{EE@L_A5G>%>IVEB_DHTCC{PC{HDzlz]A4o5d>KIR5G}LZ?YZIAZI`ZH]LE]BBVL>VBHXLEXBLMLAM3n7y$",2EEKIR&O30y$",2E}?Q6&o9y$",2EbD?Q6&n2pI`ZJNM`BRG~J`M`CRO9dBKIRibPC@NMBNB]6n0dBKIRib>C@CVBCE]6n1dBKIR6n3y*",~1F0G%Ii%1R6Ob")",?-1n4y*",BK0G%1Ri%I6Ob")",In8dEKIRib"*",b1F0G%Ii%1R6O>%CCD8Gb")",An9p@ciuB?LFD?`RC?Ji~F?JRBc6OUdBKIAib1Bciu1>?JFDtDM>DV>DZ>DX>QtQM>QV>a>>PT>PwPr>Pa>s>WT[][M[V[Z[XAI]AIMAICAo1eKIREJ`NGuv`3G~>{AB@MC@JJ@SJES2o2eKIREI`NGBKJ`2GCKAEABBfPT>PwPr>Pa>s>WT[V[Z[XAI]AIM^T^_^r^aA^vATA@VA@ZA@XAJ]AJSO0dHKQFXRC{NzB@D@ZNG}r>>Z>@TBB@Mw>F?C[>>^MJ@VABTACVAE_3GF%Cr>EFMP_[FAO3dHKIFFBFB[FNG}w>FMBHTFZ>HwDFS?HCACFJGFK@T>>>>{ZCCMF@VX>>PtPBE[CBACSO5dH%WBHL[ELBPLGbWwQT@W@S[v@aABDLO4dH%1>?@JB?B4Gb1?]^>v@MJBCLGF%1B]AVvESodHK?EF_@3G}w>FMBEMECMEtZ>>HSndH%I?EF`zCBP|}XSt@a>BX>CaB`M>R>>>YMBREAo3duH?J6o4d~EPFiu`]@FP|bFDVREVN]N[>CEa[aAIV>`CAo6dEK?Cl?E7G}YF9GE%BHWG>K>BRMCF?DHBDDHBN@HBI{LJ@C3o7eKIRi>K?B@?@MB?S>?CATSCMAEV@?V2o8eKIR6O6y(",E%H4&O7y(",bHCF3&O8y(",>%H4&&&#;Ø=Kxt3r@6X>8_J1ZA3TJ6VA8>>@PM2D{5HM7F@L0ES2C@L5BS7zBU>JG>x>>>3a>6a>8rA1rA3_A6_A8T[M3>M5DM7PS0FS2HS5CS7EMU@JG@x>M3PM6PM8HS1HS3ES6ES8BS?T3>T5DT7PBA0FBA2HBA5CBA7ETU@LGBx?M3Hz6DM8E@J1FS3B@J6CS8>zPT2DBB5HT7FBL0EBA2CBL5BBA7{BU>LGu1PM3FM6HM8CS1ES3@S6BS8?MDT2HT5FT7EBA0CBA2BBA5{A7>TU?LGE%1a>3Z>6r>8VA1_A3MA6TA8tDM2HM5FM7ES0CS2BS5@S7>MU?JGF%1^>2L>>4^@5s7^>8jA0lA1jA3lA5lA6l>U`|H%1fB2N>>4f@6kB7f>9kJ0gL2kA3gJ5gA6g>UR|D%1`>>2`>>4N>>6L>>7L>>9fA1^A2^A4kA5jA6sUY|P%^Al>4s6`>>9lA1Lv4`v6^hL>>UsJ]5I]9Qc4Rc9NIG1bL>>5^>9jA4lh`|1>%f>5k>9gA4R>hN|1@%1Y]6`c1Lc6[>UW]@a5?a9DPA4FPhCWG1~kAR>>4g>6N>>9Rv1fA4Nv6khf>Ug>[>4W]9Yc4`c9LIG1uNvg>5f>6Rv0kA1Nv6fhR>>21k>L]5[>9Wc4Yc9`IG1E%IB6P7ALE8WB6N5`B5HI@6P7AJE8W@6N5`@57G1F%1FX2>X2BX7Dm0Fm0Pm1@m7?X2@V9CCA0PCA2PC2G1Hx?X2@X2CX7HX7PX9Cm0?m1Dm2PDJ6DDJ7>X8?CD9>CL2>CL2DCA3>NG1D%13N>N4kN4g`5`>N8^W9gA3`?L4I?L4W?N5`?L8J?Q3FPJ4?PJ5?PL5EPJ8BPY3Hm4?m5>DJ5Em8CDR8EH`8FFN8HEL8DC2G1Pxg>3g>4R>>5lA6Lv7s3Q]4R]5Y]4Fa5HWqb2s3s4l>5gA6Nv8k>3W]4Y]5Q]4Ha5DWq>xQc6Lc7W]3Da4FX5HQq@xWc6Nc8I]3Pa4HX5DQq~19Qc9DPhDDhDHhDFhDEhDChDBhDJqu19mqE%Uf@U`>@UJ?@U`?@Uf@U`>@UCXUBP3qF%U@PEUBH3qH%UNIqD%UNAqP%UBQG3bUEQ&&';'B%?KAG@B@@p"%2_>>AC%]>j>H>G2e%O2O1DAY>I>W>6GA9Q>J>:K:%?A?%P>E1E>A>?>A?F>H1D>P1C>20B>@AF1D19,&GC1@>B1%?@1?17,&,6,5,8,4,3,>12,0,1,'.match(/../g).forEach(function(v){X=X[u='split'](String.fromCharCode(K--))[U='join'](v);if(K==92)K=91});eval(X[u]('*')[U]('f')[u](')')[U]('d')[u]('(')[U]('b')[u]('&')[U](']')[u]('%')[U]('[')[u]('#')[U]('}')[u]('!')[U]('{'));function e(k,d,i){for(s[Y]=k,i=0;i<d[L];)s.rect[G](s,d.slice(i,i+=4))}function _(d,i,q){for(S.width=R,i=0;i<d[L];++i,s.fill(),s.beginPath())F[q=d[++i][0]]?F[q](d[i]):e(f[d[i-1]],d[i])}F={$:function(d){_(Å[d[1]].concat(d.slice(2)))},b:function(d){_(Å[d[1]].slice().map(function(i,x){return(x=d[2].indexOf(i))>-1?d[2][++x]:i}))},f:function(d,i){for(s[Y]=f[d[1]],s.moveTo[G](s,d[2]),i=3;i<d[L];++i)s.lineTo[G](s,d[i])},d:function(d,x,y,g){for(s[Y]=f[d[1]],g=d[2],y=g>0?0:15,x=0;x<R;++x,y+=g)s.rect(x,y,1,1)}};R=16;c.width=3392;c.height=224;;S=c.cloneNode();c=c[G='getContext']('2d');s=S[G]('2d');c[Y='fillStyle']='#5c94fc';c.rect[G='apply'](c,[0,0,3392,224]);c.fill();for(k=0;k<Ø[L='length'];++k)for(_(Å[Ø[k]]),t=Ø[++k],i=0;i<t[L];i+=3)for(j=0;j<t[i+2]*R;j+=R)c.drawImage(S,t[i]*R+j,t[i+1]*R)
```

---

### Blah blah:

*– Demo at end of post.*

Using *canvas* as base for an attempt to solve this. Ended up with about 6000 chars, but after some fiddling (and a custom compression - with fiddling and tweaks on that as well) I'm now at the stated number. Still high, but then again the *quality is good ;-).*

It also includes a scale option, first argument to the `xMx()`, aka *"main"* function. 1 = normal size (as in 16 bit tiles). There is not much room for tweaking, so if one use fractions some of the tiles does not fit best together. At whole numbers it should be OK. <sup>[1]</sup>

But: warning, going up, quickly eats resources and makes for a huge canvas. (It is all painted in one go.) When the original width is 3392 pixels it quickly becomes huge. <sup>[1]</sup>

<sup>*[1] As of update #1 this has been removed. It is present in the demo.*</sup>

---

### Stats:

- `Main code           　:  870`
- *`Compression:`*

  - `Main data         : 2176   (17,480 bits)`
  - `Key               :  128   ( 1,024 bits)`
  - `Code              :  236`
  - `Whole she bang    : 2540`
  - `Decompressed data : 5608   (44,864 bits)`
- `Total               　: 3410`                　 <sub>[1]</sub>

<sub>*[1]: +1 byte, ";", between the main / data code.*</sub>

The compressed data is one array, Å, and one *"object"*, Ø. Where Å is holding the tile placement and the Ø holding the data for painting the tiles. The Ø should have been an array as well – but as my code started out with something like this:

```
var tiles = {
   brick: [
        ...
   ],
   qmark: [
        ...
   ],
};
```

It ended up as is. I'll perhaps see if I can't fix this. Ideally I would have made it parseable with JSON instead of eval(), but that would not be a point in a contest like this. As it is now it can not be JSON parsed due to missing quotes around the id parts.

---

### Demo

Here is a fiddle where one can view the code in action. The code in the fiddle I have expanded somewhat (And added some HTML / CSS styling *around* the world – but the image of itself is self sustained.):

#### [*MARIOS WORLD*](http://jsfiddle.net/Ifnak/9txkyv40/2/embedded/result/)

[image]

---

### Expanded code:

Expanded and (a bit) rearranged code:

```
var D, C, c, S, s,   // Document, canvas and shadow canvas.
    R, F, Z, X, 
    Ø, Å,            // Due to the compression we have a couple of non-ascii
    K,               // variable names.
    L = 'length',
    Y = 'fillStyle',
    u = 'split',
    U = 'join',
    f = [
        '#000',    '#c84c0c', '#fc9838', '#00a800',
        '#80d010', '#fcbcb0', '#3cbcfc', '#fcfcfc'
    ]
;

/* ----------------------- data unpackeer and loader ------------------------ */
X='Å=!15d>KIRiE%>?D^?C^FVNBTJ@M^>>]ANtN?ZCW]@QM4Gb1>EVWEZAEZN@VfMI?MPckVAwNEZWNV'+
'>Q]@YT2n6d@%vN4Gb@MABMALT>JTABM>Qz@FCTI`ZEE@L?E@CDD{EE@L_A5G>%>IVEB_DHTCC{PC{H'+
'Dzlz]A4o5d>KIR5G}LZ?YZIAZI`ZH]LE]BBVL>VBHXLEXBLMLAM3n7y$",2EEKIR&O30y$",2E}?Q6'+
'&o9y$",2EbD?Q6&n2pI`ZJNM`BRG~J`M`CRO9dBKIRibPC@NMBNB]6n0dBKIRib>C@CVBCE]6n1dBK'+
'IR6n3y*",~1F0G%Ii%1R6Ob")",?-1n4y*",BK0G%1Ri%I6Ob")",In8dEKIRib"*",b1F0G%Ii%1R'+
'6O>%CCD8Gb")",An9p@ciuB?LFD?`RC?Ji~F?JRBc6OUdBKIAib1Bciu1>?JFDtDM>DV>DZ>DX>QtQ'+
'M>QV>a>>PT>PwPr>Pa>s>WT[][M[V[Z[XAI]AIMAICAo1eKIREJ`NGuv`3G~>{AB@MC@JJ@SJES2o2'+
'eKIREI`NGBKJ`2GCKAEABBfPT>PwPr>Pa>s>WT[V[Z[XAI]AIM^T^_^r^aA^vATA@VA@ZA@XAJ]AJS'+
'O0dHKQFXRC{NzB@D@ZNG}r>>Z>@TBB@Mw>F?C[>>^MJ@VABTACVAE_3GF%Cr>EFMP_[FAO3dHKIFFB'+
'FB[FNG}w>FMBHTFZ>HwDFS?HCACFJGFK@T>>>>{ZCCMF@VX>>PtPBE[CBACSO5dH%WBHL[ELBPLGbW'+
'wQT@W@S[v@aABDLO4dH%1>?@JB?B4Gb1?]^>v@MJBCLGF%1B]AVvESodHK?EF_@3G}w>FMBEMECMEt'+
'Z>>HSndH%I?EF`zCBP|}XSt@a>BX>CaB`M>R>>>YMBREAo3duH?J6o4d~EPFiu`]@FP|bFDVREVN]N'+
'[>CEa[aAIV>`CAo6dEK?Cl?E7G}YF9GE%BHWG>K>BRMCF?DHBDDHBN@HBI{LJ@C3o7eKIRi>K?B@?@'+
'MB?S>?CATSCMAEV@?V2o8eKIR6O6y(",E%H4&O7y(",bHCF3&O8y(",>%H4&&&#;Ø=Kxt3r@6X>8_'+
'J1ZA3TJ6VA8>>@PM2D{5HM7F@L0ES2C@L5BS7zBU>JG>x>>>3a>6a>8rA1rA3_A6_A8T[M3>M5DM7P'+
'S0FS2HS5CS7EMU@JG@x>M3PM6PM8HS1HS3ES6ES8BS?T3>T5DT7PBA0FBA2HBA5CBA7ETU@LGBx?M3'+
'Hz6DM8E@J1FS3B@J6CS8>zPT2DBB5HT7FBL0EBA2CBL5BBA7{BU>LGu1PM3FM6HM8CS1ES3@S6BS8?'+
'MDT2HT5FT7EBA0CBA2BBA5{A7>TU?LGE%1a>3Z>6r>8VA1_A3MA6TA8tDM2HM5FM7ES0CS2BS5@S7>'+
'MU?JGF%1^>2L>>4^@5s7^>8jA0lA1jA3lA5lA6l>U`|H%1fB2N>>4f@6kB7f>9kJ0gL2kA3gJ5gA6g'+
'>UR|D%1`>>2`>>4N>>6L>>7L>>9fA1^A2^A4kA5jA6sUY|P%^Al>4s6`>>9lA1Lv4`v6^hL>>UsJ]5'+
'I]9Qc4Rc9NIG1bL>>5^>9jA4lh`|1>%f>5k>9gA4R>hN|1@%1Y]6`c1Lc6[>UW]@a5?a9DPA4FPhCW'+
'G1~kAR>>4g>6N>>9Rv1fA4Nv6khf>Ug>[>4W]9Yc4`c9LIG1uNvg>5f>6Rv0kA1Nv6fhR>>21k>L]5'+
'[>9Wc4Yc9`IG1E%IB6P7ALE8WB6N5`B5HI@6P7AJE8W@6N5`@57G1F%1FX2>X2BX7Dm0Fm0Pm1@m7?'+
'X2@V9CCA0PCA2PC2G1Hx?X2@X2CX7HX7PX9Cm0?m1Dm2PDJ6DDJ7>X8?CD9>CL2>CL2DCA3>NG1D%1'+
'3N>N4kN4g`5`>N8^W9gA3`?L4I?L4W?N5`?L8J?Q3FPJ4?PJ5?PL5EPJ8BPY3Hm4?m5>DJ5Em8CDR8'+
'EH`8FFN8HEL8DC2G1Pxg>3g>4R>>5lA6Lv7s3Q]4R]5Y]4Fa5HWqb2s3s4l>5gA6Nv8k>3W]4Y]5Q]'+
'4Ha5DWq>xQc6Lc7W]3Da4FX5HQq@xWc6Nc8I]3Pa4HX5DQq~19Qc9DPhDDhDHhDFhDEhDChDBhDJqu'+
'19mqE%Uf@U`>@UJ?@U`?@Uf@U`>@UCXUBP3qF%U@PEUBH3qH%UNIqD%UNAqP%UBQG3bUEQ&&';

K = 126;  // Key pos (char) counting down.
('B%?KAG@B@@p"%2_>>AC%]>j>H>G2e%O2O1DAY>I>W>6GA9Q>J>:K:%?A?%P>E1E>A>?>A?F>H1D>P'+
'1C>20B>@AF1D19,&GC1@>B1%?@1?17,&,6,5,8,4,3,>12,0,1,').match(/.{2}/g).forEach(
    function (v) {
        X = X[u](String.fromCharCode(K--))[U](v);
        if (K === 92)
            K = 91;
    }
);

/*
* Initially JSON, but got lost in compression work + a somewhat bad design
* on the obj. to begin with. Is eval, at least for now.
*
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
try {
    eval(X
    [u]('*')[U]('f')
    [u](')')[U]('d')
    [u]('(')[U]('b')
    [u]('&')[U](']')
    [u]('%')[U]('[')
    [u]('#')[U]('}')
    [u]('!')[U]('{')
    );
} catch (e) {
    console.warn(e);
}


// Scaling function
function z(a) {
    return a.slice().map(
        function (v) {
            return v * Z;
        }
    );
}
// Tile painter "normal tiles"
function e(k, d, i) {
    for (s[Y] = k, i = 0; i < d[L];)
        s.rect.apply(s, z(d.slice(i, i += 4)));
}
// 
function _(d, i, q) {
    S.width = R;
    for (i = 0; i < d[L]; ++i) {
        s.beginPath();
        F[q=d[++i][0]] ? F[q](d[i]) : e(f[d[i-1]],d[i]);
        s.fill();
    }
}
F = {
    $ : function (d) {  // Expand a tile (e.g. add border on top
                        // of "normal" bricks as with the "in-air".
        _(Å[d[1]].concat(d.slice(2)));
    },
    b : function (d) {  // Replace colors. (Used for bushes.)
        _(Å[d[1]].slice().map(
            function(i,x){
                return(x = d[2].indexOf(i)) > -1 ? d[2][++x] : i;
            }
        ));
    },
    f : function (d, i) { // Free-paint (fill). E.g. "hill-sides"
        s[Y] = f[d[1]];
        s.moveTo.apply(s, z(d[2]));
        for (i = 3; i < d[L]; ++i)
            s.lineTo.apply(s, z(d[i]));
    },
    d : function (d, x, y, g) { // Diagonal lines.
        s[Y] = f[d[1]];
        g = d[2] * Z;
        y = g > 0 ? 0 : 15 * Z;
        for (x = 0; x < 16 * Z; x += Z, y += g)
            s.rect(x, y, Z, Z);
    }
};
// Main function.
function xMx(h, k, i, j, t) {
    Z = h || 1;
    R = 16 * Z;
    D = document;
    C = D.getElementById('m');              // Doc canvas
    c = C.getContext('2d');
    S = D.createElement('CANVAS');          // Memory canvas
    s = S.getContext('2d');

    C.width  = 3392 * Z;
    C.height =  224 * Z;
    c[Y] = '#5c94fc';
    c.rect.apply(c, z([0, 0, 3392, 224]));  // Blue sky (rest is tiles)
    c.fill();

    for (k = 0; k < Ø[L]; ++k) { // Loop coordinate array. This has fixed
        _(Å[Ø[k]]);              // order.
        t = Ø[++k];
        for (i = 0; i < t[L]; i += 3) {
            for (j = 0; j < t[i+2] * R; j += R)
                c.drawImage(S, t[i] * R + j, t[i+1] * R); // Apply tile.
        }
    }
}

xMx(); // Load main.
```

Comment: woah, That's great! +1 for the nice presentation in the provided link. +1 for the homemade packer. If only you could avoid using non-ASCII chars (like Å,Ø), you could use tools like http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/ to compress (much) more, because the score is counted in chars.

Comment: You don't need to use `var` to declare variables; they are automatically declared when you define them, so you should be able to remove `var D,C,c,S,s,R,F,Z,` from your code. (also you can replace `/.{2}/` with `/../`.)

Comment: @hsl: Yes, thank you. I thought of doing the removal of `var` but left it as I had to run when I posted it. Done now. The RegExp was a nice one, somehow did not manage to see that ;)

Comment: @xem: Thank you. There is no problem using the Unicode trick with ÆØÅ as those are within the first set (0x80+0xNN) where 0xNN is the *interesting* part. I was not sure, however, if that was *"legal"* as it depends on how one view it. A code point above 0x7f has a length of 2. As such the code would be equal in length (+1 byte if odd - or, actually longer by 45 bytes due to the `ev(a|i)l` routine). If it is *"legal"* then OK.

Comment: You're right, those chars are okay: ````eval(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))````works as intended. And yes, your score is counted in characters so you can totally use tricks like Unicode compression and eval.You could have a score near 1750 with that!

Answer (score 5):

## Python <del>1331</del> <del>1326</del> <del>1314</del> <del>1272</del> <del>1268</del> 1217 bytes

### (code: <del>219</del> <del>214</del> <del>202</del> <del>186</del> 182, data: <del>362+750=1112</del> <del>363+723=1086</del> 346+689=1035)

The idea here is that I first generate a map one 16th the size in each dimension, where each pixel is colored by the index in the tile map. To ensure that the same pallette was used, I first combined the given tile map and the map into a single image. From this and the tile map (both minified pngs) we can now regenerate the original map. (The code for this process can be seen below the submission code). It should be noted that I saved the tile map as a file "t" and the generated map as an image "m"

EDIT: I started exploring how the ordering of the tiles influenced the compression, and for the sake of exploration I generated 10000 random permutations and compressed them with this result: [image: result]
This was all with the tiles in one line, as that reduced the code quite a bit. I tried similar things with different configurations (2*16, 4*8), but none with a better average result.

Assuming that png would compress better with greater continuous similar regions, I built a tool that would let me move the tiles around, and using what I perceived to be a more continuous image I got the tile image down to 723 from 750b.

EDIT2: Afte rmuch (much) more analysis on how png actually works, and a lot of experimenting (still ongoing), the images have now been compressed even further. Link below updated. I'll write more about this analysis later when it is complete.

New images used are here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gofpw.jpg

Here are the other images generated in the process: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s1GD.jpg, though some are a bit outdated because of above edit.

```
import PIL.Image as I
O=I.open
t=O("t")
m=O("m").load()
o=I.new("RGB",(3392,224))
s=16
for i in range(2968):y=i/212;x=i%212;v=s*m[x,y];o.paste(t.crop((v,0,v+s,s)),(x*s,y*s))
o.show()
```

The script I wrote to reduce the map is pretty crude, but here goes (also might be outdated because of changes above):

```
from PIL import Image

blockSize = 16
combined = Image.open("combined.png")
tileImage = combined.crop((0,224,256,224+32))
w,h = tileImage.size

tiles = []
for y in range(0,h,16):
    for x in range(0,w,16):
        tiles+=[list(tileImage.crop((x,y,x+blockSize,y+blockSize)).getdata())]

referenceImage = combined.crop((0,0,3392,224))
w,h = referenceImage.size

mapImage = Image.new("RGB", (w/blockSize, h/blockSize))

colorScale = 256/len(tiles)

for y in range(0,h,16):
    for x in range(0,w,16):
        i = tiles.index(list(referenceImage.crop((x,y,x+blockSize,y+blockSize)).getdata()))
        mapImage.putpixel((x/16,y/16),(i*colorScale,i*colorScale,i*colorScale))

mapImage.save("map.png")
```

Comment: Wow, that's really impressive. And it's even more impressive when we see that you count in bytes and not chars. Congrats!

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 5 + PNG: 689 + 593 = 1282

A failed attempt to replace PNG compressed tile map from Christian's solution with Perl code. In the end it is 65 bytes longer. Takes [the same PNG tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxmZE.png) on input and generates a PNG on the output.

Usage: `perl mario.pl <tiles.png >world.png`

```
eval'+s/\d+(<?)(.+?)\1/$2x$&/ge'x2?$x|=$_:
map{/A/&&y'{}['Y';push@l,split"";y/D-IMNOY[|_@-_/EF@EE}JKLY~__@/;
s'@Y'YY'g;s'y@'yy'g;s'@E'DE'g;s'E@'EG'g}($x)x$_
for@z=qw(256@ 1
4<19@MNO14@MNNO8@<6@I 1
5<8@MNO16@M3NO16@< 2
22@X57@8T3@3TX14@X11@3T4@TXXT56@YY 3
203@3U 1
16@X3@TXTXT21@[|9@[|18@TXT14@T5@T5@X2@X2@X5@T10@2T6@Y2@y10@YY2@y12@TTXT31@QPS 1
5<2@H45@< 38@[|162@U3VU 1
5<17@H30@< 28@[|133@[|14@[|21@PPWPP 1
4<11@A3BC7@ABC15@ABBC3@<10@PPRPPC48@2<69Z2@15Z3@64Z2@101Z< 1);
$p=GD::Image;use GD;$f=new$p(3392,224);$k=newFromPng$p('-');
copy$f($k,map$_*16,$i%256,$i++>>8,31&ord,0,1,1)for@l;print$f->png
```

Answer (score 1):

## JS: <s>4012</s> 3921 chars

JS is used to unpack many Unicode characters and write an img tag which src is the image given in the OP, saved as PNG, compressed, encoded in base64 and trimmed.

```
document.write(unescape(escape('').replace(/uD./g,'')))
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/fojidejoco/1/

PS: I know it's a little bit cheating (even if the rules allow it), but at least, it gives us a goal: do it in less than 4012 chars.

Tools used:

- https://tinypng.com/
- http://xem.github.io/miniURI/
- http://xem.github.io/obfuscatweet/

Comment: I know that this is a non-optimal solution, but why have you answered your own question so soon?

Comment: An additional option would be to use a [sprite sheet](http://i.imgur.com/NXJ3r34.gif) and an array of where the sprites go. o_O

Comment: @BetaDecay to get rid of this "hardcoded" approach asap and let people do something more creative, like, use a sprite sheet and an array. :p

Comment: Counting unicode characters as 'chars', seems little unreasonable. How many bytes is that uncoded into UTF-8?

If we are taking a char to be a single displayed unicode character, you can make arbitarily large unicode characters.

Comment: I disagree. There is a limited number of possible Unicode characters (U+0000 to U+10FFFF). whichever encoding you use (utf-8, 16, 32, ...) a character stays a character. Only the size in bytes varies.

Comment: And I would disagree with that. It's pretty easy to encode binary data as Unicode via simple methods, and thus we'll all end up writing uninteresting extra code in order to pretend binary data is really Unicode. That is the opposite of being creative in my opinion.

Comment: You can indeed encode up to 20 bits per Unicode character, and for this exact reason, I think it can lead to interesting and creative approaches.

Comment: Then the task really becomes two unrelated tasks - Encode the image data as small as possible, then convert the compressed data to as few Unicode characters as possible. I think the second task hinders being creative on the first, and would be better off as it's own challenge.