# Golf Your Favorite Minecraft Tool

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, kolmogorov-complexity, game

In [Minecraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft), the [default item textures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbk6q.png) are all reasonably simple 16×16 pixel images, which makes them seem ideal for [golfing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf).

Below are simplified textures of the five "core" diamond tools in Minecraft: [pickaxe](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Pickaxe), [shovel](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Shovel), [axe](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Axe), [sword](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Sword), and [hoe](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Hoe).

**The images shown are enlarged to show their detail. Click on an image to view its correctly sized 16×16 pixel version.**

[image: pickaxe] [image: shovel] [image: axe] [image: sword] [image: hoe]

To make golfing easier, I've modified each of them from [the originals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOWJm.png) to only use the five same 24-bit RGB colors:

- `R=75 G=82 B=73` for the background.
- `R=51 G=235 B=203` for the diamond tool heads.
- `R=14 G=63 B=54` for the diamond outlines.
- `R=137 G=103 B=39` for the wooden handle core.
- `R=40 G=30 B=11` for the wooden handle outlines.

Choose your favorite tool out of the five and write a program that outputs its simplified 16×16 pixel texture in any common lossless truecolor image format (such as `bpm`, `png`, `ppm`, etc.).

So, for example, if you chose the axe, you would write a program that outputs this image: [image: axe example]

No input should be taken and a web connection should not be required. The image can be output as a file with the name of your choice, or the raw image file data can be output to stdout, or you can simply display the image.

You only need to choose *one* of the five images. **The program that outputs any one of the five images in the fewest number of bytes is the winner.**

You may write programs for more than one of the images, but only the one with the minimum number of bytes counts towards your score. If there's a tie, the highest voted post wins.

---

*If you enjoy [PPCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) and play Minecraft, I invite you to come join our trial Minecraft server. Just ask in [the dedicated chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24544/ppcg-minecraft-server).*

Comment: "Enlarged to show detail." I can only think of cereal boxes.

Comment: I think there may be some compression issues or you have some typos in the colours. Mathematica claims, these five colours are used (at least for the shovel): `[[76 82 73] [26 63 54] [106 234 204] [39 30 13] [133 102 45]]`

Comment: Similar: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39915/pixel-art-episode-1-display-super-mario

Comment: @MartinBüttner Are you sure? I re-downloaded the [shovel image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xqFA2.png) and made sure that the 5 colors are correct. I also made sure there were exactly 5 colors. imgur may be compressing the enlarged images but those are not the ones you should be using.

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies Is input allowed?

Comment: @user41805 [Input is never allowed if it isn't explicitly mentioned in the challenge.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1789/94066)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 119 bytes

```
'P3NGSGN255N]o67T"…vîþáy$<OW¥ÓNZ"256b9b~99T]2/e~W%"LRI?6jêÌ'
…f-":i3/f=F,_W%:)+{)/(\:~}%{G/({)S*S+oNo}%1>\:~+}G*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/Xz3A2M892N3PyNTULzbfzDxE6VBr2eF1h/cdXijEwlypYuMffmjp4cn8h@b6RSkZmZolWSbVWVqGxBrpp9aFqyr5BHlK2ZtlHV51uEddjutQa5quklWmsX6arZtOfLiqlaZ2taa@RoxVXa1qtbu@RrVmsFawdr5ffq2qoR1QVLvWXev/fwA)

I've chosen the shovel.

This program prints a PPM file to STDOUT.

The basic idea is to unroll the image along antidiagonals and then use run-length encoding. With this technique, the shovel contains the fewest runs. For reference the number of runs per image (in the order given in the challenge) is:

```
{60, 26, 38, 43, 37}
```

Comment: This is 129 bytes, not 119.

Comment: @Makonede [I don't think so?](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/Xz3A2M892N3PyNTULzbfzDxE6VBr2eF1h/cdXijEwlypYuMffmjp4cn8h@b6RSkZmZolWSbVWVqGxBrpp9aFqyr5BHlK2ZtlHV51uEddjutQa5quklWmsX6arZtOfLiqlaZ2taa@RoxVXa1qtbu@RrVmsFawdr5ffq2qoR1QVLvWXev/fwA)

Comment: Well, [TIO also claims Pyth uses an SBCS](https://tio.run/#pyth) when in reality it does not. If CJam really does use an SBCS, could you link to it?

Comment: CJam doesn't so much use an SBCS as allow any byte value in the program @Makonede. These are often shown in older CJam answers, such as this, using extended ASCII characters to avoid using unprintable characters.

Answer (score 12):

## Minecraft 18w11a (.mcfunction), 757 bytes

```
fill ~ ~ ~ ~15 ~ ~15 ice
fill ~13 ~ ~13 ~7 ~ ~11 cyan_wool
fill ~12 ~ ~14 ~10 ~ ~8 cyan_wool
fill ~12 ~ ~13 ~10 ~ ~11 diamond_block
fill ~11 ~ ~12 ~9 ~ ~10 diamond_block
fill ~10 ~ ~11 ~8 ~ ~9 diamond_block
fill ~3 ~ ~4 ~1 ~ ~2 dirt
setblock ~3 ~ ~4 oak_planks
setblock ~2 ~ ~3 oak_planks
clone ~3 ~ ~4 ~1 ~ ~2 ~4 ~ ~5
setblock ~4 ~ ~5 oak_planks
setblock ~4 ~ ~7 ice
setblock ~6 ~ ~5 ice
clone ~6 ~ ~5 ~4 ~ ~7 ~7 ~ ~8
setblock ~9 ~ ~10 diamond_block
setblock ~4 ~ ~4 dirt
setblock ~3 ~ ~5 dirt
setblock ~7 ~ ~7 dirt
setblock ~6 ~ ~8 dirt
setblock ~1 ~ ~2 ice
fill ~12 ~ ~9 ~12 ~ ~8 ice
setblock ~11 ~ ~8 ice
fill ~8 ~ ~13 ~7 ~ ~13 ice
setblock ~7 ~ ~12 ice
fill ~ ~ ~ ~15 ~ ~15 light_gray_concrete replace ice
fill ~ ~ ~ ~9 ~ ~10 dark_oak_bark replace dirt
```

Of course someone had to answer the question with Minecraft. Place answer inside of a datapack, and run with `/function <packname>:<filename>`. The shovel is drawn relative to you in the +X and +Z direction. Colors are wrong but I'll count that as a language limitation ;)

But the shovel is actually made out of wood and diamonds!!!!

### Output

[image: Shoveled]

Comment: [Answers in languages that postdate the question no longer need to be marked as non-competing](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges)

Comment: oh hey, that's cool!

Comment: I really like the idea of using `fill ... replace` to save bytes. +1

Comment: You can use TNT or air instead of dirt to save 6 bytes.

Comment: You can save a lot of bytes by using absolute coordinates.

Comment: @xigoi Wow! That's a 76 byte save. Combined with my tip, you save 82 bytes!

Comment: @Makonede air can use `keep` shorter?

Comment: @l4m2 Oh yeah! That saves 7 more bytes. 89 bytes saved so far

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript ES6, 353 bytes

```
document.write(`<p style="width:1px;height:1px;box-shadow:${'931a31b31841940a40b40c41951a51b50c50d51e53f52b61c60d60e62f63c73d70e70f71b83c82d83e81a93b92c939a3aa2ba38b39b2ab37c38c29c36d37d28d35e36e27e34f35f26f34g35g3'.replace(/.../g,e=>(p=parseInt)(e[0],17)+`px ${p(e[1],17)}px 0 #${['33EBCB','0E3F36','896727','281E0B'][e[2]]},`)}9px 9px 0 8px #4B5249"`)
```

This heavily abuses CSS3 [box-shadows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) to create a pixelized version of the image, in this case the Minecraft hoe. The Stack Snippet below uses ES5 for easy testing and is somewhat ungolfed (You'll have to zoom in to see it well).

```js
s='931a31b31841940a40b40c41951a51b50c50d51e53f52b61c60d60e62f63c73d70e70f71b83c82d83e81a93b92c939a3aa2ba38b39b2ab37c38c29c36d37d28d35e36e27e34f35f26f34g35g3'.replace(/.../g,function(e){
  return parseInt(e[0],17)+'px '+parseInt(e[1],17)+'px 0 #'+['33EBCB','0E3F36','896727','281E0B'][e[2]]+','
})
document.write('<p style="width:1px;height:1px;box-shadow:'+s+'9px 9px 0 8px #4B5249"')
```

Comment: Could this be shortened by using base64 encoding instead of hex?

Comment: The largest source image is 297 bytes. Kinda sad to be over that :)

Comment: @JB It's [kolmogorov-complexity] for a reason ;)

Comment: @ThomasKwa Doesn't base64 actually make it longer? (It's actually base-17 because there's `g`s near the end.)

Comment: I don't know how expensive interpreting base64 encoding is in Javascript, but the string literal itself should be 2/3rds the size in base64 as in hex.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>113</s> 97 bytes

*-16 by using RLE (run-length encoding) for the color palette indices.*

```
„P3žvD₅•P{¡æjž²+JGÀ‰íÔñ•Ƶ‡в3ô•N…ý~îc|\мï¶„Ä^€¿^•5в¦•RθÅª`<≠cλS²bÖ"₁Þ@„ÉI¬5øëY4ÀΘØ¥P@û h•29вÅΓè˜»»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AbcASP9vc2FiaWX//@KAnlAzxb52ROKCheKAolB7wqHDpmrFvsKyK0pHw4DigLDDrcOUw7HigKLGteKAodCyM8O04oCiTuKApsO9fsOuY3xc0LzDr8K24oCew4Re4oKswr9e4oCiNdCywqbigKJSzrjDhcKqYDziiaBjzrtTwrJiw5Yi4oKBw55A4oCew4lJwqw1w7jDq1k0w4DOmMOYwqVQQMO7IGjigKIyOdCyw4XOk8Ooy5zCu8K7//8) Beats all other answers. Outputs a plain PPM of a diamond hoe.

**Note:** The first `»` can be a `)` (or a `¶`, `ð`, or `õ`) to output the image data separated by spaces: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AbYASf9vc2FiaWX//@KAnlAzxb52ROKCheKAolB7wqHDpmrFvsKyK0pHw4DigLDDrcOUw7HigKLGteKAodCyM8O04oCiTuKApsO9fsOuY3xc0LzDr8K24oCew4Re4oKswr9e4oCiNdCywqbigKJSzrjDhcKqYDziiaBjzrtTwrJiw5Yi4oKBw55A4oCew4lJwqw1w7jDq1k0w4DOmMOYwqVQQMO7IGjigKIyOdCyw4XOk8Ooy5wpwrv//w) However, in the [official PPM Format Specification](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html), under [*Plain PPM*](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html#plainppm), it states:

> - No line should be longer than 70 characters.

It still renders properly, but is not recommended.

The first `»` can also be a `` ` `` with no change in functionality: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AbYASf9vc2FiaWX//@KAnlAzxb52ROKCheKAolB7wqHDpmrFvsKyK0pHw4DigLDDrcOUw7HigKLGteKAodCyM8O04oCiTuKApsO9fsOuY3xc0LzDr8K24oCew4Re4oKswr9e4oCiNdCywqbigKJSzrjDhcKqYDziiaBjzrtTwrJiw5Yi4oKBw55A4oCew4lJwqw1w7jDq1k0w4DOmMOYwqVQQMO7IGjigKIyOdCyw4XOk8Ooy5xgwrv//w)

#### Pure GIF compression, <s>109</s> 107 bytes

```
•+Ùι1Ù³œ¤∞4ûи„ĆQ´ηÏzεÝ₅¼úΣ¨ü6Ó…Ï,È–ð:<û∞¢Þ§α»«¥<çp:Ù“ζÞ¢ó‡lÿнδßiÌ$}ªiƒ*₅xΛxJ=yh‹×м’’®']!JÍ¦Z¹JQc›Vàÿ¸Ìм•h2ô
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxPS8JwGMdfSyAE2sWQDmJvYDcvHoIOGoKDoKCLCsKDUHhQBHeIkU5dpaEgyuafuYXwfMvjj72G543Mef78eXoplvRyFAnZKZjKS8Nk59/gL2lZGfjhTsj6e8uzq7bo1tUaA2m@coC9@uQfBDcwhCboXqElZGCZzcGPS7Zh8VSt2Oc5f@cwfc7CFOqrDc7MERo/4hD@KhdDHe1Eg2f6sZeM11X1UdVuaxUhD@9hIBRnJi8u7y80dHhyx56WfxDaFzDCgXdonx27cg03ik4) Outputs as a list of hexadecimal codepoints.

```
•...•h2ô  # trimmed program
•...•     # 121686424391392225557581524495943776461362082974476220323034665137613008241067075561955081975776948192923502794622971144661356950543760600319115998403445050769039958830830234731371315671091547736084642764295720991029129326629299863698388004372539...
     h    # in hexadecimal...
       ô  # split into pieces of length...
      2   # literal
          # implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## Node.JS using [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp), <s>393</s> <s>377</s> 376 bytes

377, 376 thanks to [Makonede](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51556/golf-your-favorite-minecraft-tool#comment516210_222504)

```javascript
new(require('jimp'))(16,16,1263684095,(e,i)=>{i.z=i.setPixelColor;i.z(x=673057791,2,12);i.z(x,4,14);i.z(d=871091199,13,3);for(j=0;j<8;j++){i.z(w=2305239039,3+j,13-j);i.z(x,2+j,13-j);i.z(x,3+j,14-j)}for(j=0;j<3;j++){i.z(e=239023871,11+j,2);i.z(e,14,3+j);i.z(e,8+j,5-j);i.z(d,9+j,5-j);i.z(d,10+j,5-j);i.z(d,10+j,6-j);i.z(d,11+j,6-j);i.z(d,11+j,7-j);i.z(e,11+j,8-j)}i.write('')})
```

I'm not sure if this one is allowed as it uses a separate library for processing the image.

Uses hex colors in decimal, sets `i.s` to `i.setPixelColor` to save bytes, sets color variables as it's first used

Comment: as long as the question does not disallow libraries, and the library is explicitly stated, it is fine.

Comment: However, it is a good idea to tell us which tool you've made.

Comment: -49 by removing some semicolons, using an empty file name, using `s` instead of `i.s`, and only assigning variables when first needed: `new(require('jimp'))(16,16,1263684095,(e,i)=>{(s=i.setPixelColor)(x=673057791,2,12);s(x,4,14);s(d=871091199,13,3);for(j=0;j<8;j++){s(w=2305239039,3+j,13-j);s(x,2+j,13-j);s(x,3+j,14-j)}for(j=0;j<3;j++){s(e=239023871,11+j,2);s(e,14,3+j);s(e,8+j,5-j);s(d,9+j,5-j);s(d,10+j,5-j);s(d,10+j,6-j);s(d,11+j,6-j);s(d,11+j,7-j);s(e,11+j,8-j)}i.write('')})`.

Comment: @Makonede that's actually really clever assigning variables like that. however i tried using `s` instead of `i.s` and jimp threw an error for `this` being `undefined`.

Comment: actually it seems it's if it's `s` not `i.s` or if it's using the assignment in the use or both

Comment: also a blank filename shouldn't/doesn't work, however single letter names work, and `.png` with no name

Comment: @mekb While it is true that most operating systems don't support blank filenames, it's OK to assume that a blank filename should work, so it's allowed. :)

Comment: ah okay ;;;;;;;

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 483 bytes

I chose to make the sword

```
from PIL import Image as IG, ImageColor as IC
s=IG.new('RGB',(16,16))
w='#6b6727'
b='#4b5249'
d='#33ebcb'
a='#0e3f36'
n='#281e0b'
t=b*13+a*3+b*12+a+d*2+a+b*11+a+d*3+a+b*10+a+d*3+a+b+b*9+a+d*3+a+b*2+b*8+a+d*3+a+b*3+b*2+a*2+b*3+a+d*3+a+b*4+b*2+a+d+a+b+a+d*3+a+b*5+b*3+a+d+a+d*3+a+b*6+b*3+a+d+a+d*2+a+b*7+b*4+a+d+a*2+b*8+b*3+n+w+a+d*2+a+b*7+b*2+n+w+n+b+a*2+d+a+b*6+a*2+w+n+b*4+a*2+b*6+a+d+a+b*13+a*3+b*13
s.putdata([IC.getrgb(t[i:i+7]) for i in range(0,len(t),7)])
s.save('s.png','PNG')
```

here is the output:
[image]

I created a string for each color, and combined them to get a string of hexadecimal numbers. Then I used the python image library to convert that string into an image.

Comment: You can save 5 bytes by replacing `'s.png'` with `''`. It assumes that the system the program is being run on allows empty file names. This does not apply to any popular OS (AFAIK) but it's OK to make assumptions here.

Comment: Actually, you can save 7 bytes by using `s.save('.png')`. The `format` argument isn't necessary if a corresponding extension is given, and `s.save('.png')` is 2 bytes shorter than `s.save('','PNG')`.

Comment: You can save another 9 on top of that by changing `Image as IG, ImageColor as IC` to `Image,ImageColor as c`, changing `IG` to `Image`, changing `IC` to `c`, removing the space between `(t[i:i+7])` and `for`, and replacing `len(t)` with `1792` (the guaranteed length of `t`).

Comment: And yet another 18 saved by 1. fixing some inefficiencies in the definition of `t` (for example, `b+b*9` -> `b*10`), 2. making `t` a tuple instead of a string, 3. not using a variable (this method uses `t` only once) and 4. using all that to allow for a much shorter `putdata` method: `s.putdata(map(c.getrgb,[*[b]*13,a,a,a,*[b]*12,a,d,d,a,*[b]*11,a,d,d,d,a,*[*[b]*10,a,d,d,d,a]*2,*[b]*5,a,a,b,b,b,a,d,d,d,a,*[b]*6,a,d,a,b,a,d,d,d,a,*[b]*8,a,d,a,d,d,d,a,*[b]*9,a,d,a,d,d,a,*[b]*11,a,d,a,a,*[b]*11,n,w,a,d,d,a,*[b]*9,n,w,n,b,a,a,d,a,*[b]*6,a,a,w,n,*[b]*4,a,a,*[b]*6,a,d,a,*[b]*13,a,a,a,*[b]*13]))`.

Comment: (continued from previous comment because of length limitations) A total of 34 bytes saved!

Comment: Actually, `s.save('')` should work instead of `s.save('.png')`, saving you another 4 for a total of 38 bytes saved so far.

Comment: You can save **yet another** 10 by using `import PIL`. Current saved bytes: 48! Also, [here's](https://pastebin.com/pgLnsNra) a pastebin with all of my golfs so far applied.

Comment: -15 more by using Python 3.8's walrus operator and decimal color values: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/293XKpzE)

Comment: -39 more with a ton more `*`s and a ton more `:=`s. Saved 102 bytes so far!! [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/LEdjjh0q)

Comment: -3 more with a few less `*`s and a few more `+`s. Current saved bytes: 105. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/UZXgg3Fa)

Comment: -2 more by `show`ing the image instead of `save`ing it. Current saved bytes: 107. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/wJUApRvW)

Comment: -2 more by using a few more `*`s and `:=`s. Current saved bytes: 109. [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/c9193ZUe)

Answer (score 1):

## [GIF](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt), 102 bytes

Hexdump:

```sh
00000000: 4749 4638 3961 1000 1000 7000 002c 0000  GIF89a....p..,..
00000010: 0000 1000 1000 824b 5249 0e3f 3633 ebcb  .......KRI.?63..
00000020: 281e 0b89 6727 0000 0000 0000 0000 0003  (...g'..........
00000030: 3308 babc f12d 8220 4490 8cd6 8b67 b59d  3....-. D....g..
00000040: b785 1a98 71a2 9981 25da 506d 078f a4e5  ....q...%.Pm....
00000050: 4a03 a1dd 4c3e 4cb0 c883 f073 f082 21c5  J...L>L....s..!.
00000060: 8327 4900 003b                           .'I..;
```

Renders as:

[image: Diamond Sword]