# A Skittish Program

Tags: code-golf, file-system

## Objective

You are to write a program that receives an integer `n` as input (from the command line), and embeds itself (the program) `n` directories down the directory tree. Example with `n=5`:

[image: Example with n = 5]

The folder names may be whatever you wish. The only requirements are that the depth is correct, and that the program can then be ran again from its new spot in the directory tree, and that the new source file retains the same filename.

### Bonuses:

- **Score * 0.9** If the directories all have a different name (must be true at least to depth 1 000 000)
- **Score * 0.5** If you do not **directly or indirectly** read or move the source file, or access the source code of the program

Comment: What counts as "*reading the source*"? You mean the file? Or the real source code?

Comment: The file. Will clarify in post @GiantTree

Comment: @globby What do you mean by 'do not read the source file of the program'?

Comment: Copying the exact source into the directory, without explicitly reading the file that your source code is in. Basically make a quine that drops itself into another directory. Sorry if I'm not explaining it well

Comment: @globby So execution of the CMD command `move` does not count as reading the source file?

Comment: @unclemeat It does, because to move the file you (or the system) has to access the data in the file.

Comment: Seems like you are just trying to hide your porn stash.

Comment: I'm not paying enough attention to tell; is the [quine] tag appropriate?

Comment: @globby how about the `ln` command in *nix? If I'm not mistaken, it's just creating another entry to the file inode, and no content is read at all.

Comment: Seriously don't need to write a quine this late...

Comment: @globby As far as I'm aware, moving a file does not read the contents, unless you're moving between hard drives or partitions. It's basically just changing some pointers in the file system.

Comment: @MartinBüttner fair. Updated the original post.

Comment: Unique names up to depth 1 000 000? If I see code which promises to do that, but looks like the cat danced on the keyboard, I would never dare test it on my computer. Not with an input above 10, anyway.

Comment: The logic just needs to work up to depth 1000000. You can modify the code to print the directory names instead of making them, or work out the logic on paper.

Comment: A _million_ nested subfolders? Hey man, some of us use Windows!

Comment: @MarkReed Look a few comments up

Answer (score 36):

## Bash, 30*0.9*0.5 = 13.5

```
mkdir -p `seq -s/ $1`;ln $0 $_
```

Takes depth as the first argument. Creates a hard link to itself into the following directory structure:

```
1/2/3/4/5/.../n
```

The script may then be run from the new location, even if `rm` is run on the old script.

**Explanation:**

`seq -s/ $1` outputs the numbers from 1 to `$1` (the first argument), separated by a forward slash.

`` mkdir -p `seq -s` $1 `` creates the directory specified by `seq`, with `-p` creating all intermediate directories.

`ln $0 $_` create a hard link to the current running script in the newly created directory.

**Old (30 * 0.9 = 27):**

```
mkdir -p `seq -s/ $1`;cp $0 $_
```

**Example run (with ln):**

```
$ ls -lGR
.:
total 1
-rwx------+ 1 ducks 41 Jan  5 15:00 test.sh

$ ./test.sh 4

$ ls -lgR
.:
total 1
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 ducks  0 Jan  5 15:01 1
-rwx------+ 2 ducks 41 Jan  5 15:00 test.sh

./1:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 ducks 0 Jan  5 15:01 2

./1/2:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 ducks 0 Jan  5 15:01 3

./1/2/3:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 ducks 0 Jan  5 15:01 4

./1/2/3/4:
total 1
-rwx------+ 2 ducks 41 Jan  5 15:00 test.sh

$ rm ./test.sh

$ ls -lg
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 ducks 0 Jan  5 15:01 1

$ ls -lg 1/2/3/4
total 1
-rwx------+ 1 ducks 41 Jan  5 15:00 test.sh
```

Thanks to @DigitalTrauma for suggestion to replace `$(..)` with `` `..` ``

Thanks to @h.j.k. for suggestion to use `ln`.

Comment: Brilliant use of `$_`!

Comment: Save a char - use backticks instead of `$( )`: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25572/11259

Comment: Depending on the answer to my comment on the [question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/43201/a-skittish-program#comment102352_43201), maybe replace `cp` with `ln` to get the 0.5 bonus too...

Comment: Wells, there's the update from the OP now, and `mv` is also restricted from that 0.5 bonus. That still leaves `ln` in the clear, yes?

Comment: Yes, `ln` (you don't need `-s`) would actually place the program in the new directory, so that it can be executed from there, without ever reading, moving, or accessing its original source. I say go for the FALCON PUNCH score of 13.5!

Answer (score 12):

## C, 225 * 0.9 * 0.5 = 101.25

My solution in C:

```
$ cat d.c
#define R(x)#x
#define T(x)R(x)
#define S(p)b[9];main(i,v)char**v;{for(i=atoi(v[1]);i--;sprintf(b,"%i",i),mkdir(b),chdir(b));fputs("#define R(x)#x\n#define T(x)R(x)\n#define S(p)"p"\nS(T(S(p)))",fopen("d.c","w"));}
S(T(S(p)))
```

Here in a somewhat more readable form:

```
#define R(x) #x
#define T(x) R(x)
#define S(p) char b[9];\
             main(int i,char**v) { \
                for(i=atoi(v[1]); i--; sprintf(b,"%i",i), \
                                       mkdir(b), \
                                       chdir(b)); \
                fputs("#define R(x) #x\n" \
                      "#define T(x) R(x)\n" \
                      "#define S(p) " p "\n" \
                      "S(T(S(p)))", \
                      fopen("d.c", "w")); \
             }
S(T(S(p)))
```

The check if it works:

```
$ gcc -o d d.c
# a lot of warning and notes from gcc ... 
$ ./d 10
$ diff -s d.c 9/8/7/6/5/4/3/2/1/0/d.c
Files d.c and 9/8/7/6/5/4/3/2/1/0/d.c are identical
```

There most probably is a lot of golfing potential in the source code.

Comment: Great use of the preprocessor!

Answer (score 5):

## Zsh, <s>63</s> <s>60</s> <s>58</s> 52 * 0.9 = <s>56.7</s> <s>54</s> <s>52.2</s> 46.8

```
s=$(<$0);for i in {1..$1};{mkdir $i;cd $i};echo $s>f
```

Example:

```
llama@llama:...Code/misc/foo$ zsh f 5
llama@llama:...Code/misc/foo$ ls -R
.:
d1  f

./d1:
d2

./d1/d2:
d3

./d1/d2/d3:
d4

./d1/d2/d3/d4:
d5

./d1/d2/d3/d4/d5:
f
llama@llama:...Code/misc/foo$ cat d1/d2/d3/d4/d5/f 
s=$(cat $0);for i in {1..$1};do;mkdir d$i;cd d$i;done;echo $s>f
llama@llama:...Code/misc/foo$ cat f
s=$(cat $0);for i in {1..$1};do;mkdir d$i;cd d$i;done;echo $s>f
llama@llama:...Code/misc/foo$ diff f d1/d2/d3/d4/d5/f
llama@llama:...Code/misc/foo$
```

Comment: [UUOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) `s=$(<$0)` (Just for the record, it fails for me with `bash` 4.3.11: “syntax error near unexpected token \`;'”. But works fine with `zsh` 5.0.2)

Comment: Could you save a character by removing the `d` before `$i`?

Comment: @CanadianLuke Huh, I never knew you could have a directory named `1`. Thanks

Comment: I think you should be able to use curly brackets: `for i in {1..$1};{mkdir $i;cd $i};echo $s>f`.

Comment: @U2744SNOWFLAKE Thanks, that saved a few bytes. Edited.

Answer (score 5):

### Batch - 48 * 0.9 = 43.2

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,%1)do md %%a&cd %%a&move..\%0
```

This script simply creates a new directory, and moves the source file to it - `n` times.

```
H:\MyDocuments\uprof\top>embed.bat 5

     ...

H:\MyDocuments\uprof\top>tree /f
Folder PATH listing for volume DATA009_HOMES
Volume serial number is B88B-384C
H:.
└───1
    └───2
        └───3
            └───4
                └───5
                        embed.bat
```

Answer (score 3):

## Rebol - 114 * 0.9 * 0.5 = 51.3

```
do b:[d: copy %./ repeat n do input[mkdir repend d[n"/"]]write join d s: system/options/script join"do b: "mold b]
```

Ungolfed:

```
do b: [
    d: copy %./
    repeat n do input [
        mkdir repend d [n "/"]
    ]
    write join d s: system/options/script join "do b: " mold b
]
```

#### Original non-quine version - 90 * 0.9 = 81

```
d: %./ repeat n do input[mkdir repend d[n"/"]write join d s: system/options/script read s]
```

Ungolfed:

```
d: %./
repeat n do input [
    mkdir repend d [n "/"]
]
write join d s: system/options/script read s
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bash 167*0.5*0.9 = 75.15

Borrowing heavily from [@es1024's great answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/43205/11259), but this one is a true quine, so it qualifies for both bonuses.

```
b=\' c=\\ a='d=`seq -s/ $1`;mkdir -p $d;echo b=$c$b c=$c$c a=$b$a$b>>$d/$0;echo $a>>$d/$0'
d=`seq -s/ $1`;mkdir -p $d;echo b=$c$b c=$c$c a=$b$a$b>>$d/$0;echo $a>>$d/$0
```

Also, shell quine techniques from [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?QuineProgram).

Answer (score 1):

## AutoIt3, 106 * 0,9 = 95,4 bytes

---

A bit long but I can't help with those long function/variable names:

```
$f = @WorkingDir
For $i = 1 To $CmdLine[1]
    $f &= "\" & $i
Next
DirCreate($f)
FileCopy(@ScriptFullPath, $f)
```

Simply call it with `<script/.exe name> <depth>` eg. `script.exe 5`.
It will work for any amount of directories; maybe even more than your file system can handle. :D

### How it works:

It's just a simple loop that adds the index to a string. Then the directory (and all parent directories, too) get created and the file copies itself to that directory.

Answer (score 1):

## Node.js, <s>136</s> 133 * 0.9 * 0.5 = <s>61.2</s> 59.85

```
r=require,f=r('fs'),p=__dirname;while(i=process.argv[2]--)f.mkdirSync(p+='/'+i);f.linkSync(a=__filename,p+'/'+r('path').basename(a))
```

`fs.linkSync` maps to the POSIX call [link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/link.html), which creates a hard link. An invalid argument will cause the program to crash.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 82 * 0.9 = 73.8

This is mostly a port of the top-voted answer.

```
exit (1!:1[1{A) 1!:2 <] (s,'/',>1{A)[fpathcreate s=:' /'charsub":1+i.".>{:A=:ARGV
```

Save as `skittish.ijs` or whatever you want, and call it from the command line using your version of `jconsole`. Mine is symlinked to `jc`:

```
$ jc skittish.ijs 20
$ ls 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13/14/15/16/17/18/19/20/skittish.ijs 
1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13/14/15/16/17/18/19/20/skittish.ijs
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 55 * 0.9 * 0.5 = 24.75 bytes

I had my eyes on this challenge for a long time, but I wanted to complete it in Zsh without calling any external programs like `mkdir` and `ln` (otherwise, it would be identical to the bash solution). Turns out, Zsh can provide its own versions of those programs!

```sh
zmodload zsh/files
mkdir -p ${(j:/:):-{1..$1}}
ln $0 $_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcuxDoMgFAXQna@4wxugCaiDTcrPNKY8gxbFiEsxfvvr4HK2U0sUqUsOKQ8BtcRmnBIXtXzDtMNuoFPPvvHG27NzjrrrUmkFtaC3HDsz7KCO38a4R1oVf2IGad33eKB1ty9jRJ5/)