# Translate a Glypho program

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing, syntax

Given an input of any valid [Glypho](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Glypho) program,
output its "human-readable" counterpart.

Glypho is an interesting esolang idea:

> The instruction reference is given here. For each instruction, the characters
>   abcd represent the symbols composing each instruction. a refers to the first
>   unique symbol, b refers to the second unique symbol, etc.
>
> ```
> aaaa ..... n NOP - no operation; do nothing
> aaab ..... i Input - push input onto top of stack
> aaba ..... > Rot - pops top stack element and pushes to bottom of stack
> aabb ..... \ Swap - swaps top two stack elements
> aabc ..... 1 Push - pushes a 1 onto the top of stack (creates new element)
> abaa ..... < RRot - pops bottom element and pushes to top of stack
> abab ..... d Dup - Duplicates top stack element
> abac ..... + Add - pops top two elements and pushes their sum
> abba ..... [ L-brace - skip to matching ] if top stack element is 0
> abbb ..... o Output - pops and outputs top stack element
> abbc ..... * Multiply - pops top two elements and pushes their product
> abca ..... e Execute - Pops four elements and interprets them as an instruction
> abcb ..... - Negate - pops value from stack, pushes -(value)
> abcc ..... ! Pop - pops and discards top stack element
> abcd ..... ] R-brace - skip back to matching [
> ```
>
> <sub>(credit: [Brian Thompson](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brian_Thompson) aka
>   Wildhalcyon)</sub>

So, for example, `PPCG` would represent the *Push* instruction—`PPCG` matches
the pattern `aabc`, where `a` represents `P`, `b` represents `C`, and `c`
represents `G`.

The input will be a single string consisting of only printable ASCII
characters. It will always have a length divisible by four (duh).

The output is each group of four characters in the input string replaced by
which instruction they designate. Use the single-letter instruction names (the
ones right after the five dots in the table quoted above).

Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code in bytes will win.

Test cases:

```
In                                Out
------------------------------------------------
Programming Puzzles & Code Golof  ]!]!]]]+
nananananananana batman!          dddd]]
;;;;;;;:;;:;;;::                  ni>\
llamas sleep                      1-*
8488133190003453                  <[oe
<empty string>                    <empty string>
```

Comment: Ah yes Code Golof. My favorite sporot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>37</s> <s>35</s> 34 bytes

The code contains unprintable characters, so here is the `xxd` hexdump:

```
0000000: 5663 7a34 7040 2e22 216f d78c 40bf d4f0  Vcz4p@."!o..@...
0000010: 38d6 7dfe 7312 3ff8 ea22 6958 4e7b 4e55  8.}.s.?.."iXN{NU
0000020: 5433                                     T3
```

Here's a printable version at 36 bytes:

```
Vcz4p@"ni >\\1   <d+[o*e-!]"iXN{NUT3
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Vcz4p%40.%22!o%C3%97%C2%8C%40%C2%BF%C3%94%C3%B08%C3%96%7D%C3%BEs%12%3F%C3%B8%C3%AA%22iXN%7BNU4%203&input=Programming+Puzzles+%26+Code+Golof&debug=0) [Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Vcz4p%40.%22!o%C3%97%C2%8C%40%C2%BF%C3%94%C3%B08%C3%96%7D%C3%BEs%12%3F%C3%B8%C3%AA%22iXN%7BNU4%203&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=Programming+Puzzles+%26+Code+Golof%0Anananananananana+batman%21%0A%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3A%3B%3B%3A%3B%3B%3B%3A%3A%0Allamas+sleep%0A8488133190003453%0A%0A&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
Vcz4p@."…"iXN{NUT3       implicit: z = input
  z                      input
 c 4                     split to 4-character blocks
V                        loop over that in N
           X               replace...
            N                in current part
             {N              unique chars in current part, in order
               UT            with numbers 0-9
          i      3         interpret as base 3
     @                     take that item of
      ."…"                   string "ni >\\1   <d+[o*e-!]"
    p                      and print without newline
```

Answer (score 4):

### CJam, <s>42</s> <s>39</s> 35 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes borrowing user81655's idea of using base 3 instead of base 4.*

```
l4/{__&f#3b"ni >\1   <d+[o*e-!]"=}%
```

[Run all test cases.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7BS2*%2F0%3D%3AL%3B%0A%0AL4%2F%7B__%26f%233b%22ni%20%3E%5C1%20%20%20%3Cd%2B%5Bo*e-!%5D%22%3D%7D%25%0A%0A%5DoNo%7D%2F&input=aaaaaaabaabaaabbaabcabaaabababacabbaabbbabbcabcaabcbabccabcd%0AProgramming%20Puzzles%20%26%20Code%20Golof%20%20%5D!%5D%5D!%5D%5D%5D%2B%0Anananananananana%20batman!%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dddd%5D%5D%0A%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3A%3B%3B%3A%3B%3B%3B%3A%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ni%3E%5C%0Allamas%20sleep%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201-*%0A8488133190003453%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%5Boe%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)

There's gotta be a better way to compress the lookup table of commands...

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 97

For each block of 4 characters, I substitute each symbol with its position in the block, getting a base 4 number. For instance `'aabc' -> '0023'`. The possibile numbers are in the range 0..0123, that is 0..27 in decimal. I use the number as an index to find the right instruction character from a 28 chars string.

```js
s=>s.replace(/.{4}/g,s=>'n..i....>.\\1....<d.+[o.*e-!]'[[...s].map(c=>n=n*4+s.indexOf(c),n=0),n])
```

**Test**

```js
F=s=>s.replace(/.{4}/g,s=>'n..i....>.\\1....<d.+[o.*e-!]'[[...s].map(c=>n=n*4+s.indexOf(c),n=0),n])

function test() { O.textContent=F(I.value) }

test();
```

```css
#I { width:90% }
```

```html
<input id=I value="nananananananana batman!" oninput="test()">
<br><span id=O></span>
```

Answer (score 4):

## MATLAB, 291 bytes

I hesitated for quite a long time if I should commit my answer. I was just playing around with MATLAB. I am aware that it's not really possible to generate dense code (a low number of instructions/bytes; about 3 times larget than your ~100 byte solutions) and that MATLAB might not be too suitable for code golf and I am new to code golf. But I simply wanted to try, and the code works (newline characters kept). Any hints welcome. :P

```
i=input('','s');
l=reshape(i,4,length(i)/4)';
m=']!- e';m(9)='*';m(12:22)='o[   + d  <';m(33:34)='1\';m(39)='>';m(57)='i';m(64)='n';
s='';
for k = 1:size(l,1)
n=l(k,:);
c=combvec(n,n);
t=triu(reshape(c(1,:)==c(2,:),4,4),1);
t=sum(t([5,9:10,13:15]).*2.^[5:-1:0]);
s=[s,m(t+1)];
end
display(s)
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! All answers are welcome, even if they get outgolfed by a ridiculous amount (has definitely happened to me before). ;) Nice first answer!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>115</s> 101 bytes

```js
s=>s.replace(/..../g,g=>"ni >\\1   <d+[o*e-!]"[[...g].map(c=>r=r*3+(m[c]=m[c]||++i)-1,i=r=0,m={})|r])
```

*Saved 14 bytes thanks to [@edc65](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21348/edc65)!*

### Explanation

Stores the list of instructions in a string with each character at it's base-3 index. For example, `+` corresponds to `abac` which can be represented in base-3 as `0102`, or `11` in decimal. The only instruction that cannot be represented in base-3 is `]`, but with the algorithm used to compute the base-3 number, it conveniently ends up needing to be at position 18 at the end of the string.

```js
s=>
  s.replace(/..../g,g=>    // replace each four-character group with it's instruction
    "ni >\\1   <d+[o*e-!]" // list of instructions at their base-3 index
    [
      [...g].map(c=>       // for each character c
        r=r*3+(m[c]=m[c]   // shift r left and add the number associated with c to r
          ||++i)-1,        // if nothing is associated, associate the next number to c
                           // save i + 1 to m[c] so that it is truthy for 0
        i=                 // i = current number to assign to the next unique character
        r=0,               // r = 4-character group as a base-3 number
        m={}               // m = map of numbers assigned to each character
      )
      |r                   // return r
    ]
  )
```

### Test

```js
var solution = s=>s.replace(/..../g,g=>"ni >\\1   <d+[o*e-!]"[[...g].map(c=>r=r*3+(m[c]=m[c]||++i)-1,i=r=0,m={})|r])
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="Programming Puzzles & Code Golof" />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(input.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: You can save many bytes not using `parseInt` and computing the number with repeated sum and multiply. This avoid the problem with '0123' that is invalid in base 3 but gives 1*9+2*6+3==18 that is a good position. Result: `F=s=>s.replace(/..../g,g=>"ni]>\\1   <d+[o*e-!]"[[...g].map(c=>r=r*3+(m[c]=m[c]||++i)-1,r=i=0,m={})|r])`

Comment: @edc65 Great suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 158 bytes

Takes input like `"test"`. Output is a list of characters.

```python
def b(s,i=0):
    for c in s:i=i*4+s.index(c)
    return"n..i....>.\\1....<d.+[o.*e-!]"[i]
print map(b,(lambda l,n:[l[i:i+n]for i in range(0,len(l),n)])(input(),4))
```

[**Try it Online!**](https://tio.run/##HY2xDoIwFAB3vuLJYFqoDRomIi4OruzAUGjBl5RXUiBRfh7Bmy654cbv/HZ02zZtOmjYJDBPeBbATuc8tIAEU4Y5Rmk8SSRtPqzl/@7NvHgKSUqUOw9ZVddD7lrGpZORuZzqsMQ6GD3SDIMaWSOYVUOjFVhBWWlLzDCm@jjhcfKKesMSYQ0xywXxmjOkcZkZFynn2xYW3vVeDQNSD8WyrtZMcIan0wZezrou/AE)

**Ungolfed:**

```python
def chunks(l, n):
    return (l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n))
    
def convert(inst):
    i = 0
    for c in inst:
        i = i*4 + inst.index(c)
    
    return "n..i....>.\\1....<d.+[o.*e-!]"[i]

print map(convert, chunks(input(), 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 118 bytes

```sh
0="n  i      > \1${(l:11:)}<d + [o * e-!]"
for s (`tr \  £|fold -4`)(eval ';n+=$s[(i)$s['{2..4}]];printf $0[5#$n-30])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcQxDoIwAAXQ3VN8kUiRQEBxAXFxcGWHJpBQkKS0pkUHkNN4Ey9WjW94k74ZE2aWAHr8nVFG9kx4EkWJu5waeCgkdmD@mlqrVipokGpUKIHP@9VK3sCPK5ewZ83hpMLLbF2Q3v3tzPsgiBdK07vqxdjCDovjxhb@IaSuMbmSnaqHoRcd8sc0caaxxUU2DFfJZfsF)

- `0="n  i      > \1${(l:11:)}<d + [o * e-!]"` - store this string in the variable `$0`. `${(l:11:)}` generates 11 spaces (literally, left-padding an empty string to a length of 11), and is 1 byte shorter than writing them literally.
- `tr \  £` - replace spaces (`\` ) with `£`s. This is because spaces in the input will be eaten when word splitting, messing up the 4 character grouping. Word splitting is useful though, because it allows us to loop over each line, which is how `fold` splits things. I used `£` because it's outside the printable ASCII range that we're required to accept and only 2 bytes in UTF-8 (I could probably technically save a byte if I used a different encoding, but that's not worth the effort). Unfortunately I can't use a control character because `zsh` doesn't like them.
- `fold -4` - group into 4 characters per line
- ``` for s (``) ``` - for each group, `$s`, of 4 characters:

  - `';n+=$s[(i)$s['{2..4}]]`: generate the string `;n+=$s[(i)$s[2]];n+=$s[(i)$s[3]];n+=$s[(i)$s[4]]`
  - `eval`uate that as `zsh` code:

    - `$s[X]` - the `X`th character of `$s` (1-indexed)
    - `$s[(i)]` - find the index of the first appearance of that character within `$s`
    - `n+=` - append that to `$n` (which implicitly starts out empty)
    - `eval` with brace expansion (like `{2..4}`) is a shorter way to do a simple loop than using `for`
    - We only need to use `{2..4}` as the first index of the first character of the string will obviously always be `1`. This lets us save a byte when subtracting later (otherwise it would be -155 rather than -30)
    - `5#$n` - interpret `n` as a base-5 integer (if zsh used 0-based indexing, this could be base 4, we wouldn't need to subtract anything, and the `$0` string could be shorter)
  - `-30` - the minimum base-5 value we can get from any combination of characters is `31`, and since `zsh` is 1-indexed, we subtract 30 to get an index into the string `$0`
  - `$0[]` - get that index into the string `$0` for the relevant character to print. The spaces in `$0` are padding to make the right characters appear in the right places since the possible base-5 values aren't contiguous.
  - `printf` - print that with no newline

    - `()` - subshell; any changes to variables do not persist outside the brackets. This is used to reset `$n` to an empty string on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 37 bytes

```
'ni >\1   <d+[o*e-!]'{~_4(3#.~.i.])\]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcJNC4IwHIDx@z7FX4LsxYZjBqYWQVCXDt5TZOW0xV7C2cXAr76gTj2/5@Fcs8XgawG7ggBAVi8vZsFXXum/xyqa0QkescDlvCgdv91NgLN9k@KKwPkYgO1roYG4vDNtx5QSuoX8NQySW5jCwdQcTkaaBmn2D66sV0x7KP2VfE@TBEnJFLNgJedPFEdxTCglmzAMabSm6AM)