# Making an acronym

Tags: code-golf, string

## Objective

Your goal is to make a program that converts an input to its acronym. Your input is guaranteed to have only letters and spaces. The input will have exactly one space between words. You must output the acronym of the input.

## Rules

- Your code cannot be case-sensitive(e.g. `foo` and `Foo` are the same)
- Your code must ignore the following words and not put them in the acronym:
  `and or by of`
- You **cannot** assume that the words are all lowercase.
- The output must be entirely capitalised, with no separation between characters.
- A trailing newline is accepted but not necessary.
- If your language has an acronym function builtin, you may **not** use it.

### Examples

(inputs/outputs grouped)

```
United States of America
USA

Light Amplification by Stimulation of Emitted Radiation
LASER

united states of america
USA

Jordan Of the World
JTW
```

## Scoring

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge so the shortest code wins.

## Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=75448,OVERRIDE_USER=8478;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: I have added 2 test cases.

Comment: What should be the output for `UPPER And lowercase TestCase`?

Comment: Can we assume that all other words than `and,or,by,of` are in titlecase?

Comment: You may assume that they are in titlecase.

Comment: @Aplet123 Are you sure that's what you want? Because if that's the case, the challenge boils down to removing spaces and lower case letters. (E.g. 4 bytes in Retina: `T\` l`)

Comment: I have made an edit to the rules.

Comment: Will there always be one space between the words or can it be more?

Comment: There will always be one space between the words.

Comment: Bit too late to change it, but you'd generally also expect words like "a", "an", "the", "for", "to", etc. to be removed.

Comment: How about every word at most three letters?

Comment: If every word was at most three letters, it would be unfair to many people that they have made their code so long.

Comment: This is setting aside the fact that USA is not an acronym, it's an abbreviation? NASA is an acronym because you say the word "nasa". If you spell out the letters, it isn't an acronym.

Comment: Can we assume the input will always have a non-empty output?

Comment: You may assume that the input will always have a non-empty output.

Comment: @MarkWright that's the odd case out

Comment: What about Unicode / ascii?

Comment: @corsiKa you're thinking of "alliteration", an abbreviation is something like "adverb" -> "adv.". if you're going to be pedantic, be correct ;)

Comment: It's a bit late for a comment for clarification, but `a` and `an` aren't mentioned in the list of words to be removed, though it's rather common to remove them from acronyms. Should they remain?

Comment: @undergroundmonorail I'm aware that this was over 7 years ago, but the definition of alliteration, according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alliteration), is "the repetition of usually initial consonant sounds in two or more neighboring words or syllables (such as wild and woolly, threatening throngs)". If you're going to correct someone's pedantry, at least be correct yourself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>25</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
shM-crz1dc4."@YK½¼
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=shM-crz1dc4.%22%40YK%19%17%C2%BD%C2%BC&input=United+States+of+America&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=United+States+of+America%0ALight+Amplification+by+Stimulation+of+Emitted+Radiation%0Aunited+states+of+america&debug=0)

Thanks to @Jakube for saving one byte!

### Explanation

```
shM-crz1dc4."@YK½¼  # z = input

     rz1               # convert input to uppercase
    c   d              # split input on spaces
         c4."@YK½¼     # create a list of the words from a packed string which shall be ignored
   -                   # filter those words out
 hM                    # only take the first letter of all words
s                      # join them into one string
```

The packed string becomes `ANDBYOROF`

Comment: A little string packing trick: `."@YK½¼` saves one byte over `"ANDORBYOF`. It's basically `@ANDBYOROF` packed.

Comment: Dang, the non-ascii-chars got deleted. Just pack `@ANDBYOROF` and see what you get.

Comment: @Jakube Thanks! Tried to pack it before, but always ended up with the same length or longer.

Answer (score 10):

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>21</s> [20 bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
,“°ɲịĊs°gɗ»ṣ€⁶Œuḟ/Ḣ€
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=LOKAnMKwybLhu4vEinPCsGfJl8K74bmj4oKs4oG2xZJ14bifL-G4ouKCrA&input=&args=byBieXBhc3MgYSBsYXlieSBhbmQgdGFrZSBhbiBhbnRpIGJ5IGNha2U)

*(-1 thanks to @Dennis.)*

```
,“°ɲịĊs°gɗ»              Pair input with the string "OR OF by AND"
           ṣ€⁶           Split both by spaces
              Œu         Uppercase
                ḟ/       Reduce filter (removing ignored words from input)
                  Ḣ€     Keep first letters of remaining words
```

Jelly's dictionary is a bit weird in that it has `AND` in uppercase yet `by` in lowercase...

Answer (score 8):

### Retina, 29 <s>31</s> <s>36</s> bytes

```
T`l`L
 |(AND|OR|BY|OF)\b|\B.
```

Intended newline at the end.

Thanks to [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner) for saving 5 bytes

[Try it online](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGBsYEwKIHwoQU5EfE9SfEJZfE9GKVxifFxCLgo&input=TGlnaHQgQW1wbGlmaWNhdGlvbiBieSAgIFN0aW11bGF0aW9uIG9mIEVtaXR0ZWQgUmFkaWF0aW9u)

```
T`l`L                  # Replace lowercase with uppercase
 |(AND|OR|BY|OF)\b|\B. # Regex match, it doesn't matter if we match 'AND' in SHAND
                       #   since the 'SH' will still become 'S' or am I missing something?
                       # Replace with nothing
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with retina. What does ``T`l`L`` do?

Comment: @Cyoce See update with explanation

Answer (score 7):

### vim, 46

```
gUU:s/ /\r/g<cr>:g/\vAND|OR|OF|BY/d<cr>:%s/.\zs.*\n<cr>
```

```
gUU                      make line uppercase
:s/ /\r/g<cr>            replace all spaces with newlines
:g/\vAND|OR|OF|BY/d<cr>  remove unwanted words
:%s/.\zs.*\n<cr>         remove all non-initial characters and newlines
```

I particularly like that last bit. The first `.` in the regex matches the first character of the line. Then we use `\zs` to start the "actually-being-replaced" part, effectively *not* replacing the initial character. `.*` matches the rest of the line, and `\n` matches the trailing newline. Since we don't specify a replace string, vim simply removes everything in the match, leaving only initials.

Comment: `vim` is a programming language

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 56 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to @edc65.

```
s=>s.toUpperCase().replace(/\B.| |(AND|O[RF]|BY)\b/g,"")
```

### Explanation

The code is self explanatory, I'll just explain the regex:

```
\B.          // Matches any character (`.`), that's not the start of a word
|            // Matches spaces
|(...)\b     // Matches all the words that should be ignored
```

It removed all of these matched characers and uppercases the word

Comment: putting .toUpperCase() before the regexp you could avoid the `i` flag

Comment: @edc65 smart idea, thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure the parens are not needed here

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, <s>61</s> <s>64</s> <s>66</s> 63 bytes

```
a=>a.toUpperCase().replace(/(AND|O[FR]|BY|(\w)\w+)( |$)/g,"$2")
```

It uses a Regular Expression to find get words that aren't from the list: `and, or, of, by`, and captures the first letter. It then capitalizes the resulting string of letters.

**EDIT:** 64 Bytes - Fixed for words start with `of,or,by,and`

**EDIT:** 66 Bytes - Fixed to check all words including last word.

**EDIT:** 63 Bytes - Saved 3 Bytes thanks to [@edc65](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21348/edc65) and [@Cyoce](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41042/cyoce)!

Comment: Doesn't work for `Foo Offline Bar`

Comment: General consensus is you don't need to assign the function to a variable.

Comment: putting .toUpperCase() before the regexp you could avoid the `i` flag

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>28</s> <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
qeuS/"AOBONRYFD"4/z-:c
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qeuS%2F%22AOBONRYFD%224%2Fz-%3Ac&input=Light%20Amplification%20by%20Stimulation%20of%20Emitted%20Radiation). Thanks to Sp3000 for pointing out a bug and suggesting a fix, and to Dennis for saving <s>4</s> 6(!) bytes.

#### Explanation

```
qeuS/  e# Convert the input to uppercase and split on spaces
"AOBONRYFD"4/z  e# Push the array of short words. See more below
-      e# Remove each short word from the input words
:c     e# Cast the remaining words to characters, which is a
       e# shorter way of taking the first letter
```

Dennis suggested this trick for shortening the word list: Splitting `AOBONRYFD` into chunks of four, we get

```
AOBO
NRYF
D
```

Transposing columns into rows with the `z` operator, we get the proper words!

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <s>72</s> <s>63</s> <s>61</s> 55 bytes

```
s->join(matchall(r"\b(?!AND|OR|OF|BY)\S",uppercase(s)))
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts a string and returns a string. To call it, assign it to a variable.

We convert the string to `uppercase`, select each match of the regular expression `\b(?!AND|OR|OF|BY)\S` as an array, and `join` it into a string.

Saved 8 bytes thanks to Dennis!

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 32 bytes

```
say uc=~/\b(?!AND|OR|OF|BY)\S/g
```

+1 byte for the `-n` flag.

Algorithm stolen from [@AlexA's Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75463/3808).

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>34</s> 27 bytes

*1 byte fewer thanks to @AandN*

```
KkYb'OF AND OR BY'YbX-c1Z)!
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WGtZYidPRiBBTkQgT1IgQlknWWJYLWMxWikh&input=J1VuaXRlZCBTdGF0ZXMgT2YgQW1lcmljYSc)

```
Xk                  % convert to uppercase
Yb                  % split by spaces. Gives a cell array of input words
'AND OR BY OF'      % ignored words separated by spaces
Yb                  % split by spaces. Gives a cell array of ignored words
X-                  % setdiff: remove ignored words (result is stable)
c                   % convert to 2D char array, padding words with spaces
1Z)                 % take first column
!                   % transpose into a row
```

Comment: Maybe this works with 33 bytes? `XkYb{'OF' 'AND' 'OR' 'BY'}X-c1Z)!`

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>104</s> 85 bytes

Saved 19 bytes thanks to *@Aplet123*.

Splits the string by spaces then checks if it is the words of, or, and, or by. If it is, it ignores it, otherwise it takes the first letter of it. It then joins the array and makes the string uppercase.

```
a=_=>_.split` `.map(v=>/\b(o(f|r)|and|by)\b/i.test(v)?"":v[0]).join("").toUpperCase()
```

Ungolfed:

```
function a(_) {
       _ = _.split` `; //Split on spaces
       _ = _.map(function(v){return new RegExp("\b(o(f|r)|and|by)\b","i").test(v)}); //Check if the banned words are in the result
       _ = _.join(""); //Join it into a string
       _ = _.toUpperCase(); //Convert it to uppercase
};
```

Comment: Why is there a backtick at the end? It causes an error and is not intended to be there. You should probably remove the backtick.

Comment: Also, you don't need `var`. We don't worry about polluting the global scope in code golf :P

Comment: It does not work. If you look at the examples the input
`
united states of america
`
it gives the output
`
usa
`
not
`
USA
`

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. Stupid super long built-in function names.

Comment: You can set Z to
 ```_.map(v=>/o(f|r)|and|by/.test(v)?"":v[0])```
 instead of `""`. You can remove your
```_.forEach(p=>Z+=p[0].toUpperCase());```
line and replace your 
```return Z```
line with 
```return Z.join("").toUpperCase()```

Comment: Here is a 78 byte version made from chaining code:
```a=_=>_.split` `.map(v=>/o(f|r)|and|by/.test(v)?"":v[0]).join("").toUpperCase()```
Note the space after the split` that didn't get displayed.

Comment: Oh my god those tenary operators are evil.

Comment: Fixed the bug with the following 85 byte code:
```a=_=>_.split` `.map(v=>/\b(o(f|r)|and|by)\b/i.test(v)?"":v[0]).join("").toUpperCase()```

Comment: Use `[fr]` instead of `(f|r)`? ```join`` ``` instead of `join("")`? `/^...$/` instead of `/\b...\b/`?

Comment: Also, if you move the `toUpperCase` to before the `split` then you can uppercase the regex and remove the `i` flag.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>45</s> 43 bytes

```rb
->s{s.upcase.scan(/\b(?!AND|OR|OF|BY)\S/)*''}
```

This is a lambda function that accepts a string and returns a string. To call it, assign it to a variable and do `f.call(input)`.

It uses the same approach as my [Julia answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75463/20469), namely convert to uppercase, get matches of the regular expression `\b(?!AND|OR|OF|BY)\S`, and join into a string.

[Try it here](https://repl.it/BviG/1)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to manatwork!

Comment: `.join` → `*''`. By the way, no need to assign it to anything to call it. Just pass it the arguments as subscript: `->s{s.upcase.scan(/\b(?!AND|OR|OF|BY)\S/)*''}['United States of America']`

Comment: @manatwork Oh nice, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 92 bytes

First attempt at code golf.

```
foreach(explode(" ",str_replace(["AND","OR","BY","OF"],"",strtoupper($s)))as$x){echo$x[0];}
```

The variable `$s` is the phrase to be converted: `$s = "United States of America"`.

Requires PHP 5.4 or above for short array syntax to work.

Comment: Just FYI, [tag:code-golf]s are scored in `bytes` unless otherwise noted, and you can use just a `#` at the beginning of the line to make a header.

Comment: There's a problem. Using `$s` requires `register_globals`, but that has been removed from PHP since 5.4, so your answer cannot work as you require 5.4 for short array syntax. You need to get the input string as an argument (`$argv`, a function argument or similar).

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 81 bytes

```
lambda s:''.join(c[0]for c in s.upper().split()if c not in'AND OF OR BY'.split())
```

Comment: 76 bytes using set difference: `lambda s:''.join(c[0]for c in s.upper().split()if{c}-{'AND','OF','OR','BY'})`

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + GNU coreutils, <s>103</s> 76 bytes

```
for i in ${@^^};do grep -qE '\b(AND|OR|BY|OF)\b'<<<$i||echo -n ${i:0:1};done
```

Run with

```
./codegolf.sh Light Amplification BY Stimulation of Emitted Radiationofo
```

either with single argument quoted or with multiple arguments.

(I distorted the last word to contain *of*).

---

## 60 bytes

Thanks to @manatwork.

```
for i in ${@^^};{ [[ $i = @(AND|OR|BY|OF) ]]||printf %c $i;}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that `awk` call looks horrible. What about replacing it with `${@^^}`?

Comment: @manatwork, good point, didnot think of that...

Comment: Looks much better. Now please replace the `grep` call with `[[ $i = @(AND|OR|BY|OF) ]]`. ;) And with that you can also remove the “ + GNU coreutils” part from the post header.

Comment: One more thing: you could replace the `echo` with `printf`. Furthermore you can apply [Digital Trauma](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11259/digital-trauma)'s [brace tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25802) too. (More in [Tips for golfing in Bash](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash).) `for i in ${@^^};{ [[ $i = @(AND|OR|BY|OF) ]]||printf %c $i;}`

Comment: I was looking for the bash notation similar to *grep*'s `\b` but couldnot find it... And I did not know that `do...done` can be replace by curly braces.

Comment: The word boundary is still `\b`, just needs to escape the `\ ` with another one. But unfortunately it works only with compat31 shell option set (`shopt -s compat31`). By the way, the `grep` way can also be written shorter without `\b`: `grep -qwE 'AND|OR|BY|OF'`

Comment: Maybe I was thinking too complicated, as in the grep-step the input is line by line, so `[[ $i =~ ^(AND|OR|BY|OF)$ ]]` would have also worked, but is 2 bytes longer.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>80</s> <s>72</s> <s>55</s> 53 bytes

### Code

```
function a(t){t=t.toUpperCase();t=t.replace(/AND|OR|BY|OF|\B.| |/g,"");return t}
```

```
function a(t){return t.toUpperCase().replace(/AND|OR|BY|OF|\B.| |/g,"")}
```

I just read about arrow functions and realized I could shorten this up even more.

```
a=t=>t.toUpperCase().replace(/AND|OR|BY|OF|\B.| |/g,"")
```

According to [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/how-do-we-calculate-the-length-of-lambda), you don't count the assignment in the length, so -2 bytes.

```
t=>t.toUpperCase().replace(/AND|OR|BY|OF|\B.| |/g,"")
```

This is my first golf, so it's not very good.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 28 bytes

Code:

```
‘€ƒ€—€‚€‹‘ð¡)Uuð¡)vXyQO>iy¬?
```

Uses **CP-1252** encoding.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>100</s> <s>99</s> <s>98</s> <s>82</s> 75 bytes

<s>I am quite sure it can be shortened a lot more as I still suck at using `$`,`.` etc. so I keep using `()` insted=)</s>

Thanks @nimi for your help magic!

```
import Data.Char
w=words
x=[h!!0|h<-w$toUpper<$>x,notElem h$w"OF BY OR AND"]
```

Example:

```
*Main> a "united states by america"
"USA"
```

Comment: Oh, that `.` composition operator looks quite intuitive. I am just never sure what is evaluated in what order.

Comment: chapter 6 of _Learn you a Haskell for Great Good!_ has a good introduction to [function application with `$` and composition with `.`](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#function-application).

Comment: Switching back to non-pointfree and a list comprehension is even shorter: `a x=[h!!0|h<-w$toUpper<$>x,notElem h$w"OF BY OR AND"]`.

Comment: Now this is definitely over my head, I'm going to have to learn quicker=)

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <strike>103</strike> 96 bytes

This is my first attempt at code golf, and this could probably be golfed a lot more.
Thanks to DenkerAffe for saving seven characters.

```
lambda x:"".join([x[0]for y in x.split(" ") if y.lower() not in ['and','or','of','by']]).upper()
```

It takes the input, turns it into a list of words and takes their first letter if it's not one of the forbidden words, then turns everything to uppercase.

Comment: It _was_ trying to execute the input. In Python 3 that doesn't happen. (I think it saves 2 bytes to switch to Python 3 (-4 for `input` vs `raw_input`, +2 for `print("".join..)` vs `print"".join..`) Also no space between a symbol and a keyword.

Comment: Or you just go with a lambda which gets the input as argument. This is always allowed here if the challenge doesn't forbid it explicitly.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy It might help to switch to Python 3, but I highly prefer Python 2 over it because who likes parentheses anyways?

Comment: You can save the lower() when you uppercase the input first, before you do anything. Your filter list then becomes ['AND','OR',...]., but the rest would stay the same. You can also drop some whitespaces behind braces. `x[0]for ...` is completly valid in Python.

Comment: Remove spaces between symbols and keywords(it works)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>68</s> <s>61</s> 58 bytes

Uses ISO-8859-1 encoding.

```
for(;$w=$argv[++$x];)stripos(_AND_OR_BY_OF,$w)||print$w&ß;
```

Run like this (`-d` added for aesthetics only):

```
php -d error_reporting=30709 -r 'for(;$w=$argv[++$x];)stripos(_AND_OR_BY_OF,$w)||print$w&ß; echo"\n";' united states oF america
```

Ungolfed:

```
// Iterate over the CLI arguments (words).
for(;$w = $argv[++$x];)
    // Check if the word is one of the excluded words by substring index.
    // The check is case insensitive.
    stripos("_AND_OR_BY_OF", $w) ||
        // Print the word, converting to uppercase and getting only the
        // first char by using bitwise AND.
        print $w & "ß";
```

- Saved 7 bytes by using bitwise AND instead of using `ucwords`.
- Saved 3 bytes by using ISO-8859-1 encoding and using `ß` (binary `11011111`) for binary `AND` instead of a negated space (binary `00100000`).

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>77</s> 75 bytes

```r
cat(substr(w<-toupper(scan(,'')),1,1)[!grepl('^(AND|OR|OF|BY)$',w)],sep='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrBCsIwDADQX6kgNIV42F0Pinh04G0MhdhFGWhXkpRd@u/Vd37SWiQDLU81gXW/s6XkzAIaKQF6HwJ22IVx8xbOH/APOF7Ptb/V/lJPQ9h6XMMdlfPhf1tJs/Hk1MhY3fJylCZHX5Y5UvsB)

-1 byte thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen) changing the indexing.

Reads from stdin. Takes the words, converts them to uppercase, removes those that are excluded from acronyms, extracts the first character from each, and prints them to the stdout.

Comment: [76 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/v9y2JL@0oCC1SKM4OTFPQ0ddXVPTOjmxRKO4NKm4pEijPFoxvSi1IEdDPU7D0c@lxj@oxt@txilSU0Vdp1wzVsdQx1BTpzi1wBao8X9pXmZJaopCcUliSWqxQn6aQmJualFmcuJ/AA)...?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen very nice! And another byte down by setting `w` inline.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 34 bytes

```
{`c$-32+*'(" "\_x)^$`and`or`by`of}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLCsIwFER/5RIKWqUb3enKhRsRBEXciCZtkvZiHpLegkX89hgtdDkzZ86jcLWLUa/evMqK5WI@m0wZsOv9ld8yLpzkPvCy515/ok7T2SEpCScSpFrwGjZWBawEW7M91g2l/DSoU0PoHZR9QtF2ZoiJ31qkn@EoJP7L9OwGaTtKxSjd@SCFg4MGahRcfDCS5fEL)

- `_x` lowercase the input
- `(" "\...)` split input on spaces
- `` (...)^$`and`or`by`of `` remove and/or/by/of
- `*'` take the first character of each remaining word
- `` `c$-32+ `` convert to uppercase

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>132</s> 117 bytes

```
ToUpperCase[First/@Characters@DeleteCases[StringDelete[StringSplit@#,"of"|"and"|"or"|"by",IgnoreCase->True],""]<>""]&
```

15 bytes saved thanks to @CatsAreFluffy.

Comment: 1arg `StringSplit` defaults to splitting on whitespace (-5bytes)

Comment: Also you can replace the word list with `"of"|"and"|"or"|"by"`. Also `{"a","b","c"}<>""==StringJoin[{"a","b","c"}]`. One last thing: `Characters` automatically maps over lists.

Comment: The leaderboard would prefer that you put a comma after Mathematica. Also you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 81 Bytes

```
(-join($args[0].Split(" ")|?{$_-notmatch"^(and|or|by|of)$"}|%{$_[0]})).ToUpper()
```

---

Explanation

Split on the spaces creating an array. Drop the offending members. Pull the first character and join together. Use `ToUpper()` on the resulting string.

Comment: Realized that would match Anderson and drop it. Added 4 bytes

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 122 Bytes

I would have love to use a pattern to get rid of the banned words, but sadly, lua isn't made to match groups of characters... So I had to use a for loop instead, which is much more expensive.

```lua
s=arg[1]for k,v in next,{"of","and","by","or"}do
s=s:gsub(v,"")end
print(s:gsub("(%a)%a+",string.upper):gsub("%s","").."")
```

#### Ungolfed

```lua
s=arg[1]                               -- initialise s with the argument
for k,v in next,{"of","and","by","or"} -- iterate over the array of banned words
do
    s=s:gsub(v,"")                     -- replace the occurences of v by 
end                                    --   an empty string
print(s:gsub("(%a)%a+",                -- replace words (separated by spaces)
              string.upper)            -- by their first letter capitalised
         :gsub("%s","")                -- replace spaces with empty strings
                       .."")           -- concatenate to prevent the number of 
                                       -- substitutions to be shown
```

Comment: Hey! I also made a Lua submission, here: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75616/33183.

Answer (score 1):

## Factor, 175 bytes

I learned a lot by writing this.

```
USING: strings ascii sets splitting kernel sequences math.ranges ;
>lower " " split [ { "and" "or" "by" "of" } in? not ] filter [ first dup [a,b] >string ] map "" join >upper
```

As a word:

```
USING: strings ascii sets splitting kernel sequences math.ranges ;

: >initialism ( str -- str )
  >lower " " split                            ! string.lower.split(" ")
  [ { "and" "or" "by" "of" } in? not ] filter ! word in { } ?
  [ first dup [a,b] >string ]          map    ! word[0]
  "" join >upper ;                            ! "".join.upper
```

Unit tests:

```
USING: tools.test mk-initialism ;
IN: mk-initialism.tests

{ "LASER" } [ "Light Amplification by Stimulation of Emitted Radiation" >initialism ] unit-test
{ "USA"   } [ "United States OF Americaof" >initialism ]                              unit-test
{ "USA"   } [ "united states and america" >initialism ]                               unit-test
{ "JTW"   } [ "Jordan Of the World" >initialism ]                                     unit-test
```

Pass!

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, <s>113</s> <s>112</s> 93 bytes

```
arg[1]:upper():gsub("%w+",function(w)io.write(("AND OR BY OF"):find(w)and""or w:sub(0,1))end)
```

Comment: Wow, totally forgot the existence of `%w`! That's a great one!

Comment: Katenkyo: Well, this would also work with `%a`; `%a` matches letters, and `%w` matches letters and numbers. The main thing is using a custom function in `gsub`.

Comment: Yeah, I see that it is easier to remove `AND OR BY OF` when selecting words... I used no custom function because they cost a lot, so I though `gsub("(%a)%a+",string.upper)` after removing them would have been better

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 134 bytes

Golfed

```
class P{static void Main(string[] a){foreach (var s in a){if(!"AND OR BY OF".Contains(s.ToUpper())){Console.Write(s.ToUpper()[0]);}}}}
```

Readable

```
class P
{
    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        foreach (var s in a)
        {
            if (!"AND OR BY OF".Contains(s.ToUpper()))
            {
                Console.Write(s.ToUpper()[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Execute from command line

75448.exe Light Amplification by Stimulation of Emitted Radiation

> LASER

75448.exe united states of america

> USA

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>19</s></sup> 18 bytes

```
m←¤-w¨BYΘRΘF⁴ND¨ma
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9odXNr//9t4oaQwqQtd8KoQlnOmFLOmEbigbRORMKobWH///9Kb3JkYW4gT2YgdGhlIFdvcmxk)

-1 byte from Dominic Van Essen.

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9odXNr//9t4oaQwqQtd8KoQlnOmFLOmEbigbRORMKobWH///9Kb3JkYW4gT2YgdGhlIFdvcmxk) by using an uppercase string of words to avoid (and searching for a permutation that compresses well...)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <sup><s>46</s> <s>45</s></sup> 44 bytes

```sh
for i;printf ${${${i:u}:#(AND|OR|BY|OF)}[1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqLgk5meUaKQ6Bvg4@nm6ewY4unvp5AUqRBckplbmpNYkpmfp@CfpuCam1lSkpqiEJSYkgkW/J@WX6SQaV1QlJlXkqagUg2CmValtVbKGo5@LjX@QTVOkTX@bpq10Yaxtf//AwA)

*-1 thanks to @roblogic*

Explanation:

```
for i;printf ${${${i:u}:#(AND|OR|BY|OF)}[1]}
for i;                                         # for each word in the input
                 ${i  }                        # take that word
                    :u                         # capitalised
                         (AND|OR|BY|OF)        # if it matches one of these words
               ${      :#              }       # replace it with an empty string
             ${                         [1]}   # take the first character
      printf                                   # and print with no newline
```

Comment: Very nice. -1 byte using `${i:u}` instead of `${(U)i}`

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>16</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
î♣}ïû┴N=a,╥Ç
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8c057d8b96c14e3d612cd280&i=United+States+of+America%0ALight+Amplification+by+Stimulation+of+Emitted+Radiation%0Aunited+states+of+america%0AJordan+Of+the+World&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 149 bytes

```c
#define x*strcmp(c,
F(char*s){char*d,*c=s;while(*s)*s++|=32;for(s=c;c;c=!d?*s=0:d+1)d=index(c,32),d?*d=0:0,1 x"and")x"or")x"by")x"of")?*s++=*c^32:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFda9swFH22foWmUvCHNpykfamrlTy0D6VQaFb6kHigSnJ8wZYzS95SMv/27CptRgtjCCTdc849V/dKfV4rtT8Bq5pBG3rpvIbuS/2VvId6sGvE9ifaVGAN3aaIqXYTK05uYlXLPnXJ7nBqnirhil81NCZGNHVZ9lvMpkXV9bETqsAlPumr1In8QmeTRAuw2mzRajZNOBIaiZxP6JZJq1myZV0f9ueXw71iyVXwFKn6Ppte5MW4B@tpK8HGCd2RKLyC0h9yeVYup@Xy/DyblALxaMceLXij6cJLbxztKjpvTQ9KMs4eF3M28oPqDta1R2rTQIWkh87S5xfMgnZoXkNMvW7BB7MHqeEAosndfHH9cLQZXou5v8Xkv4rddr2Wlt5X1NeGPnV9o1Fw@@2JjSQaC0IiEoX@oCDRZvAuZmB5N3j@UzaA00E4DBZEXsDlWZFlkIReN/hjvorZip26FRpynAeUy7wMCdFN/CH8v/jInuoV9vj270fFm3RSJkLkQT6Scf8H)

Very naive approach. Will try to optimize it further. My first priority was to create a working example in C as there was no C submission yet.

Edit: optimized it by replacing initial conversion to upper case with conversion to lower case (easier as space is no longer an exception). I replaced strcmp with a define and replaced a while loop with a for. I did some further small optimizations and am now out of ideas.

Thanks to ceiling cat for bringing it down even more!

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks! I was able to bring it down to 149 by adding a comma to your define!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `sr`, <s>20</s> 16 bytes

-4 thanks to @Underslash.

```
⇧⌈«X⟩qḊ8ɖ⇩«⇧⌈Fvh
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=sr&code=%E2%87%A7%E2%8C%88%C2%ABX%E2%9F%A9q%E1%B8%8A8%C9%96%E2%87%A9%C2%AB%E2%87%A7%E2%8C%88Fvh&inputs=Light%20Amplification%20by%20Stimulation%20of%20Emitted%20Radiation&header=&footer=)

```
⇧⌈«X⟩qḊ8ɖ⇩«⇧⌈Fvh    # Full program
⇧                   # Convert (implicit) input converted to uppercase...
 ⌈                  # Split on spaces
  «X⟩qḊ8ɖ⇩«⇧⌈       # Create the list ['OR', 'BY', 'OF', 'AND']
             F      # and remove those from the input.
              vh    # Replace each word with its first letter
                    # `s` flag: Concatenate the letters and print
```

Comment: you can compress the string and uppercase it, yielding [16 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=sr&code=%E2%87%A7%E2%8C%88%C2%ABX%E2%9F%A9q%E1%B8%8A8%C9%96%E2%87%A9%C2%AB%E2%87%A7%E2%8C%88Fvh&inputs=Light%20Amplification%20by%20Stimulation%20of%20Emitted%20Radiation&header=&footer=)

Comment: @Underslash Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [IPOS](https://github.com/DenkerAffe/IPOS) - non competing, 27 bytes

```
uS`"AND|OR|BY|OF"ER`%S!h%S-
```

This works in the [current version (v0.2) of the interpreter](https://github.com/DenkerAffe/IPOS/releases/tag/v0.2).

**Example run**

```
python IPOS.py -i "United States of America" uS`\"AND|OR|BY|OF\"ER`%S!h%S-
USA
```

*The backslashes there are only for escaping of the quotes and are not needed for the program.*

### Explanation

```
u                  # Make the input uppercase
S                  # Push a space to the stack
`"AND|OR|BY|OF"ER` # Push a command to the stack, that replaces matches of the regex
                   # with an empty string
%                  # Split the uppercased input string on spaces, apply the command and
                   # join back on spaces. This removes the required words from the input.
S                  # Push a space to the stack
!h                 # Push a command that only selects the first character of a string
%                  # Split on spaces, apply the command and join back on spaces
S-                 # Remove the remaining spaces (forgot to make this usuable
                   # with regexes, would have saved me some bytes here :( )
```

Answer (score 0):

## bash / GNU coreutils, 60 bytes

`sed -e's/\b'{and,o[rf],by}'\W*//Ig' -re's/(\w)\S* ?/\u\1/g'`

Answer (score 0):

## [Pylongolf2](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/pylongolf2), 14 bytes (UTF-8)

```
c| l1╨3♀~
```

Pylongolf2 has many non-ASCII characters that count as 2 bytes.

```
c| l1╨3♀~
c         read input
 |        split by space (note the space after |)
   l1     substring(0, 1)
     ╨3   convert to uppercase
       ♀~ pop the array into the stack and print it.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 19 bytes

```
lð¡“€ƒ€—€‹€‚“#K€нJu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/5/CGQwsfNcx51LTm2CQg8ahhCpjcCSZnAWWUvYHMC3u9Sv//98ovSknMU/BPUyjJSFUIzy/KSQEA)

A 21 byte version:

```
lð¡“€ƒ€—€‹€‚“#Kvy0èuJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/5/CGQwsfNcx51LTm2CQg8ahhCpjcCSZnAWWUvcsqDQ6vKPX6/98rvyglMU/BP02hJCNVITy/KCcFAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 43 bytes

```
a:UCq^sFi,#a{`(OR|OF|AND|BY)`~=a@i?xOa@i@0}
```

definitely golfable, but I'm still learning regex

explanation:

```
a:UCq^s                                     input toUpper, split on " "
       Fi,#a{                             } iterate over a
             `(OR|OF|AND|BY)`~=a@i?xOa@i@0  if not exact match, output first char of this word
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0SrUuTCu2C1TRzmxOkHDP6jG363G0c@lxilSM6HONtEh077CH0g6GNT@/@@VX5SSmKfgn6ZQkpGqEJ5flJMCAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C# .NET](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 144 bytes

```
class P{static void Main(string[]a){foreach(var c in a[0].ToUpper().Split(' '))if(c!="OR"&c!="AND"&c!="BY"&c!="OF")System.Console.Write(c[0]);}}
```

[Try Online](https://tio.run/##Lc7BCoJAFIXhV7m50JlF0j5aWNGujEwipMVwHeuCzsjcQQjx2ScDdx//4nCQ18gYAraKGa4je@UJYbBUw1mREewdmXf1UnJsrNMKP2JQDhDIgKo2r/Ruy77XTsi06FvyIoFESmoErnZRfovi@I/scly0fy7IT5Esvux1lx6sYdvq9OHIa4HzqtxOUwihNHOooZhPaQbbQNZpR6h@)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
lð¡“€ƒ€—€‹€‚“#K€нu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/5/CGQwsfNcx51LTm2CQg8ahhCpjcCSZnAWWUvYHMC3tL///3yUzPKFFwzC3IyUzLTE4syczPU0iqVAguycwtzYFw89MUXHMzS0pSUxSCElMywYIA)

```
lð¡“€ƒ€—€‹€‚“#K€нu  # full program
                 u  # convert...
                н   # first character of...
               €    # each element of...
                    # implicit input...
l                   # in lowercase...
  ¡                 # split by...
 ð                  # spaces...
              K     # without any of the elements of...
   “€ƒ€—€‹€‚“       # "and or by of"...
             #      # split by spaces...
                 u  # to uppercase
                    # implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 68 bytes

```scala
_.toUpperCase.replaceAll("\\b(AND|OR|BY|OF) ?|(?<=\\b\\w)\\w+ ?","")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5hS8MwEIa/71e85FOLsh8gzhK7FZFpYbIPQkGuTbpF0iSk0Tmsv72mEwayD8fdvffce9c3pGm09btsAp5IGcivII3owZ3D9wz4JI32Bi/BK7PD4u5cjW/zYLfOSZ9TL@deOk2N5FonrKrqhD8vh3Iz3L8OZZEiG5LsdhH1qjqkMa6QsWvG0hFw0S5ok7QJ2xoVpEAfKMgetgB10qucszSd/QPXarcP4J3TqlUNBWUN6mN8TXUf@q@1LVadCpPfhoQ6iRc@j9YLOrHhQeJQ@rW4YLi1qMkj17SfyOWUyQhYj1WcRSmeLsjXx2n3Z/wF)

Not the most creative answer ever.

#### Without regex, 75 bytes

```scala
_.toUpperCase split " "filterNot Set("AND","OR","OF","BY")map(_(0))mkString
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/OKB9JUTTRc2VO2sf7AWZug)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 47 bytes

```
[ >upper R/ AND|OF|OR|BY|\B.| |/ ""re-replace ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxdS8NAEEXf8ysu@277bkFo8YMWaSClFFEf1s2kHUh218kEWlx/e1yNCM7bnHvvaazTION@t94@XMP2jhlCRzpH9PQ@kHfUIwqpXqKwVyyK4qNAPrP3rFRjp1ZzJzRYdiTsrJniRz6eNLPYcpOpcvB4u@Q6d0M7vXlz17F@Wypb8w/8XQ@TvP@T23/yTZDaepQN9EQ4BGlrU3yOz7gZYiRBNcdye5vK@1RWafWUXlazhDSHMUJXQrG1jvA6djZiNn4B)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RO“œẆḶuıdƓ“ROṗ€h
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPVJPJUUyJTgwJTlDJUM1JTkzJUUxJUJBJTg2JUUxJUI4JUI2dSVDNCVCMWQlQzYlOTMlRTIlODAlOUNSTyVFMSVCOSU5NyVFMiU4MiVBQ2gmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD11bml0ZWQlMjBzdGF0ZXMlMjBvZiUyMGFtZXJpY2EmZmxhZ3M9Sg==)

##### Explanation

```python
RO“œẆḶuıdƓ“ROṗ€h  # Implicit input
RO                # Uppercase and split on spaces
  “œẆḶuıdƓ“       # Compressed string "and or by of"
           RO     # Uppercase and split on spaces
             ṗ    # Remove these words
              €h  # First character of each
                  # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 26 bytes

```
@_M_N"OROFBYAND"CH4FNUCa^s
```

Takes the string as a command-line argument. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuha7HOJ94_2U_IP83ZwiHf1clJw9TNz8Qp0T44ohCqDqbqpFK5XmZZakpigUlySWpBYr5KcpANUr-AcpJFUqJOamFmUmJyrFQpUDAA)

A version that takes each word as a separate command-line argument would be **24 bytes** (replace `a^s` at the end with `g`). This *might* meet the spec, since the invocation would look something like:

```
pip.py acronym.pip United states of America
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJAX01fTlwiT1JPRkJZQU5EXCJDSDRGTlVDZyIsIiIsIiIsIlVuaXRlZCBzdGF0ZXMgb2YgQW1lcmljYSJd)

#### Explanation

```lisp
@_M_N"OROFBYAND"CH4FNUCa^s
                       a   ; Command-line argument
                     UC    ; Uppercase
                        ^s ; Split on spaces
                   FN      ; Filter, keeping elements for which this function is falsey:
     "OROFBYAND"           ;   Take that string
                CH4        ;   Chop it into 4 pieces: ["OR";"OF";"BY";"AND"]
   _N                      ;   Is the argument in that list?
  M                        ; Map this function to each remaining string:
@_                         ;   Get the first character
                           ; Join and autoprint (implicit)
```