# Produce n n-squares of integers with rotating *'s in consecuitive corners

Tags: code-golf, number, random

The objective is to produce output of n squares (nxn) of random integers (`0-9`) with a moving `*` that rotates clockwise around the corners, starting from the top left. The squares should be side by side and separated by a single space.

If `n = 0`, the output should be empty.

Output for `n=1`:

`*`

Output for `n=2`:

```
*3 4*
14 07
```

Output for `n=3`:

```
*34 82* 291
453 224 924
145 158 57*
```

Output for `n=4`:

```
*153 135* 0154 0235
2352 5604 3602 2065
2245 6895 3561 7105
7225 5785 479* *662
```

Notice how, for each square, the `*` rotates around the corners of the square, from left to right, beginning in the top left corner of the first, then moving to the top right of the second, and so on.

[image]

The shortest answer (measured in bytes) wins.

Comment: Please halp me understand this

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala, what aren't  you understanding specifically?

Comment: Please explain how it is possible that people can understand [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92834/counting-goats-to-sleep), and not what I'm asking.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is completely clear to me. Have made some minor edits. ("perfect square" sounded too much like the algebra term to me)

Comment: Nice first question by the way.

Comment: May we print them below each other instead of next to each other (with a blank line in between)? How about returning an N×N×N 3D array?

Comment: *separated by a single space* `*3  4*`

Comment: How "random" do the random numbers need to be? It's probably also worth being explicit in your question about the fact that the numbers need to be exactly N digits long, counting the asterisks as digits.

Comment: are trailing spaces ok?

Comment: <Shrug> Perhaps I'm being slow, but its still unclear to me.  Can you explain the placing of the `*`s in the `n=4` example?  Perhaps give some more examples?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, think of the first * as being at the 10 o'clock position, then the second being at the 2 o'clock position, then the third being at the 4 o'clock position, then the fourth at the 8 o'clock position, then the fifth at the 10 o'clock position, etc.

Comment: @Forwarding Where on the matrix is the centre of the "clock"?  Normally I would expect the 4 o'clock position to be directly underneath the 2 o'clock position, and the 8 o'clock position to be directly underneath the 10 o'clock position.

Comment: @JesseAmano, pseudorandom is fine.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, see my original post for an added image (bottom).

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I couldn't figure it out either until I realized that you're not printing one "clock," you're printing *n* clocks side-by-side (which was not at all clear from the question). So in the *n* = 4 example, you see four "clocks"—the first with the top row `*153`, the second with the top row `*135`, and so on.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I'm not sure if people have already directed you to it or not, but we do have a [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1). It's where you can post work-in-progress challenges and get meaningful feedback, like the kind received in the comments here, before posting the challenge to the main site.

Comment: @Jordan Thank you! Before your explanation I didn't understand case 4. Perhaps it should be specified somewhere in the question that each column is a separate clock. Apart from that, this looks like a good first question.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear per the comments on Dominic van Essen's answer about the lack of a definition for the term "pseudo-random integers".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```
3mF9Ý.R}J¹ô¹ävy`¦'*ìN4%©>ir}®iRr}®<iR})ˆ}¯øvyðý}»
```

**Explanation**

Examples for input = 4.

First we create a string of input^3 random numbers between 0 and 9.

```
3mF9Ý.R}J
```

producing

```
6799762549425893341317984133999075245812305412010122884262903656
```

Then we split that into pieces each the size of the input.
That is further split into input pieces.

```
¹ô¹ä
```

This gives us a matrix of numbers.

```
[['6799', '7625', '4942', '5893'], 
 ['3413', '1798', '4133', '9990'], 
 ['7524', '5812', '3054', '1201'], 
 ['0122', '8842', '6290', '3656']]
```

We then loop over the rows of the matrix, inserting asterisks in the right places.

```
v                          } # for each row in matrix 
 y`                          # flatten list to stack
   ¦'*ì                      # replace the first digit of the last number with "*"
       N4%©>ir}              # if row-nr % 4 == 0, move the number with "*" to the front
               ®iRr}         # if row-nr % 4 == 1, move the number with "*" to the front
                             # and reverse the number, moving "*" to the numbers right side
                    ®<iR}    # if row-nr % 4 == 2, reverse the number, moving "*" 
                             # to the numbers right side
                         )ˆ  # wrap row in a list and add to global array
```

Now we have the matrix with a "*" on each row, but we want an asterisk per column.

```
[['*893', '4942', '7625', '6799'], 
 ['099*', '4133', '1798', '3413'], 
 ['7524', '5812', '3054', '102*'], 
 ['0122', '8842', '6290', '*656']]
```

So we zip this list turning rows into columns and vice versa.

```
[['*893', '099*', '7524', '0122'], 
 ['4942', '4133', '5812', '8842'], 
 ['7625', '1798', '3054', '6290'], 
 ['6799', '3413', '102*', '*656']]
```

All that's left now is to format the output.

```
vyðý}»
```

Joining the rows on spaces and the columns on newlines gives us the final result.

```
*893 099* 7524 0122
4942 4133 5812 8842
7625 1798 3054 6290
6799 3413 102* *656
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=M21GOcOdLlJ9SsK5w7TCucOkdnlgwqYnKsOsTjQlwqk-aXJ9wq5pUnJ9wq48aVJ9KcuGfcKvw7h2ecOww719wrs&input=Ng)

**Old 50 byte solution**

```
F¹Fõ¹F9Ý.R«}}¦'*ì})¹ävyN4%©>iR}®iíÁ}®<ií}})øvyðý}»
```

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 47 bytes

```apl
{⍉⎕FMT'*'@((⍳⍵),¨⍵⍴2⍴¨1(⍵1)⍵(1⍵))⊢⎕D[?10⍴⍨3⍴⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pRb@ejvqluviHqWuoOGhqPejc/6t2qqXNoBZB61LvFCIgPrTAEim811AQSGoYgac1HXYuAulyi7Q0NgAoe9a4wBlNbY2v/pz1qm/Cot@9RV/Oj3jUg3euNH7VNBKoODnIGkiEensH/0xQMudIUjIDYGIhNgNgUAA)

Anonymous prefix lambda.

`{`…`}` "dfn"; n is called `⍵`

`⎕D[`…`]` index the list of digits with the indices:

`3⍴⍵` cyclically **r**eshape n into a list of length 3

`10⍴⍨` cyclically **r**eshape the number 10 into an array of those dimensions (3×n×n)

`?` random index (1…10) for each

`⊢` yield that as argument to the upcoming function (separates indices from data)

`'*'@(`…`)` place asterisks **at** the following locations:

`1(⍵1)⍵(1⍵)` the list `[1,[n,1],n,[1,n]]`

`2⍴¨` cyclically reshape each into a list of length 2: `[[1,1],[n,1],[n,n],[1,n]]`

`⍵⍴` cyclically reshape that list into length n

`(`…`),¨` prepend an element to each, taking elements from this list:

`⍳⍵` indices 1…n

`⎕FMT` ForMaT as character matrix (joins layers with a line of spaces)

`⍉` transpose

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, <s>370</s> ... <s>243</s> 242 bytes

```java
n->{int j=n*n,k,m=1;var a=new String[j];var r="";for(m*=Math.pow(10,n-1);j-->0;a[j]=(k*=Math.random())+m+r)k=9*m;for(;++j<n;m=k<2?0:n*n-n,a[m+j]=a[m+j].replaceAll(k%3<1?"^.":".$","*"))k=j%4;for(j=0;j<n*n;r+=j%n<1?"\n":" ")r+=a[j++];return r;}
```

Returns the result-String with trailing newline.

-51 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fZFNT8MwDIbv/AorYlLTtFUHCIml2cSRw8aB4xhS6Drol1ul6SY09bcX9@MKl1ixn7yOX2f6rP3smPdxoZsGtjrF6w1AijYxJx0nsBuuAG/WpPgFsUMVQC4p2d3Q0Vht0xh2gKB69NfXoZ4pdNHLvVINON9q@x3U1cVZhh76Sy7P2oBWmFxm2X12GHNGMSZPlXFk5vvrUGoqKCd31ahgNB6r0uFclMLwXD255QQLkUUoS5VHd5twRa199PS@FPR4CoFJ6oKGeS4KJ1/cR8sN@wjYigW3zGMu4ySWLR5GsUyFktRclEZQEgf2HYkFxilDPxLiIE1iW4NgZNfLwYW6/SzIhdmMc5UeoSQnnXm8A2g@2UgtYLQwBQWhpBApeKQoBIcJIa9/GpuUQdXaoKb3tkCHvWDd2hUwkY7e/4W9tnbi/qMwoDXymejGTXb9Lw)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                             // Method with integer parameter & String return-type
  int j=n*n,k,                   //  Index-integers
      m=1;                       //  Temp-integer
  var a=new String[j];           //  Create a String-matrix of size n by n
  var r="";                      //  Result-String, starting empty
  for(m*=Math.pow(10,n-1);       //  Start the temp-integer `m` at 10 to the power the
                                 //  input minus 1
      j-->0                      //  Loop `j` in the range [0,n²):
      ;                          //    After every iteration:
       a[j]=                     //     Set the j'th cell to:
         (k*=Math.random())      //      A random integer in the range [0,k)
         +m                      //      Add `m`
         +r;                     //      And then convert it to a String
    k=9*m;                       //   Set `k` to 9 multiplied by `m`, so the random
                                 //   integer will be in the range [0,9*m)
  for(;++j<n;                    //  Loop `j` in the range (-1,n):
      ;                          //    After every iteration:
       m=k<2?                    //     If `k` is 0 or 1:
             0                   //      Set `m` to 0 (first row)
            :                    //     Else:
             n*n-n,              //      Set `m` to n²-n instead (last row)
       a[m+j]=a[m+j].replaceAll( //     Then replace a digit in the (m*j)'th cell:
               k%3<1?            //      If `k` is 0 or 3 (first column):
                "^."             //       Replace its first digit
               :                 //      Else (last column instead):
                ".$",            //       Replace its last digit
               "*"))             //      And replace this digit with a "*"
    k=j%4;                       //   Set `k` to `j` modulo-4
  for(j=0;j<n*n;                 //  Loop `j` in the range [0,n²) again:
      ;                          //    After every iteration:
       r+=j%n<1?                 //     If `j` is divisible by `n`:
           "\n"                  //      Append a newline to the result
          :                      //     Else:
           " ";                  //      Append a space to the result instead
    r+=a[j++];                   //   Append the j'th value to the result
  return r;}                     //  Return the result-String
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP ,181 Bytes

```
for($i=-1;++$i<$c=($n=$argv[1])**3;){echo!($i%$q=$n*$n)?"\n":((!$m=$i%$n)?" ":"");echo(!$m&!($b=$i%$q/$n&3)|$m==$n-1&$b==1)&$i<$q|($m==$n-1&$b==2|!$m&$b==3)&$i>$c-$q?"*":rand(0,9);}
```

Comment: Can you make a "Try it online!"-version of this?

Comment: @forwarding [Test it](http://ideone.com/zuDswx)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>20</s> 19 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I could save a byte by either filling each square with the same random digit but

```
Æ²ÆAöÃ¬h* òU zXÃÕm¸
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=xrLGQfbDrGgqIPJVIHpYw9VtuA&input=OA)

### 18 bytes

By using the same random digit to fill each square. Dunno if that'd fit the definition of "pseudo-random" for this challenge, though.

```
Æ²çAö)h* òU zXÃÕm¸
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=xrLnQfYpaCog8lUgeljD1W24&input=OA)

```
Æ²ÆAöÃ¬h* òU zXÃÕm¸     :Implicit input of integer U
Æ                       :Map each X in the range [0,U)
 ²                      :  U squared
  Æ                     :  Map the range [0,U²)
   A                    :    10
    ö                   :    Random number in the range [0,A)
     Ã                  :  End map
      ¬                 :  Join
       h*               :  Replace 1st char with "*" (Handles the edge case of U=1 by instead inserting the "*" into the empty string)
          òU            :  Partitions of length U
             zX         :  Rotate 90 degrees clockwise X times
               Ã        :End map
                Õ       :Transpose
                 m      :Map
                  ¸     :  Join with spaces
                        :Implicit output, joined with newlines
```

```
Æ²çAö)h* òU zXÃÕm¸     :Implicit input of integer U
Æ²                     :As above
  ç                    :  Repeat to length U²
   Aö                  :   As above
     )                 :  End repeat
      h* òU zXÃÕm¸     :As above
                       :Implicit output, joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 27 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
иLdć'*0ǝšIGDøí})øJ»εDižhΩ]J
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9vc2FiaWX//9C4TGTEhycqMMedxaFJR0TDuMOtfSnDuErCu861RGnFvmjOqV1K//81) or [verify multiple dimensions](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W92bJKSZ15BaYmVgpK9nw6Xkn9pCYSn4@ei9P/CDp@UI@3qWgbH5x5d6OfucnjH4bW1mod3eB3afW6rS@bRfRnnVsZ6/VfSC9M5tM3@PwA).

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Create a matrix of the input by input amount of `1`s, with the top-left value replaced with a `"*"`:

```python
и          # Repeat the (implicit) input the (implicit) input amount of times as list
           # (e.g. 5 → [5,5,5,5,5])
 L         # Convert each inner integer to a list in the range [1,input]
  d        # Convert each inner integer to a 1 (with a >=0 check)
   ć       # Extract head; pop and push remainder-list and first item separated
    '*0ǝ  '# Replace the first item in this list with a "*"
        š  # Prepend this list back to the matrix
```

[Try just step 1 online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//wg6flCPt6loGx@ceXfj/vykA)

Step 2: Rotate it the input-1 amount of times clockwise and keep each intermediate matrix in a list:

```python
IG         # Loop the input-1 amount of times:
  D        #  Duplicate the current matrix
   øí      #  Rotate it once clockwise:
   ø       #   Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
    í      #   Reverse each inner row
 })        # After the loop: wrap all matrices on the stack into a list
```

[Try just the first 2 steps online.](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9vc2FiaWX//9C4TGTEhycqMMedxaFJR0TDuMOtfSn//zU)

Step 3: Format these lists of loose matrices to the output-format by putting them next to each other with space delimiter:

```python
ø          # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
 J         # Join each inner-most list together to a string
  »        # Join each inner lists by spaces, and then these lines by newlines
```

[Try just the first 3 steps online.](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9vc2FiaWX//9C4TGTEhycqMMedxaFJR0TDuMOtfSnDuErCu///NQ)

Step 4: Replace every 1 with a random digit, and output the final result:

```python
ε          # Map over each character in the multi-line string:
 D         #  Duplicate the current character
  i        #  Pop, and if it's a 1:
   žh      #   Push constant "0123456789"
     Ω     #   Pop and push a random digit from this
]          # Close both the if-statement and map
 J         # Join this list of characters back to a string again
```