# Counting Sheep to Fall Asleep

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Most people are familiar with the trope about counting sheep to fall asleep. There's a herd of sheep, some of them jumping over a fence, and you count the sheep as they jump. Supposedly, this helps quiet your mind and gets you into a sleep-like state so that you'll fall asleep.

Here's an ASCII sheep facing to the right, waiting to be counted:

```
'00^>
 ||
```

Here's an ASCII sheep jumping over a fence:

```
'00^>
 /\
 ++
```

Here's one facing to the left, having already been counted:

```
<^00'
  ||
```

#### The Challenge

Given two input integers, `n` and `m`, with `n > 2` describing how many sheep total, and `m > 0` saying how many sheep have already been counted, output an ASCII art representation of counting sheep to fall asleep.

**Now for the twist:**

- Due to the size of the pens the sheep are in, the top row can only hold a maximum of `10` sheep, not counting the currently jumping sheep which must also always be in the top row.
- The subsequent rows cannot have the sheep outside their respective pens (you can't have more sheep on the left in the second row than you do in the first row, and same for the right).
- If there are `11` or more total sheep, the top row must have `10` plus the jumping sheep in it.
- Leading/trailing whitespace, and whitespace between the sheep doesn't matter, so long as:

  1. There is a minimum of one whitespace character between sheep
  2. All the characters line up appropriately.

So long as these rules are met, the actual arrangement of the sheep is up to your implementation.

#### Examples

For example, here is `n=3` and `m=1`, the simplest case.

```
         '00^>
'00^>     /\      <^00'
 ||       ++        ||
```

Here is `n=11` and `m=6`, the most sheep that can fit on one horizontal line.

```
                        '00^>
'00^> '00^> '00^> '00^>  /\   <^00' <^00' <^00' <^00' <^00' <^00'
 ||    ||    ||    ||    ++     ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||
```

Here's a different example of that, with `n=11` and `m=1`

```
                                                      '00^>
'00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^>  /\   <^00'
 ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ++     ||
```

A bigger example with `n=30` and `m=12`

```
                                                '00^>
'00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^>  /\   <^00' <^00'
 ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ++     ||    || 

'00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^>       <^00' <^00'
 ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||           ||    || 

'00^>                                                 <^00' <^00'
 ||                                                     ||    || 

                                                      <^00' <^00'
                                                        ||    || 

                                                      <^00' <^00'
                                                        ||    || 

                                                      <^00' <^00'
                                                        ||    ||
```

Here's an example with `n=17` and `m=2`

```
                                                '00^>
'00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^>  /\   <^00' <^00'
 ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ++     ||    ||

'00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^>
 ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||
```

Here's an example with `n=19` and `m=3`

```
                                          '00^>
'00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^>  /\   <^00' <^00' <^00'
 ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ++     ||    ||    || 

'00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^> '00^>
 ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||    ||  

'00^>
 ||
```

Note that all of these are *examples*. For the last one, you may wind up creating a vertical array of sheep on the right-hand side, which will allow the left hand side to fit onto two rows instead. Or maybe a 2x2 square of sheep on the right-hand side, which would also fit the left-hand side sheep onto two rows. Etc.

### I/O and Rules

- Input can be taken in any reasonable format and [by any convenient method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/42963).
- Leading/trailing newlines or other whitespace are optional, provided that the characters line up appropriately.
- Either a full program or a function are acceptable. If a function, you can return the output rather than printing it.
- Output can be to the console, returned as a list of strings, returned as a single string, etc.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so all usual golfing rules apply, and the shortest code (in bytes) wins.

Comment: @Rod I added a bigger example, but note that it's only an *example* and your output could be different.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92834/counting-goats-to-sleep)

Comment: Recommended test case: `n=11` and `m=9`

Comment: @Adám There can be 10 test cases for `n=11` such that `0<m<=10`. This forces you to have all the sheep on the top row and a dynamic number of sheep on the left (`n-1-m`) and right (`m`) of the fence and cannot use fixed pen sizes.

Comment: @MT0 True, but one or two test cases should be enough to show that a solution works.

Comment: @Adám There exist two `n=11` test cases already. Do more test cases actually add anything at this point?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Yes, you don't have a case with less than 9 waiting but plenty of already counted. The two answers so far failed on such cases.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I changed your formatting slightly to "prettify" the part that used `1)` and `2)`. Feel free to roll it back.

Comment: [Also related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95099/so-sayeth-the-shepherd).

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 118 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous infix lambda. Takes `n` as left argument and `m` as right argument. Returns a nested array result, but the default display of this nested array follows specifications. Uses up to nine columns for counted sheep and remaining columns for waiting sheep.

```apl
{(r⍴(×/r←d,⍨⌈w÷d←10-⍵⌊⊢/r)↑w⍴(w←⍺-⍵+1)⍴⊂s@2⌽S)(↑(s←'>',⍨¯1↓b)' /\' ' ++')(r⍴(×/r←9,⍨⌈⍵÷9)↑⍵⍴⊂S←⌽↑''(b←'''00^<')' ||')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BasJAEIbvPsXeZpco2U1ADIj0HXIthUjQHAJKPISiQvEQJCTQ0oJ3T731oghCLuZN5kXizFIsvX3zz8/3R8t0EL9G6WLedTMs3tcyw/ok24Ob0RX3sf7Gap@3l5hOowdYn7EqsTy6mcLiI@dyTi@sr/xzjKIEy93qycOqCZWkklxRASbAstuPweJzqkC4zyBAOA6of5PB7yTJ2kvAGzxpnSHvVA1FAHLKTgCtX8ZAts0G1LZL2DDSLuDXG3S@mAnTS7KeMUTDB9nM10zeI/yjkSWPKLBkNfoO)

`{`…`}` anonymous lambda; `⍺` is left argument, `⍵` is right argument

This function has three distinct parts: **Waiting**, **Jumping**, and **Counted**. Each one is parenthesised, causing the result to be a three-element list.

#### Counted `(r⍴(×/r←9,⍨∘⌈⍵÷9)↑⍵⍴⊂S←⌽↑''(b←'''00^<')' ||')`

`''(`…`)' ||'` the three lines of a mirrored counted sheep, the middle one being:

`b←'''00^<'` the body and is assigned to `b`

`↑` mix the list of strings into a character matrix (padding with spaces)

`⌽` mirror that

`S←` assign to `S` (big **S**heep)

`⊂` enclose it so we can deal with it as a unit

`⍵⍴` use the number of counted sheep to cyclically reshape that

`(`…`)↑` take the following number of elements from that (padding with prototypical items, i.e. the same array but with all characters replaced by spaces)

`⍵÷9` a ninth of the number of counted sheep

`⌈` round up

`9,⍨` append 9 to that

`r←` assign to `r` (what we will **r**eshape with; rows and columns)

`×/` product of that list (this is how many elements we need, including fills)

`r⍴` reshape that to an array with the dimension lengths `r`

#### Jumping `(↑(s←'>',⍨¯1↓b)' /\' ' ++')`

`(`…`)' /\' ' ++'` the three lines of a jumping sheep, the first one being:

`¯1↓b` drop the last character from `b`

`'>',⍨` append a right-facing head

`s←` store in `s` (small **s**heep)

`↑` mix the list of strings into a character matrix (padding with spaces)

#### Waiting `(r⍴(×/r←d,⍨⌈w÷d←10-⍵⌊⊢/r)↑w⍴(w←⍺-⍵+1)⍴⊂s@2⌽S)`

`⌽S` mirror `S`

`s@2` put `s` **at** line 2 of that (replacing the current data there)

`⊂` enclose it so we can deal with it as a unit

`(`…`)⍴` cyclically reshape that to the following size:

`⍵+1` the number of counted sheep plus one

`⍺-` subtract that from the total

`w←` assign to `w` (**w**aiting)

`(`…`)↑` take the following number of elements from that (padding with prototypical items)

`⊢/r` the rightmost element of `r` (i.e. the number of used columns for counted sheep)

`⍵⌊` the minimum of total and that

`10-` subtract that from ten

`d←` assign to `d` (**d**ifference; missing columns)

`w÷` divide `w` by that

`⌈` round up (gives number of needed rows)

`d,⍨` append `d`

`r←` assign to `r` (what we will **r**eshape with; rows and columns)

`×/` product of that list (this is how many elements we need, including fills)

`r⍴` reshape that to an array with the dimension lengths `r`

Comment: @WeijunZhou You're right, will fix.

Comment: I was wondering how the heck I would answer this challenge. I guess that's how :p

Comment: @WeijunZhou Fixed.

Comment: "Always reserves nine columns for waiting sheep and a single column for counted sheep." Does this work for `n=11,m=9` and the rule "the top row must have 10 plus the jumping sheep in it."?

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript, <s>281</s>, <s>293</s>, 288 Bytes

```
a="      ";c=((n,m)=>{b="";for(i=0;i<(q=m>(o=(l=(t=n-m-1)?t:0)/9)?m:o);++i){for(j=0;j<3;++j){b+=[a,"'00^> "," ||   "][j].repeat(r=l>i*9?(z=o-i)>1?9:Math.ceil(z*9):0)+a.repeat((l>9?9:l)-r)+(i?"     ":["'00^>"," /\\  "," ++  "][j])+[a," <^00'","   || "][j].repeat(m>i?1:0)+"\n"}}return b});
```

#### Be careful when using the below snippet, there's a heavy risk of sudden induced narcolepsy.

```html
  <form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="n" placeholder="n (sheep total)">
    <input type="text" name="m" placeholder="m (sheep in right hand field)">
    <button type="submit">Let's Go!</button>    
  </form>

  <pre id="output">
  </pre>

  <script>
    a="      ";c=((n,m)=>{b="";for(i=0;i<(q=m>(o=(l=(t=n-m-1)?t:0)/9)?m:o);++i){for(j=0;j<3;++j){b+=[a,"'00^> "," ||   "][j].repeat(r=l>i*9?(z=o-i)>1?9:Math.ceil(z*9):0)+a.repeat((l>9?9:l)-r)+(i?"     ":["'00^>"," /\\  "," ++  "][j])+[a," <^00'","   || "][j].repeat(m>i?1:0)+"\n"}}return b});
      form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
  
        var n = parseInt(form.n.value);
        var m = parseInt(form.m.value);
  
        if(n != NaN && m != NaN){
          if(m > n){
            output.innerText = "C'mon man, how can you have more sheep in the right hand field than there are sheep in general?";
          }
          else{
            output.innerText = c(n, m);
          }
        }
        else{
          output.innerText = "Numbers only please.";
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: This shows 4 counted sheep for n=50, m=3 and also has misaligned sheep for n=20, m=3. Also n=20, m=1 shows 2 counted sheep.

Comment: Fixed those errors. Also found some sheep were escaping due to rounding errors.

Comment: If `m = n` you get an error.

Comment: This is a scenario that i assumed could be ignored. The way the question was written stated that:
m = The count of sheep on the right hand side
n = The count of sheep in total
And that there's a sheep also jumping the fence. Therefore n cannot be equal to m, i therefore didn't account for it.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 392 bytes

*Thanks to @Jonathan Frech for saving a byte!*

```c
#define F;for(
x,y,k;p(L,a,b,t)char L[][78];{F k=5;k--;)L[x=a*4+(t<2)][y=b*6+k]=t?"'00^>"[k]:"<^00'"[k];L[++x][y-=~!t]=47;L[x][++y]=92;L[x][--y]=L[x+=(t>1)][y]=t<2?'|':43;}i,l;f(n,m){char L[i=n*4][78]F;i--;){F L[i][l=77]=0;l--;)L[i][l]=32;}F l=n+~m;++i<l&&i<9+!m;)p(L,0,i,1);l-=i;p(L,0,i++,2)F;i<11&&m--;)p(L,0,i++,0)F i=0;l--;)p(L,++i,0,1)F i=1;m-->0;)p(L,i++,10,0)F l=0;l<i*4;)puts(L+l++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY9NTsMwEIX3PYUbRGvHjmQngVAmLruscoPUSKUQsPIDaoPUqrRXL@ME1AXd4ZXnezNv3qyC19XqdLp6filt@0IyKN/XdLQVO1HBB83FUjyJjq3elmuSF6ZI7gzsM1LpG6iCAFhebPXSjznt0pCZYqef/FteGd09eFMpH@deUZl7L32Ucuq@kBecb7Ev0MdxZ3ScIMGa853Rs3AoggAL/HFNu7lyruiXhg/Tr@l9HMHBihpK2oqG7X9yWd36cR8uA@tiYUSkpqh1khgtoR6yOmJ0FMIhI7Vu@bEBzm1aTyY2nfFxA8ydLIUViuGMtvBTcy5Cht6pUpNJ48zOgmQZsb87HEZLlFSPFWD3XA6C61ayH6jdQGr9GJXPbkNzXnPO4HCybUeapW0pG@1HBF9/or/RXvDvt2g96D0/1rimpN6ivd4gFGTDBqGkkSB4e5/pDJUS5PYi/dsbSaTh3@ZEkAt0Jkh00XiGdEjp@OH0DQ)

**Unrolled:**

```c
#define F;for(

x, y, k;
p(L, a, b, t) char L[][78];
{
    F k=5; k--;)
        L[x=a*4+(t<2)][y=b*6+k] = t ? "'00^>"[k] : "<^00'"[k];

    L[++x][y-=~!t] = 47;
    L[x][++y] = 92;
    L[x][--y] = L[x+=(t>1)][y] = t<2 ? '|' : 43;
}

i, l;
f(n, m)
{
    char L[i=n*4][78]
    F; i--;)
    {
        F L[i][l=77]=0; l--;)
            L[i][l] = 32;
    }

    F l=n+~m; ++i<l&&i<9+!m;)
        p(L,0,i,1);

    l-=i;
    p(L,0,i++,2)

    F; i<11&&m--;)
        p(L,0,i++,0)

    F i=0; l--;)
        p(L,++i,0,1)

    F i=1; m-->0;)
        p(L,i++,10,0)

    F l=0; l<i*4;)
        puts(L+l++);
}
```

Comment: `y+=1+!t` can be `y-=~!t`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Yep, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>222</s> 277 bytes

```python
n,m=input();n-=m+1
s=" '00^>"
j=1;L='  ||  '
a,b=[[[5,5],[10-m,m]][m<9],[n,10-n]][n<9]
print' '*6*a+s
while n>0 or 0<m:N,M=min(n,a),min(m,b);n-=a;m-=b;print '%-*s'%(6*a,N*s),'%5s'%('/\  '*j)+'%*s'%(6*b,M*" <^00'")+'\n'+'%*s'%(-6*a,N*L),'%5s'%('++  '*j),'%*s'%(6*b,M*L)+'\n';j=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7RasMwDEXf8xUiEJTYMrMHGbSO@wVpf8BNIYFCE2Y1NBlj0H/P3GZj7E3nSkfc8Wu@XPl1WZiC63n8mPPCsnJBmmRyKaDWp12aDM7Y2iHA/Q6ASUud896XVDbkjVaBQtP4UG0iMsWAI3LEZLz1PCOgeBOtnJLPS/9@Bt5puN5AV2F7oL0LPedMbUGPIVD3LNDaoFxnnz5gpsSEWR6f0EFMBWFWPhhfjrGOGAqJ2c9BR3uRQnXSGtMYHxl/d2q16z9bytWmf3a9anZwelmMJvMN)

Comment: Fails on [`n=11` and `m=2`](https://tio.run/##TYxBCoMwEEX3OcUgyKiJNFHcVOMJ1BOI4KKg0IxiLKXg3a2pC7v5PD68N3/WYaJk30kYPdL8WoMwp1gbrpjVHqCUXemxeRlpRcAoVdyyXqu80giwbQDI3sP4fACVEqYFZGHujai1GSkgkYXCgTnAVbPcuPnVAP04VRb9oIlsKNDPHOOtPZJR745UuqeOPCg6KdELObaE/M@rLo/zy1OnV51C3mu570oJSL4 "Python 2 – Try It Online").

Comment: I don't get 11 sheep on the first row when I ran this.

Comment: @RobertBenson Thanks, fixed

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 293 bytes

```
{f=" '00^>"
l="  ||  " 
L="  /\\   "
p="  ++   "
Y=$2
X=$1-Y-1
E="      "
x=$1>11?Y<5?10-Y:X>5?5:X:X
y=$1>11?X<5?10-X:5:Y
printf"%"6*(x+1)"s\n",f
for(;X>0||Y>0;A=B=""){for(i=0;i++<x;B=B (X>=0?l:E))A=A (--X>=0?f:E)
A=A L
B=B p
for(i=0;i++<y&&--Y>=0;B=B l)A=A"<^00' "
print A"\n"B"\n"
L=p=E" "}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDBasMwDL3rK4To2mSZmdUsHXNqhwRy6wfYEAq9BMJCF7rBUpp@e2ZnO@zyeHrvSUg6fb/P863VhBspj4ag9xSnCZEQDoE/Nw36CoZQJMnCnV5tweoVCycY6uDgYoxeM8yF22cFS@GUNVmRKassXP8s@2tZlSkHw6U7f7X0QLvHaEw4ps/mTE8ttB@XKLdGTpMzMi91pYniW1A7LfMuSfZjXukKI2u0LHpVx3GpS4yEWITWCxCEA4TUAP87r@u1EM7Hlgl9aKT9UcpNODLsgyX5LaoA/gWDrgnpfp9nfkMJKTIw4y4AQyqRt8CvuAC/gM@k8AM)

I tried using string substitutions to avoid some loops, but it took a lot more code.

**Explanation**

```
{f=" '00^>"    Let's assign
l="  ||  "     some variables
L="  /\\   "   for the ASCII
p="  ++   "    pieces
Y=$2        The number of sheep that have already jumped
X=$1-Y-1    Sheep patiently waiting to jump
E="      "  A string to keep things spaced properly
x=$1>11?Y<5?10-Y:X>5?5:X:X  If there's enough sheep, let's use 5 per column
y=$1>11?X<5?10-X:5:Y        Otherwise, use enough to get 11 sheep in first row
printf"%"6*(x+1)"s\n",f     Print the top part of the jumping sheep
for(;X>0||Y>0;A=B=""){      Loop until we've printed all the sheep
  for(i=0;i++<x;              Loop over waiting sheep in this row
    B=B (X>=0?l:E))             Build the "legs" string
      A=A (--X>=0?f:E)            Build the "bodies" string
  A=A L                       Add the legs and post 
  B=B p                       for the jumping sheep
  for(i=0;i++<y&&--Y>=0;   Loop over the jumped sheep in this row
    B=B l) A=A"<^00' "     Add to the "legs" and "bodies" string 
  print A"\n"B"\n"         Print what we've got so far
  L=p=E" "                 Prevent the jumping sheep's parts from printing lots of times
}}
```

I must say the sheep art is rather cute. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 98 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔⁻⊖ＮθηＦ⟦⟦00¶/\¶++ θ⌊⟦⌈⟦⁵⁻χη⟧θ⟧⟧⟦0^>¶\¶+  η⌊⟦⌈⟦⁵⁻χθ⟧η⟧⟧⟧«Ｊ⁰¦⁰‖Ｔ§ι⁰↗Ｆ§ι¹«<^00'¶  || ↗¿¬﹪⊕κ§ι²”|Ｉ4Ｏ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDNasMwEITP8VMsvnRFUuq09NAfCoFeUnAoIT1ZDri2Eovaki3LIdDk2d2VEmigh64QiNn5RivlZWZynVXDMFdNbxd9/SkMtuwpmHWd3CqMpeo7fBW5EbVQVhR4aWRsAi3tkoCNNoBJEkYRVzecczUeQ0jtCVCGrPsakzjbnw73XqTgaeTg1MWkLJ0A4esXrjwODi//xVuPl4SnDL6D0VtfNyuN1IloqtFSbCqR25XJVEcj1ujEdyOVxZmdq0LsUTqrk2O9E/j40SzltrRO8G@6sE2Zv@LMh8/rKLriCuBwgND5/yaM5AZwoS3GuugrTb/3@5NfNPdF@C2jgnM0N24BlQ8@BsdhuAumD8P1rvoB) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the number of sheep that have already been counted.

```
≔⁻⊖Ｎθη
```

Input the total number of sheep and calculate how many still need to be counted.

```
Ｆ⟦⟦00¶/\¶++ θ⌊⟦⌈⟦⁵⁻χη⟧θ⟧⟧⟦0^>¶\¶+  η⌊⟦⌈⟦⁵⁻χθ⟧η⟧⟧⟧«
```

Create an array of two arrays. Each array has the following elements:

- A string containing half of the jumping sheep
- The number of sheep on that side of the fence
- The number of sheep in one row on that side of the fence, which is either

  - the number of sheep on that side of the fence, if fewer than 5, or
  - 10 - the number of sheep on the other side of the fence, if fewer than 5, or
  - 5, if both sides have at least 5 sheep

```
Ｊ⁰¦⁰‖Ｔ§ι⁰↗
```

Reflect the canvas and print the half jumping sheep.

```
Ｆ§ι¹«
```

Loop through the sheep on that side.

```
<^00'¶  || ↗
```

Print a sheep.

```
¿¬﹪⊕κ§ι²”|Ｉ4Ｏ
```

If this is the end of the row then print some newlines and spaces to get to the start of the next sheep.