# Blink the CAPS LOCK

Tags: code-golf, keyboard, hardware

Most computer keyboards feature a small integrated LED light,
indicating the current input mode, as controlled with the CAPS LOCK button.

[image]

Your task is to blink it:

- Turn it on;
- Wait for 0.5 (+/-0.1) seconds;
- Turn it off again.

Video footage of the LED blinking is highly appreciated !

### Rules

- You can blink a different LED (e.g. Scroll Lock, Num Lock, Wi-Fi status etc), if you wish, but it must be physically located on your keyboard;
- If your language is missing a subsecond `sleep` command, your program may use a 1 second delay instead, at a penalty of +2 bytes (that's for `0.`);
- Your program must blink at least once, what happens afterward is up to you, i.e. it can continue to blink (in which case you must wait for the same delay, before turning it on again), or halt e.t.c.;
- If the chosen LED is ON by default, on your system, you can assume that it has been explicitly switched off (e.g. manually), before the program is run;
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=110974,OVERRIDE_USER=61904;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Cheating answer that doesn't quite work: on a Linux system, intentionally crash the kernel. Linux's equivalent of a BSOD flashes the Caps Lock light, just in case the crash also took down the video hardware and you can't see the BSOD report onscreen. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell it flashes a little too fast to be an eligible answer. This would lead to a (somewhat malicious) 14-byte solution if it were allowed.

Comment: Does it need to be an LED, or can it be any type of indicator light on the keyboard?

Comment: @12Me21 Well, it's a tricky one, I'm probably ok with a different type of indicator, as long as it is a dedicated hardware thing, which sole purpose is to indicate that something is on or off, e.g. blinking a pixel on a general purpose touch screen does not count.

Comment: Now blink it in Morse code: "Help, I'm trapped in a keyboard factory!"

Comment: @ais523 my laptop will do that if I shake it (0 bytes). Too fast tho...

Comment: The capslock key on a C64 is a mechanical switch.  Blinking that might be a bit tricky...

Comment: @Mark, still can be done with a bit of Arduino and some type of actuator, not sure on how to include them in the byte count though.

Comment: I want to see an Objective-c or Swift answer toggling the capslock on an iPhone keyboard

Comment: Now I'm wondering whether the low-battery LED on my wireless keyboard flashes at the correct rate. If so: zero bytes.

Comment: Is it okay if we write a snippet (I'm thinking about Swift, where writing an entire program is literally making a whole app).

Comment: @Dopapp, by default, you should either submit a full program or a function,
so you can probably just do the latter.

Comment: @mbomb007 I wrote that patch once :)

Comment: @mbomb007 [Cameras can steal data from computer hard drive LED lights](https://phys.org/news/2017-02-cameras-hard.html). "The researchers found that once malware is on a computer, it can indirectly control the HDD LED, turning it on and off rapidly (thousands of flickers per second)—a rate that exceeds the human visual perception capabilities. As a result, highly sensitive information can be encoded and leaked over the fast LED signals, which are received and recorded by remote cameras or light sensors."

Comment: @KeithMcClary Even more impressive is that data may be exfiltrated from an air-gapped machine (up to 8 bits per hour) using room [temperature fluctuations](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7243739/) created by changing the amount of heat the machine generates. [Other methods](http://hackaday.com/2017/02/02/hacking-the-aether/)

Comment: @whrrgarbl - I believe most implementations here will actually be longer without the loop, as this way they don't have to repeat the code to turn the Caps Lock (or whatever indicator they use) off. Otherwise, it is not required (i.e. you can just blink once).

Comment: I made a code golf puzzle inspired by this one, called "[Blink the webcam light!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111375/blink-the-webcam-light)" Is this okay? I've given the appropriate credit, including linking to both [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110974/blink-the-caps-lock) and [your user profile](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61904/zeppelin) on [codegolf.se].

Comment: @haykam I'm fine with that, it's actually nice to hear that my challenge has inspired you to post your own.

Comment: @zeppelin if my language has a way to do a subsecond sleep but it's more than 2 bytes longer than a 1 second sleep, can I choose to take the penalty for the 1 sec sleep?

Comment: @briantist This rule was introduced to allow languages which can not do a sub-second delay to still compete, so if your language can do a sub-second delay, I would say that you have to use that. However, I release that there might be some borderline cases (e.g. there is a sub-second delay command, but it is not documented or is only available in some implementations but not the others), in those cases I rely on the community to do its vote.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe you would need a program to drain the battery then ;)

Comment: By the way, why a two-byte penalty for a one second delay? In many languages (e.g., C) you can just drop the zero and write ".5".

Comment: @Ale, in some languages you can shortcut it to .5, but in others it would be `500` or `0.5` instead, I was trying to find a compromise here.

Comment: @zeppelin right didn't think that even in C it would have even been a usleep(500000)... as it doesn't take floating point parameters

Comment: @mbomb007 lol beat me to it

Comment: @DLosc are you there? It really deserves a QBasic answer!

Answer (score 130):

## Befunge (BEF32), <s>390</s> <s>334</s> 305 bytes

This is really silly, but as long as this site accepts the notion that [the interpreter defines the language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7833/62101), I might as well abuse the rule. This code only works in Kevin Vigor's Win32 Befunge-93 Implementation, version 1.01 (I think the only version available). You can download the binary [here](http://www.club.cc.cmu.edu/%7Eajo/funge/quadium.net/funge/downloads/befun.zip).

```
p55p99+5p65*5p")"5p"M"3*"I~q"+\3*3445"|"2*"lm"2v
v"y"*3\*2"e/n"4\5"nnIn"*833*2"mn"4\7"nnIn"*833*<
>2*"yO"4"DJG"3*\2*55*3"T"4"DLG"3*\2*55*3"/~M"+\3*4446"~A"+4v
>+00p9p:v:"l'"*2"^D"4"l3"*2"^D"4"l"*54*2"^D"4"l"*2+94*2"^D"<
^1:g00-4_5"u1"*-:1+:1+"@"\0p"%"5*\0p"P"\0p@
Sleep kernel32.dll keybd_event user32.dll
```

Now normally you wouldn't expect this sort of challenge to be possible in a Befunge, but BEF32 is a Win32 port of a very old version of the reference implementation, and back then there was no bounds checking on the `p` (put) command. This effectively allows us to write to any location in memory, which ultimately lets us force the interpreter to execute arbitrary machine code.

Now we can't actually alter any of the existing code, since the .text section of the executable won't have write permissions. However, we can trick the system into executing an address in the .data section, by writing that address into the the runtime library's `atexit` table (at least I suspect that's what it is). The end result is that our code is automatically executed when the interpreter exits.

This relies on the fact that the executable is loaded at a fixed address, so we know exactly where everything is in memory - it assumedly wouldn't work if you overrode the default [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows) settings. It also relies on the .data section being executable, despite not having the executable attribute set, so again it most likely wouldn't work if you overrode the default [DEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection) settings.

The code itself is essentially a copy of [Mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45941/mego)'s `keybd_event` technique translated into machine code:

```
6823B84000         push "keybd_event"
682FB84000         push "user32.dll"
6810B84000         push "Sleep"
6816B84000         push "kernel32.dll"
BB02000000         mov  ebx,2
               initloop:
89C7               mov  edi,eax
FF1594D14000       call LoadLibraryA
50                 push eax
FF1590D14000       call GetProcAddressA
4B                 dec  ebx
75EE               jnz  initloop
89C6               mov  esi,eax
               flashloop:
6A00               push 0
6A01               push 1
6A45               push 69
6A14               push 20
FFD6               call esi
6A00               push 0
6A03               push 3
6A45               push 69
6A14               push 20
FFD6               call esi
68F4010000         push 500
FFD7               call edi
EBE3               jmp  flashloop
```

This version of the code continues flashing forever (or at least until you kill the process), since that turned out to be easier to golf than a single flash.

And since everyone is posting animations, this is an approximation of what it looks like on my keyboard.

[image: Animation of the capslock light flashing]

Comment: People usually abuse rules in order to make life easier for them, but those are not Befunge coders :)

Comment: Never expected an esolang answer to this challenge +1

Comment: This is now my favourite answer on this site

Comment: Excellent implementation!

Comment: While I very much appreciate all the upvotes, and the bounty (thank you @Pureferret), I feel obliged to point out that for a code golf challenge this is literally the worst answer here!

Comment: @JamesHolderness So? This is a great answer, even if it is long.

Answer (score 73):

## AutoHotkey, <s>29</s> 26 bytes

<sub>*Thanks to @Dane for saving 3 bytes*</sub>

```
Loop{
Send,{VK14}
Sleep,500
}
```

I originally chose `NumLock` because it's one character shorter than `CapsLock`. The GIF below reflects that condition. It's the same effect as the altered code above. I could have gone with `VK90` above to make the GIF still be accurate but aligning with the original challenge felt better.

[image: BlinkingNumLock]

---

In honor of [mbomb007's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110974/blink-the-caps-lock#comment270217_110974), here's a morse code message in **239 bytes**:

```
s:=000090901009011091100110090111109111901090190110901109091000091001101909101191000911190190109100001090191010919111901091011
Loop,123{
StringMid,c,s,A_Index,1
IfEqual,c,9
{
Sleep,2000
Continue
}
Send,{NumLock}
Sleep,%c%500
Send,{NumLock}
Sleep,500
}
```

Here are the first 30 seconds of that message:

[image: MorseCodeBlinking]

Comment: How about `send,{vk14}` instead to shave off 3 bytes? Bonus: you'd be blinking the CapsLock.

Answer (score 34):

## [GFA-Basic 3.51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GFA_BASIC) (Atari ST),  <s>61 56 43</s>  35 bytes

This code will make the floppy drive LED blink forever at the required rate (`PAUSE 25` = pause for 25 / 50 second).

This would probably be shorter in assembly, but I don't have the appropriate tools at my fingertips. This is the size of the GFA-Basic listing once saved in .LST format and manually edited to remove useless whitespace, rename instructions to shorter strings and replace each `CR+LF` with a simple `CR`. Note that a final `CR` is required.

```
DO
i=i XOR2
SP &HFF8802,i
PA 25
LO
```

Will automatically expand to:

```
DO
  i=i XOR 2
  SPOKE &HFF8802,i
  PAUSE 25
LOOP
```

`SPOKE` is a supercharged `POKE` that first puts the 68000 in *supervisor* mode, so that it's allowed to access restricted memory areas (here: the *register write* address of the YM2149 soundchip, which is also responsible for some other I/O).

And yes: the LED is physically located on the keyboard ... I suppose.

[image: ST Floppy LED]

<sup>*I don't have access to a real ST right now, so this is just a mockup.*</sup>

Comment: Floppy drive! Wow!

Comment: Hand-drawn red circle missing ...

Answer (score 24):

## [fish](https://fishshell.com) + [ckb](https://github.com/ccMSC/ckb), <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```
while cd;echo rgb (random)|tee /d*/*/*/c*;sleep .5;end
```

Blinks my entire keyboard in random colors, though since the number isn't 6 hex digits long it's a bit limited.

[image]

And yes, that shell glob is potentially dangerous. Works On My Machine™

Bonus script, 8 months later: This will go through all colors. Not golfed.

```
#!/usr/bin/fish
while true
        echo rgb (printf '%06x' (random 0 16777215)) | tee /dev/input/ckb*/cmd > /dev/null
        sleep 0.5
end
```

Comment: Which keyboard is it? lol

Comment: @McKernel bump curious as to what keyboard that is as well

Comment: K70 RGB with custom keycaps - https://unascribed.com/f/67209fe8_keyboard_design.svg

Comment: Bonus points for going above and beyond by making the entire keyboard blink.

Comment: `tee /d*/*/*/c*`? Bonus points for being liable to brick some poor sod's computer in the future when this inevitably expands to something important. (EFI variables anyone? Maybe there'll be something like `/dev/efi/vars/cpu_type`)

Answer (score 21):

## Bash + amixer, 45 Bytes

```
a() { amixer set Master toggle
}
a;sleep .5;a
```

Blinks the mute light on my keyboard.

[image]

Comment: `a()(amixer set Master toggle;sleep .5;a)` or `amixer set Master toggle;sleep .5;$0` as a full program are a bit shorter.

Answer (score 19):

### C (Windows), 79 bytes

```c
#include<windows.h>
k(n){keybd_event(20,69,n,0);}f(){k(1);k(3);Sleep(500);f();}
```

#### Explanation

[`keybd_event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304%28VS.85%29.aspx) is a (deprecated) Windows API function to send a keyboard event (keyup or keydown). `20` is the code for the Caps Lock key, `69` is the hardware scan code (I have no idea what that means), and `1` means keydown and `3` means keyup. A keypress is simulated by sending a keydown event immediately followed by a keyup event. One keypress is sent to turn on Caps Lock, then the program sleeps for 500 milliseconds, and then another keypress is sent to turn Caps Lock back off.

Thanks to Steadybox for a bunch of bytes saved

Comment: Given this is C, can you not declare `int keybd_event();`?

Comment: @Neil It would be `void keybd_event();`, and I also need `void Sleep();` from `windows.h`. Those two declarations together are longer than the include.

Comment: D'oh, I totally overlooked `Sleep`. (But C doesn't really care if something doesn't return `int` if you don't use the result.)

Comment: @Neil There would still be a return type mismatch between the declarations and the definitions.

Comment: 79 bytes: `#include<windows.h>
k(n){keybd_event(20,69,n,0);}f(){k(1);k(3);Sleep(500);f();}`

Comment: Sure, but for primitive types, C doesn't care about the mismatch if you never use the result.

Comment: @Neil Regardless, the `windows.h` header also does a lot of other preprocessing needed to make things work. That's not how C is supposed to be done, but it's Windows...

Comment: Scan codes are what your keyboard sends over the wire at the lowest level. Their values are based on positions in a standard layout because doing that let them make the keyboard as dumb as possible and without having to wire each key up (limitations of this design are part of why cheaper keyboards can only return a few simultaneous keystrokes - the baseline USB keyboard interface then baked the limitation into the vast majority of keyboards about 20 years ago by designing to the min std) at the cost of offloading a translation step onto the host computer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode

Comment: I didn't even see this answer and wrote the C# version, nice!

Answer (score 16):

## MATLAB, <s>146</s> <s>136</s> 70

*Thanks to [@Poke](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51785/poke) for removing 66 bytes!*

```
r=java.awt.Robot;while 1
r.keyPress(20)
r.keyRelease(20)
pause(.5);end
```

This uses Matlab's ability to call Java classes. The Caps Lock light is blinked in a loop by programmatically pressing and releasing <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.

[Video or it didn't happen](https://youtu.be/QFBwFunc9qs).

Comment: Can you use `144` instead of `java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_NUM_LOCK`? CAPS_LOCK would be `20`

Comment: @Poke Yes! There go 66 bytes!!

Comment: Funny that it's shorter than the java answer

Answer (score 16):

### x86 machine code for PC (e.g. MS-DOS COM file), 27 bytes

This machine code (displayed here with a Unicode rendering of the usual CP437 of PC BIOS) will blink the CAPS LOCK indicator forever on a PC:

```
j@▼î▐j`Z░φεê╪εÇ≤♦╞♦◙Ç<☺t∩δ∙
```

The code has been made so it contains no NULL bytes, and can thus be typed with the keyboard (using the Alt+XXX trick for extended characters) to create a COM file (e.g., using the `COPY CON blink.com` command under MS-DOS, in which case the output file will have to contain a spurious 28<sup>th</sup> byte, the `^Z` (EOF) character required to stop the copy operation).

The effect is achieved by directly sending commands to the keyboard controller of the PC (port 60h) to set the LED state (as a side-effect, it might set Num Lock and Scroll Lock LEDs to a random non-blinking state). The timing, to minimize the number of instructions, is achieved by using the countdown timer maintained by the BIOS at address `0040:0040` (it decrements every 54.925 ms, with 9 cycles the blinking cycle is 494.3 ms, which is within the allowed margin) — this counter is normally used by the BIOS to stop the floppy disk motor; as the floppy drive is not used by the program and the code is assumed to run in a single-task environment (e.g. DOS), playing with the floppy motor timer is not an issue.

The code runs fine under MS-DOS (tried with VirtualBox, it should also run fine on real hardware, although I didn't have the time yet to make a bootable MS-DOS USB stick to test). As it doesn't rely on any OS functions, it can even run without the operating system (e.g., by placing it in the boot sector of a disk). It requires at least a 80186 processor to run, because of the "immediate push" instructions used to shorten the code of some bytes.

Assembly source code:

```
  PUSH 0x40               ; pushes 0x0040 (BIOS data segment) on the stack
  POP DS                  ; pops it into DS segment selector
  MOV SI, DS              ; copies DS to SI (timer counter is nicely placed at 40:40)
  PUSH 0x60               ; pushes 0x0060 (kbd controller port) on the stack
  POP DX                  ; pops it to DX
loop:
  MOV AL, 0xED            ; 8042 keyboard controller 'set mode indicators' command
  OUT DX, AL              ; outputs the command to the keyboard contr oller
  MOV AL, BL              ; copy BL register to AL
  OUT DX, AL              ; outputs LED state to keyboard controller
  XOR BL, 4               ; toggles bit 2 (CAPS LOCK) for next iteration
  MOV BYTE PTR[SI], 0x0A  ; sets floppy motor countdown timer to 10
wait:
  CMP BYTE PTR[SI], 0x01  ; checks if timer reached 1
  JE loop                 ; if yes, time for next iteration
  JMP wait                ; if not, checks again
```

Hexadecimal dump of the assembled code:

```
6A 40 1F 8C DE 6A 60 5A B0 ED EE 88 D8 EE 80 F3 04 C6 04 0A 80 3C 01 74 EF EB F9
```

Here is the result running under MS-DOS in VirtualBox (doesn't work with DosBox, presumably because the keyboard controller is not completely emulated):

[image: Blinking CAPS LOCK]

(sorry for the shaky video).

Comment: An example of actually using `copy con program.exe` : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iefuJ_jZAiQ

Answer (score 13):

## SmileBASIC, <s>36</s> 23 bytes

```
XON MIC
WAIT 30XOFF MIC
```

Blinks the microphone status light.
(video coming soon)

Answer (score 13):

## Python2 - 108 bytes

Does the capslock key. Interestingly, this actually turns on just the LED itself without affecting the keyboard or pressing the key. You can change the `4` at the end to `2` to do numlock. `6` does both.

```
import fcntl,os,time;exec"fcntl.ioctl(os.open('/dev/console',os.O_NOCTTY),19250,%d);time.sleep(.5);"*2%(4,0)
```

Comment: Looks like I got an error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Comment: @haykam are you on Windows?

Comment: No, I'm on `macOS Sierra Version 10.12.1 (16B2555)`.

Answer (score 8):

## shell+numlockx, <s>40</s> 35 bytes

[Saved 5 bytes thanks to Ryan.]

Continually blinks the NumLock light on unixish systems.

```
numlockx toggle;sleep .5;exec sh $0
```

## Single blink, 33 bytes

```
numlockx on;sleep .5;numlockx off
```

Comment: You can use `exec sh $0` instead of `while` to save 5 bytes, or `sh $0` if creating processes forever is considered okay.

Comment: `watch -n0.5 numlockx toggle`   for 27 bytes.

Comment: For a different flavour of the above, on interactive shells, you could type in: `numlockx toggle;sleep .5;!#` (27 bytes) for a single blink . `!#` is the history expansion event replaced by everything typed so far in the command line.

Comment: in the single blink command, the `on` can be omitted. it's the default.

Comment: With assignments, no tricks: `f=numlockx;$f;sleep .5;$f off` (29). And (an inferior) looping version using recursion: `g(){ f=numlockx;$f toggle;sleep .5;g;};g` (40).

Answer (score 8):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 71 bytes

```powershell
for(){(New-Object -c WScript.Shell).SendKeys('{NUMLOCK}');sleep -m 500}
```

#### Notes

- Blinks forever
- Uses <kbd>NUM LOCK</kbd> to save a byte.

Comment: "If your language is missing a subsecond sleep command..." - doesn't sound like it's missing from PowerShell.

Comment: @Dane I've asked the poster for clarification. If electing to accept the penalty is not allowed I will revert it.

Comment: @Dane rolled back.

Comment: How come sleep .5 doesn't work here? I tried it and it seems to go at like 5ms but I thought by default it's (-s) so it would be 0.5 s?

Comment: @JakeHarry: The `-Seconds` parameter is an `int`, so `0.5` will be converted to `int`, which results in `0` (round to even is the default rounding mode). So you're not sleeping at all (results in a delay of about 1000 ticks here, so 10 µs). Fairly basic conversion and parameter binding rules in PowerShell.

Answer (score 7):

## VBS, 75 bytes

```
do
wscript.sleep 500
Createobject("wscript.shell").sendkeys"{numlock}"
loop
```

Repeatedly blinks Num Lock key, as `numlock` is 1 byte shorter than `capslock`.

Answer (score 7):

### C#, <s>215</s> <s>202</s> <s>198</s> <s>195</s> 185 bytes

<s>Without realising I have done the "same" code as [this answer by @Mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110985/38550), go check it out!.</s>

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32")]static extern void keybd_event(int v,int s,int f,int e);n=>{for(n=0;;System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(125))keybd_event(20,69,n++&2,0);};
```

*Saved 13 bytes thanks to @Metoniem*
*Saved 10 bytes thanks to @VisualMelon*

Here's a full formatted version showing it working:

```
class P
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32")]
    static extern void keybd_event(int v, int s, int f, int e);

    static void Main()
    {
        System.Action<int> a = n =>
        {
            for (n = 0; ; System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(125))
                keybd_event(20, 69, n++ & 2, 0);
        };

        a(0);
    }
}
```

---

For bonus fun change `n++ & 2` to `n+=2 & 2` and watch the num lock and caps lock keys alternate in flashing on and off. I have no idea why that happens because it shouldn't but it looks "cool".

Comment: Wait, you're `using System;` but as far as I can tell you're not actually using anything directly from the System namespace? I think you can remove that.

Comment: @Metoniem Good spot the signature for the `keybd_event` method is actually `void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);`. I releasise I could remove the `UIntPtr`'s after posting and have them as `int`'s and just forgot to remove the using.

Comment: Ahh, I see haha, stuff like that happens! Nice answer man :)

Comment: I think you really should name and type the two 'functions': you refer to `k` in one, but it is clearly undefined. Not checked, but I think you'd be better off having one call to keybd_event in an unbraced for loop, I should think: `for(int i=0;;...Sleep(250))keybd_event(i++&2)` or something.

Comment: @VisualMelon Thanks, I have updated the code, had to alter the sleep to get the timing right though :)

Comment: With `++` you send `0`, `0`, `2`, `2` in a loop. With `+=`, the parsing is `n += (2 & 2)` so you send `2`, `4`, `6`, `8`... That parameter's only documented as supporting `0`, `1` and `2` so maybe the higher numbers are interfering somehow.

Answer (score 6):

## Java 7, <s>121</s> <s>118</s> 113 bytes

```
void a()throws Exception{java.awt.Robot r=new java.awt.Robot();r.keyPress(20);r.delay(500);r.keyRelease(20);a();}
```

A single press and release just triggers the state; it doesn't blink it. Thus we may as well loop it and it looks like recursion is the cheapest manner of doing that.

Comment: What a pity I don't have a QBasic interpreter here! Because it is done using a **Poke** instruction!

Comment: Does this get tail-call optimized or will this eventually exceed the call stack limit?

Comment: @Cyoce I don't think Java has tail call optimization until Java 9 so this eventually hits the recursion depth limit but that's ok because I only needed to blink the light once :]

Comment: What about wrapping the whole thing in a `for(;;){...}`? Seems to me to be 22-byte saving.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury I'm not sure what you mean. Currently the looping mechanism (tail recursion) only costs 4 bytes `a();`. If I instead use an infinite loop, that will cost 10 bytes `for(;;){}`

Comment: I mean that you can put the entire code into a lambda, which loses the function declaration overhead. Kind of like: `()->for(;;){java.awt.Robot r=new java.awt.Robot();r.keyPress(20);r.delay(500);r.keyRelease(20);}`, which is a saving of 18 bytes due to the 4-character lambda declaration overhead.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury no lambdas in Java 7 ;)

Comment: One more reason I'm not going back! ;) In all seriousness, just change the answer to Java 8 and go into double-digit scores. Install it if you don't have it already for testing.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Wouldn't you have to wrap the `for(;;){}` in other curled braces, meaning `()->{for(;;){...}}`? I can't get your sample compile with Java 8, while it does with the curved braces.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I think I missed a semicolon at the end of the thing. Let me check.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire You are correct, but that shouldn't be happening. IDK why. A for loop is a valid single line statement.

Answer (score 6):

## Linux terminal, 8+11 = 19 bytes

[image: demo]

File `f` = `1B 5B 33 71 1B 5B 30 71`

`native@shell:~$` `pv f -q -L8`

### WAT?

According to [ECMA-48](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), `1B` starts terminal control escape sequence.

Caps on =`1B 5B 33 71`, then off = `1B 5B 30 71`

`pv` progress view

`f` file

`-q` quiet

`-L8` 8 bytes/s = 0.5 sec delay

### Usage

Prepare

```
#Create file
echo "1B 5B 33 71 1B 5B 30 71"|xxd -r -p > f 

#Install progress view utility
sudo apt install pv
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> switch to native console

run `pv f -q -L8`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> switch back

Answer (score 5):

**JavaScript, 82 bytes**

**Credit goes to @FinW** actually, I just changed old function to new ES6 arrow function in order to save some bytes. And becuase I don't have enough points to comment I wrote a new reply.

Edit - deleted brackets to save another 2 bytes.

```
o=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");setInterval(()=>o.SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}"),500);
```

His code looked like this

```
o=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");setInterval(function(){o.SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}")},500);
```

Comment: For arrow function you don't need the parentheses in front of it.

Comment: Totally forgot about this, thanks.

Comment: I had meant the parentheses which were left over from when you removed function()

Comment: Oh, but you can't do that, it won't work. But you can remove the brackets as they are not needed in one-line statements (for some reason your comment reminded me of them even though you meant something different)

Comment: Save a byte by either replacing the `()` with another, single character, such as `_` or by making `o` a parameter with a default, like so: `(o=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"))=>`.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk Does ES6 implemented in Microsoft JScript?

Answer (score 4):

## Scala, <strike>84</strike> <strike>83</strike> 78 bytes

#### Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @TheLethalCoder,

He suggested using `1>0` in place of `true`.

#### Edit 2: Saved 5 bytes thanks to @Corvus_192,

He suggested using infix notation and dropping the parentheses after the constructor

```
while(1>0){val r=new java.awt.Robot;r keyPress 20;r keyRelease 20;r delay 500}
```

### Ungolfed:

```
while(1>0) {
    val r=new java.awt.Robot()
    r.keyPress(20)
    r.keyRelease(20)
    r.delay(500)
}
```

Standard Scala port of [@Poke](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51785/poke)'s Java [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110983/48620). Type it directly into the Scala interpreter prompt.

A video of it blinking both my Caps Lock LED and my OSD to boot!

[image: Blinking Caps Lock LED and OSD]

Comment: Can you do `for(;;)` or `while(1>0)` or `while(1)` in Scala?

Comment: The second is possible. A 1-byte saving which hadn't occurred to me before. Thanks!

Comment: You can use infix notation: `r keyPress 20` is a byte shorter than `r.keyPress(20)`. The same applies to the other method calls, saving 3 bytes in total.

Comment: Also, drop the parenthesis from the constructor call to save another 2 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

**Bash, 31 bytes**

```
xset led 1;sleep .5;xset -led 1
```

Works in X, without root access ! (If it does not work for you, see the init function of the code below to make sure xkbcomp is configured correctly)

And a bonus script to send any morse code through caps lock (not golfed) :

```
unit=0.15
id=1
function init {
        file=/tmp/blink_tmp
        xkbcomp $DISPLAY $file
        sed -i 's/!allowExplicit/allowExplicit/' $file
        xkbcomp $file $DISPLAY &>/dev/null
        rm $file
}
if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
        echo "Usage : blink [message]"
        exit 1
fi
init
function finish {
        off
}

function on {
#su -c 'setleds -L +caps < /dev/console'
xset led $id
}
function off {
#su -c 'setleds -L -caps < /dev/console'
xset -led $id
}
function slp {
        sleep $(echo "$unit*$1" | bc)
}
function dot {
on
slp 1
off
slp 1
}
function dash {
on
slp 3
off
slp 1
}
function gap {
        slp 3
}
function morse {
        msg=$1
        for (( i=0; i<${#msg}; i++ )); do
                char=${msg:$i:1}
                if [[ $char == "-" ]]; then
                dash
                elif [[ $char == "." ]]; then
                dot
                elif [[ $char == "/" ]]; then
                gap
                fi
        done
}
while true; do
        morse $1
done
```

Exemple : `blink "...././.-../.-../---//.--/---/.-./.-../-..///"`

Answer (score 3):

**Bash + Xdotool, 36 bytes**

```
for((;;)){ xdotool key 66;sleep .5;}
```

Just execute it in a bash shell.  It needs to be in a graphical environment.  Infinite loop from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash).  Changed Num_Lock to 66 to save 6 bytes, and thanks to @Michael Kjörling for 2 bytes.

Comment: You can save at least two bytes by removing unnecessary whitespace. You don't need the whitespace before the closing curly bracket, and you don't need whitespace surrounding the semicolons separating the commands. You *do* need the whitespace after the opening curly bracket, though.

Comment: Also, regarding your initial revision: Keep in mind that you can use `:` as an alias for `true` on most systems. `while :;do sth;done` does the same thing as `while true;do sth;done` but is three bytes shorter. `for((;;)){ sth;}` is still shorter, though.

Comment: @Cyoce Where?  It didn't work for me.

Comment: @Cyoce I think that only works for declaring functions.

Comment: @Feldspar15523 oops nevermind then

Answer (score 3):

## Python using pyautogui: <strike>126 143 115</strike> 103 bytes

*Thanks to @nedla2004 for saving 12 bytes*

```
from pyautogui import*
import time
while 1:keyDown('capslock');time.sleep(.5);keyUp('capslock')pslock')
```

Comment: You could change the while loop to `while 1:keyDown('capslock');time.sleep(.5);keyUp('capslock')`, and you can change the first line to `from pyautogui import*`, and the second to `import time`.

Comment: you can remove the duplicate 'capslock'.   `import time;c='capslock' ...`

Comment: you could also remove `time` altogether.

`from pyautogui import*; while 1:press('capslock',1,.5)`. ymmv. on my environment pyautogui does affect the case I type, but the light doesn't blink.

Answer (score 3):

## [xdotool](//semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/), 20 bytes

```bash
key -delay=500 66 66
```

Presses the key **66** aka *Caps Lock* twice, with a delay of **500 ms** between key presses.

Note that xdotool is a scripting language; it can be run from a file and it even supports shebangs. Since its `exec` command allow running external programs, it is capable of addition and primality testing, so it satisfies our definition of programming language.

#### Test run

```
$ cat blink.xdo; echo
key -delay=500 66 66
$ xdotool blink.xdo
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + [setleds](https://github.com/damieng/setledsmac), 43 bytes

```
setleds -D +caps;sleep 0.5;setleds -D -caps
```

Pretty simple. Uses `setleds` to toggle the light.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 103 bytes

```
cd /sys/class/leds/asus\:\:kbd_backlight;while true;do echo 3;sleep .5;echo 0;sleep .5;done>brightness
```

Must be run as root.

Does flashing the entire keyboard backlight work? (video to come when I get home)

Comment: `Does flashing the entire keyboard backlight work?` Well, if you think of it, the keyboard highlight  is an indicator of the keyboard highlight being on or off, and it is definitely "physically located on the keyboard", so, yes, I think it counts.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 90 bytes

```
o=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");setInterval(function(){o.SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}")},500);
```

It requires `ActiveX` meaning it will only run on IE (Edge *doesn't* support it, though). It flashes the NUMLOCK key because, as with other answers, it is shorter than CAPSLOCK or SCROLLLOCK.

### Ungolfed

```
shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
setInterval(
    function(){
        shell.SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}")
    }
,500);
```

Answer (score 2):

## Batch File (With help of vbs), 74+2=76 bytes

```
echo Createobject("wscript.shell").sendkeys"{numlock}">z.vbs&z&timeout 1&z
```

Partially based on [Trelzevir's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110978).

`.vbs` is automatically included in `PATHEXT`.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 33 Bytes

This assumes Num-Lock to be on before it is run. Switch `off` and `on` otherwise. Requires the `numlockx` package obviously ;)

```
numlockx off;sleep .5;numlockx on
```

**Edit:**

Saw Alex Howansky has already posted this solution, yet not marked it with Bash and I just searched the site for "Bash".

Comment: +1, you don't have to repeatedly blink it (I think).

Comment: If you're in an interactive shell, you can type at the command line: `numlockx toggle;sleep .5;!#`   (27 bytes) . `!#` is the event that expands to everything in the command line that has been typed so far.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (msvc)](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/cplusplus/) + Win32, 51 bytes

```c
main(i){main(i+keybd_event(20,69,i%4,Sleep(125)));}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Kotlin Script, 72 bytes

While not smallest one, still it's pretty good. I'm loving kotlin's *run* for some things, and this is one of them ( smaller than val r = java.awt.Robot() because we don't need both r. and val r =. Still, it's longer than MathLab )

```
java.awt.Robot().run{while(1>0){keyPress(20);keyRelease(20);delay(500)}}
```

### Ungolfed:

```
java.awt.Robot().run {
    while(1>0) {
        keyPress(20)
        keyRelease(20)
        delay(500)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python3 , <strike>55</strike> 49 bytes

*Thank you @NoOneIsHere for -4 bytes!*

This includes packages: [pyautogui](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) and `time` modules 
Code:

```
while(1):pag.press("capslock");time.sleep(0.5)
```

Thank you @NoOneIsHere for -4 bytes! 
The key in action: 
[image: Caps Lock]

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: You can save quite a few bytes by using `while 1`, and making it a one-liner with a semicolon. (`while 1:pyautogui.press("capslock");time.sleep(.5)`)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is also a snippet but by adding `import pyautogui` to the start of the program and changing the rest to `while 1:pyautogui.press("capslock");time.sleep(.5)` you can make this a valid answer.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing There's also need to be an `import time` there.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Exactly, which is why you need an `import time`...

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 82 Bytes

Anonymous VBE Immediate window function that takes no input and annoys the user indefinitely. Depedant upon the windows kernel32 function sleep that is declared below.

#### Sleep Declaration (Win-32)

```vb
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal M&)
```

#### Sleep Declaration (Win-64, + 8 Bytes)

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal M&)
```

#### Anonymous VBE immediate window function

```vb
Do:SendKeys"{CAPSLOCK}":Sleep 500:DoEvents:Loop
```

## Slightly more fun version, 97 Bytes

A set of mutually recursive subroutines that indefinitely annoys the user

```vb
Sub A
Application.OnTime Now+5.8E-6,"B"
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub B
DoEvents
SendKeys"{CAPSLOCK}"
A
End Sub
```

## Questionable version, 66 + 2 Bytes

I'm not sure if having to declare a function from a dll counts as having an inbuilt function so, in the case that it does not, then here is a 66+2 byte version that waits 1 second

```vb
Do:DoEvents:Application.Wait Now+#0:0:1#:SendKeys"{CAPSLOCK}":Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

## 按键精灵, 41 bytes

```
For 2
KeyPress"Num Lock",1
Delay 500
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 134 bytes

```clj
(repeatedly(fn[](Thread/sleep 500)(.setLockingKeyState(java.awt.Toolkit/getDefaultToolkit)java.awt.event.KeyEvent/VK_CAPS_LOCK true)))
```

Loops infinitely, constantly resetting the caps lock's key state. For some reason, setting it to `true` over and over again toggles it, even though that's not supposed to happen.

Those imports are killer. Might try going the route of the Java answer and use `Robot` instead; see if that helps.

Thanks for posting this challenege. I'm currently sitting in a chair at the dentist waiting to get a tooth pulled. The distraction is appreciated!

The GIF ended up being too big to upload.

```clj
(repeatedly ; Implicit infinite loop
  (fn[]
     (Thread/sleep 500)
    
     (.setLockingKeyState
       (java.awt.Toolkit/getDefaultToolkit)
       java.awt.event.KeyEvent/VK_CAPS_LOCK
       true)))
```

Comment: "I took a video of it, but I can't upload it to a gif converter until I get onto wifi." Please don't upload videos of your teeth being pulled-- it might upset the dentist!

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I took a picture of the tooth post op! But obviously I won't post that. I had to sit in the chair for awhile to wait, so I whipped out my computer and did this challenge, then took a video. I feel like crap though, so I'll get to the GIF eventually. It's not high on my list anymore lol.