# Blink the webcam light!

Tags: code-golf, hardware

*This challenge is inspired by [Blink the CAPS LOCK](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110974/blink-the-caps-lock) by [zeppelin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61904/zeppelin).*

Most webcams feature a small integrated LED light, indicating if the webcam is in use, as controlled by a hardware mechanism to prevent spying.

[image]

Your task is to blink it:

1. Turn it on.
2. Wait for 0.5 (±0.1) seconds.
3. Turn it off again.
4. Wait for 0.5 (±0.1) seconds;
5. Repeat.

Please include a GIF or video of the webcam blinking, if possible. If an answer doesn't have the GIF, please add a GIF of the program running.

### Rules

- If your language is missing a subsecond `sleep` command, your program may use a 1 second delay instead, at a penalty of an additional byte. (replacing `.5` with `1`)

  - If your language, for some reason, doesn't support `.5`, your penalty is 2 bytes. (replacing `0.5` with `1`)
- Your program must loop unless halted by the user.
- Your LED can start either on or off; whichever is more beneficial can be used.
- If your LED has a turning-off delay, then it doesn't have to be taken into account, unless if you want to provide an additional version.

  - See [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111375/blink-the-webcam-light#comment271230_111375) and [its answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/111375/blink-the-webcam-light#comment271231_111375) for more information.

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), which means the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: My laptop's webcam LED takes a while (around 0.3 seconds, it seems) to turn off after the video device stops being accessed. Does this have to be taken into account?

Comment: @Doorknob No, but you can provide a version that takes it into account if you'd like.

Comment: The penalty should only be 1 byte, since you can just use `.5`

Comment: @Elronnd I was going to add that, but I forgot.

Answer (score 8):

## MATLAB, 40 bytes

```
while 1;w=webcam;pause(.5);delete(w);end
```

Creates an infinite `while` loop and each time through the loop, a `webcam` object is initialized (turns on the webcam), the script is paused for 0.5 seconds using `pause`, and then the `webcam` object is deleted (turning the webcam off).

[image]

Comment: The delay between each blink is more than 0.5

Comment: @haykam The directions (and comments) indicate that inaccuracies due to the hardware are acceptable unless I'm misreading them.

Comment: Ok... do you mind maybe adding an additional golf that does it so it looks like 0.5s?

Comment: @haykam It's impossible, it's a limitation of MATLAB (and maybe the hardware itself). I am already showing it being turned off and back on as fast as possible.

Comment: Last beep was good

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 82 bytes

(Uses OpenCV for accessing the webcam.)

```
import cv2,time
s=time.sleep
while 1:w=cv2.VideoCapture(0);s(.5);w.release();s(.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript (ES6), 100 bytes

```js
(f=_=>navigator.getUserMedia({video:1},x=>s(_=>x.getTracks()[0].stop(s(f,500)),500),s=setTimeout))()
```

During my testing, I saw a delay between the camera being activated and the LED turning on, so the timing may not be perfect. It also must run on an https:// page.

Comment: @haykam thanks for the edit, but for some reason this script doesn't work inside the snippet iframe sandbox

Answer (score 1):

### Scratch in  scratchblocks2, 61 bytes

```
when gf clicked
turn video[on v
wait(.5)secs
turn video[off v
```

Sorry about the absolutely terrible video. My LED has a slight turning-on delay, it is very faint, and the GIF is 18 MB.

[image: gif]

Comment: @JonathanFrech I've taken a look at some Scratch answers and they all seem to use scratchblocks2.  Secondly, I was doing what the challenge required?

Comment: "Please include a GIF or video of the webcam blinking, if possible. If an answer doesn't have the GIF, please add a GIF of the program running."

I included everything else above it.

Comment: You are right. I seldom see a Scratch answer but it appears that your answer satisfies both the current byte count consensus and challenge-specific rules. Sorry for my partially uninformed critique.