# Digitangular numbers

Tags: code-golf, math

A [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) is a number that can be expressed as the sum of consecutive positive integers, starting at 1. They can also be expressed with the formula `n(n + 1) / 2`, where `n` is some positive integer.

A number's digitangular counterpart is calculated in the following way:

1. Split a number into an array of its digits e.g. `613 => [6 1 3]`
2. For each number in the array, calculate the `n`th triangular number; `[6 1 3] => [21 1 6]`
3. Sum the resultant array; `[21 1 6] => 28`

Your task is, given an integer `n`, repeatedly calculate `n`'s digitangular counterpart, until the result is equal to 1, then output all values that were calculated. You may output the values in any order, and with an optional inclusion of the original number at the start of the array. This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins.

### Test cases

```
23 => 9 45 25 18 37 34 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
72 => 31 7 28 39 51 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
55 => 30 6 21 4 10 1
78 => 64 31 7 28 39 51 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
613 => 28 39 51 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
8392 => 90 45 25 18 37 34 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
11111 => 5 15 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
8592025 => 117 30 6 21 4 10 1
999999999 => 405 25 18 37 34 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
```

Comment: May we include the original number as first in the resultant array?

Comment: How do we know it always goes down to 1?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Well, I've tested every integer from 1 to 10000, and all have reached the same pattern that eventually leads to 1. I can't be bothered to write a proof, but if you can find an integer that doesn't, tell me and I'll edit that into the question.

Comment: Let's suppose that a number is larger than `141` and has `n` digits. The maximum value its digitangular counterpart can have is `45n`, so `digi-△(x) ≤ 45n < 45(1+log_10(x))`, and for `x > 141`, we have `45(1+log_10(x)) < x`, hence `digi-△(x) ≤ x-1` for `x > 141`, and once we pass the `141` limit, well, we brute force prove via programs.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Shouldn't it be stated that `digi-△(x) ≤ 45n ≤ 45(1+log_10(x))` since `45n = 45(1+log_10(x))` for any `n`-digit number `x > 141` that is a power of `10`?

Comment: Oh, you're right. A tad too late to edit + it happily doesn't affect my analysis of this sequence.

Comment: @R.Kap Also, we could more nicely write `n = ⌊1+log10(x)⌋`, for any `x`.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems as if the sequence always ends with `6 21 4 10 1`. I don't know how to rigorously prove this for all the natural numbers though.

Comment: *I have 13 bytes in Jelly* - Outgolfed :^)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder As usual, I overthought it :P

Comment: The wording of the question implies that we can't start output until after the calculation is completed.  Is that intentional?  Or should "*then*" be merely "*and*"?

Comment: Can I have trailing 1's at the end of my output?

Comment: @R.Kap Trivially, it won't. Consider `1en, 4en, or 6en` for any natural `n`. (really bad scientific notation)

Comment: Related: [Digitangular numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2532297), seeking alternative proofs that this sequence goes to 1 eventually.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Huh, that's pretty cool. That's two of my challenges where people are seeking proof that they work for given numbers

Comment: @TobySpeight You may output at any point of the execution of the program, be that at the start (somehow), the middle or the end

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt As in more than a single one? If so, then no, as your program doesn't terminate when it reaches one.

Answer (score 10):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
U¡(ṁΣd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vcGhbrsajpsZMzQqlQ9v@hx5aqPFwZ@O5xSn///83MuYyN@IyNeUyt@AyMzTmsjC2NOIyBAEuC1NLIwMjUy5LGAAA)

#### Explanation

```
U¡(ṁΣd
 ¡(       Iterate the following function on the input:
     d       Split the number into digits
   ṁΣ        Map each digit to its triangular number, then sum the results
U         Take the results of iteration until before the first repeated one
```

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
Δ=SLO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3BTbYB////8tTC2NDIxMAQ) Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @Emigna. Explanation:

```
Δ       Repeat until value doesn't change
 =      Print current value
  S     Split into characters
   L    Turn each character into range from 1 to N
    O   Sum
```

Comment: If you replace `€` with `S`, you can skip one `O`.

Comment: @Emigna ...why does `L` even behave that way?

Comment: If I recall correctly it was a bug that turned out to be useful and got to remain as a feature. I think it was one the first methods that vectorized.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>23</s> <s>20</s> 17 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to @ngn*

```apl
{⍵∪⍨+/∊⍳¨⍎¨⍕⊃⍵}⍣≡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR71bH3WsetS7Qlv/UUfXo97Nh1Y86u0DEVMfdTUDZWsf9S5@1LkQqFzByJgrTcHcCEgYmQIJM0MQ3xIGAA)

**How?**

`⍵∪⍨` - prepend current array to the

`+/` - sum of

`∊` - flattened

`⍳¨` - ranges of each

`⍎¨⍕` - digit of the

`⊃⍵` - previous value

`⍣≡` until convergence. The usage of `∪` (union) makes sure after the first 1 is joined, the next will be excluded due to set uniqueness, and the array will converge.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long would it be if you weren't allowed to output the original value as well?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing 2 bytes - `1↓` (drop first)

Comment: @Uriel Here power limit (⍣≡) gives a shorter solution than recursion: {⍵∪⍨+/∊⍳¨⍎¨⍕⊃⍵}⍣≡ but it's a shame APL doesn't have a concise way to collect all iterations of a function until convergence: ⍵(f⍵)(f⍣2⊢⍵)(f⍣3⊢⍵)...

Comment: @ngn thanks! I did try to use the power operator, but I didn't think about the fact it converges after 1. Will update soon

Comment: @ngn any idea on how to use `{+/∊⍳¨⍎¨⍕⎕←⍵}⍣≡` without getting the last 1 printed?

Comment: @Uriel append ~1 ?

Comment: @ngn that would remove them both.

Comment: ...I don't see any `∇` there?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer residue from previous, fixed, thanks

Comment: @Uriel both? I see just one. By the way, if you prefer to have the result in the same order as in the problem description, this is the same number of bytes: {⍵∪+/∊⍳¨⍎¨⍕⊃⌽⍵}⍣≡

Answer (score 4):

## J, <sub><s>20</s></sub> 19 bytes

```
(1#.2!1+,.&.":)^:a:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZDLCsIwEEX3fsVVQRrUkJlkmgf4K4KIRdz4/6uYVFsVtHoXAwdyuJO55Nxhp9HQUvOc1hu90ouk9umQZqfj@Yqmg2eFR7apECzBgwNshBCoBTPKIDiQAY2iyKsoAms@vvPhrSCgdX93tGTV0y30jxRsHP5UpEqIBk7AAiq6h3UTOtWoQe8JRZSpRolsuL9HbbxTUf23m8QhqgojwZkfW@Z8Aw)

Outputs the original number, too.

## Explanation

```
(1#.2!1+,.&.":)^:a:
               ^:a:  Apply until input converges, storing all results in an array
(1#.2!1+,.&.":)      Digitangular sum
        ,.&.":         Split to digits
          &.":           Convert to string, apply left function, then undo conversion
        ,.               Ravel items (make array of singleton arrays of items)
                         This ensures that when cast back to integers, the digits are split.
      1+               Add 1 to each
    2!                 Compute (n choose 2) on each (nth triangular number)
 1#.                   Sum (debase 1)
```

Comment: `[:+/` ->`1#.` meow!

Comment: @FrownyFrog not an original trick, though I certainly make ample use of it when I remember to.

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, <s>51</s> <s>47</s> 46 bytes

```
f 1=[1]
f x=x:f(sum$do d<-show x;[1..read[d]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcHRCsIgFADQ977iPvSwwU26ik0rP6EvEAnBycbmNmaRf2/00DmDz1M/z7VGIGPJHSIUU66xye90DCuE@ykP6wfKzRJje@@DDc61NflxAQPJb48nNNs@Li9gsQXLBXYcpcRO4YUEKqE50g8qqfmZS9R/rn4B)

```
f 1=[1]                     -- if x == 1, return the singleton list [1]
f x=                        -- else
         do d<-show x       --  for each char 'd' in the string representation of x
                            --    (using the list monad)
           [1..read[d]]     --  make a list of [1..d]
                            --    (the list monad concatenates all those lists into a single list)
        sum                 --  sum those numbers
      f                     --  call f on it
    x:                      --  and put x in front of it
```

Edit: @H.PWiz saved a byte. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x<2and[1]or[x]+f(sum(-~int(i)*int(i)/2for i in`x`))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1BCsIwFET3PcVfJhrR/FJtij1JCLRSg4E2LU2EuPHq8av0bYaZgZnlFR@zx5xtO/bTbeghNemKvR@0NPOqk9lbFp4TO7ydj8zx3V@OaOcVHDjfpY7zHO8hBmhBYyngggKqirQWcJYU1KWiSH4hUyk8IdVqwxTFtga/oaYAYlnpCyy95Q8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```
Echo@#>1&&#0[#.(#+1)/2&@IntegerDigits@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n1aaZ/vfNTkj30HZzlBNTdkgWllPQ1nbUFPfSM3BM68kNT21yCUzPbOk2EE5Vg2kPNrM0Dj2PwA)

### How it works

The expression `#.(#+1)/2&@IntegerDigits@#` gives the digitangular counterpart of `#`. We `Echo` the input, use short-circuit evaluation with `&&` to stop if we've reached `1`, and otherwise recurse on the digitangular counterpart.

---

*-2 bytes thanks to Martin Ender for the `.` trick: we don't have to use `Tr` to sum the digits if we replace the multiplication `#(#+1)/2` by the dot product `#.(#+1)/2`.*

Comment: Only just saw your answer now. You can beat mine by using the scalar product trick to avoid the `Tr`: `Echo@#>1&&#0[#.(#+1)/2&@IntegerDigits@#]&`

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks, that's a neat trick. I wonder if there any even golfier ways to do "print all iterations of this function on the way to a fixed point" (essentially, reimplementing `FixedPointList` except for how that prints the fixed point twice). It seems like that should have come up before.

Answer (score 2):

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>49</s> <s>42</s> 39 bytes

*Thanks to Misha Lavrov for saving 3 bytes.*

```
#//.x_:>(y=IntegerDigits@Echo@x).++y/2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcSHaum4KCloPFfWV9fryLeyk6j0tYzryQ1PbXIJTM9s6TYwTU5I9@hQlNPQ1u7UlPfSO2/poK@g0K1kbGOgrmRjoKpKZC20FEwMwQKWBhbAoUMQQDIMbU0MjACSlvCQO1/AA) (TIO needs parentheses around the `++y` for some reason. In my local Mathematica installation it works without them, as it should.)

Prints each value on its own line, preceded by `>>`, and includes the starting number.

Comment: You can go back to beating my answer with `#//.x_:>(y=IntegerDigits@Echo@x).++y/2&`. (...maybe. For some reason, TIO doesn't like this, but Mathematica's fine with it?)

Comment: Well, `#//.x_:>(y=IntegerDigits@Echo@x).(++y)/2&` is 41 bytes and works in TIO. But my copy of Mathematica doesn't think the parentheses are necessary.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks. Yeah, no clue why TIO needs the parentheses, but syntax in script files is sometimes a bit wonky.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>60 47</s> 42 bytes

-13 bytes by @JustinMariner

-5 bytes by @GB

```
->x{p x=x.digits.sum{|k|k*-~k/2}while x>1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iukChwrZCLyUzPbOkWK@4NLe6JrsmW0u3LlvfqLY8IzMnVaHCzrD2f1q0maFx7H8A)

Comment: You can drop the array and splat (`[*...]`) and change `(k+1)` to `-~k` to save a total of 5 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v8JWRSvaIFavJD8@07pAocK2Qi8lMz2zpFgvN7Gguia7JltLty5b36hWr7g0V6E8IzMnVaHCzvD///9mhsYA)  Additionally, you can save 8 more by switching to an anonymous lambda function: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iukChwrZCLyUzPbOkWC83saC6JrsmW0u3LlvfqFavuDRXoTwjMydVocLOsPZ/WrSZoXHsfwA)

Comment: Hm, no idea why I thought `.map` couldn't take arrays.

Comment: You can use "sum{...}" instead of "map{...}.sum" and then remove the space before "while"

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Doesn't include the input as the first element.

```
Æ=ì cò xÃâ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=xj3sIGPyIHjD4g&input=NjEzCi1R)

```
Æ=ì cò xÃâ     :Implicit input of integer U
Æ              :Map the range [0,U)
 =             :  Reassign to U
  ì            :  Convert to digit array
    c          :  Flat map
     ò         :    Range [0,digit]
       x       :  Reduce by addition
        Ã      :End map
         â     :Deduplicate
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 21 bytes

```
;{:G`
.
$*1¶
1
$%`1
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/G@tquGe8N@62so9gUuPS0XL8NA2LkMuFdUEQy7D//@NjLnMjbhMTbnMLbjMDI25LIwtjbgMQYDLwtTSyMDIlMsSBgA) (The outputs of the individual cases aren't well separated, but each output ends with a `1`.)

Prints each number on its own line, in order, including the starting number.

#### Explanation

```
;{:G`
```

This is just some configuration of the program. `{` makes the program loop until it fails to change the result (which happens once we get to `1`), `:` prints number before each iteration, and `;` prevents the final result from being printed twice at the end of the program. The `G` is just my usual way of creating a no-op stage.

```
.
$*1¶
```

Convert each digit to unary and put it on its own line.

```
1
$%`1
```

Compute the triangular number on each line, by replacing each `1` with its prefix. We could also use `` M!&`1+ `` here, which gives us all suffixes of each line.

```
1
```

Count all `1`s, which sums up all the triangular numbers and converts the result back to decimal.

Comment: Is Retina a turing complete language?

Comment: @ThePirateBay yes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm),  <s>9</s>  7 bytes

```
·Ω}#ΣΣu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//9D2cytrlc8tPre49P9/cyMA)

**Explanation**

```
          Implicit input as a string
·Ω        Evaluate until the result has already been seen, pushing intermediate results
  }       Split digits
   #      Range from 0 to N
    ΣΣ    Sum
      u   Convert to string
```

Comment: Isn't `u` unnecessary?

Comment: It's necessary otherwise `}` won't split the digits

Comment: Hm. That might be a bug. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 51 bytes

```
p&>>:25*%:1+*2/v
  |:/*52p00+g00<
00<vp000_@#-1.::g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/v0DNzs7KyFRL1cpQW8tIv4xLQaHGSl/L1KjAwEA73cDAhguIy4Acg3gHZV1DPSur9P//LYwtjQA)

James Holderness cleverly reshaped my progarm into a 51-byte form. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), <s>24</s> <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 17 bytes

```
[sL:R{;Svc^#&1=?i
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/z@62McqqNo6uCw5TlnN0NY@8////5YwAAA)**

### Explanation

```
[sL:R{;Svc^#&1=?i

[           &1=?i   \ Loop until result == 1:
 s                  \   Split last result into digits
  L:  ;             \   For each digit n:
    R{              \       Push the range (1, n) inclusive
       S            \   Sum the ranges
        vc^         \   Delete all stack items, except the sum
           #        \   Print result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 70 bytes

```r
f=function(n)"if"(n-1,c(n,f((d=n%/%10^(nchar(n):0)%%10)%*%(d+1)/2)),n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoAgEAXQuwgD88tQC1oEXiUIZcjNBFLnn9w@XjeTLJ@Wtz3KCtfEsS7JF1YvzDUrBUrxZC331cc4ImgAaCKuc0JYAa8w4T1tsB8)

Returns the original value as well.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 80 bytes

```r
function(n){o={}
while(n-1){n=(d=n%/%10^(nchar(n):0)%%10)%*%(d+1)/2
o=c(o,n)}
o}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoAgEADAu6/osrBbiVnQIfIrQWhSELsQRQfx7dZ1mKvEatYlPuzvQxiZkriU1bsf54asLSV2GByDAdstyH5fr39NHcEPBDVgaCyZXonzKC1TVpJLxNEOVD4)

Does not return the original value.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 91 bytes

```lua
function f(n)x=0 for d in((0|n)..""):gmatch"."do x=x+d*(d+1)/2 end print(x)c=x==1or f(x)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvRCsMgDEDRXwk@JSs4KxS2QT6mmNoJWxzFQh76787Hy@F@zrX3fGpqpSpkVDIOkOsBAkURw6XkvXP02r9rS2/nnVQwtkluKNNM9wibCvyOog2NEhvzPPY8YkDP@FieMcSF@h8)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>20</s> 12 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing)*

```
ΔD,þ€iLO}O}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3BQXncP7HjWtyfTxr/Wvrf3/38LU0sjAyBQA)

### Explanation

(old version)

```
Δþ€iD>*;}OD1›iD,}}1,  Main program
Δ                }    Repeat until there is no changes
 þ                    Push digits of the input number
  €i    }             Apply for each digit
    D>*;              Calculate the triangular number for given digit
         O            Sum all numbers
          D1›iD,}     Print if greater than 1
                  1,  Print 1 at the end
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>61</s> 57 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>a-1?([...a+[]].map(b=>a+=b++*b/2,a=0),a)+' '+f(a):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzLDoIwEEX3foW7zlioUIKCSeVDkMWUh8EoJYD6@bUuoHd1cueeedCH5nrqxyUcTNNa2ylSVwrjAkohBPGyqsSLRtCu5UpzftBHGZCKMCDkbM94B4QXxuzT3BU42S3HydTtPIt5acx7Ed@pX1qAkpwXV2VUFew2MOcg14gQ4c650IFMcMWz3DBNfZtteIr9OEtyP4//8ac0l5H0H/I1iPYH)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 69 bytes

```python
def f(x):
 while x>1:
  x=sum(-~int(z)*int(z)/2for z in`x`)
  print x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNo0LTikuhPCMzJ1Whws4QyFaosC0uzdXQrcvMK9Go0tSCUPpGaflFClUKmXkJFQmaQFUFRUAJhYr/aRoWxpZGmv8B)

Comment: [64](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNo0LTikuhPCMzJ1Whws7QqsK2uDRXQ7cuM69Eo0pTC0LpG6XlFylUKWTmJVQkaFoXFAGFFSr@p2lYGFsaaf4HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)), 19 bytes

```
{+/(+/1+!"I"$)'$x}\
```

Unsurprisingly works similarly to the already posted APL and J solutions

```
               $x    cast x (implicit var of lambda) to string
   (         )'      apply composition (function train) to each character of string
    +/1+!"I"$        cast character to number, create list from 1 to n, sum it
 +/                  sum triangular numbers
{                }\  iterate lambda until result converges, appending each result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
Ｗ⊖Ｉθ«≔ＩΣ⭆θΣ…·0κθθ⸿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDJTW5KDU3Na8kNUXDObG4RKNQU1NToZqL07G4ODM9DyIWXJqrEVxSlJmX7ptYoFGoowAS8MxLziktzixLDUrMS0/VUDJQ0lHI1gQBHYVCTWsuzgCgBpB5cKZSTJESkFf7/7@FqaWRgZHpf92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   θ                Input
  Ｉ                 Cast to integer
 ⊖                  Decrement
Ｗ   «               Loop while not zero
         θ          Current value
        ⭆           Map over characters and concatenate
             0      Literal character 0
              κ     Current character
           …·       Inclusive range
          Σ         Concatenate
       Σ            Sum of digits
      Ｉ             Cast to string
     ≔         θ    Assign back to value
                θ   Output latest value
                 ⸿  Move to start of next line
```

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 62 bytes

```
?sj[0soljZ1-[dljr10r^/10%d1+*2/lo+sod1-r0<i]dsixlopdsj1<b]dsbx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9@@OCvaoDg/JyvKUDc6JSeryNCgKE7f0EA1xVBby0g/J1@7OD/FULfIwCYzNqU4syInvyClOMvQJgnIS6r4/9/M0BgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
DRFSµÐĿ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98lyC340NbDE47s////v5ExAA)

- `DRFSµÐĿ`: Full program / monadic link.
- `ÐĿ`: Loop until results are no longer unique (if something other than 1 would occur twice, then the given input does not have a defined result, since it would never reach 1).
- `D`: Convert from integer to decimal.
- `R`: Range (1-indexed). Vectorizes.
- `F`: Flatten and `S`: Sum (`µ` just creates a new monadic chain)

Answer (score 0):

## dc, 31 bytes

```
[[I~d1+*2/rd0<m+]dsmxpd1<f]dsfx
```

The function `m` computes the digitangular function of its input; `f` repeats this until the result reaches 1.

Note that we use the input radix to extract digits - this means it will work in any base system, not only decimal.

### Demo

```
for i in 23 72 55 78 613 8392 11111 8592025 999999999
    do echo $i '=>' $(dc -e $i'[[I~d1+*2/rd0<m+]dsmxpd1<f]dsfx')
done
```

```
23 => 9 45 25 18 37 34 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
72 => 31 7 28 39 51 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
55 => 30 6 21 4 10 1
78 => 64 31 7 28 39 51 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
613 => 28 39 51 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
8392 => 90 45 25 18 37 34 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
11111 => 5 15 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
8592025 => 117 30 6 21 4 10 1
999999999 => 405 25 18 37 34 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 76 bytes

```python
f=lambda k,s=0:k+s<2and[1]or[k]*(s<1)+f(*[k/10,s,s+k%10*(k%10+1)/2][k<1::2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBCoMwFET3nuJvCokGzP9iq0FPErKw2NCQNorJpqdPY6FvMcPMwOyf9NwC5Wzn1/K@rwt4EWepfBMnWsKq0WyH9qZmcULeWFZr36IUUcTGX1DW7NQGeUtG@wmVIsNzesQUYQZNnYAbCej74oOAK5Zi6MZS4UkJ/UiSyjz@MVVltwMcuAC/I1VBYT9cSGCZ4/kL)

Answer (score 0):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 8 bytes

```
ͻtD÷D
```

Explanation:

```
ͻ             Start infinite loop
             Split top of stack into each of its characters
  t           Push infinite list of triangular numbers
             For each of the characters, get the nth element in the above list.
              Sum.
     D         Duplicate.
      ÷        If top of stack is equal to 1, break.
       D       Duplicate.
               Implicitly print all elements in the stack, concatenated.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//@zuD3MnNJV8mDt1KpCxxuXwdpf//80MjQE)

[Formatted output](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//@zuD3MnNJV8mDt1KpCxxuXwdpf/mir/zQyNAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## C, 72 bytes

```
s;F(n){for(s=0;n;n/=10)for(;n%10;n--)s+=n%10;printf("%d ",s);s<2?:F(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYxBCsIwEEX3nkIChRk0mKREG8fgLveQSKULY2nqqvTsMRUEm7/678/wPH94n1IkBwGn9jVAtIIChYOVAhemUMm8cI5xZ7@9H7owtsCq@5btI1K8qOvZQW5z6uh56wLgtHGgaqT@PUZgDCnzSa1Z6@LerPkoC0FTm0IhlxRP2iihCrX55X@e0wc)

Answer (score 0):

## [D](https://dlang.org/), 140 bytes

```d
import std.algorithm,std.range,std.conv,std.stdio;void f(T)(T n){n=n.text.map!(u=>u.to!T-48+(u.to!T-48).iota.sum).sum;n.writeln;if(n-1)n.f;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1LCoNAEETX8RTjrpvEhnwWgcGcwgsM0TEDTrdoawLBs0/URRZVvLepqlMKsZdBzag1ua6VIegrnjYbHLfNTk/heYc1QewsoTYeKoTKMH65ZNLmoxRdn8NUPiZSyavidj/CH5GCqKNxiriVZXqvT03HNnjg4oxM3i5pn44uMKD5ZgcPlyvabEk/)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 71+1 bytes

```php
for(;1<$n="$s"?:$argn;print$s._)for($i=$s=0;$p--||~$p=$n[$i++];)$s+=$p;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a743695711e6a1cdcb65b6a2b1b973c59ec27d67). (requires PHP 5.3 or later for the Elvis operator)

Comment: What's the Elvis operator?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing `A?:B`: if A is truthy then A else B

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 32 bytes

```
D,f,@,EDBFEREss
+?
y:1
W!,$f>x,O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03HQcfVxcnNNci1uJhL256r0sqQK1xRRyXNrkLH/////2aGxgA)

Doesn't output the first value

### How it works

```
D,f,@,   - Create a monadic function, f.
         - Example argument: [613]
      ED - Digits;   STACK = [[6 1 3]]
      BF - Flatten;  STACK = [6 1 3]
      ER - Range;    STACK = [[1 2 3 4 5 6] [1] [1 2 3]]
      Es - Sum each; STACK = [21 1 6]
      s  - Sum;      STACK = [28]

           f calculates n's digitangular counterpart

+?       - Take input;     x = 613; y = 0
y:1      - Set y to 1;     x = 613; y = 1
W!,      - While x != y...
   $f>x, -   Call f;       x =  28; y = 1
   O     -   Print x;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 36 bytes

```
{$_,{sum map {sum 1..$_},.comb}...1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcnBCoQgFEbhV/kJaSWX8YqlzNSriA3jaqQoZhHiszsV9K0OnOWzfruadrQRQ83Cy7z9ElJYcIUiEr5Ies9pKkSkSt3CjkZ4DCNyxHEbxHnFizV6hjHoLTqlYbVjqBOscfxgA3cbn/UP)

Includes the input number in the output list.

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok) / [K4](http://kx.com/download/), 17 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{+/,/!:'1+.:'$x}\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v1pbX0df0UrdUFvPSl2lojbGzND4/38A)

**Examples:**

```
{+/,/!:'1+.:'$x}\23
23 9 45 25 18 37 34 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
{+/,/!:'1+.:'$x}\72
72 31 7 28 39 51 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
{+/,/!:'1+.:'$x}\999999999
999999999 405 25 18 37 34 16 22 6 21 4 10 1
```

**Explanation:**

Converge over lambda returning all results along the way:

```
{+/,/!:'1+.:'$x}\ / the solution
{              }\ / lambda {}, converge \
             $x   / string input, 613 => "613"
          .:'     / value (.:) each (') "613" => 6 1 3
        1+        / add 1, 6 1 3 => 7 1 4
     !:'          / til (!:) each (') to generate ranges
   ,/             / flatten list
 +/               / sum list
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
`Đą△ƩĐ1≠?ŕł:;ŕ↔ŕ↔
```

Explanation:

```
                        Implicit input
`         ł             Loop ... while top of stack is not zero
 Đ                      Duplicate the top of the stack
  ą△Ʃ                   Get the digitangular sum of the top of the stack
     Đ1≠                Is it not equal to 1?
        ?  :;           If top of stack is 1, Then continue; Else jump to ':'
         ŕ              Remove top of stack
          ł             Loop back to ` if top of stack is 1 
           :;           If top of stack isn't 1, then continue from ':'
             ŕ↔ŕ↔       Remove top and bottom of stack
                        Implicit print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f8/4ciEI62Ppm0@tvLIBMNHnQvsj0492mRlfXTqo7YpYOL/f0sYAAA)