# We had a question once which only failed on Sundays

Tags: code-golf, date, error-message

Inspired by [We had a unit test once which only failed on Sundays](https://qntm.org/unit), write a program or function that does nothing but throw an error when it is Sunday, and exit gracefully on any other day.

#### Rules:

- No using input or showing output through the [usual IO methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), except to print to STDERR or your language's equivalent. You are allowed to print to STDOUT if it's a by-product of your error.
- A function may return a value on non-Sundays as long as it doesn't print anything
- Your program may use a Sunday from any timezone, or the local timezone, as long as it is consistent.
- An error is a something that makes the program **terminate abnormally**, such as a divide by zero error or using an uninitialised variable. This means that if any code were to be added after the part that errors, it would not be executed on Sunday.
- You can also use statements that manually create an error, equivalent to Python’s `raise`.
- This includes runtime errors, syntax errors and errors while compiling (good luck with that!)
- On an error there must be some sign that distinguishes it from having no error
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest bytecount in each language wins!

I'll have to wait til Sunday to check the answers ;)

Comment: [Sandbox Post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14508/76162)

Comment: Can the output be on STDOUT, as long it is generated by an error?

Comment: @Rod Yes you can

Comment: By "write a program or function that does nothing but throw an error on Sunday, and exit gracefully on any other day", do you mean that whenever it is run on sunday it should fail, or do you mean that there should be at least one possibility it fails a sunday. To make it clearer, if it fails only on sunday at 2pm, but not on sunday 3pm, is it fine ?

Comment: @Bromind It has to fail at any time on Sunday

Comment: Sad :'( I wanted to do something like 
`(time-time_of_first_sunday_after_epoch)%nb_of_second_per_week`

Comment: If we use a function instead of a full program, may the function return something (which we don't use whatsoever)? To perhaps explain it better: In Java I have to assign a value when I use divide, so instead of `()->{1/sundayValue;}` I'll have to use `()->{int x=1/sundayValue;}`. This is a lambda with no parameter and no return-type. However, if I change this to a lambda with a return-type integer, I could do `()->1/sundayValue` to shorten it. I don't use the output, and it still errors on division by 0, but I'm not sure if this is allowed?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Sure. A function may return a value

Comment: This would have been even better if Saturday had been used. You could have called it "Saturday Night Error" and even worked in some adjusted song lyrics to the question.

Comment: I was confused after seeing some of the answers to this. Does the program/function *itself* need to produce some output which you are considering an error, or does the logic to determine if something is output need to be triggered by some error in the code? I had assumed the former, but others seem to be assuming the latter. With my interpretation, Dennis' answer could be shortened by 2 characters by removing the back-ticks, otherwise they are necessary.

Comment: Sundays? How about [failing between midnight and 1am](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/405783)?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what constitutes an error.  I'm voting to close until this is remedied.

Comment: @WheatWizard Better?

Comment: Not really ... How can we distinguish the output of an error from regular output.  Is something like `print "error"` an error?  The added paragraph doesn't really clarify anything.

Answer (score 27):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```bash
`date|grep Su`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfoKGpoFFQlJlXkqagrpoUk6dqoFUak6euoKTioKRQo1BSpGCgoKtgp2akycVVoBDi7@IYqWD6PyElsSS1Jr0otUAhuDThf4GCekyen2tEiEJwqB9QhbqCoSEXWI2CbkpxaV5KYiVcMcgYmGpffwzVufkoqv8DAA)

Answer (score 18):

## PHP 7, 12 bytes

```
1%date("w");
```

On PHP 7 it throws an exception of type [`DivisionByZero`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php) on Sundays. The same happens if it is interpreted using [HHVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HHVM).

On PHP 5 it displays a warning (on `stderr`) on Sundays:

```
PHP Warning:  Division by zero in Command line code on line 1
```

On any PHP version, it doesn't display anything on the other days of the week.

Run using the CLI:

```
php -r '1%date("w");'
```

or [try it online!](https://3v4l.org/IXe7i)

Two more bytes can be squeezed by stripping the quotes (`1%date(w);`) but this triggers a notice (that can be suppressed by properly set [`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) in `php.ini`).

Comment: I believe you **must** specify (in the title) that this answer is only and only for PHP7+ and for HHVM, since PHP5.6 and lower exit without any problem. Warnings aren't errors and don't stop the execution of the code. If you do `1%date("w");echo "Alive!"`, it will stop in PHP7+ and HHVM, but not in all the other versions since PHP 4.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel the question classifies any printing to Standard Error as an error, so a warning's good enough in this case.

Comment: Quoting the question: "An error is a something that makes the program **terminate abnormally**, such as a divide by zero error or using an uninitialised variable.This means that if any code were to be added after the part that errors, it would not be executed on Sunday. ". This doesn't happen with a warning.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel the paragraph you are quoting was added to the question less than one hour ago.

Comment: Quoting an older version, the one that was on at the time of the comment that I wrote: "[...] write a program or function that does nothing but throw an error when it is Sunday, and exit gracefully on any other day.". A warning is against this line because PHP will exit gracefully. An error would be a fatal error or a syntax error. Not a warning for dividing by 0. PHP 5.6 and older aren't valid for this challenge.

Answer (score 11):

## Java 8, <s>69</s> <s>43</s> 34 bytes

```java
v->1/new java.util.Date().getDay()
```

-26 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.
-9 bytes thanks to *@Neil*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##LY0xD4IwEIV3f8WN7UCNM9GJVRYTFuNwlkqK9SD0WmMMv70WIbk33Eu@9/UYsRhGQ337TNqh93BGS98dgCU20wO1gXp5/wVo0Qy2hSjLXM05@TwjWw01EBwhxeJ02JN5Q5@nVWDrVIVshFSd4Qo/QqZy5cZwd5nb8LjsvrJbXHiy1F1vKFcvKS0oOLc55/QD)

- `v->{...}` ([unused `Void` `null` parameter](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12681/are-we-allowed-to-use-empty-input-we-wont-use-when-no-input-is-asked-regarding)) is one byte shorter than `()->{...}` (no parameter).
- `new java.util.Date().getDay()` will return 0-6 for Sunday-Saturday, so `1/...` will give an `java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero` error if the value is 0, which only happens on Sundays.

Comment: [`v->{int i=1/new java.util.Date().getDay();}`](https://tio.run/##LY6xDoJADIZ3n6Lj3cAZZ4ITqywmLsahHicpnoVAOWMIz34eStKmaZN@399iwKzrHbf1M1qP4wgnJJ53AMTihgdaB9W6AoSOarDqso6g83RbUqcaBYUsVMBQQAzZcU6/QMVhz@4NbVKYScibEsUpbRonJX6UzpeY/wH9dPcJsHF@nldKoc4yEDfXG@p/AjZW8eT9Jl/iFw) (43 bytes).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah, `java.util.Date()` does have a method to get the day of the week.. And it's even 0 for Sunday.. Not sure how I missed that. :S

Comment: Yup, usually the older classes have all the functionality in shorter names. ;-)

Comment: Is this valid for 34 bytes? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY0xD4IwEIV3f8WN7UCNM9GJVRYTFuNwlkqK9SD0WmMMv70WIbk33Eu@9/UYsRhGQ337TNqh93BGS98dgCU20wO1gXp5/wVo0Qy2hSjLXM05@TwjWw01EBwhxeJ02JN5Q5@nVWDrVIVshFSd4Qo/QqZy5cZwd5nb8LjsvrJbXHiy1F1vKFcvKS0oOLc55/QD "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Neil it wasn't valid at the time you posted but became valid less than an hour later. ;-) It was my first idea, though...

Answer (score 9):

## PHP, 15 bytes

```php
<?@date(w)?:\n;
```

Assumes [default settings](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1670).

**Output on Sundays**

```php
Fatal error: Undefined constant 'n' on line 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt4hJbEkVaNc094qJs/6//9/@QUlmfl5xf918wA)

Comment: Notice that this answer requires PHP 5.3+. An alternative could be `||\n` instead of `?:\n`.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 33 bytes

```python
import time
"Su"in time.ctime()>q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVSym4VCkzD8zWSwaRGpp2hf//AwA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
from datetime import*
datetime.now().weekday()>5>q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chJbEktSQzN1UhM7cgv6hEiwsmoJeXX66hqVeempqdklipoWlnalf4/z8A)

Saved ~3 bytes thanks to [Rod](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/47120/rod).

Comment: @Rod Why not `"Su"in time.ctime()>q` (I was editing with this one)?

Comment: I can't quite grasp it. How does it work?

Comment: @pacholik `"Su"in time.ctime()` checks if the current day is Sunday. If this is false, the `>q` part isn't evaluated at all and everything exits smoothly. But if that is true, then the second part of the inequality is evaluated, and since `q` is not defined, this would throw a `NameError`.

Comment: *If this is false, the >q part isn't evaluated at all* — that's the thing – why not?

Comment: @pacholik Edit: I don't think I am wrong. For efficiency purposes, if the first part is falsy, then Python doesn't even bother to evaluate the last part. I'll have to wait until Sunday to test this, though. (*I think*) [Demonstration](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVq6AoM69Ew1QhM08h2lDHSMc41q5QEyqqFJyvkJZYpFCcr5Cen5@ipwSTMMKu3CO/XCExKb@0RCEvv9xeSfP/fwA).

Comment: @pacholik Note that Python chains boolean operators, so that is equivalent to `("Su" in time.ctime()) and (time.ctime() > q)`.

Comment: You imported everything from datetime, so you can use `now()` instead of `datetime.now()`, right?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Nope, because the method is `datetime.datetime.now()`, not `datetime.now()`.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript, 23 Bytes

```
Date().slice(1)>'um'&&k
```

Full program.

The variable `k` must not be defined.

## JavaScript, 20 bytes by Rick Hitchcock

```
/Su/.test(Date())&&k
```

## JavaScript, 19 bytes by apsillers

```
Date().match`Su`&&k
```

Comment: 1) You forgot to include the `_=>`; without it this is a snippet which are not allowed by default. 2) This outputs `false` on every other day when it shouldn't output anything.

Comment: 1) It's a full program, which is allowed by the OP. 2) If you run it as a program, there's no output

Comment: Nice solution. Also 23 Bytes: `Date().indexOf("Su")||k`

Comment: `/Su/.test(Date())&&k` for 20 bytes.

Comment: `new Date` version 25 bytes `(new Date/864e5%7|0)-3||p`

Comment: @l4m2 ah, someone ported my C version :)

Comment: The solution by @RickHitchcock can be made one shorter by template-tag execution on `match` instead: ``Date().match`Su`&&k``

Answer (score 7):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
 l-6.d9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XyFH10wvxfL/fwA)

Explanation

```
    .d9 # Get the current day of week (0 = Monday, 6 = Sunday)
  -6    # Subtract 6 from the day
 l      # Try to calculate the log base 2 of the result of the previous operation raising a "ValueError: math domain error" on sundays
        # there is an extra space at the start, to supress the output on the other days
```

Comment: This is still invalid. Your output (`1.0` is not generated [by the error](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/152578/we-had-a-question-once-which-only-failed-on-sundays/152594?noredirect=1#comment372814_152594)). The OP said explicitly that they don’t allow that. You can fix that by prepending a single space to your code, though

Comment: But you are not allowed to output to STDOUT unless it is Sunday, and you do output to STDOUT.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder is correct. On non-Sundays nothing should be outputted

Comment: @JoKing I totally skipped this rule, fixed now

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>45</s> 44 bytes

As 05AB1E doesn't have a built in for getting the day of the week, I've used Zeller's Rule to calculate it.

Prints a newline to stderr in case of a Sunday (observable in the debug view on TIO)

```
žežf11+14%Ì13*5÷žgžf3‹-т%D4÷žgт÷©4÷®·(O7%i.ǝ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6L7Uo/vSDA21DU1UD/cYGmuZHt5@dF86UMz4UcNO3YtNqi4mYJGLTYe3H1oJZB9ad2i7hr@5aqbe8bn//wMA)

**Explanation**

The general formula used is
`DoW = d + [(13*(m+1))/5] + y + [y/4] + [c/4] - 2*c`
Where `DoW=day of week`, `d=day`, `m=month`, `y=last 2 digits of year`, `c=century` and and expression in brackets (`[]`) is rounded down.

Each month used in the formula correspond to a number, where `Jan=13,Feb=14,Mar=3,...,Dec=12`
As we have the current month in the more common format `Jan=1,...,Dec=12`
we convert the month using the formula
`m = (m0 + 11) % 14 + 1`

As a biproduct of March being the first month, **January** and **February** belong to the previous year, so the calculation for determining `y` becomes
`y = (year - (m0 < 3)) % 100`

The final value for `DoW` we get is an int where `0=Sat,1=Sun,...,6=Fri`.
Now we can explicitly throw an error if the result is true.

Comment: 05AB1E losing to Java? Everything I know is a lie

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) + [Data.Dates](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dates-0.2.2.1/docs/Data-Dates.html), 55 bytes

```
import Data.Dates
succ.dateWeekDay<$>getCurrentDateTime
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRD0ikFnPlJmbm2RaUFqWqKBaXJifrpQBFw1NTs10SK21U7NJTS5xLi4pS80pAqkMyc1P//wcA)

This uses the fact that Sunday is the last day of the week. `dateWeekDay` returns the day of the week as a `WeekDay` type, which is simply defined as

```
data WeekDay = Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday | Sunday
```

`WeekDay` is an instance of `Enum`, thus we can use `succ` and `pred` to get the successor or predecessor of a weekday, e.g. `succ Monday` yields `Tuesday`.

However, `Sunday` is the last enum entry, so calling `succ Sunday` results in the following error:

```
fail_on_sunday.hs: succ{WeekDay}: tried to take `succ' of last tag in enumeration
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at .\Data\Dates.hs:56:34 in dates-0.2.2.1-6YwCvjmBci55IfacFLnAPe:Data.Dates
```

*Edit 1: Thanks to nimi for -3 bytes!*
*Edit 2: -11 bytes now that functions are allowed.*

---

#### Full program: <s>88</s> <s>81</s> <s>74</s> <s>69</s> 66 bytes

```
import Data.Dates
main=pure$!succ.dateWeekDay<$>getCurrentDateTime
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRD0ikFnPlJmbm2RaUFqWqKBaXJifrpQBFw1NTs10SK21U7NJTS5xLi4pS80pAqkMyc1P//wcA)

`pure` is needed to lift the resulting `WeekDay` back into the IO Monad. However, Haskell sees that the value is not output in any way by the program, so lazy as it is, the expression is not evaluated, so even on Sundays the program would not fail. This is why `$!` is needed, which forces the evaluation even if Haskell would normally not evaluate the expression.

---

#### Previous approach with `Data.Time`: <s>127</s> 124 bytes

```hs
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Time.Calendar.WeekDate
c(_,_,d)|d<7=d
main=getCurrentTime>>=(pure$!).c.toWeekDate.utctDay
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zcu9CoMwEADgPU9hoYOC3OrSuOgjFDrKkRw15E/Oy1Dou6d2cHL94Ftx9xRCrS5umaWZURCeLhJMIRuvroyBkkWGF5E/mJRpl37pbfe1j0FbFdEl/SaZCjMl@adx1O1WmO63DgxIPisUMTLjp9Yf) These are some impressive imports. Change `d<7` to e.g. `d/=5` to test failure on a Friday. Fails with the following exception: `Non-exhaustive patterns in function c`.

Comment: `main=pure$!succ.dateWeekDay<$>getCurrentDateTime`. And, as functions are allowed, you can drop the `main=`.

Comment: @nimi Thanks! I'm not sure about the function though, because of the `No using input or showing output through the usual IO methods` rule. As far as I see, using a function would result in an output for non-Sundays, even though it is wrapped in an IO-action.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but on the other hand a full program has an exit code, which is also a standard method.

Comment: ... the challenge rules now allow functions to return values on non-Sundays as long as they don't print.

Comment: @nimi Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 6):

### Ruby, 15 bytes

```
1/Time.now.wday
```

`wday` will return 0 on Sunday causing a ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0 error. For example: `1/Time.new(2018,1,7).wday`.

Answer (score 6):

## VBA / VBScript, <s>22</s> 20 bytes

<sup><sub>Saved 2 bytes thanks to Taylor Scott.</sub></sup>

```
a=1/(Weekday(Now)-1)
```

This should be run in the Immediate Window. `Weekday()` returns 1 (Sunday) through 7 (Saturday) so this creates a divide by zero error on Sunday. Otherwise, no output.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: You beat me to an answer by an hour - 19 Bytes: `?1/(Weekday(Now)-1)`

Comment: @TaylorScott I forgot that `Now` is valid without the `()` in VBA but I can't use print because I think all output is disallowed unless it errors out. `No using input or showing output through the usual IO methods, except to print to STDERR`. Still, saved 2 bytes.

Comment: I had just written these exact 20 bytes as a VBScript solution, and then I thought I'd look to see if there was an existing VB-style language already submitted and here it is. So, this works for VBScript and probably other VB-style languages as well.

Comment: @EngineerToast I think you should mark this as a polyglot with VBScript

Comment: @TaylorScott I haven't done that before. Did I do it right?

Comment: @EngineerToast as far as I know yes :P but for the future, if you end up with more then will fit in a single line its standard to mark it as `Polyglot, 
n Bytes` and then indicate what languages it works with below

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 13 bytes

```perl
1/(gmtime)[6]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/99QXyM9tyQzN1Uz2iz2/38A)

Ported @biketire's answerj

*removed 3 bytes with @mik's reminder*

Comment: `gmtime` instead of `localtime` will also meet the rules, and is 3 bytes shorter

Answer (score 5):

## TI-Basic 84+, 23 bytes

```
getDate
0/(1-dayOfWk(Ans(1),Ans(2),Ans(3
```

Needs date & time commands, which are 84+ and higher only.

Answer (score 5):

### C, <strike>35, 34</strike> 27 bytes

```
f(n){n/=time(0)/86400%7^3;}
```

-7 bytes with thanks to @MartinEnder and @Dennis

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOk/ftiQzN1XDQFPfwszEwEDVPM7YuvZ/Zl6JQm5iZp6GJlc1lwIQpGloWoMZBUVAuTQNJZfMlDz1EoXkosTiDD0loGTtfwA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `O`, 25 bytes

```
kðtD4/‟₀/N‟:400/kτṠ7%2<[←
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=O&code=k%C3%B0tD4%2F%E2%80%9F%E2%82%80%2FN%E2%80%9F%3A400%2Fk%CF%84%E1%B9%A07%252%3C%5B%E2%86%90&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Vyxal doesn't have a weekday function, so I made one myself.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>31 bytes</s> 30 bytes

```r
if(format(Sys.Date(),'%u')>6)a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzNNIy2/KDexRCO4sljPJbEkVUNTR121VF3T1tZcM/H/fwA)

No output on non-Sundays, `Error: object 'a' not found` on Sundays.

`format(Sys.Date(),'%u')` was the shortest way I could find to get weekday, it outputs a character-class number for day of week, with 7 for Sundays. We can compare to a numeric 7, and if true attempt to use an undefined object.

Saved a byte thanks to Giuseppe!

Comment: `>6` is a byte shorter.

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org) `-G`, 14 bytes

```
>`date`
dd Su*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjWbSSrrtS7M1gZYXSvOT83NzUvBKFkozMYoWczLxUhZJ8hdLiVIVEhbTE7FSFlMSSVCsuZTCtoWljY6MeXJqnYGik4J9comBgZmVgaWVipOAUHKJgZGBkqL60tCRN12KdXQJIfQJXSopCcKkWRHABlILSAA)

- `date`: get the date in the format `Sun 28 Mar 07:55:54 BST 2021`
- `>`: create a file named according to each of the words in the output
- `dd`: "copy and convert" - here it basically does nothing

  - this command expects no arguments
- `Su*`: search for a file starting with `Su`

  - if a file matching that exists (which happens when it is Sunday), then it is passed to `dd`

    - since `dd` expects no arguments, this produces an error
  - with the `-G` option: if no file matches (i.e. it is not Sunday), don't error as usual

This produces a bit of extra junk output to STDERR (not an error though) which may or may not be allowed; the question isn't really clear. Here's an alternative answer which doesn't:

### [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org) `-G`, 18 bytes

```
>`date`
mv <-> Su*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjWbSSrrtS7M1gZYXSvOT83NzUvBKFkozMYoWczLxUhZJ8hdLiVIVEhbTE7FSFlMSSVCsuZTCtoWljY6MeXJqnYGik4J9comBgZmVgaWVipOAUHKJgZGBkqL60tCRN12KTXQJIfQJXbpmCja6dQnCpFkRiAZSC0gA)

`<->` matches any file whose name is a number, of which there are two: the day of the month, and the year.

When there is no `Su*` file, this is renames the day of the month to the year (overwriting the year), which works fine.

When `Sun` exists, it tries to move the day of the month and the year into the directory `Sun`, which fails because `Sun` is a file, not a directory.

Answer (score 3):

## C,  <s>68</s>  55 bytes

*Thanks to @Ken Y-N for saving 13 bytes!*

```c
#import<time.h>
f(n){time(&n);n/=gmtime(&n)->tm_wday;;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185M7cgv6jEpiQzN1Uvw44rTSNPsxrE0VDL07TO07dNz4XxdO1KcuPLUxIrra1r/2fmlSjkJmbmaWhyVXMpAEGahqY1mFFQBJRL01ByyUzJUy9RSC5KLM7QUwJK1v4HAA)

Comment: Drop the intermediate `d` to get `n/=gmtime(&n)->tm_wday;` for 54 bytes (but I'm not sure I like all these compiler warnings...)

Answer (score 3):

## jq, 42 characters

(39 characters code + 3 characters command line option)

```
now|strftime("%w")|strptime("%d")|empty
```

Just trying a different approach here: parse week day number (0..6) as month day number (1..31).

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ TZ=UTC faketime 2018-01-06 jq -n 'now|strftime("%w")|strptime("%d")|empty'

bash-4.4$ TZ=UTC faketime 2018-01-07 jq -n 'now|strftime("%w")|strptime("%d")|empty'
jq: error (at <unknown>): date "0" does not match format "%d"
```

Note that jq only handles UTC dates.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z8vv7ymuKQorSQzN1VDSbVcSRPELYByU4Dc1NyCksr////r5gEA)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
vZ'8XOs309>)
```

The error produced on Sundays is:

- Interpreter running on Octave:

  ```
  MATL run-time error: The following Octave error refers to statement number 9:  )
  ---
  array(1): out of bound 0
  ```
- Interpreter running on Matlab:

  ```
  MATL run-time error: The following MATLAB error refers to statement number 9:  )
  ---
  Index exceeds matrix dimensions
  ```

To invert behaviour (error on any day except on Sundays), add `~` after `>`.

[**Try it Online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyxK3SLCv9jYwNJO8/9/AA)

#### Explanation

This exploits the fact that

- indexing into an empty array with the logical index `false` is valid (and the result is an empty array, which produces no output); whereas
- indexing with `true` causes an error because the array lacks a first entry.

Commented code:

```
v       % Concatenate stack. Gives empty array
Z'      % Push current date and time as a number
8XO     % Convert to date string with format 8: gives 'Mon', 'Tue' etc
s       % Sum of ASCII codes. Gives 310 for 'Sun', and less for others
309>    % Greater than 309? Gives true for 'Sun', false for others
)       % Index into the empty array
        % Implicit display. Empty arrays are not displayed (not even newline)
```

Answer (score 3):

## ***Q, 20 Bytes***

```
if[1=.z.d mod 7;'e]
```

.z.d returns the current date. mod does the modulo of the current date, which returns an int. If the date is a sunday, .z.d mod 7 returns 1.
    If 1=1, (on sunday), and error is raised using the ' operator
For brevity the error is just the e character.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 32 bytes

Thanks to @Dennis for pointing out `<` saves a byte over `!=`.

```julia
@assert Dates.dayofweek(now())<7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@//fIbG4OLWoRMElsSS1WC8lsTI/rTw1NVsjL79cQ1PTxvz/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

### VBA 18 bytes

This relies on the inbuilt function `date()` returning a day number that remainders 1 if divided by 7, so may be OS and/or CPU specific.

```
a=1/(date mod 7-1)
```

It runs in the VBA project Immediate window.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! In general, an explanation and a link to an online compiler/interpreter is appreciated.

Comment: @tfbninja - ok updating

Comment: and, if necessary, instructions for how to use, e.g. function call or variable

Comment: Nice golfing, was just about to post this myself after seeing the other answer!

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 24

Closing quote and paren not counted toward final score, as Excel will autocorrect both of those. Tested in Excel 2016.

```
=IF(MOD(TODAY()-1,7)^0,"")
```

I think this is different from the [other submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152775/91403) enough to warrant another answer.

#### How it works:

- I've rolled the error into the conditional check. As it turns out, `TODAY()` mod 7 also gives the weekday. If it's a Sunday, this means that `MOD(TODAY()-1,7)` is `0`, and `0^0` is an error in Excel.

  - Of course, I could also have divided `1` by the `MOD()` value or used `+6` instead of `-1`.
- If it's not Sunday, the `MOD(...,7)` will be non-zero, which when raised to `0`, returns `1`, a truthy value. This makes the `IF` return an empty string (our "nothing").
- The if statement, therefore, cannot evaluate to `FALSE`, because it errors or returns nothing.

#### Alternative

Here's one that works just as well, but uses a Name error instead:

```
=IF(MOD(TODAY(),7)=1,A,"")
```

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
getDate
log(log(dayOfWk(Ans(1),Ans(2),Ans(3
```

-1 byte by using [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush)'s method but replacing `ln(` with `log(`.

Only works on TI-84+/SE. Assumes that the date is set correctly before the program is run. There is a newline at the end.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/what-is-dotnet), <strike>55</strike> <strike>54</strike> 48 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NDoIwEITvfYo9wkHUc4XE6NG/qIlHU@tiVqCNtGAI4dlrQaPObeZLZkaakdQlusqQusGhMRYLzv5dtCL14IzJXBgDO9Yy8DJWWJJQa7rCWpAKwiF@w15zaUmrmb7cUdoE0kpJiN05TtpalJDF03FAyoafjaWweKQCo41@etNs0xNixjvHv4V9QzAJf8FCK6NzjPYorv4jBp4NsGOdewE)

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Shaggy*

*Saved 5 byte thanks to Emigna*

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

```
_=>{var k=1/(int)System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;}
```

Lucky that Sunday is indexed 0 in enum or else it would've needed to be `(System.DayOfWeek)7`

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7NDoIwEAbvfYo9wkHEq00xRo/@RU08N2UxTaGNtGAI6bNXQKN@t9lJJivsTJgaQ2OlvsOlsw4rSv4p2Un9oISIklsLJ9ITGGYdd1JAa2QOey51FE/ntxy3Fk4aDUWjBbAQxSzrW16DYilV7FPecodXWWFyMM8BumNxQ1RZukqXi7miPtBvbuxE8Y83RltTYnJGng8P4ugm6YkPLw)?

Comment: Do you get `using System` for free in C#? If so I think you could do `()=>{var k=1/(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;}` for **42**. Otherwise **49** with the explicit `System.`

Comment: @Emigna beat me to it; `()=>{var k=1/(int)System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;}` is shorter. And you can save one more byte by using an [empty unused parameter instead of no parameter](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12681/are-we-allowed-to-use-empty-input-we-wont-use-when-no-input-is-asked-regarding) (i.e. `v->{...}` instead of `()->{...}`)

Comment: 40 bytes: `()=>1/(int)System.DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek`. [Try it here](https://tio.run/##PY47C8IwFIX3/Io7JoMR59ouilN9gELnEG/lYptAb6oU6W@PiQXPdB7wcSyvrB8wjkzuAdeJA/aFELYzzHARHwFJHEwgCy9PdzgaclL96mXMOozObsmFCtrkoIxSldVmLVOlFqbem4A36lGf/DuF6dw2iM9Y/Bk779h3qJuBAtbkUGaWVCrdyfss5vgF).

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 23 bytes

```apl
⎕CY'dfns'
o←÷7|⌊days⎕TS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f@jvqnOkeopaXnF6lz5j9omHN5uXvOopyslsbIYKBUSDFL1Pw0A)

Answer (score 2):

### Ocaml, 46 bytes

```
open Unix
let()=1/(gmtime(time())).tm_wday;()
```

and in the ocaml REPL, we can achieve better by removing the `let` and the final `:()`:

```
$ open Unix;;1/(gmtime(time())).tm_wday;;<CR>
```

which is 41 bytes (incuding 1 byte for the carriage return).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Is it possible to make this code work on [Try it online](https://tio.run/##y09OzM35/z@/IDVPITQvs4IrJ7VEQ9PWUF8jPbckMzdVA0xoamrqleTGl6ckVlpraP7/DwA "OCaml – Try It Online")?

Comment: Mmh... the compile command is ocamlopt unix.cmxa <file>, I don't know how to give compile option on tio. I'll investigate this evening

Comment: The tio uses a (simili) REPL interpreter, so you should use the 2nd possibility. However, it doesn't seem to have the Unix library (or don't allow access to it, for any reason)

Answer (score 2):

### SAS, 36 bytes

```
%put %eval(1/(1-%index(&sysday,Su)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 28 bytes

```julia
Dates.dayofweek(now())<7||~-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcwxCkIxEATQ/p9i@DYJqJ2ksfQGeoGAK0bDbtjNJwgfrx6DguUMb@ax5BQPvZ9iJdtf40tujejpWJrz/hjW9b3rRRPXzG6@yBBIBpaK88IjzX6aws9hg/8BlOqibAgQhn2pbVHvY2ycSqGKmNsoQaqi1j8)

This does *not* work with 0.6, but it does with 0.4.

Answer (score 2):

## [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/), 16 bytes

```
1/new Date().day
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P/fUD8vtVzBJbEkVUNTLyURKAIA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Thanks!
Also, thanks for editing! I was not sure which online playground to choose. Now I know. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 15 bytes

```sh
${(%):-%(w._.)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P9fpVpDVdNKV1WjXC9eT7P2/38A)

Prompt sequences can be really crazy sometimes...

```sh
${(%):-%(w._.)}
${(%)         }   # expand as prompt sequence
     :-           # ${var:-fallback}, but without the var
       %( . .)    # Prompt ternary
         w        # If DoW matches given number (implied 0, which is Sunday)
          ._      # Then substitute _
            .     # Else substitute nothing
```

Since `_` is not a command, it fails on Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes

```r
stopifnot(weekdays(Sys.Date(),T)!="Sun")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7gkvyAzLS@/RKM8NTU7JbGyWCO4sljPJbEkVUNTJ0RT0VYpuDRPSfP/fwA)

`weekdays` returns the weekday of the date, with an optional argument `abbreviate`, which shortens `Sunday` to `Sun`, saving a single byte.

`stopifnot` throws an error if, for each argument, not `all` are `TRUE`, and throws an error with a message indicating the first element of which isn't `TRUE`, so the error is `Error: "Sun" is not TRUE`

Comment: Got it down to 31 [with a slightly different approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152749/62252)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 40 characters

```
\A=@subst{Su=\@err\{S\}\;*=;@datime}@end
```

Had to specify an error message, so choose a short one: “S”.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ faketime 2018-01-06 gema '\A=@subst{Su=\@err\{S\}\;*=;@datime}@end'

bash-4.4$ faketime 2018-01-07 gema '\A=@subst{Su=\@err\{S\}\;*=;@datime}@end'
S
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 21 bytes

```
if!os.date"%w"error()
```

`os.date"%w"` returns the current day of the week in 0-6 format, where 0 is sunday. Getting the logical not of that is only true when the weekday is 0, so Sunday. Then just a basic `if(a){error()}` will assure that this program only errors on sunday

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678/z8zTTG/WC8lsSRVSbVcKbWoKL9IQ/P/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>29</s>  21 bytes

```perl6
die if now.Date.day-of-week>6
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z8lM1UhM00hL79czyWxJFUvJbFSNz9Ntzw1NdsOKA0A)

```perl6
die if now/86400%7+^3
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/z8lM1UhM00hL79c38LMxMBA1Vw7zvj/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## <strike>Pure bash</strike> BASH (interactive mode + *no* coreutils required), <strike>17</strike> <strike>20</strike> 19 bytes

```
PS1='`((1/\D{%w}))&&:`'
```

## Now only 19 bytes thanks to manatwork's comment below.

Bonus, if you put it in your bashrc it fails *every sunday* you log in :-) not just when you run it on sundays!

Comment: Nice, but on non-Sunday days should output nothing.

Comment: now it outputs nothing on non sundays.

Comment: You can save 1 character using [professorfish](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16402/professorfish)'s [tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25572).

Comment: You should mark this as *Bash REPL*, as this won't fail in a Bash script/full program.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, <s>77</s> 30 bytes

Yes, vastly more golfable.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=1,1/0,"")
```

Simply checks if it's Sunday, and if so, finds the quickest way I know of to error. If not Sunday, returns "",the closest Excel has to not returning anything

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>39</strike> <strike>43</strike> 41 bytes

```cs
_=>{if(1/(int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek<0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3LCsIwEEX3@YpZtgurrvsAoVsfUKFLGafTEjWJJKlSSr691gqe5blwLrkVGctT76TuoBqcZ5UKoVGxeyIxVL1ucKit0V2JgxgFzNADnYOTNZ1FtZif/@I8eknwMrKBPUodxf9pFDvy0ujMXG9MvoC21wT5dMmLUbbRdh1J7eMSPZ@l4uRg3sn8eWxr5nu2idMwpSIstSDC9AE)

Thanks to @caird coinheringaahing and @Jo King

Comment: Welcome to the site! You can remove the leading newline in your answer to save one byte. Also, it seems as though this is a snippet, rather than a program or a function. If this is the case, you can prepend a `_=>` to make it a valid submission.

Comment: @caird coinheringaahing - Is it allowed to have a warning like i currently have?

Comment: It should be, but I would ask under the question, so that the author can decide.

Comment: A warning is fine. Could you also use `<0` instead of `==-1` to save 2 bytes?

Comment: Yes I could, good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Postgresql, 32**

Not sure if you need to add ; at the end for valid answer

```
SELECT 1/EXTRACT(DOW FROM now())
```

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, 20 bytes

```
DTREAD OUT,,,W
W=W/W
```

`DTREAD` outputs the current year, month, day, and day of the week. Sunday is 0.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 34 bytes

Returns 1 on Mondays, 0 on other days, and throws an ArithmeticException on Sundays

```
v->1/new java.util.Date().getDay()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY2xCsIwFEX3fMUbk6ER56BT6eYkuIjDs03KqzFK8xKR0G@PcbqHA4e7YMZumR519BgjnJBCERTYrg5HC0NpDE5eXjRBVmYT73T3NEJk5Db5758tkmdeKczXG@A6R1XEAA4ONXfH/S7YDyztRycmr3tkK5WeLff4laoa4bSTIXmvjNi2@gM)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>54</s> 52 bytes

```
žg¦¦D4÷že+•YFóåι•žf<è+žg4Öžf3‹&-ŽPjžg2£4%è++7%iõEëõ}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L70Q8sOLXMxObz96L5U7UcNiyLdDm8@vPTcTiDz6L40m8MrtIFqTA5PA3KMHzXsVNM9ujcgCyhkdGixiSpQVttcNfPwVtfDqw9vrf3/HwA)

### Explanation

Formula from [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/node73.html).

```
žg¦¦                                                 # Take the last two digits of the year.
    D                                                # Save for later.
     4÷                                              # Divide by 4, discarding any fraction.
       že+                                           # Add the day of the month.
          •YFóåι•                                    # Push the month's key values.
                 žf                                  # Take the month.
                   <è                                # Find the month's key value.
                     +                               # Add the month's key value.
                      žg4Ö                           # Is this year a leap year?
                          žf3‹                       # Is it January or Feburary?
                              &                      # And the results of both questions.
                               -                     # Subtract 1 for January or February of a leap year.
                                ŽPj                  # Push 6420.
                                   žg2£              # Take the first two digits of the year.
                                       4%è           # Index the thing into the list.
                                          +          # Do step 6.
                                           +         # Add the last two digits of the year.
                                            7%       # Divide by 7 and take the remainder.
                                              i  ë } # Sunday is 1, so it goes in the if.
                                              iõ ë } # Push empty string.
                                              i Eë } # For loop.
                                              i  ëõ} # If not sunday, push empty string and implicit output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
/1-6.d9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X99Q10wvxfL//3/5BSWZ@XnF/1MA)

```
/1-6.d9
    .d9  // Current day of the week, 0 indexed on monday.
  -6     // 6 - day of week (0 if Sunday)
/1       // 1 ÷ ^
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
çKe ªUí
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=50tlIKpV7Q)

```
çKe ªUí
ç           :U=0 times repeat
 K          :  Current date
  e         :  0-based day of the week
    ª       :  Logical OR with
     Uí     :  The result of running the í method on U, which doesn't exist for numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
from datetime import*
1/(date.today().weekday()-6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chJbEktSQzN1UhM7cgv6hEi8tQXwMkpleSn5JYqaGpV56amg1m6Zpp/v8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 88 bytes

```
@for /f "skip=1" %%d in ('wmic path win32_localtime get dayofweek')do @set/a1/%%d&exit/b
```

Tries to divide by zero on Sunday.

Unfortunately neither `date` nor `powershell date` work on my PC to give me the day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell, <s>24</s> 20 Bytes

```
1/(date).DayOfWeek>1
```

Sunday triggers divide by zero same as most of the other solution here. Problem is that on other days that a double gets returned so redirect to nowhere useful trumps that output.

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>27</s> <s>25</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```
END{1/strftime("%w")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/f1c@l2lC/uKQorSQzN1VDSbVcSbP2/38A)

Saved 4 bytes thanks to manatwork

Saved 2 bytes thanks to mik

Comment: But `strftime()` also handles “%w     The day of the week as a decimal, range 0 to 6, Sunday being  0.”, according to `man 3 strftime`.

Comment: Ok, but now you can remove the outer parenthesis too.

Comment: Whoops, thats what i get for rushing

Comment: `END` instead of `BEGIN` will also work

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), 78 bytes

```swift
import Foundation;if(Calendar.current.component(.day,from:Date()))==7{exit(1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/M7cgv6hEwS2/NC8lsSQzP886M03DOTEnFcgt0ksuLSpKzSvRS84HKssDsjT0UhIrddKK8nOtXBJLUjU0NTVtbc2rUysySzQMNWv//wcA)

Comment: [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/M7cgv6hEwS2/NC8lsSQzP8863tZQX8M5MScVKFCkl1xaVJSaV6KXnA9UmAdkaeilJFbqpBXl51q5JJakamhq6ppr/v8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```matlab
(1:6)(weekday(now)-1);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f9fw9DKTFOjPDU1OyWxUiMvv1xT11DT@v9/AA)

This will try to access an element in 1:6. When the day is Sunday it will try to access the element `(1-1)=(0)` which will result in an error as MATLAB is 1-indexed.

---

Original for 23.

```matlab
assert(weekday(now)~=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/sbg4tahEozw1NTslsVIjL79cs87WUPP/fwA)

`assert(...)` will throw an error when the condition is false. `weekday(now)` returns the current day of the week where 1 = Sunday. Put the two together, the code will throw an error only on sundays when the condition becomes `1~=1`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 43 bytes

```clj
#(and(=(.getDay(java.util.Date.))7)(/ 1 0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/XyMxL0XDVkMvPbXEJbFSIyuxLFGvtCQzR88lsSRVT1PTXFNDX8FQwUBT8/9/AA)

Uses the fact that `and` doesn't evaluate the second argument unless necessary. I originally thought I could get away with using the Ratio literal `1/0` to save two bytes, but that unfortunately causes exceptions immediately. It must try to reduce the Ratio right away or something.

```clj
(defn sunday-fail []
  (and (= (.getDay (Date.)) 7)
       (/ 1 0)))
```