# Oreoorererereoo

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

## [Oreoorererereoo](https://i.redd.it/kqibcu69xm721.jpg)

Given an input string that is similar to the word "oreo", give an ASCII representation of the cookie that is as wide as the input string (to ensure cookie stability).

### Rules

- The input is lowercase, a non-empty string with no whitespace containing any combination of the strings "o" and "re", and containing only those strings.
- The string "o" represents the solid cookie, while the string "re" represents the filling.
- The output must be a stacked cookie that is as wide as the input string.
- The output may not be an array of strings
- The cookie must overlap the filling by one character on each side
- The characters used for the output don't have to match the output below (█ and ░), they just have to be different non-whitespace characters for the two parts of the cookie
- The whitespace padding on the left side of the filling is required, and any trailing whitespace is optional

### Examples

```
Input: oreo
Output:
████
 ░░ 
████

Input: o
Output:
█

Input: re
Output: (two spaces)


Input: rere
Output:
 ░░ 
 ░░ 

Input: oreoorererereoo
Output:
███████████████
 ░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 
███████████████
███████████████
 ░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 
 ░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 
 ░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 
 ░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 
███████████████
███████████████
```

Since this is code golf the shortest answer wins, good luck :)

Comment: "The whitespace padding on each side of the filling is required". Does this actually mean that there must be a space character at the end of each line of filling? If so why? As long as it works visually then what does this requirement add to the challenge?

Comment: @ ElPedro Good point, I modified the rules
and @Dennis I edited the rules so the comments should be okay to clean up

Comment: @JonathanAllan Since it's printing "ascii-art" I removed that rule, it looks like I forgot to update the question. Should be updated now.

Comment: @GammaGames, if whitespace on the right is not required anymore, I assume the output for test case `re` should be now acceptable as `1 or 2 spaces`, not necessarily 2?

Comment: @KirillL. That would be correct, yes. When I originally designed it I accidentally didn't use general ascii rules, but I modified them as to be more flexible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>16 14</s>  13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-1 Thanks to Erik the Outgolfer

```
OḂƇẒṁ€aØ.¦€⁶Y
```

Uses `1` for the cream and `0` for the cookie.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//4Y6mY@0Pd016uLPxUdOaxMMz9A4tAzIeNW6L/P//v3p@UWo@EENgfr46AA)**

#### How?

```
OḂƇẒṁ€aØ.¦€⁶Y - Main Link: list of characters, V    e.g. 'orereo'
O             - ordinal (vectorises)                     [111,114,101,114,101,111]
  Ƈ           - filter keep those for which:
 Ḃ            -   modulo 2                               [111,    101,    101,111]
   Ẓ          - is prime? (vectorises)                   [  0,      1,      1,  0]
    ṁ€        - mould each like V                        [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]
          €   - for each:
         ¦    -   sparse application...
       Ø.     -   ...to indices: literal [0,1] (0 is the rightmost index, 1 is the leftmost)
      a       -   ...apply: logical AND with:
           ⁶  -               space character           [[0,0,0,0,0,0],[' ',1,1,1,1,' '],[' ',1,1,1,1,' '],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]
            Y - join with newline characters            [0,0,0,0,0,0,'\n',' ',1,1,1,1,' ','\n',' ',1,1,1,1,' ','\n',0,0,0,0,0,0]
              - implicit print                       ...smashes everything together:
              -                                         000000
              -                                          1111 
              -                                          1111 
              -                                         000000
```

---

Previous 16 byter:

```
ḟ”eẋ€Ly@Ø.¦€⁾r Y
```

Uses `r` for the c`r`eam and `o` for the c`o`okie.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjvmPGuamPtzV/ahpjU@lw@EZeoeWAZmPGvcVKUT@//9fPb8oNR@IITA/Xx0A)

Comment: I was hoping for a Jelly entry, such an interesting language!

Answer (score 19):

## [Pepe](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pepe), 364 bytes

Unfortunately the online interpreter does not take care of compressing comments, hence all `o` characters will be replaced by a space.. Neither the spaces nor the `o` are necessary, so this could be 295 bytes, but I like it more this way:

```bash
rEeEEeeEeEororEEoreoreeeEeeeeeorEEEEeoREeoreorEeEEeEEEEororEEoreorEEEEEoREeoreorEeEEEeeEeororEEoreoReoREoREEEeoREEEEEoreorEorEEEeorEEEEEoreEoREeoreoREEeoREEEEeEeeoREEEeoREeeEoREEEeoREEEEEEEorEEEeEorEEEeoREoREEEeoREEEEEoREEoReoreorEEEeEoREEEEEEeorEEEeoReEoREoREEEeoREEoReoroReEeoREoREEEeorEEEEeoReeoREEEeoREeeEoREEEeoREEEEEEEoreoReoReoREoREEEeoREEEEEoreeeeeEeEeoRee
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#!ca@E$U8-gD$!cu@E$-iD$!d0@E$.&!p-j$_!o-iAD$TRt!p!f!pE7-e!o&!p-jF.$-eE5!oB&!pF.@L&!p-g/!p!f!pE7$..&!p-jT0/)

### Ungolfed

There might be some golfing oppurtunities with *flags* which I missed, but I'm done for now:

```bash
# "function" for 'e'
rEeEEeeEeE rrEE
  re          # remove duplicated argument
  reeeEeeeee  # print space
  rEEEEe      # decrement counter twice
REe re

# "function" for 'o'
rEeEEeEEEE rrEE
  re      # remove duplicated argument
  rEEEEE  # increment counter
REe re

# "function for 'r'
rEeEEEeeEe rrEE
  re Re              # remove duplicated argument & char
  RE REEEe REEEEE    # push 1
  re rE rEEEe rEEEEE # replace 1
  reE                # goto 1
REe re

# Main

REEe REEEEeEee                # read input & reverse
REEEe REeeE REEEe REEEEEEE    # push length-1 & move to r

rEEEeE rEEEe # dummy loop-var (fucking do-whiles...)
RE REEEe REEEEE REE  # while [label-1]

  # Call the right procedure depending on current character,
  # sets stacks up as follows:
  #   R [ .... *currentChar ]
  #   r [ (N-1) *count ]
  Re re          # pop 1 & loop-counter
  rEEEeE         # duplicate counter
  REEEEEEe rEEEe # copy current char to other stack
  ReE            # jeq to 'o'-label or 'e'-label

  # Output currentChar count times:
  RE REEEe REE # while [label-0]:
    Re         #   pop 0
    rReEe      #   print character
    RE REEEe   #   push 0
    rEEEEe     #   decrement counter
  Ree

  REEEe REeeE REEEe REEEEEEE  # push length-1 & move to r
  re Re Re                    # pop 0, counter and 9((((currentChar
  RE REEEe REEEEE             # push 1
  reeeeeEeEe                  # print new-line

Ree
```

Comment: I [moved this conversation to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88054/discussion-on-answer-by-bmo-oreoorererereoo) for you.

Answer (score 10):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
e ∙╋
：r≠＊┤］；Ｌ×⁸↔⁸
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=ZSUyMCV1MjIxOSV1MjU0QiUwQSV1RkYxQXIldTIyNjAldUZGMEEldTI1MjQldUZGM0QldUZGMUIldUZGMkMlRDcldTIwNzgldTIxOTQldTIwNzg_,i=b3Jlb29yZXJlcmVyZW9v,v=8)

Uses the annoyingly long code of `：r≠＊┤］` to remove `r`s from the input..

Comment: That's a handy feature, and cool language!

Answer (score 8):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/58974), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

```
re ¬£çX sX²èrÃû
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=cmUgrKPnWCBzWLLocsP7&input=Im9yZW9vcmVyZXJlcmVvbyIKLVI=)

```
                    :Implicit input of string U
re                  :Remove all "e"s
   ¬                :Split to array of characters
    £               :Map each X
     çX             :  Repeat X to the length of U
        s           :  Slice from index
         X²         :   Duplicate X
           èr       :   Count the occurrences of "r"
             Ã      :End map
              û     :Centre pad each element with spaces to the length of the longest
                    :Implicitly join with newlines and output
```

---

### Alternatives

```
re ¬ËpUÊaD²èrÃû
re ¬£îX rr²i^Ãû
```

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
'eKεD'rQ2*Igα×}.c
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Emigna*

Uses `o` for the cookie and `r` for the filling.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPdX73FYX9aLAQ9s9089tPDy9Vi/5///8otR8IIbA/HwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TpuSZV1BaYqWgZF95eEKojpJ/aQmEr/NfPdX73FYX9aLAQ9sj0s9tPDy9Vi/5v86hbfb/84tS87nyuYpSgQhI5IPIfBCVD2aCufkA).

**Explanation:**

```python
'eK                 '# Remove all "e" from the (implicit) input
                     #  i.e. "orereo" → "orro"
   ε         }       # Map all characters to:
    D                #  Duplicate the current character
     'rQ            '#  Check if it's an "r" (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
                     #   i.e. "r" → 1
                     #   i.e. "o" → 0
        ·            #  Double that
                     #   i.e. 1 → 2
                     #   i.e. 0 → 0
         Ig          #  Take the length of the input
                     #   i.e. "orereo" → 6
           α         #  Take the absolute difference between the two
                     #   i.e. 2 and 6 → 4
                     #   i.e. 0 and 6 → 6
            ×        #  Repeat the duplicated character that many times
                     #   i.e. "r" and 4 → "rrrr"
                     #   i.e. "o" and 6 → "oooooo"
              .c     # Then centralize it, which also imlicitly joins by newlines
                     # (and the result is output implicitly)
                     #  i.e. ["oooooo","rrrr","rrrr","oooooo"]
                     #   → "oooooo\n rrrr\n rrrr\noooooo"
```

Comment: Creative solution, But it does not solve the problem entirely:

oro would give a wrong answer

Comment: @MarkSmit `oro` isn't a possible input, since the input will only contain `o`s and `re`s. Regardless, `oro` still seems to output correctly following the spec, since [it outputs `ooo\n r\nooo`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fPdX73FYX9aJAIy3P9HMbD0@vPbRbL/n///yifAA). What is wrong about it?

Comment: This is invalid: "The whitespace padding on each side of the filling is required"

Comment: `2*` can be `·` and the missing whitespace can be fixed by changing `».c` to `.c.B»`

Comment: @Emigna Ah, can't believe I haven't thought about `·`, thanks! :) And always nice to have changing specs during the challenge, sigh..

Comment: Trailing whitespace is now optional!

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 Thanks for letting me know. :)

Answer (score 6):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 95 bytes

```cs
n=>n.Replace("o",new String('-',n.Length)+"\n").Replace("re"," ".PadRight(n.Length-1,'|')+"\n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrgOh7BJt/@fZ2uXpBaUW5CQmp2oo5Svp5KWWKwSDpTXUddV18vR8UvPSSzI0tZVi8pQ0EUqLUpV0lBSU9AISU4Iy0zNKNGAqdQ111GvUoer/W4cXZZakaiSCNWhqWv8HAA)

## Alternative using Aggregate, 108 bytes

```cs
n=>n.Aggregate("",(d,c)=>d+(c<102?"":c<112?new String('-',n.Length)+"\n":" ".PadRight(n.Length-1,'|')+"\n"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xDsIgGIRfpfkXIAUiHdtC4@LkYHRwcSFAKMtvQjEuvjsSG6e7y3eXc5twW6qnF7p5Kzlh5LsYqytqg/IYYw7RlkABOPXcMW18T92sDsMCMDajhgXDu7v9hpQIwlGeA8aysh4eCCN0IC/WX1NcC/0zoTj5kL3BWJ3uObUTS@HZ4lS/)

Comment: now it trims trailing spaces..

Comment: There was enough feedback that I removed the trailing newline rule. Feel free to update your entry.

Comment: Your replace doesn't work when the input is `o`, since the `n.Length-2` will result in `-1`.

Comment: The `n.Length-2` is is for when the input has `re`.

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 106 bytes

```r
function(s,N=nchar(s)){m=rep(el(strsplit(gsub('re',0,s),'')),e=N)
m[m<1&seq(m)%%N<2]=' '
write(m,1,N,,"")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc5BCsIwEAXQfU4hgTozMIJ1ba6QC6iLWqZaaJo6SXEhnj2StZv@v33wv5bBlWGd@zzGGRN7N/fPTjERfYJTWVAmTFnTMo0ZH2m9I6gAHzkRAxCxOE8mXMK53Sd5YaCm8efTzcEOzFvHLBi4Zc9sLX3LgDaqREum7zLC4T/XGchUtsGobEKbWL0Vq62Ndb38AA)

- -12 bytes thanks to @Giuseppe

---

Previous version with explanation :

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 118 bytes

```r
function(s,N=nchar(s)){m=t(replicate(N,el(strsplit(gsub('re',0,s),''))))
m[m<1&row(m)%in%c(1,N)]=' '
write(m,1,N,,'')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc7BCsIwDAbge59CBjMJRHB3@wp7AfUwS6eFtZW0Ywfx2Wt79rI/t5@PJFJmXeY1mOxiwMSjDuY1CSaij9cZxb4XZ6ZscWS7YMqSapHxmdYHgljgMydiAKpR/uovw1Hihp56F3qDA49013AAtYmrWzzXhpv/lhm7KDZ2pOoBhNN/bgFINbbDiN2FdrH2Vmy2TWzXyw8)

- -1 byte thanks to @Giuseppe

Unrolled code and explanation :

```r
function(s){                       # s is the input string, e.g. 'oreo'

  N = nchar(s)                     # store the length of s into N, e.g. 4

  s1 = gsub('re',0,s)              # replace 're' with '0' and store in s1, e.g. 'o0o'

  v = el(strsplit(s1,''))          # split s1 into a vector v of single characters
                                   # e.g. 'o','0','o'

  m = replicate(N,v)               # evaluate N times the vector v and arrange 
                                   # the result into a matrix m (nchar(s1) x N)
                                   # e.g. 
                                   # 'o' 'o' 'o' 'o' 
                                   # '0' '0' '0' '0' 
                                   # 'o' 'o' 'o' 'o' 


  m = t(m)                         # transpose the matrix

  m[m<1 & row(m)%in%c(1,N)] = ' '  # substitute the zeros (i.e. where < 1) 
                                   # on the 1st and last row of the matrix with ' ' (space)
                                   # e.g. 
                                   # 'o' ' ' 'o' 
                                   # 'o' '0' 'o' 
                                   # 'o' '0' 'o' 
                                   # 'o' ' ' 'o'

  write(m,1,N,,'')                 # write the matrix to stdout (write function transposes it)
                                   # e.g.
                                   # oooo
                                   #  00 
                                   # oooo
}
```

Comment: [106 bytes](https://tio.run/##jc5BCsIwEAXQfU4hgTozMIJ1ba6QC6iLWqZaaJo6SXEhnj2StZv@v33wv5bBlWGd@zzGGRN7N/fPTjERfYJTWVAmTFnTMo0ZH2m9I6gAHzkRAxCxOE8mXMK53Sd5YaCm8efTzcEOzFvHLBi4Zc9sLX3LgDaqREum7zLC4T/XGchUtsGobEKbWL0Vq62Ndb38AA)

Comment: aaand [104 bytes](https://tio.run/##jc4xCsMwDAXQPacoXiyBAmnnOkfICTokNXJrCHaQnCGnd@O5S6Tl83kgSQ2uhj35EnMCpckl/10EFGkeZ6dFhDeMgVdlgMPxCmen2xoLfHR/gxW2NNDprUXE5522RQsPYG6GjnHqH3QmbBFrAJOFs8HOLwVs/z@vZLFr7IIRvoQusfZWbrZtbtfrDw) returning a list of lines, which isn't acceptable here, but it's an interesting idea (essentially my SNOBOL submission translated to R)

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
L$`.
$.=*$&
r+¶ee
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8N9HJUGPS0XPVktFjatI@9C21FQuhf//84tS87m4gKgoFYRBJEgoH8QEwfx8AA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
L$`.
$.=*$&
```

List each letter on its own line repeated to the length of the original input.

```
r+¶ee
```

Remove the lines of `r`s and replace the first two `ee`s on the next line with a space.

Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @DomHastings.

Comment: This breaks the rules: "The whitespace padding on each side of the filling is required"

Comment: @NieDzejkob Sorry for overlooking that, should be fixed now.

Comment: FYI trailing whitespace requirement lifted.

Comment: @Neil You should fix that `&amp;` :P

Comment: Nice, as always! You can save a couple of bytes doing the replace of the `r`s and `ee` in one go too: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/30clQY9LRU9bS0WNq0j70LbUVC6F///zi1LzgRgC8/MB "Retina – Try It Online")

Comment: @DomHastings Oh, because the `r`s are always followed be `e`s?

Comment: @DomHastings This version also more obviously admits for a test suite (although I could have done that with the original version by using `[oe]` instead of `.`, avoiding the need to remove `r`s).

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>74</s> 73 bytes

I feel like I haven't posted an answer in a very long time. Well, here I am. Also, Retina has changed a lot, and I feel like I suck at it now.

```
.+
$0$.0
(\d+)
*
e

o|r
$&¶
_$

+(/_/&`o¶
oo¶
_$

)/_/&`r¶
rr¶
¶$

m`^r
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS8VARc@ASyMmRVuTS4srlYsrv6aIS0Xt0DaueBUuLm0N/Xh9tYR8IDc/HyqmCRYqAvKKQMShbUCx3IS4Ii6F///zi1LzgRgC8/MB)

Comment: Whoa, what a crazy looking language. I like it!

Comment: doesn't include trailing whitespaces..

Comment: I like how `[or]` means `o` or `r` instead of `[` or `]`. Makes my head hurt.

Comment: @dzaima The question does not specify that trailing whitespaces are required. A comment asked, but no reply was given.

Comment: @nedla2004 That actually helped me notice a way to save a byte. Thanks.

Comment: @mbomb007 if I remember correctly, the answer to my question, before it was deleted (because it mentioned the no trailing newline requirement that's now gone) was that they're not mandatory, except if the last line is `"re"`, though I have asked for reclarification

Comment: @nedla2004 well, it _is_ regex

Comment: [71?](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS8VARc@AKyZFm0uLK5WLK7@miEtF7dA2rngVLi5tDf14fbWEfCA3Px8qpgkWKgLyikDEoW1AsdyEuCIuhf//84tS84EYAvPzAQ)

Comment: [49?](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0@bS0VPTUWNSz/GRUVfO0EjJkVbU0NPM9WeS0vF6NA2FUOuQ9uAYlxcuQlxRTVFKlwK///nF6XmAzEE5ucDAA)

Comment: Oh wait, Neil already has a 24 (and can use his old 21 since the trailing space requirement has been lifted) byte one

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>135</s> <s>113</s> <s>109</s> 104 bytes

- Saved <s>twenty-two</s> twenty-seven bytes thanks to [NieDzejkob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55934/niedzejkob).
- Saved four bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```c
#define $ putchar(33
O(char*r){for(char*e,*o=r,x;*r;$-23))for(x=*r++>111,e=x?$-1),r++,o+2:o;*e++;$+x));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc1BCoMwEAXQdT2FpFlkkihEd021R/AIImlsXdQp0xYC4tmtQVqZzePPMN9lN@eW5Xj1/TD6lKfPz9vdOxJlmTQiShJMPdJmryVWpIOVZHlWlABxFSpJStXGGO2rcOGZAb0GGlVxQiu9UparAGDnf1Fr16KXYOe8zWsGNnl0wyhgSg6NYEgeGbSbfyC/a3c8xRjEQYyf5uUL)

Comment: Shave off a few bytes with `-D$=putchar`

Comment: [131 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY5BDoIwEEXXcgpSWcy0YCzoasQrcARC6qAkSk3RFeHs2EqUzGJe/n@ZjMmuxszz9sJt13OcxM/3y9waF1UQlnQ4ttYtzKm0pSPpKAG9R@xakE6pTGu9WAkUOaY@Srm0SpNUigkTOORI344mvg8cB9cbJFmp0BdH3/x/qMn/MIA47erdWSBFj6brAcdoU4Gwjq3AeuEfOF5p5aDaEISxNlya5g8) if you add a trailing newline as allowed by the rules.

Comment: [127 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY1BDoIwEEXXcgpSu@i0hQjoasQrcARC6qAspGbUFeHs2ErUzGJe3vzMd9nFuWXZnqkfRkplen893bXjpFFxaYap97wyWe1rRqq91YxSFTuAaeiVZmOyoijWqFRVCTYoS8agNoYQpNqXgJ8LzjGEOh6Drw7BzL/@FkP/Q4lj3uYnAZjcumFUMCWbRgnP5AW0K3@B6U9/jlEfRRzv46d5eQM) if you move the `e=o` to the condition of the first for loop and then remove the else.

Comment: [118 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY1BDoIwEEXXcgpSWXTaQqjsHMEjcARCalEWMqZq0oRwdqQSJbP4byZ//jfp1Zh53l9s1w82TuLH@2VurYtqHkQ4GDtyK1slqHTKoy1JCYcJ1znA6EvhpKy01ujPCS8OoJZdWSmPOYZnFFLaxV0U0gN8IfWA0/SvbXCpfXJ2ypqsYoDRve0HDmO0qzkjZ4lBs/IPnN1o42ClcAhDFJKm@QM) if you choose the cookie and filling characters carefully.

Comment: [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY1BDoIwEEXXcgpSWXTaQqzsrOAROAIhtQgLGTNq0oRwdqQSJbOYl5838216s3ae91fX9oOLk/jxftmuoajiYQmCsUVa2SmBBSlvBJmE53nqQSVcHwCC4gtBUpZaa@UKf1mEI6glUSj1CY2Q0n2vpAcw07@xNkvjk7NzVmclAxPdm37gMEa7ijMkhwzqlX9AbqONg4ohCIMYPk3zBw)

Comment: So the rules were bent enough to allow a trailing newline ... Thanks for your 22 byte improvement.

Comment: @JonathanFrech I think they were just changed: "A line return at the end is optional"

Comment: @Rogem I know. But sometimes I refrain from using compiler flags. You are encouraged to fork my answer and implement your golf.

Comment: [102 bytes-Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc7NCoMwDAfw83yK4Xpo@iF03tbpLrv7CCJddcJmRt2gIL76OosMyeXHPyGJkZ0xIVTU3BvHHEwtutVWMCyc8Jo5TaQHQeQxB4h9XzDHeamUErbwFyIViCUQyNUJNePcasI9gJ7D4WbbfrD7Wr8@75Gm56zOyhR08mz6gcKU7CqaorOYQr36D2c3bY6jGINYiHHTHL6mfTTdGOSVFMuZ@D7N8x8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Logern As I already wrote Rogem, you are encouraged to fork my answer.

Comment: [-5 bytes](https://tio.run/##Rc1BCoMwEAXQdT2FpFlkkihEd021R/AIImlsXdQp0xYC4tmtQVqZzePPMN9lN@eW5Xj1/TD6lKfPz9vdOxJlmTQiShJMPdJmryVWpIOVZHlWlABxFSpJStXGGO2rcOGZAb0GGlVxQiu9UparAGDnf1Fr16KXYOe8zWsGNnl0wyhgSg6NYEgeGbSbfyC/a3c8xRjEQYyf5uUL) since the whitespace rules changed.

Comment: @NieDzejkob The specifications really changed ... Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, <s>72</s> <s>65</s> 64 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/.e?/g,([x,y])=>(y?`
 `:`
`).padEnd(s.length+!y,x))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##lc6xCoMwFIXhWZ/CZkpojHtBnXyKWkjQq20JuSGRYp4@xRRKoYue@fvhPNVL@cE97FIaHCFOdfR144UDq9UAtBLQVjOn15WHG6sbGlqZF/Iic8mEVWNnRuqFBjMv9/Mp8JWxOKDxqEFonGk2UYIOkLAs46Q3vSm/Iyz/pUWyG9wlHRygH7zrwIbxgMZUpGrL/qv4Bg)

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 47 bytes

```perl
s|o|X x($i=y///c).$/|ge;s|re|$".O x($i-2).$/|ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@4Jr8mQqFCQyXTtlJfXz9ZU09FvyY91bq4pii1RkVJzx8sp2sEFf//P78oNR@IITA//19@QUlmfl7xf90CAA)

Comment: This breaks the rules: "The whitespace padding on each side of the filling is required"

Comment: with some variations https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YJ78mVUdFrUKjUl9fP1lTT0VfJz3VulinqCY1VUVHQSc99////KLUfCCGwPz8f/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA

Comment: Nice! I tried combining the two `s///` but couldn't make it shorter, however `-F` can save you a few: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YMV/RX6HCwU1PRV8xPdW6WLEoVVFFSS9VoULDwU3XSBMi/v9/flFqPhCDYP6//IKSzPy84v@6BW4A "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript ES6, 103 bytes

#### Using replace 103 bytes:

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/o/g,"-".repeat(s=x.length)+`
`).replace(/re/g," "+"|".repeat(s>1?s-2:0)+` 
`).slice(0,-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcyxCsMgEIDhPU8RnJREk3QsJH2ViL3YFPGCSnHou1ulQ6BYXI7/vvMpX9Irtx@BW7xD2uYU5yUKB4eRCuiAg@4JJyWADNTPURiwOjxYtzYrO6GDIlvSkfepl@nm@eU6ZtwW7c2e7djziSWF1qMBYVDTjRJ0gISx5jdXmoNqxD@9vNrP@QK/2zJlkT4)

#### Using split and map 116 bytes:

```javascript
x=>x.split("re").map(y=>("-"[h='repeat'](r=x.length)+`
`)[h](y.length)).join(" "+"|"[h](r>1?r-2:0)+` 
`).slice(0,-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BCoMwEEX3PYXMxgk2QbssxB5EBIONGkkzIUpR6N1tpHRTLLMZ3n8z/FE91dQG42fu6K63Tm6LLBcxeWtmhKCBiYfyuMoSgUM1yDRor9Wc1hjkIqx2/TywrDk1rBpqXL@EiZGMQ0gggxfsUSiLW@CXax7tJOpisqbVmJ95wbaW3ERWC0s9dggUNAFjp198wPaKB5D@8H2OPscL@qT7Fo3tDQ)

Comment: JS, nice! You reminded me that I was going to add a rule about not having line returns at the end of the output, I've added it. Sorry about that!

Comment: just removing the final newline is 12 bytes

Comment: There was enough feedback that I removed the trailing newline rule. Feel free to update your entry.

Comment: You can save a byte by using a template string with `${"|".repeat(s>1?s-2:0)}` and its whitespaces, instead of using `" "+"|".repeat(s>1?s-2:0)`.

Comment: If you use backticks for the string in the first split, you can remove the parentheses around it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 77 bytes

```python
lambda x:x.replace("o","-"*len(x)+"\n").replace("re"," "+'.'*(len(x)-2)+"\n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqkKvKLUgJzE5VUMpX0lHSVdJKyc1T6NCU1spJk9JEyFZlAqUVVDSVtdT19KAKNE1gqr6nwbUXJSaD2QBAA)

Comment: Clever! I did intend the output to not be printing whitespace for the filling (it's pretty much oreo ascii), so I have edited the rules accordingly. Sorry about that! And I always love a python answer :)

Comment: @JonathanFrech migth as well delete the comments, that approach was invalidated. I'll work on golfing more tomorrow.

Comment: You can remove the space at `+" \n"` to save a byte.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen can I? The input program says the whole cookie must be as wide as the input.

Comment: I interpreted that as meaning that a trailing space is the same (visually) as no space. That's the beauty of answers to ascii art challenges. If they look right they are right :-)

Comment: Rules now say trailing whitespace is optional.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 28 bytes

```
FNzIqN"o"*lzN)IqN"r"+d*-lz2N
FNz                              For each value, N, in input
   IqN"o"                        if the character is "o"
         *lzN                    return the character times the length of the input
             )                   end if
              IqN"r"             if the character is "r"
FNzIqN"o"*lzN)IqN"r"+d*-lz2N
                        *-lz2N   return the character times length - 2
                    +d           padded on the left with " "
```

[Try it here!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/382vyrPQTylfSSunyk8TxCxS0k7R0s2pMvL7/z@/KDUfiCEwPx8A) This one uses a loop.

## Pyth, 30 bytes

(As string replace)

```
::z"o"+*lz"="b"re"++d*-lz2"~"b
 :z"o"                           With the input, replace "o" with
       *lz"="                    "=" times the length of the input
      +      b                   and a newline added to the end
:             "re"               With the input, replace "re" with
                     *    "~"    "~" times
                      -lz2       the length of the input minus 2
                   +d            padded on the left with " "
                  +          b   and a newline added to the end
```

[Try it here!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/38qqSilfSVsrp0rJVilJqShVSVs7RUs3p8pIqU4p6f///KLUfCCGwPx8AA) This one uses string replacement.

I really like python (it's what I wrote my original test scripts in), so I thought I'd do a pyth entry for fun :)

Comment: Isn't this 37 bytes? I thought Pyth uses default ASCII as its codepage just like Python, if I remember correctly. So even though your code is 33 characters, both `█` and `░` are three bytes each. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Good call, I didn't realize that (I couldn't get pyth to work on tio.run, so I used the length counter on the herokuapp page). In the for loop I could just replace the character with `N`, even saving a few bytes!

Comment: Thought something like that happened. :) I once had the same issue with a 05AB1E answer of mine that was using characters outside its code page. Unfortunately TIO displays chars and bytes the same for most golfing languages. For Java or Python TIO will correctly state `33 chars, 37 bytes`, but not in golfing languages on TIO. But in your solutions just changing those characters indeed fixes the issue, so it's not that big of a deal here.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Wait, 05AB1E doesn't use an actual SBCS?

Comment: @ASCII-only Nope, it uses [this codepage](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage). If you use any character not in this codepage you'll have to use a different encoding (like ASCII), increasing the byte-count by A LOT considering the many non-ASCII characters 05AB1E uses itself already.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Isn't that an actual SBCS? Even though 05AB1E can use different encodings, that specific codepage _does_ still have glyphs for all 256 bytes (meaning it can't have muti-byte sequences)

Comment: If you're interested, [it seems to work effortlessly](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/382vyrPQTylfSSunyk8TxCxS0k7R0s2pMvL7/z@/KDUfAA) on TIO for me.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Thank you! I updated the post with the tio links

Answer (score 4):

## Java 11, <s>110</s> 106 bytes

```java
s->{int l=s.length();return s.replace("re"," "+"~".repeat(l-2+1/l)+"\n").replace("o","=".repeat(l)+"\n");}
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

Uses `=` for the cookie and `~` for the filling.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZZDBTgMhEIbvfYoJJ8i6GL1u1jewlx7VA9KxUilsYLaJadZXX2cpsVovhPn@n5l/2Jujaffbj9l6kzM8GhdOKwAXCNObsQjrpQTYUHJhB1bWS1Yd82nFRyZDzsIaAvQw5/bhxK/B91l7DDt6l6pLSGMKkHXCwXNXKRKKGwGiEV9igWhI@va@ubv1qhHPQaiLNbKzv7iq3k1zt0wfxlfP02uIY3RbOPASNefTCxh13oAwEzdLGEXJ/kP@lhzsqr4mcUHxH4uFF62Kv3@nBCve@oEuDCPVaJvPTHjQcSQ9sEg@yKCtPFtqq2n@Bg)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                       // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  int l=s.length();        //  Get the length of the input
  return s                 //  Return the input
          .replace("re",   //  After we've replaced all "re" with:
            " "            //   A space
            +"~".repeat(l-2+1/l)
                           //   Appended with length-2 amount of "~"
                           //   (or length-1 if the input-length was 1)
            +"\n")         //   Appended with a newline
          .replace("o",    //  And we've also replaced all "o" with:
            "=".repeat(l)  //   Length amount of "="
            +"\n");}       //   Appended with a newline
```

---

The above solution uses a replace. The following maps over the characters of the input instead:

## Java 11, <s>113</s> 112 bytes

```java
s->s.chars().forEach(c->{if(c>101)System.out.println((c>111?" ":"")+(""+(char)c).repeat(s.length()-2*(~c&1)));})
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Neil*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bZAxT8MwEIX3/oqTB3RHFYswEjVMjHTpiBiM6zQuqR3Zl0qoCn89JE6EoLBYeu9ZT9@9ozqr7Lh/H3SjYoRnZd1lBWAdm1ApbWA7SYCzt3vQuONg3QEiFaPbr8YnsmKrYQsONjDErIxS1ypEJFn58KR0jTorL7ZCXeZ3Oe0@IpuT9B3LduzixuGU5PmjAPEgBK1RiDVOHaRJBtMaxRhlY9yBa6Ts/hY/9U1OREVPQzExtN1bMzIsKAn1NB6y0L68gqL5CjaRUfhgvEgXfDu/ZTDX@trxk@X/eD75KVvCnxslsPR3mdG6tuMFzUmNs547/9lpKeyHLw)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->                           // Method with String parameter and no return-type
  s.chars().forEach(c->{      //  Loop over the characters as codepoint-integers
    if(c>101)                 //   If it's not an 'e':
      System.out.println(     //    Print with trailing newline:
       (c>111?                //     If it's an 'r'
         " "                  //      Start with a space
        :                     //     Else (it's an 'o' instead)
         "")                  //      Start with an empty string
       +(""+(char)c).repeat(  //     And append the character itself
          .repeat(            //     Repeated the following amount of times:
           s.length()         //      The input-length
           -2*(~c&1)));})     //      Minus 2 if it's an "r", or 0 if it's an "o"
```

Comment: Can you use `~c&1`?

Comment: @Neil I indeed can, thanks.

Comment: This is invalid: "The whitespace padding on each side of the filling is required"

Comment: @NieDzejkob Fixed.. Always nice to have changing specs during the challenge, sigh..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen not anymore :P

Comment: @ASCII-only Rollbacked. :)

Answer (score 4):

## Powershell, <s>71</s> <s>69</s> 66 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks @Veskah*

*-3 bytes thanks @AdmBorkBork*

```powershell
$l=$args|% le*
switch($args|% t*y){'o'{'#'*$l}'r'{" "+'%'*($l-2)}}
```

Less golfed test script:

```powershell
$f = {

$l=$args|% length
switch($args|% t*y){
    'o'{'#'*$l}
    'r'{" "+'%'*($l-2)}
}

}

@(

,(
'oreo',
'####',
' %%',
'####'
)
,(
'o',
'#'
)
,(
're',
' '
)
,(
'rere',
' %%',
' %%'
)
,(
'oreoorererereoo',
'###############',
' %%%%%%%%%%%%%',
'###############',
'###############',
' %%%%%%%%%%%%%',
' %%%%%%%%%%%%%',
' %%%%%%%%%%%%%',
' %%%%%%%%%%%%%',
'###############',
'###############'
)

) | % {
    $s,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $s
    "$result"-eq"$expected"
    # $result # uncomment this line to display a result
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True
True
True
True
True
```

Comment: Looks like you don't need parens around the `$args` [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##NcjBCoAgDADQe18hNZkKXbr3MREjg4ExBQnz2xcd4t3elSpJjsSsCrzCJkd@rGEKQ65n2aP7q4TbN0zYcMIA3FGwjQYcWgwOeF68N2PvqiqUhD7pBQ)

Comment: The length of `[string[]]` is an `[int[]]`... The `[int[]]` is `[int]` if the array contains one element only. Great! Thanks!

Comment: The OP updated the challenge so you don't need trailing spaces anymore. This means your `r` can be `" "+'%'*($l-2)` instead for -3 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>100</del> <del>99</del> 93 bytes

```php
$l=strlen($i=$argv[1]);$r=str_repeat;echo strtr($i,[o=>$r(X,$l)."
",re=>' '.$r(o,$l-2)."
"]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBCsIwEETvfkUoC00gFvUaU39DKCJFlqYQumEM/n7cKsMc5vGYkkq73koqhgHBE1wEdd0We3KhUY7visybpTXSjOUznR8uEHa8uzzXwK8kRneFWn6SOBLs3VN2Q3foPDiOvekHhaLwePlhfWmtCVi0/4h8AQ)

OUCH. PHP's waaaay_too_long function names strike again!

Output:

```php
$php oreo.php oreo
XXXX
 oo
XXXX

$php oreo.php o
X

$php oreo.php rere
 oo
 oo

$ php oreo.php oreoorererereoo
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 ooooooooooooo
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 ooooooooooooo
 ooooooooooooo
 ooooooooooooo
 ooooooooooooo
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Invalid, cream lines need a trailing space

Comment: Fixed the trailing space. Thanks!

Comment: Oh boy, PHP! Also any trailing whitespace is now optional, there were enough people that pointed out that since it's printing out ascii it shouldn't really be required.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>111</s> 91 bytes

```
#~StringReplace~{"o"->"O"~Table~(n=StringLength@#)<>"\n","re"->" "<>Table["R",n-2]<>" \n"}&
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/V@5LrgEyEoPSi3ISUxOratWylfStVPyV6oLSUzKSa3TyLOFKPBJzUsvyXBQ1rSxU4rJU9JRKkoFKVRQsrEDq4xWClLSydM1igXKKwAV1Kr9V3BQUMovSgXBfCCdrxT7HwA)

This was majorly shortened thanks to [Misha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/74672/misha-lavrov)'s [edits](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/178344/oreoorererereoo/178418#comment430012_178418).

---

My original code:

```
(z=StringRepeat;n=StringLength@#;#~StringReplace~{"o"->"O"~z~n<>"\n","re"->" "<>If[n>2,z["R",n-2],""]<>" \n"})&
```

This code is not very fancy but it seems too expensive to convert away from strings and then back or to do anything else clever.

In particular, with only 3-4 commands that have the name String, my original approach couldn't save bytes at all by trying to abstract that away. For example, the following is 129 bytes:

```
(w=Symbol["String"<>#]&;z=w@"Repeat";n=w["Length"]@#;#~w@"Replace"~{"o"->"O"~z~n<>"\n","re"->" "<>If[n>2,z["R",n-2],""]<>" \n"})&
```

Comment: A few improvements: `StringRepeat` can be `Table` since `<>` will convert the list into a string later; the `If` is unnecessary since we take the `re` branch only when `n` is at least 2; we can save on parentheses by defining `n` only when we use it. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/V@5LrgEyEoPSi3ISUxOratWylfStVPyV6oLSUzKSa3TyLOFKPBJzUsvyXBQ1rSxU4rJU9JRKkoFKVRQsrEDq4xWClLSydM1igXKKwAV1Kr9V3BQUMovSgXBfCCdrxT7HwA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Comment: @MishaLavrov The `If` was added because `StringRepeat` would throw an error on the case of "re"; it doesn't allow you to repeat a string 0 times. `Table` has no such limitation, so that's a big save!

Answer (score 4):

## Bash, 87 bytes

Without `sed`:

```bash
f(){ printf %$1s|tr \  $2;}
c=${1//o/`f ${#1} B`
}
echo "${c//re/ `f $[${#1}-2] F` 
}"
```

Thanks to @manatwork.

With `sed` (90 bytes):

```bash
f(){ printf %$1s|tr \  $2;}
echo $1|sed "s/o/`f ${#1} B`\n/g;s/re/ `f $[${#1}-2] F` \n/g"
```

Comment: Could you show us some sample usage? I'm a bit confused by your function expecting 2 parameters.

Comment: You write that into a script called `test.sh`. Then, you call test.sh from the command line as follows: `bash test.sh oreoorererereoo`. `f` is needed to repeat the character `$2` `$1` number of times

Comment: Oops. I completely misunderstood function f. Some further minor changes could be made there: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P01Ds1qhoCgzryRNQVXFsLimpEghRkFBxci6livZVqXaUF8/Xz8hTUGlWtmwVsEpgauWKzU5I19BSaU6WV@/KFVfASQZDZbWNYpVcEtQ4KpV@v//f35Raj4QQ2B@PgA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your suggestions! I will incorporate them into my answer. :)

Comment: For the `sed` based one you could use `sed "…"<<<$1` instead of `echo $1|sed "…"`.

Comment: [75 bytes.](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v8C2oCgzrySNK9lWpdpQXz9fP0GlQEHVQKVa2bC2NIGrlgvIVVKpTtbXL0rVV4BKRoOldY1iS2tKihQMFAyBCpX@//@fX5SaD8QQmJ8PAA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9JWpdrQyqjWusJWCcjS18/XB1P2@vm1XLVK1qnJGfkKQJkKff2iVH0FlepKkFxqrQJQ8v////lFqflADIH5@QA)

Comment: with zsh, [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/NTkjX0FJpVql2lBfP18fTNnr59dy1errF6XqK4BlrIxqQaKptQpctUr////PL0rNB2IIzM8HAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>62</s> 60 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.gsub /./,?r=>" #{(?**z=s.size)[0..-3]}
",?o=>?O*z+?\n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYlBDsIgFET3noLgRhF@G10a@EfwAMjCGqpuioGyEMrZMbSZ5M2bjI/Dr46yChVygFeIA@mg4@ilomSfD8hYkgHCJ9mj7gHExZQd5eikwhtLJ7xPpWrqvHWUE7rC241bt8u10eIcNWAfz3de5uUb50BGPZsrWRUFO/el/gE)

Uses `O` for the cookie, `*` for the filling.

-1 thanks to @manatwork pointing out a silly mistake and another -1 due to relaxation of the rules about whitespaces.

Comment: No need for parenthesis around `.gsub`'s parameters.

Comment: `$/` is an alias for `?\n`.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <strike>96</strike> <strike>87</strike> 85 bytes

Thanks to @gwaugh    -9 Bytes
Thanks to @manatwork 	 -2 Bytes

```php
<?=strtr($i=$argv[1],[o=>($r=str_repeat)(X,$l=strlen($i))."
",re=>" {$r(o,$l-2)}
"]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcvBCoMwEATQu18hIYddSEvbq038DUGkeFhUEDdMQy/Fb08TCnOaNxPXmJ99XGMrgOIFiYq0HQvduOtDMf9OSCC7eTtj@Yz3yY3qA1lUqQeZE9Pg7F6LXY6yZb6axjiID6b9WpAWvjz4bMzEXc5ZIf9Afg)

[Try it online! (87 Bytes)](https://tio.run/##HcvBCoMwEIThe58iyIJZiNL2ahNfoyBSPCwqiBumoa@fJl7/byZuMb/GuEUjgOIDiYq0n6u982DGUNB/ExIs7Z4WrL/pMbtJfbCEKvUhS2L7dnTUcMhZtsx9c2scxIfWtD3BavHueeWZh5yzQvQP)

[Try it online (original 97 bytes submition)!](https://tio.run/##K8go@M/538betrikqKRIQ6XcViWxKL0s2jBWJzrf1k5DJQ0kE1@UWpCaWKKp8Whah45KDkgoJzUPqFpTU0@JS0mnyNZOSUFJTyUNqGAiUIGuEUQ8FSiuFKtp/f////yi1HwghsD8fAA)

---

**And a recursive function**

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 135 bytes

```php
function f($w,$x=0){$f=str_repeat;echo($x<($l=strlen($w)))?($w[$x]=='o')?$f(█,$l)."
".f($w,$x+1):" ".$f(░,$l-2)."
".f($w,$x+2):"";}
```

[Try it online! (recursive)](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRUynVUKmwNNKtV0myLS4rii1ILUhNLrFOTM/I1VCpsNFRyQMI5qXlAlZqamvZAKlqlItbWVj1fXdNeJU3j0bQOHZUcTT0lLiU9qHHahppWSgpKemDZiUBZXSNUeSOgvJJ17f80DaX8otR8JU3r//8B)

Comment: by combining the best of our two submissions I was able to get it down to [87 bytes TIO](https://tio.run/##HcvBCoMwEIThe58iyIJZiNL2ahNfoyBSPCwqiBumoa@fJl7/byZuMb/GuEUjgOIDiYq0n6u982DGUNB/ExIs7Z4WrL/pMbtJfbCEKvUhS2L7dnTUcMhZtsx9c2scxIfWtD3BavHueeWZh5yzQvQP). Would you be game to go in with this as a collaborative submission? :)

Comment: I think we can remove 1 more byte by using the command short_tag_open, and instead of `<?=` we can use `<?`, or am i mistaken?

Comment: 2 characters shorter with string interpolation: `' '.$r(o,$l-2)."␤"` → `" {$r(o,$l-2)}␤"`.

Comment: Thanks @manatwork sometimes i forgot php vars are evaluated in a string if the entire string is declared with `""` istead of `''`

Comment: This can be 3 bytes shorter using `$argn`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKSopEhDJbEoPU8nOt/WTkOlCCQWX5RakJpYoqkRoaOSAxLISc2DqNLU1FPiUtIpSrW1U1KoVinSyAeq0DXSrOVSitW0/v8/vygVgopS///LLyjJzM8r/q/rBgA "PHP – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 37 bytes

```perl6
{m:g/o|r/>>.&({S/rr/ /.say}o*x.comb)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzrXKl0/v6ZI385OT02jOli/qEhfQV@vOLGyNl@rQi85PzdJs/a/TX5Rar5CvkJRKhABCRA3H8QCwfx8O5DmtP8A)

Anonymous code block that takes a string and prints the oreo, with `o` as the cookie and `r` as the cream.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                   }   # Anonymous code block
 m:g/o|r/                               # Select all o s and r s
         >>.&(                     )    # Map each letter to
                            *x.comb     # The letter padded to the width
               S/rr/ /                  # Substitute a leading rr with a space
                      .say              # And print with a newline
```

Comment: I didn't realize `o` could be used in place of `∘`. Very nicely golfed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), <s>276</s> <s>268</s> 206 bytes

Technically as the brainfuck only has 8 instructions, that means it needs only 3 bits per character instead of 8 (that also means we could encode brainfuck in base64 with exactly 2 instructions per character), but I'll play fair and say it's 268 bytes long.

It was a fun challenge, thanks!

**Edit**: now featuring the 3rd rule!

**Edit**: moving the line feed from the data pool to the display part of the code allowed me to get down to 268 bytes:

```
>>+<,[<++++++++++[>-----------<-]>-[>-<,>>+<<[-]>>>>[>]>++++[<++++++++>-]+>>++++++++++[<+++++++++++>-]<+>>++++[<++++++++>-]<[<]<<<]>[[-]>>>[>]>+++++++[<+++++>-]+>>+++++++[<+++++>-]>+++++++[<+++++>-]<[<]<<]+<,>>+<<]>>--[>>>+<<<-]>>[.>-[>>>>+<<<<->.<]>>.[-]++++++++++.>]
```

Here's a more readable version:

The data pool is made like so: [first character, placeholder value used to move the input character count, repeated character, last character]

```
>>+<,[//start of the loop
<++++++++++[>-----------<-]>-//"o"
[>-<,>>+<<[-]//if it's not a "o", skip one character and:

>>>>[>]//go to the data pool and search for the end
>++++[<++++++++>-]//put " " in memory
+>//put 1 in memory
>++++++++++[<+++++++++++>-]<+>//put a "o" in memory
>++++[<++++++++>-]<//put another " " in memory
[<]<<<//get back to the beginning of the data pool and get back to the program

]>[[-]//else (so if it's a "o"):

>>>[>]//go to the data pool and search for the end
>+++++++[<+++++>-]//put a "#" in memory
+>//put 1 in memory
>+++++++[<+++++>-]//put a "#" in memory
>+++++++[<+++++>-]<//put a "#" in memory
[<]<<//get back to the beginning of the data pool and get back to the program

]+<,>>+<<]//loop until the end of the input line and count the number of characters

>>//go to the number of characters variable
--//substract 2 to it because the first and last characters take one space each
[>>>+<<<-]//copy the value to the next place
>>[.>//start of the loop and display of the first character
-[>>>>+<<<<->.<]//display of the repeated character while copying the character count to the next line
>>.//display of the last character
[-]++++++++++.//display a line feed
>]//loop until the end of the data pool
```

It works on copy.sh/brainfuck with default settings
([link](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=Pj4rPCxbPCsrKysrKysrKytbPi0tLS0tLS0tLS0tPC1dPi1bPi08LD4-Kzw8Wy1dPj4-Pls-XT4rKysrWzwrKysrKysrKz4tXSs-PisrKysrKysrKytbPCsrKysrKysrKysrPi1dPCs-PisrKytbPCsrKysrKysrPi1dPFs8XTw8PF0-W1stXT4-Pls-XT4rKysrKysrWzwrKysrKz4tXSs-PisrKysrKytbPCsrKysrPi1dPisrKysrKytbPCsrKysrPi1dPFs8XTw8XSs8LD4-Kzw8XT4-LS1bPj4-Kzw8PC1dPj5bLj4tWz4-Pj4rPDw8PC0-LjxdPj4uWy1dKysrKysrKysrKy4-XQ$$))

**Edit**: now down to only 206 Bytes thanks to @RezNesX

```
>>+<,[<-[>++<-------]>-[,[-]>->+>>[>]>+>+>-[<-->-------]>++++[<<<<++++++++>>>++++++++>-]<[<]<<<]>[[-]>>>[>]->+>->->--[<<<<-->>-->-->+++++++]<[<]<<]+>+<<,]>>--[>>>+<<<-]>>[.>-[>>>>+<<<.<-]>>.[-]++++++++++.>]
```

The code is quite similar but a lot of optimisation has been done in the creation of the data pool, very interesting.

Comment: Fun language, nice entry! :)

Comment: Oops, it looks like it breaks the third rule! The output isn't as wide as the input :s

Comment: ah sorry, I didn't read that one, thanks I'm gonna work on that

Comment: alright the only case where the result is not the expected one is "o"
"re" outputs 2 spaces and "" outputs nothing
but "o" is not doable with the method I chose because the repeated character should be negative here

Comment: [206 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY1rCgMxCIQPZMwJZC4i/uiWFkphAws9f3Z0txkJPka/bMfjs79/z@@cgFhzU4eI6aWAevNMEMARTMIZfawVodwouQVglRrmFjQDnqCiJE0ztO4IQwH/Z/dN8DOzFul6QnOXnXdUX4Neo062LHXEnON4Db4rxjgB)

Comment: @RezNesX Awesome job! I'm adding this to the post

Answer (score 4):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 67 bytes

```sh
a=$#1
o()<<<${(l/a//=/)}
r()<<<\ ${(l/a>1?a-2:0//+/)}
eval ${1///;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/0VZF2ZArX0PTxsZGpVojRz9RX99WX7OWqwgsFKMAEbQztE/UNbIy0NfXBkmmliXmAGUM9fX1rWv///@fX5Sanw8A)

Explanation:

- `$1`: input
- `#`: length
- `a=`: assign to global variable `$a`
- `o()`: define a function called `o`:

  - `${(l/a//=/)}`: left pad {nothing} with `=` signs to the width `$a` (i.e., print this many equals signs)
  - `<<<`: print
- `r()`: define a function called `r`:

  - `${(l///+/)}` left pad {nothing} with `+` signs,
  - `a>1?a-2:0`: to the width of `$a - 2` if `$a > 1` else `0` (because otherwise, if `$a - 2` was negative, zsh would use its absolute value)
  - `<<<\` : print with a space before
- `${1}`: input
- `///;`: replace all {empty string}s with `;` (effectively intersperses; `oreo` -> `;o;r;e;o`)
- `eval`: evaluate that as zsh code

  - `o` and `r` call the functions defined above
  - `e` is a non-existent command, so does nothing
  - `;` separates the commands

Comment: cunning use of functions!

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
Ｆθ≡ιo⟦⭆θ#⟧e«→Ｐ⁻Ｌθ²↙
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xCsMgFEXn@BUPuyikS8d07RihtGPpIGJUCL5ETTKEfLu1tjwud7jn8JSVQaEccx4wAJs5xM0lZYE5DjtRMmqgSDu4B@cTez1TaSPkxOYW6InyN7/@KV2onTQCV826hzM2lakRy5jcVGXh/BJZr71Jtnxq4cIrUYUbbr7Xw9c5yJEzBo0lv0PM53X8AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆθ
```

Loop through the characters of the input string.

```
≡ι
```

Switch on each character.

```
o⟦⭆θ#⟧
```

If it's an `o` then print the input string replaced with `#`s on its own line.

```
e«→Ｐ⁻Ｌθ²↙
```

If it's an `e` then move right, print a line of `-`s that's two less than the length of the input string, then move down and left.

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 71 bytes

```cs
s=>s.Aggregate("",(a,c)=>a+(c>111?" ":"\n".PadLeft(s.Length+c/5-21,c)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcqxDgIhEATQ3q8gWy25OwwmNioYGysKOxsbsi4cDSaA34@ndsZmJnkzVCeqqZ@fmQ61lZTj@C0rgjC9GlvVKcbC0TdGgBH9SNJYPyBZrfURBOzglkFd/N1xaFiV4xzbPNB6O2308pay71fXkhq7lBkDwgOk/KXC/3XxT7zH/gI)

Borrowed some ideas from on [Embodiment of Ignorance's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178349/8340) for sure.

-6 bytes thanks to @ASCIIOnly!

The overall concept is to compute a string aggregate over the input characters following these rules:

- If an `r` is encountered, append a single space  character for indentation. We know the next character will be an `e`.
- If an `o` or an `e` is encountered, generate a string by repeating the current character a specific number of times and prepending it to a newline or some padding and a newline.
- The number of times to repeat is determined by length of input string and whether the current line is indented.
- The `PadLeft` function is used to generate the repeating character string.

The result is the concatenation of all of these strings.

Comment: [71](https://tio.run/##bcqxDgIhEATQ3q8g2xzkOIwmNioYG6sr7GxsyLpwNFzC4vfjqZ2xmUneDPKAnNrlmfHItaQc9becCMI2to7NOcZC0VeSAFp6jco630t03dydQMAe7hnM1T9GClWyGSnHOvW43g3bzfJWqh1Wt5IqjSmTDBJmUOqXCv3XxT/xHtsL)

Comment: @ASCIIOnly - Thanks :)

Comment: > The whitespace padding on each side of the filling is required

Comment: [85?](https://tio.run/##bYuxDgIhEER7v4JsBTkOpfQULjZWV9jZ2BBckAYTFr8f8eyMzZvJm4yn0VNq51f2R6ol5Si/YVlgppGxpE4xFoyuIgeQ3EkvjHUD91ZrPQODaa27GW4ZJmCdQl3cfcFQOakFc6yPwW/3o9b9K0Q7bK4lVVxSRh44PEGIX1Xwv@1@xWdsbw)

Comment: I didn't notice that :) Although, in reviewing the posted answers about 1/2 have done this incorrectly as well. Good catch though!

Answer (score 2):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), <s>120</s> <s>106</s> 107 bytes

```
f(s)=>s.replaceAll('o',''.padRight(s.length,'#')+'\n').replaceAll('re',' '.padRight(s.length-1,'-')+' \n');
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BCsMgEEX3PYXQxTjUCF2HFnqFrLuRZJIIVkXdlZ7dOmSVpszuzX//TyaVWmeZ8XbPOlF0ZqSHcxICKAAdzTTYZS0ya0d@KauCM@AFnh5wF0/U8uKP0F0VdKwIdvr6MtZLfJ@EiMn6Iuc2lSgAYr9jv6ANHMiRcVXgB1/YSj71Cw)

- +1 byte : Added trailing whitespace

Comment: This is invalid: "The whitespace padding on each side of the filling is required"

Comment: Oh, never mind then, I'll correct it soon. Thanks for the info, I missed it

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>77</s> <s>76</s> 72 bytes

```python
lambda i:'\n'.join((x*len(i),' '+x*(len(i)-2))[x>'o']for x in i if'e'<x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcyxDsIwDATQna@wsthuC0NHBPwI6VBEIoyKXUUdwtcHRQxdopvunXTrd3uZjiVefVnmz@M5g5zRK57eJkqUuyUoCQ8I2OeO/u04Mt/zDQ2naAkyiIKARAx4yVzWJLpBJGcpmGPowXl1h50blkITm1xvrW41tr@VHw)

The outer part of the cookie is 'o' and the filling is 'r'.

Comment: [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcM7CsAgDADQ3VNki/azOErtRUpHpQFJRCykp7eF8nj16ZewH4Micb27dabEktiSM1kaKBADBQOUMeGmoTbibnUqCwLOOtmyeucO3VHwHAOlJfn@RPAF). Although I doubt if you can really omit the trailing spaces, the spec does say "The whitespace padding **on each side** of the filling is required"...

Comment: Thanks @EriktheOutgolfer. Thought a lambda would be shorter! Guess in this case not. Had missed the requirement about the mandatory trailing space on the filling. Really can't see the point with an ascii art challenge but if that's what OP requires then I guess my answer is invalid anyway.

Comment: Now corrected...

Comment: Why bring it back to 76? Just put `+' '` after `(l-2)`. Also, you have a typo, `*' '` must be `+' '`.

Comment: That's what I did with my current solution. Will take a closer look at your hints tomorrow (later today). It's late here and I have been shoveling snow all day so too tired for golf. Thanks for the tips though :)

Comment: It's not a strange reason, if anything it's expected, since most of the like... three existing ASCII-art languages, as well as the matrix based languages output a trailing space anyway. Plus, for some languages the symmetry may even help

Comment: I guess that's why in the majority of challenges, trailing whitespace is optional.

Comment: Well, it's optional now (yay)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 143 bytes

Without LINQ.

```cs
p=>{var q="";foreach(char c in p){if(c!='e'){for(var j=0;j<p.Length;j++)q+=(j<1|j>p.Length-2)&c>'q'?" ":c<'p'?"█":"░";q+="\n";}}return q;};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU89T8MwEN3zKw4PxFZoBIx1HAYkJpCQGFhYnMNNHKW2YzuVUMjOysIP5I8EVy26073Te/eJYYPWq3UK2rTw8hGi2vMMBxkCPHvbermfMwA3NYNGCFHGBAer3@FJakPZUQR4mAxWIfo04@oENTQgVifq@SA9jIIQvkt7JHYUu8QgaAOOzXpH8ULkKmdz0umxuBfXvK9c@ahMGzveFwUbC0H76uazr//pzS27xDof8zsCZItV7lL2@/NFtil@E546yJshfFm8ipM3MPKFr6f/yntrgh1U@ep1VLShJF12dsIYz5Zk6x8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 137 bytes

```clj
(fn[f](let[w(count f)r #(apply str(repeat % %2))](clojure.string/join"\n"(replace{\o(r w \#)\e(str \ (r(- w 2)\-) \ )}(remove #{\r}f)))))
```

I'm not using the nice characters in the printout in the golfed version since those are expensive. Returns a string to be printed.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxRC4MwDIT/SqgIyYMb@HesD6WkQ@maktXJEH97V/GOPNzl43yUdVOumHVJJSbAiiFNYcbIZdrRy5YKBFLo0OUcf/ApisqZXYEe@pFoRn@PPNprSa/nKksyNpkLi87zYQUVdrAdWcYGgQVUHFo1kh2oRTob/JYvQ3dYPQNdqkaUpd1tEUME9Q8)

See below for explanation.

Pre-golfed:

```clj
; Backslashes indicate a character literal
(defn oreo [format-str]
  (let [width (count format-str)

        ; A helper function since Clojure doesn't have built-in string multiplication
        str-repeat #(apply str (repeat % %2))

        ; Define the layers
        cookie (str-repeat width \█)
        cream (str \ (str-repeat (- width 2) \░) \ )]

    (->> format-str ; Take the input string,
         (remove #{\r}) ; remove r for simplcity,
         (replace {\o cookie, \e cream}) ; replace the remaining letters with the layers,
         (clojure.string/join "\n")))) ; and join the layers together with newlines
```

Answer (score 2):

## Sed, 89 characters

(86 characters code + 3 characters command line option)

```
h;s/./E/g;H;g;s/\n//;:b;s/(o|re)([ore]+)(E*)/\1\3\n\2\3/;tb;s/o//g;s/reE(E*)E/ \L\1 /g
```

Commented with example for input “oreo”:

```
h        # copy to hold space
s/./E/g  # change into cookie: EEEE
H        # append to hold space
g        # copy back to pattern space: oreo␤EEEE
s/\n//   # remove the newline: oreoEEEE

:b                                 # split the os and res in separate lines
  s/(o|re)([ore]+)(E*)/\1\3\n\2\3/ # repeating the EEEE for each:
tb                                 # oEEEE␤reEEEE␤oEEEE

s/o//g                # remove the os: EEEE␤reEEEE␤EEEE
s/reE(E*)E/ \L\1 /g   # remove the res, cut edge, change fill: EEEE␤ ee ␤EEEE
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ sed -r 'h;s/./E/g;H;g;s/\n//;:b;s/(o|re)([ore]+)(E*)/\1\3\n\2\3/;tb;s/o//g;s/reE(E*)E/ \L\1 /g' <<< oreoorererereoo
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
 eeeeeeeeeeeee 
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
 eeeeeeeeeeeee 
 eeeeeeeeeeeee 
 eeeeeeeeeeeee 
 eeeeeeeeeeeee 
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYsxCoAwEAT7e0U6E0UXtbMPWPgDz0IxxMqDxNK/xwRZFgZ259jjlaI7VRtUlS6K6GDhaSafmW@ApiOTljc4o1cJbmuMtrUB9zzyzQOPoKd8BChScLbsFooX7hV8qlLWJPePyAc)

Comment: I didn't expect an entry like that, creative!

Comment: [Same byte count but with newlines - Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYsxCoAwEAT7e0U6E0SXaGcfsPAHnoViiJUHiaV/jwmyLAzszrGnKyd/qi6qJl@U0MMh0EyhMN8ATUchLW/0Rq8S/dYa7VoDtjzyzQOPoKd@BKhS9K7uDooXtgohN7loUvpH5AM "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @Logern, thanks for playing with it. This brought to my attention that the TIO code was still the first version, which didn't handled input “re” correctly.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), `-D$=putchar(33` +  88 = 102 bytes

```c
O(char*r){for(char*e,*o=r,x;*r;$-x),$-23))for(x=*r++>111,e=x?$-1),r++,o+1:o;*++e;$+x));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/NCsIwEITP9imk5pDNzyH2ZqhevPcFCqXEtBY0K6lCoPTVjQ1FunP5mFl2GSN7Y2KsqLm3nnmYOvQrW8Gw9CJo5jWRAQSRxwIg5aFknvOzUkrYMlyIVCAWQyBXJ9SMc6sJDwB6joeb7QZn941@fd4jzWvH0tQuB50928FRmLJdRXP0FnNoVv6DtxttnFYxGUmI6dIcv6Z7tP0Y5ZWUy6tUgRbFDw)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 22 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. C**o**okies are `o`, c**r**eam is `r`.

```apl
'^rr'⎕R' '⍤1≢⊢⍤/⍪~'e'⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/Xz2uqEj9Ud/UIHUF9Ue9SwwfdS561LUIyNJ/1LuqTj0VKLjif9qjtgmPevuAyjz9H3U1H1pv/KhtIpAXHOQMJEM8PIP/p6nnF6Xmq3MBaRBRlAohITRIKh/EAcH8fHUA)

…`⍨` swap the input for:

`'e'` this letter

…`~` remove all the "e"s from:

`⍪` the columnised argument

…`⊢⍤/` replicate that single column to be as many columns as:

`≢` the tally of characters in the input

…`⍤1` on each row (lit. on each 1D sub-array):

`'^rr'⎕R' '` PCRE **R**eplace leading "rr" with a single space

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
äNëY┬2-]‼Cv6╤
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=844e8959c2322d5d13437636d1&i=oreoorererereoo&a=1&m=1)

Uses "o" and "r" characters for the layers.

Comment: Oh man, you tied the current lowest! Really cool language too, I appreciate stack-based languages.

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 93 bytes

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"o",REPT("O",LEN(A4))&"
"),"re"," "&REPT("r",MAX(0,LEN(A4)-2))&"
")
```

`MAX(0,` is needed to handle `o`.
Uses `O` and `r`.

Comment: Very cool, though since it is an ascii challenge you should output the text in a stack (probably with `CHAR(10)` in excel), and you can replace the block characters with letters to cut down a few bytes :)

Comment: @GammaGames, `\n` is included in code and bytecount.  You need to switch on "Wrap text" to see them though.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles) 10 bytes

```
&" ",@~.|@%$~
^-,_%$3 # $
```

explanation

```
&           # Justify
  " "       # (value to pad in justify)
  ,         # length (size to justify to)
    @       # first input string
  ~         # centered
  .         # map
    |       # filter  
      @     # first input string
      %$~   # mod char element 2
    ^       # replicate (begin map body)
     -      # minus
      ,_    # length of first input string
        %$3 # mod char element 3
            # implicit $ (the char element to be replicated)
```

Comment: Coming in lower than jelly! How do I run this?

Comment: echo oreoorererereoo | nibbles filename. It isn't on TIO.run yet, but I've contacted them.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 136 bytes

```
	S =INPUT
	N =SIZE(S)
S	S ('o' | 're') . X REM . S	:F(END)
	OUTPUT =IDENT('o',X) DUPL(X,N)	:S(S)
	OUTPUT =' ' DUPL(0,N - 2) ' '	:(S)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYyxCgIxEETr5Cu22yycImIVuC4RDnQ93ASCpXDdYeBs/fe4QbAaZubNvF/1WddTa0ZgnHjOyRqGUaZHdEJWNHZYET6A24IEeyhwj1dVMf7sIgey5paTDnUfIqeOD4Ug5PniysBkvPSrP4WAv/IwMOzgSOrR@M7oXWt1W@oX)

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 133 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@set o=%s:r=o%
@set o=%o:e=o%
@set r=%o:o=-%
@set r= %r:~2%
@set s=%s:e= %
@for %%c in (%s:o=o %)do @call echo %%%%c%%
```

Takes input on STDIN. Explanation:

```
@set/ps=
```

Input the string.

```
@set o=%s:r=o%
@set o=%o:e=o%
```

Make a copy of the string with all of the `r`s and `e`s replaced with `o`s.

```
@set r=%o:o=-%
@set r= %r:~2%
```

Make a copy of the string of `o`s, change them to `-`s and replace the first two with a space.

```
@set s=%s:e= %
@for %%c in (%s:o=o %)do @call echo %%%%c%%
```

Change the `e`s into spaces and also add a space after each `o`, allowing the `o`s and `r`s to be iterated over, printing the appropriate string each time.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 27 bytes

```
q:T'e-{i2%T,'9*_:)2>S\+?N}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v9AqRD1VtzrTSDVER91SK95K08guOEbb3q9W/////KJUCAISAA)

### Explanation:

```
q                            read input:                    | "oreoo"
 :T                          store in variable T            | "oreoo", T="oreoo"
   'e-                       remove all 'e' characters:     | "oroo"
      {                  }/  for each character:            | 'o
       i                       get Unicode value:           | 79
        2%                     modulo 2:                    | 1
          T                    push original input:         | 1 "oreoo"
           ,                   get length:                  | 1 5
            '9*                repeat '9' that many times:  | 1 "99999"
               _               duplicate:                   | 1 "99999" "99999"
                :)             increment every character:   | 1 "99999" ":::::"
                  2>           remove first two characters: | 1 "99999" ":::"
                    S\+        prepend a space:             | 1 "99999" " :::"
                       ?       conditional:                 | "99999"
                        N      add a newline:               | "99999" N
                             (implicit output)              | "99999" N " :::" N "99999" N "99999" N
```

Comment: This breaks the rules: "The whitespace padding on each side of the filling is required"

Comment: Sorry, I allowed the optional trailing whitespaces. Nice entry!

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 112 bytes

```lua
s=io.read()for t in s:gmatch"."do io.write(t=="o"and t:rep(#s).."\n"or(t=="r"and" "..t:rep(#s-2).." \n"or""))end
```

---

### Explanation

```lua
s = io.read() -- Reads the input
for t in s:gmatch(".") do -- For each character in the input, call it 't' and enter the loop
 io.write(t=="o" and t:rep(#s).."\n" or (t=="r" and " "..t:rep(#s-2).." \n" or ""))

          t=="o" and  -- if 't' is equal to "o" then
                     t:rep(#s).."\n"  -- you have to write 't' repeated N times, where N is
                                      -- is the size of the input s, appended by a new line
                                     or (t=="r" and  -- else, if 't' is equal to "r" then
                                                    " "..t:rep(#s-2).." \n"  -- write a space, followed by 't' repeated N-2 times,
                                                                             -- where N is the size of the input.
                                                                             -- followed by a space and a new line.
                                                                            or "" -- else, just don't write anything.

end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nco7DgIxDIThq1hDkxTrgnKl3IQmIgYiQYwcr/b4YR9Co6m@/73kMXqqyia5hPhQI6faqM/PT/b7C4yitPlq1SV4SlDkVshnk2@49MiMW4PaYbYbCMx/n657QUcCxCitjKEmuv2c6g8)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 70 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/()()o|re/g,(_,o=1,s=' ')=>s.padEnd(x.length-o,+o)+s+`
`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jctBDoIwEEbhPacw3TATSokHKDtvYSINDKhp@pOWGBbevUYWLoyJvPX37u7hUh9v81IHDJJHm1fbribK7F0v1BAT4xmlmTRdNOxRJ1seSrZtMrMbTmGg1XgJ03KtoStwlaqu6Dj3CAlejMdEIylEgWKtzqH@pLj4Vv9JlD1mj8KbYZfDZjf/Y8gv)

Or... If we're allowed to use other characters for whitespace, we can get it down to 65 bytes:

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/()()o|re/g,(_,o=1,s=' ')=>s.padEnd(x.length-o,+o)+s+`
`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jcuxDoIwFEbhncfoQq@UEt3LxluYSAMX1DT9m0JMB9@9RgYHYyJn/s7dPuwyxFtYa4@R82RyMm3SkYOzA8tGEp6Rm1nJi4IpjyWZFjrYsfOjTNqxn9drDYXDiSpUfdFTHuAXONYOs5ykQGQIUuLs60@Cim/1n0TeY/YovBl2OWx28z@G/AI)

...but I don't think that counts.

Comment: You're right, the padding has to be whitespace. Nice entry!

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 65 bytes

```javascript
s=>s[R='replace'](/.e?/g,x=>s[R](/./g,x[0])[R](/^r|r$/g,' ')+`
`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBCsIwEETvfoUHYbMYU@9S@w9eSyUhbksldsOmSA/@e0zKDMu8WZi3@7rkZY7rZeEX5bHNqb2n/tGCUAzOEwyqMdQ1k972R8UK/XXAnZ7yk1Np4Ah4tgeLGViINWuh4nIqck1VzGBSDPNqtTUfF1WZ9bwkDmQCT2pUGyLe8h8)

Thanks to [Yair Rand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79145/yair-rand), saves 2 bytes.

Comment: You can save a byte by moving the last replace a bit earlier and removing the `m` flag: `s=>s[R='replace'](/re|o/g,x=>s[R](/./g,x[0])[R](/^r|r$/g,' ')+`
`)`

Comment: And another byte by using `/.e?/g` instead of `/re|o/g` .

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 machine code (Linux), 97 bytes

```
0000000000000000 <oreo_asm>:
   0:   56                      push   %rsi
   1:   57                      push   %rdi

0000000000000002 <len>:
   2:   48 ff c7                inc    %rdi
   5:   80 3f 00                cmpb   $0x0,(%rdi)
   8:   75 f8                   jne    2 <len>
   a:   49 89 fc                mov    %rdi,%r12
   d:   5f                      pop    %rdi
   e:   49 29 fc                sub    %rdi,%r12
  11:   4d 31 f6                xor    %r14,%r14
  14:   eb 18                   jmp    2e <outer_loop.skip>

0000000000000016 <extra>:
  16:   41 c6 01 20             movb   $0x20,(%r9)
  1a:   c6 03 20                movb   $0x20,(%rbx)
  1d:   49 ff ce                dec    %r14
  20:   eb 06                   jmp    28 <outer_loop>

0000000000000022 <newline>:
  22:   c6 06 0a                movb   $0xa,(%rsi)
  25:   48 ff c6                inc    %rsi

0000000000000028 <outer_loop>:
  28:   49 ff c6                inc    %r14
  2b:   48 ff c7                inc    %rdi

000000000000002e <outer_loop.skip>:
  2e:   44 8a 07                mov    (%rdi),%r8b
  31:   41 80 f8 65             cmp    $0x65,%r8b
  35:   74 df                   je     16 <extra>
  37:   45 84 c0                test   %r8b,%r8b
  3a:   74 23                   je     5f <done>
  3c:   48 89 f3                mov    %rsi,%rbx

000000000000003f <inner_loop>:
  3f:   44 88 06                mov    %r8b,(%rsi)
  42:   49 89 f1                mov    %rsi,%r9
  45:   48 ff c6                inc    %rsi
  48:   48 31 d2                xor    %rdx,%rdx
  4b:   48 89 f0                mov    %rsi,%rax
  4e:   48 2b 04 24             sub    (%rsp),%rax
  52:   4c 29 f0                sub    %r14,%rax
  55:   49 f7 f4                div    %r12
  58:   48 85 d2                test   %rdx,%rdx
  5b:   74 c5                   je     22 <newline>
  5d:   eb e0                   jmp    3f <inner_loop>

000000000000005f <done>:
  5f:   5e                      pop    %rsi
  60:   c3                      retq
```

This x86-64 function takes in the pointer to the input string in rsi and builds the output starting at the pointer in rdi (these are the registers used to pass the first two arguments from a C function on Linux). For convenience, I've written a C++ wrapper for this which also does nice input sanitization and prints the output. That code can be located [here](https://github.com/Davey-Hughes/ppcg/tree/master/oreoorererereoo). This also shows the original nasm syntax assembly I wrote for this function (as well as the non-golfed version I got working first).

A few things to note is that this code doesn't respect any callee saved registers, which means that the C++ code likely will crash if run for a while after calling this function. On my machine it doesn't, but that's rather surprising. I also don't add a null byte to delimit the output string, and instead the space allocated for the output string is pre-filled with bytes. (If this isn't allowed I can add the null terminator at a cost of 3 bytes).

The logic for this code is essentially counting the length of the string, then building a line of this length for each 'o' and 'r' characters seen in the input string, and then for any 'e' character seen, replacing the first and last characters on the previous line with space characters.

<s>I can't find anywhere online to compile and run a mix of C++ and nasm source code, so I might write some small wrapper code for this to prove it works.</s> Otherwise you should be able to compile and run this with the makefile in the link I gave with the command:

```
$ make oreo ASM_FILE=oreo_golf.nasm
$ ./oreo oreoorererereoo --use_asm
```

I was able to format the assembly to something acceptable by gcc, so [try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVZZk9pGEH5Gv6KtpAoJBAiMnV1Y/JBKHvKSOC5XuVyYUEIaYGJpRtaxVlWyf92k55AQOryVPTRMd0/3N18fyI/jycn3L5fZCM5ZFqer2cznATnx8DhNM8//TAr/7LETmfo8mn3JSZpRztLZ/Ke7l8vljCeE47/65RxGM8P4gTI/zAMCD5SnWUK86E1NlpATKd7UrdCGstP0jMJHTgND@Nx7aWRh4ARGlMV55oDa8DzDnW38YwzQAixjMDBB/cR5ehZrktJPzOxSBKUiJGx1a4Ng4NZGK/woluvPH9//Cm/fv4MtmuwccAv31vBvRuSKvm8VEX9UrucLp@0/5nF34DQ/fOdYwROtXTri0cCiQSNbJNmHnMfT9DONtREpssRbdYOsXfNe3nLhPmt4KDotA@KXEJ9Dp/WMfA0pI89DS1UGvJ4cVgVwjdCX7ia2dh00OOwBl9wdnEaNdNeRNHSL168anKjiAZmbW1WGLVedxEf3wYAz0gPtUDg1Tihj3Zz08dwKWTm@d9rN1k5Cs2IDAScoenx6RYfTqheE9s8Pf7z7pQQY775j2cpuQKtW7OG4E1zJsa7P7mq@8qr1IiOrnmYvL7gCnLuMgxprqRifQmiigQmWHnYO7gOxl5PQ1hZ3ppDfy@fcVctcLQu1vFTLUi2vTAdPAn70Cik5qMVXS1AgHnttPBn1KexbaRasVmpCg46Ps5eyDChswF0bg69nGhIEBw8CYWYrsynOwVN2tmwb0H5Ajxr@lu5gs4EhHyrFQAbw8arw8AC1aNatG0cdKW0IC8K1OE7HY7E@AQlT0uFxCMP1/wgDE8BxO0yG9rrLVUd8GG9gISEY@If0IQdG5FEmyAAvOfnld9cIN4@SvgPnIeQpEd9yyOLRQ@zoosW1ZZp2KZffm/DohTSwzL8s/m9C7PGPQm8Mjthb1jUnIHIhIq9hPKbXBKBrhnPIEji2orXNyUSjwBq4t0ViXJ2WK7osyUmNYplJeHG1lEjRrk6qjmBXvBi1CnBVBXxydQnckGz@ztXdQRORxsSnR0oCs0V@QrI8YTBfXyO8uHK1j7zMP1v69UESZ3cF/K0ejTJp2BtrUYulKdL8IvuRV@yxkJCLRlGNmoJxWyBuMai/5KAbHDiydrba804kuzPb2qCW8IHyIvtNkq1ygY/q/Uq/YJUd6@@RBNFpeu6sm1QpucQQkJBkZLurZPUO1KNDjQtNmOYPB8bT5XIRFvKN8VJV4Df/GHqn9DKJXi/xgZIN3pGE@DnLGVGb/wA)

Comment: Oh my, now this is an entry!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>70</s> 75 bytes

```python
lambda s:"\n".join((c*(len(s)-2*(c<'f'))).center(len(s))for c in s if'r'>c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYwxDsIwDEXn5hRWlsQVdOhYUS5CGUpIRFCxqyQLpw9yFWTJ/k/fevu3vJjGGualbuvn8VwhT3ohPbw5krWut5snm/E89tZdTDCIODhPxafWYOAEDiJBhhhMMleHtfhcMsxwU53h5NmcJBw7@XZakJqFZFh@7kqJUxyiPVyT6vYUqUCwwvhHresP)

Uses 'o' for cookie, 'e' for filling. Returns a string.

EDIT:
Saved 4 bytes thanks to [Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king).

**Explanation:**

```python
# anonymous function, returns a string seperated by line breaks
lambda s:"\n".join(.......................................................)
                                                        # iterate through string, return each non-'r' character
                                                        for c in s if'r'>c
                    # duplicate the character until it is the length of the original string,
                    # minus two characters if the current letter is 'e'
                    c*(len(s)-2*(c<'f'))
                   # pad the string with spaces out to the length of the original string
                   (....................).center(len(s))
```

Comment: Sorry, the output should be a single string with line-breaks that can be printed or the program should print the output as it is processed. Arrays of strings aren't allowed, because of the "ascii" part.

Comment: @GammaGames Bluh, I should really read the rules more closely. Thank you!

Comment: [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYzBCsMgDIbP9SmCF7VsPfRY1r5I20PnlDm6pKiXPb0jxTECyf/zhe/45CdhX/y4lH173x8bpGHWttW7Q53MtW@1vSmvjDGddZhdrMR4imAhICQIXkU12bVkl3KCEWbRKIqO1IXDuaOrpwbGxI2H@GcVgp3sYO3pGkRzxIAZvOZuflUuKLsXBdQV/IksXw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 64 bytes

```python
s=input()
for c in s:
	if'n'<c:j='o'<c;print' '*j+c*(len(s)-2*j)
```

A full program which prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcUxDoAgDADAWV7RrYBxYUR5DZFYYloCOPj66i3X3nkJB9WRiNszrTNFOmQghhHNQgUZjxxrQvnfWyeeCOjrmr29T7bDbcFXp4rST8EP)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##PY/NDsIgDMfP8hS9Fea87IjuATz5ArtM1sUtkxJgiT49AktMk36k/f/aum98se2S4YmgB0QcUugX6/YolZjZg4HFQtDitMxo8Wb02iPneHV@sREBm/VsGrmRlUFdumZVKVNERWTiNr6f06ghUoiiAktWmBLZE2MLWJ2nwx@xtLgUxZhR5QPqQsD7Qc5TnpyXBaeyYrCPPeaOHiy24kQfMrJ8pf5CTD8).

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 216 bytes

```
set s [gets stdin]
set l [string map {o { o } re { re }} $s]
set n [string length $s]
foreach i $l {
if {$i eq "o"} {
puts [string repeat █ $n]
} elseif {$i eq "re"} {
puts " [string repeat ░ [expr {$n-2}]] "
}
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY49CsMwDIV3n@JhvHbpdUKGkCqJwbVd24WC0d61Sw7Yi7hqQ3@gCAnx9D6eyuhay1SQ0c1UMnI5WN@rp@TQ5ZKsn3EcImpARQAjkSwymGHy5vQfpyM/l@V1mEKiYVxgYRyqshOqsaATdNAsQjxL3JtLFGkouK9XGIlnkMv0gyT6MvqfuqGjS0xi97s99z20YsWtyQtBeqsQHg)

Comment: Assume valid input and handle “o” and “r” and ignore “e”. For this `split $s ""` is shorter than `string map`. You only need $l once, so better skip the assignment to variable and use the expression directly in `foreach`. If you reverse the conditions, you can remove the spaces: `$i eq "o"` → `"o"eq$i`. Use `if` instead of `elseif`. no need the braces around `expr`'s argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY2xDsIwEEP3foUVZWXhd0KGqlzbSFEScoeEFGVnZekH8iMhBcSCrFvs57NMvjUmAcMsJAyWswt22K0Aw5JdWOApLLJCsx3mmGmcVrgeJu@km1DKorgZRUVFF@0q0lX49KtnSjQKntsduv9@k/lLlh2F@mcfMHRLuTcOR2uham2tb8d@H8X4Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 23 bytes

```
L£\eoƛ\o=[×¥*|ð¥⇩\!*ð++
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=j&code=L%C2%A3%5Ceo%C6%9B%5Co%3D%5B%C3%97%C2%A5*%7C%C3%B0%C2%A5%E2%87%A9%5C!*%C3%B0%2B%2B&inputs=oreoorererereoo&header=&footer=)

```
L£                      # Store length to register
  \eo                   # Remove es
     ƛ                  # Map...
      \o=[              # If o then
          ×¥*           # (Register) asterisks
             |          # Else...
               ¥⇩\!*    # (Register-2 !s)
              ð     ð++ # Padded with spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-plF`, 27 bytes

```perl
s!.!$&x@F.$/!ge;s/r+
ee/ /g
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoicyEuISQmeEBGLiQvIWdlO3MvcitcbmVlLyAvZyIsImFyZ3MiOiItcGxGIiwiaW5wdXQiOiJvcmVvb3JlcmVyZXJlb29cbm9yZW9cbnJlXG5yZXJlXG5vb29vb29vbyJ9)

### Explanation

`s///`ubstitutes every character (`.`) with itself repeated the length of the string `x@F`, followed by a newline (`$/`). Then replaces any runs of `r+\nee` with a single space.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 14 bytes

```
\eoƛAd⇩?L+*?L⋏
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiXFxlb8abQWTih6k/TCsqP0zii48iLCIiLCJvcmVvb29vbyJd)

Comment: Coming in lower than the other Vyxal answer, nice work!

Answer (score 1):

## APOL, 79 bytes

This could almost certaintly be made shorter.

`v(0 i);j(ƒ(R(⁰ "re" "*") ¿(=(∋ "*") +(" " *("r" -(l(⁰) 2))) *("o" l(⁰)))) "\n")`

### Explanation

```
v(0 i);  Put user's input at memory index 0
j(  List join
  ƒ(  Listbuilder for
    R(  String replace (being iterated through)
      ⁰  Value at index 0
      "re"  Replace "re"
      "*"  with "*"
    )
    ¿(  Returning if (called for each character in replaced string)
      =(  Equals (condition)
        ∋  Current character
        "*"  The string "*"
      )
      +(  Add (true instruction, used here to join strings)
        " "  The string " " (the padding for the filling)
        *(  Multiply (used here to repeat a string)
          "r"  The string "r" (our filling) by
          -(  Subtract
            l(⁰)  The length of the input
            2  from two (one for each character of padding)
          )
        )
      )
      *(  Multiply (the false condition)
        "o"  The string "o"  (our cookie)
        l(⁰)  by the length of the input
      )
    )
  )
  "\n"  Join each string with a newline
)
```