# How long is the number in this base?

Tags: code-golf, math, base-conversion

Given a positive integer \$n\$ and another positive integer \$b\$ (\$1 < b < 36\$), return the number of digits/length of \$n\$ in base \$b\$

```
1597 16 -> 3
1709 9 -> 4
190 29 -> 2
873 24 -> 3
1061 27 -> 3
289 26 -> 2
1575 34 -> 3
1135 15 -> 3
1161 22 -> 3
585 23 -> 3
1412 23 -> 3
1268 14 -> 3
714 12 -> 3
700 29 -> 2
1007 35 -> 2
292 17 -> 3
1990 16 -> 3
439 3 -> 6
1212 17 -> 3
683 31 -> 2
535 25 -> 2
1978 32 -> 3
153 8 -> 3
1314 33 -> 3
433 2 -> 9
655 35 -> 2
865 19 -> 3
1947 25 -> 3
1873 32 -> 3
1441 12 -> 3
228 30 -> 2
947 2 -> 10
1026 11 -> 3
1172 24 -> 3
1390 32 -> 3
1495 21 -> 3
1339 10 -> 4
1357 9 -> 4
1320 27 -> 3
602 5 -> 4
1462 16 -> 3
1658 9 -> 4
519 11 -> 3
159 3 -> 5
1152 11 -> 3
1169 33 -> 3
1298 7 -> 4
1686 32 -> 3
1227 25 -> 3
770 15 -> 3
1478 20 -> 3
401 22 -> 2
1097 7 -> 4
1017 9 -> 4
784 23 -> 3
1176 15 -> 3
1521 7 -> 4
1623 23 -> 3
1552 13 -> 3
819 15 -> 3
272 32 -> 2
1546 12 -> 3
1718 4 -> 6
1686 8 -> 4
1128 2 -> 11
1617 34 -> 3
1199 34 -> 3
626 23 -> 3
991 9 -> 4
742 22 -> 3
1227 11 -> 3
1897 12 -> 4
348 35 -> 2
1107 11 -> 3
31 26 -> 2
1153 26 -> 3
432 4 -> 5
758 9 -> 4
277 21 -> 2
472 29 -> 2
1935 21 -> 3
457 27 -> 2
1807 26 -> 3
1924 26 -> 3
23 27 -> 1
558 30 -> 2
203 15 -> 2
1633 8 -> 4
769 21 -> 3
1261 32 -> 3
577 7 -> 4
1440 22 -> 3
1215 35 -> 2
1859 23 -> 3
1702 35 -> 3
1580 12 -> 3
782 15 -> 3
701 32 -> 2
177 24 -> 2
1509 28 -> 3
```

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: consider adding test case with 0 like 0 2 -> 1? a lot of them seem to fail with it

Comment: @Hydrazer But 0 is not a *positive* integer?

Comment: oh i guess you're right

Answer (score 8):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 21 bytes

```javascript
b=>g=n=>n&&1+g(n/b|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVTbThsxEH3fr5gHhHZFAM/Y47FVbX6kqkoCgaZKF5REFInm29Nx1hdeEk88lzPnHOf36n11eNxv34637@H8PJ7X4/JlnMbldH2NNy/9dL/@Z4bz31/b3Qb6A4yw36yedttp0w8DfHYA36cFrBfwcwHHH3p9uDu87bbH/h7uh7s/q7f@A8Yl3HwM3zR3rwnP/Xrop0v4@DodXnebu93rS/9w9Tmd4OpzfYLbpX7vT9Dr5zgeT8ODZp/OyFEAfbq2HYqJENPZdRgN0OVMXRAL5HKO8Qgkc0AhAvk5CVkYbMlCy4BcglRCc8CBgWy@cEgtIB8Ac73oAXOFmIYEjRGwPAcUCTAjwah4yx7ORrh09doVW5IPFizOxaxdKDfCKAFsHodsIeSjVRjWlqZKQjrGzjNXEMHrorGAcJKbapBYq02dw7oQkU4zc/mlIh3R6HLKJWIhTaiRbnW71isq9JJmdVc0WTPLUvWzZKpO3hBw/t15aoJ7DqWAdYs6nDOBrDiYvoDysRKCFANI7uqDbwCJGg0iphnBKc9kMp@mmCLJqi4srQzWJSS45g8U3zqxElBna0rN4gQ3ByGtlCtI6bRlHDtf1UDBAC67Ja0RcltUmWZpUC8UVDN3jDXwqlkZHiNW5I6q5S98VApDenA0Z1kXqpEQTctSl9Z3lQxJ1dk0Y@VOmnQkkg1BnUu2Ka8l2uYUp96Y/aAXQWeVnhjVZiVIVF6SsGNuNiVjM5Na7K0tJIn6oVqR9JkXD7A0QZ0zX7jA9nYwqM@qcqImtVXfYNofQKAqoxhsMqa1XZFU/7oov9v/)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 28 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,b:x and-~f(x/b,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVSxblsxDNzzFW90ABYVSVGUAvhLggw20qABXCdwPLhLf90lJVGZTDyfeOTdSZ9/r78/znS/v@1Phz/H18N2g@PTbTucX3/8e9vdfh7h@Hi//vq6fm3752eUpoAF@AWeUVODBtnLloAakJVVGSgPQCoIpL2man@XjkBRAZ4QZAGUWTucei1VgHh8zkirplIBx1G1XxxoTYseUzJC6TU1Ahz02GzCOXfmBgylt8OFKNUosJ8TPz9aYNMKPFhQGOqo2Gfg2c32heYdRIK5FtuqTeas3q3XLk50yxljfiLrm/rJjgZMfRUTDHFqo7RkZdtldWnGODFsi2EahrBoeMOUwoWSCGR8zYWWkUXqBItNHZTiMkknF/oepLRYHalV0NGu1LJmIlobq6ZlbzYpbZQuWupOD8MsUbNJwhhaa16eo5bVQ2zXYLT/AyI@4KirbzDQZJrxZJFcQm1UrJBHAHzsOvqhmeBr9s8eikhoa1EXT/CgaQ1j1EyR2r55CFX9plCHcK6RDMS0IB63eSU8WxTxtENdd122kKq77NDsQZhZb7zMz@a3y96ZjWI2w2ahmbXrZdzusqy8UWKXq58rzFMMNZMjVWS3cjoruqzKOX1vjSv4WC014Ypa2jiMq2nd1krhkCZcDvmKeZplD4tfiZeXh4fPy/v5ujucTjt7jewt2u8v29vHxZ8puGzv562/TY@P9/8)

thanks @Kevin Cruijssen for -1 byte by using python 2 instead of python 3

Comment: You could switch to Python 2 so the `//` can be `/`.

Comment: i think you need to include the function name if you are doing recursion

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 2 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit infix function taking \$b\$ as left argument and \$n\$ as right argument.

```apl
≢⊤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HnokddS/6nPWqb8Ki371FX86PeNY96txxab/yobeKjvqnBQc5AMsTDM/i/oZlCmoKhqaU5lyWIYW5gyWUEZlkacBmZABkW5sYA)

`≢` tally the digits of

`⊤` the anti-base (i.e. the representation in the given base)

Note that this is wasteful in that it actually does the base conversion.

### [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 bytes

Anonymous tacit infix function taking \$b\$ as left argument and \$n\$ as right argument.

```apl
⌊1+⍟
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FPl6H2o975/9MetU141Nv3qKv5Ue@aR71bDq03ftQ28VHf1OAgZyAZ4uEZ/N/QTCFNwdDU0pzLEsQwN7DkMgKzLA24jEyADAtzYwA)

`⌊` floor

`1+` the incremented

`⍟` log

Implements \$⌊1+\log_bn⌋\$.

Comment: Could you use ceiling instead of increment and floor?

Comment: @Graham No, because log₁₀1000 is 3 but 1000 takes 4 digits.

Comment: How is `≢⊤` calculated as "2 bytes"? I.e. what encoding is used?

Comment: @Feuermurmel I've updated the post heading to explain.

Answer (score 6):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 20 bytes

*My first Zsh answer, cobbled together using [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191209) [very](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31328257) [helpful](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/226010/92901) [posts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15280/92901).*

```bash
<<<${#v=$[[##$2]$1]}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGpVq5zFYlOlpZWcUoVsUwtvb///@Gppbm/w3NAA) or [run the test suite](https://tio.run/##TVRrb1oxDP1@f4Ul2KBaobEdx8lUth/SVetTWqUOqsEmbcBvZw43j35BMdeP43NO8uv3w9/T4@bpeTU7XV9fT/eTP6vpzc1kMqXbKd4eT7Nh97zdbVcf5ihJAQMsvgAPqC5Bymc/YHJA5zMNURnIlxwXEEjHgGICCmMSigpwzUIWQKlBLqExkChAXD54pB5QiIClXu2ApUJdR4LOKbCMASUCLEgwGd66h@cE567BumJPCpGBcSwW60KlESaNwGUcCkMsRzYYzLWpkZCPaQgiDUQMtmiqILyWphZk1lpT77EtRGTT3Fh@rshHdLaccYlYSVPqpLNt13slg17T2HZFVzRj0aYfk2s6BUcg5X8fqAseJNYCsS3acCkEiuEQegcqpEYIUoqgpWuIoQMk6jSoum4EbzyTK3y6aoosq7mwtnLYltDouz9QQ@8kRkCbbSktSzLcEsS8Uqkgo5PrOPGhqYGKEXxxS14jlrZoMo3SoH0wUN3cKbUgmGZ1eErYkHtqlj/z0SiM@cLRmMU@NiMhup5lLm33KhuSmrNpxCqDdulItRiCBp9tU29L4u4Ub94Y/WAfos2qPTGZzWqQqTwn4SDSbUqOC5NWHJgrSWp@aFYku@bVA6JdUO/dOy6w3x2M5rOmnJpJuekbXX8AIjUZ1WGXMa/tq6T2dNF4by@Wry/r5@3y5/3b/rA77Jbbx/v1/Orb06eri/zn/OPn3eb7y8VxeIPzO7i8f339uj@sL@HhEjYHuPu3/QGLR5hN9vkVPc5gsYDJfn20n4fj3TJXr1ab4@k/).

Full program taking \$n\$ and \$b\$ as arguments.

#### Commented

```bash
<<<                  # print
   ${#             } # length in characters of
      v=             # set dummy variable v to
        $[[##$2]$1]  # n ($1) in base b ($2)
```

---

Here's an alternative offered by @pxeger. The byte count is the same but the dummy variable is elegantly avoided using parameter expansion.

```bash
<<<${#:-$[[##$2]$1]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhZbbGxsVKqVrXRVoqOVlVWMYlUMY2shUlAVq6INTS3NdRQMzWKhIgA)

Comment: You can avoid defining `v` with the [`${:-}` construct](https://bit.ly/3q6F3ar): , which can substitute a literal string without changing any variables, exactly to workaround issues like this. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhZbbGxsVKqVrXRVoqOVlVWMYlUMY2shUlAVq6INTS3NdRQMzWKhIgA). (It's the same byte count, though)

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <sup><s>4</s></sup> 3 bytes

```
ljF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyfL7f//aENTS3MdQ7PYf/kFJZn5ecX/dVMA)

```
     # implicitly output
l    #   len of
 jF  #     convert first element in input to base second element of input
```

-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder

Comment: `ljF` saves a byte if you take input in the form `[a,b]` (or even `a,b`)

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 5 bytes

```
ＩＬ↨ＮＮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwyc1L70kQ8MpsThVwzOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NHAYULAtb//xuaGlgqGFn81y3LAQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Works for any `b>1`. Unfortunately `Base` doesn't accept implicit arguments, so I have to explicitly input the `n` and `b`. Explanation:

```
   Ｎ    Input `n` as an integer
    Ｎ   Input `b` as an integer
  ↨     Convert `n` to base `b` as an array
 Ｌ      Take the length
Ｉ       Cast to string
        Implicitly print
```

Comment: Note: This solution returns `0` for `n=0`; switching to `BaseString` means that it returns `1` for `n=0` but then it only works up to base `62` (which is still within the range required by the question).

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v1.4.5, <s>4</s> 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
slV
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.5&code=c2xW&input=MTcwOQo5)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 35 bytes

```
\d+
$*
+`\b(1+) (\1)+1*
 $1 $#2$*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZI7jhwxDERznoKAx8DsTiJ@JIon8CUmWBt24MSB4fvPVqkdCd0Ui1WP@vvr3@8/319f798@Xs@fD7m9y@Pj@eNujze9P@3tYe@iN9PbF0dJXy9barNLWq1Gi@PsIZ66K8RLbSwTX@q7JRJ3a4pNNYsp7jhZDp178rA0F8M1X1vMtSwpWWNIoGmMEiv1xiXMbUwKzWj@NEdrmK6NuVMn9AP6XVs2xoYE5IN66AjKrQkrrXtNNlhnnQ4ax2jLNImh7hstLJrBgS@GMys/l4Nh8T8bWgPfMAMEMeuEDx@CQePym8tZXHNTaxqIEN4RtunHoa0Whul99Ndex5x7EVsVxmFMIhXo5TBeHhf/YUWGtfMiXIvF6QewLUcszsMglDenuzpyMOzMJYhVdmidqVBAdO5sQZgngFNqgUFrt9FCpR//xyDpwQvYRu4rFjaG7cd5A8Y1JPATQ4ECyHkVN5zwQY7NZ1Ga87TZvtqtPfkbEbCRSX5TfcTximWis9bJg4dDJJOqZ4fXw3G7ntcGbX7X@B97j4N1n20WcHK5bOabGf0J) Link includes test cases. Takes input in the order `b`, `n`. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert `b` and `n` to unary.

```
+`\b(1+) (\1)+1*
 $1 $#2$*
```

Repeatedly integer divide `n` by `b` until `n` is less than `b`. With each division, prefix a space to `b`.

Count the total number of spaces, including the original space. This gives the desired answer.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```ruby
->n,b{/$/=~n.to_s(b)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PJ6laX0Xfti5PryQ/vlgjSbP2f4FCWrShobmRjpFJLBeEY2ShYxT7HwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
вg
```

First input is the base \$b\$, second input is \$n\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//wqb0//8NzbgMTS3NAQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##NVO5jZRRDM63itHGDp6vZ78AUchopGUlhEggQELaBiiAUmiAgAaogUYGX5PMWM/Xd/j/@u3D6@eP9@9vL8@v7/78hsuX@L38@/Hz8vz@7eX@99enO9yvV9RjgPsGV7R14GRwFlAGbgwk@bI2AllE5AeoqtUUuJLICqgVZRlFpK5AnE@CNBFtB8wGQwHMKluzCNcy4BxBhwCtQASKwiV8oAfg5LYzMOaa2Ey1@ZgDU@Fi8Pzn2MJc/cEiu1R7h@/A20TFpj@pdr8INjqiGLkiqKpCSRsQi6jRKMMBcxpPgKksB2JcFam1pEyrBdyLoDbKptF9q1eR4pnxOoxR6bFwn2aDdBxKoO17NhMNDbM1TkjoQQlB1liCK4yuxoUNylzGGrQ9fUo404knqQkiI098ZVKwH7Flt1ho6CAPWGUAhn6V2rFvLuWcjnYoWdPPwcYiNDCTTHP2vMx8Y/F2DnFNknHOMP2mPhMqADZqklnbIelV283jkIQt5QZ6DOxBh6SjJJ451fGfFo86m/u4LNxoqykuvqRQG3VF1oMJzsGhh6EtpoX9/aa@5itw6vG2ZhYm9BJM45Mkv92env4D).

Using logarithm like most other answers is **4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**:

```
.n>ï
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fL8/u8Pr//w3NuAxNLc0B) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##NVO5jZRRDM63itXGFnq@nv0CoJDRSMtKBCRLgIS0DVAAjVACwXZCI4OvSWas5@s7/H//8eXl29fbz7fnp5eP73/h8TV@H//9@v349Pnt@fbh9dP7nxvcLhfUY4D7Che0deBkcBZQBm4MJPmyNgJZROQHqKrVFLiSyAqoFWUZRaSuQJxPgjQRbQfMBkMBzCpbswjXMuAcQYcArUAEisIlfKAH4OS2MzDmmthMtfmYA1PhYvD859jCXP3BIrtUe4fvwNtExaY/qXa/CDY6ohi5IqiqQkkbEIuo0SjDAXMaT4CpLAdiXBWptaRMqwXci6A2yqbRfatXkeKZ8TqMUem@cJ9mg3QcSqDtezYTDQ2zNU5I6EEJQdZYgiuMrsaFDcpcxhq0PX1KONOJJ6kJIiNPfGVSsB@xZbdYaOggd1hlAIZ@ldqxby7lnI52KFnTz8HGIjQwk0xz9rzMfGPxdg5xTZJxzjD9pj4TKgA2apJZ2yHpVdvN45CELeUGegzsQYekoySeOdXxnxaPOpv7uCzcaKspLr6kUBt1RdadCc7BoYehLaaF/f2mvuYrcOrxtmYWJvQSTOOTJL9eHx7@Aw).

**Explanation:**

```python
      # First (implicit) input-integer = `b`
      # Second (implicit) input-integer = `n`

в     # Convert n to a base-b list
 g    # Pop and get the length of that list
      # (after which the result is output implicitly)

.n    # Log_b(n)
  >   # +1
   ï  # Truncate decimals
      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 13 bytes

```
IntegerLength
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVRNaxsxEL3vrxiWHlrYEM1Io5EICSmkhUAPhRyDDyY4zoJjB3cLhZDf7o6sr9w0q/l4897Tvq6Xl83repmf1qfn69P9ftlsN8dfm/12eTndHR6H93k6fMA17Ob95mqY9fTzeHi9m7fz8ufy9mE5zvvtw9tuXh7naYRxdTX81k8aXdw8396mb1/H6TCN38bVML2nLlMu@vFvOa6flscvD0/H@W2537/9XfLNNA7jxc333W6CES5uIAerj9UJOQqgTx/tgGIixHR2A0YDdD7TEMQCuZJjPAJJDihEIJ@TkIXB1iy0DMg1SCWUAw4MZMuFQ@oB@QBY6kUPWCrEdCRojIDlHFAkwIIEo@Ktezgb4dzVa1fsST5YsJiLWbtQaYRRAtgyDtlCKEerMKytTZWEdIyDZ24ggtdFYwXhpDTVILHWmjqHbSEinWZy@bkiHdHocsolYiVNqJNudbveKyr0mmZ1VzRFM8vS9LNkmk7eEHD57jx1wT2HWsC6RRvOhUBWHEyfQPnYCEGKAaR09cF3gESdBhHTjeCUZzKFT1NNkWRVF9ZWBtsSElz3B4rvnVgJaLM1pWVxgluCkFYqFaR02jqOnW9qoGAAV9yS1gilLapMWRrUCwXVzR1jC7xqVofHiA25o2b5Mx@NwpAeHOUs60IzEqLpWerS9q6SIak5mzJWHqRLRyLFEDS4ZJv6WqLtTnHqjewHvQg6q/bEqDarQaLynIQDc7cpGVuY1GJvbSVJ1A/NiqTPvHqApQvqnPnEBfa3g0F91pQTNalt@gbTfwCBmoxisMuY1nZVUv11UX63/wE)

Of course there's a built-in. Input `[n, b]`.

---

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 15 bytes

```
1+⌊Log@##⌋&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVTbahsxEH3frxCbUlq6ppqRRiMRElxIC4U@lPrR@MEEJ11wYuNsSyHkB9p8ZX7EHVm3vGlWM2dmzjnau/X0c3O3nsbr9fHm4ggfXp7/ftvdzs/OXp7/vT1e7Zbd4zjsntSF2o73m/NulNOXw@7uarwdp4eP88V0GO9vF/vtOC3HoVf96rz7Lp8kml3ezOc/Nr83h4fNPN6964fd0L/vV93wGNGGVPz5z3RYX0/LN4vrw7ifvt7vf03pZui7fnb5absdVK9mlyoFq6fVESiwAhc/mg5YBxXi2XYQtMLTGTvPRqHNOdqBQk4B@qDQpSQgJmVKFhhSQCWIJZgC8qTQ5AsL2AJ0XkGuZzlArmDdJgGtWRlKAQZUkCeBIPOWPawJ6oTqBBVakvNGGUjFJCiYgSCwVya3AzLK56ORMYwpoEJCPIbOEdUhvJNFQxnCcgaVILJWQa2FuhCidNOp/FQRj6BlOeESoJDG2Eg3sl3DCjJ6STOyK@ismSGu@hnUVSenUVH@bh02wR35UkCyRW1OmUCSOQhfDeVCJQQweMUZ1XnXBkRsNDDrZgQrPKPOfOpiiiiruLBAaahLsLfNH8CuIZEQUHtLSs2iOG4OfFwpV6DQaUo7sq6qAQxe2eyWuIbPsCAyJWlALmSoZu4QauBEs9I8BKiTW6yWP/FRKfTxwWHKMtZXIwHoliUure8qGhKrszHNSh036ZA5GwI7G21TXkswzSlWvJH8IBdeehVMCGKzEkQqT0nQETWbojaZSSl2xhSSWPxQrYjyzIsHiJug1upXXEB7O@DFZ1U5FpOaqq/X7QfgscrIGpqMcW1bJJVfF6Z3@x8)

Not the built-in. Input `[b, n]`.

Comment: How is #2 15 bytes?

Comment: @emanresuA `⌊⌋` are each 3 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
τL
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CF%84L&inputs=4%0A1200&header=&footer=)

Simplest method

`τ` does the base conversion, and `L` gives the length.

Comment: `ṙ` rounds, so #2 is wrong

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 16 bytes

```
[ >base length ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVTBjhMxDL3PV5gPYBXbcZyA1CviwgVxQhyGara7EtuWmdkDQnx7cdpO4r3N0zj28/OzH8f9epov375@/vLpA7yM69PDeZyXaYZl@v06HffTAud5Wtc/5/n5uMJhPr2en48HGJfltF/g4zD8HVCKAiZ4B@93wANqKFBuKA5YAtAd0ZCVgWKLDAmBdIOUC1DaQlFUgHsssgBKh/UpbVCyAHH7GZE8pJQBWya1T2wvNXh@GIICywapEGDjh8V66X1GLnCvkawG@tCUGRi3NGIZqSXFohm4EUBhyA2wkWPuJUyuGyhDEnHUcjI5SqcWtZUwWHV2JWJE1zKR1Q9bouvLG8BgAtgEELvMSn5gbAr4vMUa68FsimBok2dR5wOm4GadAoG0fzGRN1CS3B@KdekISRNdjJ3QG7KpOPGQSgZtNVJOnjqRF0w1eHNFmxCFNoXQrVYtYm7vaQO6JjVH7zvU5LOKSeX4WKCLldpKg7k23V6SDYE7AYnJTRMVM8Tmw9pmbkXQRr0NF@2nkfUrVYqDySbfCZWCrq9Ibtmu2jnZc11/2mI5ZmdTxOBjbSfchlfrk9sn2vqQQb0FSLXZjIZYLdk3trD3YDTPbS6zn9mq9wpYzMod1gHcQ3EQ8UtBgZv@liYxd1HVXOZMT3aIuq9EvTliDG90Q7/BmM3LzgFqK8HOLTn4M5XJGUIDekNUeWK3h51fahfln83/erUv32H3c1wm@DUdD@sT/Lg83q747mU8w8PlPw)

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes a number and a base (in that order) and returns the length of the number in the given base.

- `>base` Take a number and a base and return the number in the given base as a string.
- `length` The length of the string.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
bL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/J5////4YGBkAMAA)

Finally, a Jelly answer using ASCII only.

```
bL - Main link. Takes a number on left, base on right
b  - Obtain left base right
 L - Get the length of the string representation of the result
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pascal, 20 characters

Plain translation of the formula:
$$
\left\lfloor \frac{\log_c n}{\log_c b} + 1\right\rfloor
$$

```pascal
trunc(ln(n)/ln(b)+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 25 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,b)=>n<b?1:1+f(n/b,b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P81WI08nSdPWLs8myd7QylA7TSNPPwko8r@gKDOvRCNNw9DIwEDHRFPzPwA)

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 26 bytes, thanks to Adám

```javascript
n=>b=>n.toString(b).length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/z9YuydYuT68kP7ikKDMvXSNJUy8nNS@9JON/AZBfopGmYWhkYKCpYaKp@R8A)

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 32 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,b,x=1)=>b**x<n?f(n,b,x+1):x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/P81WI08nSafC1lDT1i5JS6vCJs8@DSKkbahpVfG/oCgzr0QjTcPQyMBAx0RT8z8A)

Comment: Any reason to avoid `n=>b=>n.toString(b).length`?

Comment: Recursive division approach would be shorter still.

Comment: @Adám well I wasn't aware!

Comment: @Neil thanks for the reminder!

Comment: 22 bytes by taking the arguments in reverse order: `b=>g=n=>n<b?1:1+g(n/b)`

Comment: @Neil, [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/ydYu3TbP1i7PJqmmxlA7XSNPP0nzf0FRZl6JRpqGiaaGoZGBgabmfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 27 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 20 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with `\`.

```r
function(n,b)log(n,b)%/%1+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVTbbtswDH33VwgeCthYuomkKErbOmDf0fUhDZIigJEWsQdkGPbtGRXr0j2FjMkj8pwjna@Hh@vh12m3HF9Pw2nzPE6vL7ffu8938BGuhwE4ygb8aD6Y@@@Gum63XYb@xzSZZT8v97vtvJ@//Dz1Y7edpmHevr1Nv4d5Oc9v03EZ9lOL@wRlwK84IDaamGLXQbQGbzF2QcigyzXWg0FZEwzRoF@LgIUNlSogNsAlSS24JhzYIOUPDrAl6IOB3C8aQO4Q2yYBa8UQrwlGNJAngajzlj0cRXND9YoKrcgHMgRrMysKZiCIEgzl44DJhBySjkFUQJWEFMbOM9chgtdFYxnCSQbVJLFWQZ2DuhCinmbX9ltHCsHqcsolQCFNsJFOul3Dijp6KSPdFWzWjFiqfoS26uQtGs7/O49NcM@hNLBuUQ/nTCDrHIzvhvKxEgIYg5GM6oNvAyI2GkRsM4JTntFmPm0xRZJVXVigLNQlJLjmDxDfkFgJqGdrSa3iNG5OQlopd6DSSeU4dr6qAQLBuOyWtEbIsKAyrdKAftChmrljrIlXzcrhMUKd3GG1/I2PSmFIFw7XKnKhGgnAtip1ab1XyZBYnY3rrNxJkw5FsiGwc8k25bZEak5x6o3VD/oh6FkFE6LarCSJylsRdMzNpmgpM6nNnqiQJOqHakXUa148wNIEdc6@4wLa3YGgPqvKiZqUqr7BtgcgYJVRLDQZ09quSKpPF673tt/06fEbN31K@3HT1ef0Mv5Zvt1v50/H07J/2Z//ewwvj/CkPdo5fj0MS8qWR3waHx7eNVzSP3/H8foP)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 21 bytes

This solution works with `n = 0`

```raku
{$^a.base($^b).chars}
```

```
$^a and $^b are implicit when you call a function with 2 arguments
This is similar to if you call a function with 1 argument
That function will have implicit topic variable $_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7daoNAFITv9ykmEoqCimfXdZWi6W2foTawRm0LSQxqKSH47Hb9SQu5WJjvnJk5e6naYzSerniqkY637V77he4qe7svHP/wqdtuGJ8ZM4aXvup672CWnm5bpDh@navOP@mL7WXIJ8KNYR77P01bdm@BS654zzL/9dyzwTE9ddM@FpmwnWsXeWFe8907c0unr6htMy4cpCnMHLsdrI@mKS1sNrAKXVpsGAPwqYFYACEXRTJRoGgCwUgFCZJJh4wS4541Z7ES4OHqCSICVwvwOAGPFhNJJSHuLjIHSN5hivAFZCzBxboIif8Dj2LQmldG0JpQwd9PfgE)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 12 bytes

```
Prompt N,B
1+int(log(N,B
```

Output is stored in `Ans` and is displayed. If not using OS 2.53 MP or higher, `log(N,B` should be replaced with `log(N)/log(B` to add 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```
f(n,b)=floor(log_bbn)
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rktssbfzcp)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f9qeravcfx)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
YAn
```

[Try it online!](https://matl.io/?code=YAn&inputs=1718%0A4&version=22.7.4)

```
YAn
YA   : dec2base
  n  : numel/size
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>26</s></sup> 25 bytes

```c
f(n,b){n=n?1+f(n/b,b):0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVXtbhoxEPyfp7CQIpHkUOy1fbZLaX9UfYoGVYEcKWpyiQCpqBGvXrqz9sFBgu4W337Mzs6eYD56nM/3@8WwrWZXb@2k/Wpu@OF2xo@f9Hi3X7Yb9Xy/bIdX6u1C8QeOTbPe/Gx/TNVEvRmfQqVM0Ilt0pWKwfJJ16ZSFOH0wbM1VizcPuLoDLGlOlYqGMdGa9RpRqOEUAKas4Ag5NaRgb3ApBABjEYWtc7ysfYcirXEHThlJs6BCXFB9mqqQSSghUUL4xJqrHSyHjmW2F9rpLgatvZc742MA2M8yTRCLoFMHQFLxOUhCCo4Om3QUiTSBrHopDuSPSFYE1h6AEY0IGHmHTKCOUIbkjNADGvD/DBISowRHHW9TUQv65BroKU1QtdCJM4KGIQCB5z0SdDTydAR6SYREwQlL5ka5GrIG/KwskDUs7BaVgPxoqgSRDEfNeZEM5lekr1Ou/HpCzQrLxCmwM75Rmvsv8YIqMLmMh1RCT7KufIeABm5@YhRid2Yk7mDNJXEdIwAwGoJGZN7wi270JkKY/mMnHKSLV@QoaT7Qk9niiFX2uwN5Vgeu7ZOeFEezhadUwYAvunomqwBbpczTFHIHBWSO@Rh0CXmsM1sqGChhWDSkYvoHHv7aLavzXzTPOSNWOlKMrbtHc4u6oXqd54y2bsSaNx3ObnsqfW96Fm96zndaSjzcIeVnSUdZqKuh@tRPjA1nfOsDX04fRFx/ut@dc22mf9uVlnFwd32O91t0ze@/aBS/Wc7KHWLl5UaYgPL9qHZcpkel@NntV7@bV4Ww243V7fFcX3wjNXNjWR3P87dPltGKj/SEp@OT8KzLjz7MLzmcP5HOPU37D@8KeeFrytOWQwHlw@Kr9EX2Mv1XcuTt5WaVWpdHfRZTybNtIDvLnb7f/PF0/3jej/6sx89Pf8H)

For input positive integers \$n\$ and \$b\$ returns the number of digits in \$n_b\$.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 30 bytes

```java
n->b->n.toString(n,b).length()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY8xb8IwEIVn8itutCtilYGiCBqJBakDYkCdqg6X4ASnztmyL0gR4renRrB06i337u59T7oOL5h3p5/J9N4Fhi7NamBjVTNQzcaRellnfqisqaG2GCPs0RBcM0j13EdGTu3izAn6dBVHDobar2/A0EaZzLPdM23zQaxbHeaQxCdhGA9eB2QXSmjeJ8rLKi9JsXtECJpXUllNLZ@FnNbZ7DhG1r1yAyufHGxJNAq9t6NYLIuVfOhtTPFi8SblP8jqtfiDFHfi/totu02/)

Comment: Doesn't `n->b->n.toString(b).length()` work?

Comment: @Neil No, because `Integer.toString` is a static method, not an instance method.

Comment: Ah, so `n.toString()` is an instance method, but there's no equivalent with a radix, and `n.toString(b)` just invokes `Integer.toString(b)`.

Comment: @Neil Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 40 bytes

```rust
|n,b:u8|(n as f64).log(b.into())as u64+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVTLbttADLzrK5gcEgl1jSX37TQ59BN66KUoAtuRC6Ou7FoSWiDJt6dcaR9GgaK2Ie9K5HA4nNV57Ie3sW@hH55Wq/1xtfo47j6166e7atfBj/W@qxt4hkM7wO7@7aVbbFaje6k7WPewM6pZHo7f6s1y3w3Humn45mjUO3zj7OMZDvuuhX1XsHkRADlp@z388fM@4FcwVai7BWwW0P4@tduhfWrgHk7rc98@7rvTONQ3IX45dr/O6xMXu4tZ57YfDwPH7jh/M90@nZnQobuqr59fgX/vH/h6vYAZf06YAtd9356Hx/bnVT3fvah@V73yN8hwSSJwWMFNP5ybAFtzv4vRLfhv7mPmxBlDv4LP7fbD4wNTm5j3p8N@qG/htlluj4cDV6knEgD1dA2fKfGL@LqcarJGqd3FXyH4/xD5r5Cmen1D7S2gCT3ICq3w4MNaVegF0LSmylkJpGKMMAhk5w05D2TmINRWg0xRKDWgTpuQQvNGOw0k4wOFVDZkHGDMt7zAmGFFYYJCWJB63pAnwMgEPfNNfSjpYUI1jIolyDgJEudkzSgUgdBbBzKWQy3BxaVkGlImUBYhLH1ltM4knOFGfSKhbATlTVAtgyqFuSEiribm9CkjLFFwc6wlYhLNUhFdcncFyzP1FCa5VxRxZlLbPD9JIs/JCAId7ytDZeBGu5SguYtcXEcBNfPQdEHK@CwIkndgI6pxphAkKjJYK4oRFOtMIuopkinCWNmFCUpgbsI6VfyB1hQkzQLk2hySo3SgGzcutBQziOWUqZxWJk8DLTpQ0S2hDRdhkcc0jwb5AZMq5vY@bwzPLBX3HjNzRdnykx5ZQhcOHM1RUrlsJERRotil@VwFQ1J2Ns1cdWXL6MjaaAiqVLBNOi1eFqco9sbsB37guFbCRM82S5sg5RSEldbFpiRkVJKTjZRJJMt@yFYkPubJA9qWgSolLrTAcnbQsc/y5CybVOb5OlFeAI7yGK3AMsbQtkoj5VcXzef2Dw)

Unfortunately the typecasts are neccessary because the [`int_log`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/70887) feature is not yet stabilized. With the feature the code could be shortened to

```rust
|n:u64,b|n.log(b)+1
```

Answer (score 1):

### [dc](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=d-dc-command), <s>23</s> <s>20</s> 17 bytes

```
[lb/dd0<g]dsgxz1-
```

Takes input with the base in register `b` and the number at the top of the stack. The answer is at the top of the stack once the program completes.

<s>Basically, it recursively calculates the number of digits, storing the current count as the second-topmost value in the stack and the current number at the top of the stack.</s>

What I did before was pretty long, and it turns out it's shorter to just add new elements when you delete each digit of n in base b, and use the stack's size instead of a register.

Run from the command-line as follows:

```sh
dc -e '{BASE}sb{NUMBER} [lb/dd0<g]dsgxz1- p'
```

where `{BASE}` should be replaced by the base and `{NUMBER}` should be replaced by the number. Pretty self-explanatory.

#### Explanation

```
[lb/dd0<g]dsgxz1-
[        ]dsgx        # Store the text inside the [] in register g and run it
 lb/                  # Divide the current number by the base (in register b)
    dd                # Duplicate it twice, once to store the number of digits,
                      # and another for the comparison with 0
      0<g             # Run the string (function) again if it's more than zero
              z1-     # Find the size of the stack and subtract one
```

The `1-` at the end seems wasteful, but I don't know of a way to reduce it.

PS: This is my first dc program, so any feedback would be appreciated. Also, I'm not sure if [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=d-dc-command) is the best site for dc, would the [esolangs one](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Dc) be better? It has less information and wasn't as helpful for me though.

Answer (score 1):

## [ErrLess](https://sr.ht/ruan_p/Errless/), 27 bytes

```
0m:1$@;<2+]{@;/$;$!0"+0}!.M
```

### Explanation

Basically copied [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236859/91340) JS answer.

A [macro](https://man.sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/errless_docs/reference.md#-procedures-amp-macros).

Note: ErrLess doesn't support floating point numbers, so all division is integer division.

```
0m {...} M { Define a macro identified by 0 }

:            { Wrap input in a stack: ((b n)) }
1$           { Add one to the stack, before input, used later: (1 (b n)) }
@;<          { b < n? }
2+]{ {...} } { If not so, }
 @;/          { (1 (b n) b/n) }
 $;$!         { (1 b/n b) }
 0"           { Recurse (yes, I'm using `"` to call the macro...) }
 +            { Add result to the previously added one }
 0            { Add dummy value to stack }
!            { Pop top value of stack, either dummy value or unused arguments, depending on if above code executed }
.            { Halt (return), basically returns either 1 or 1+recurse(b/n, n) }
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VvpcttIkv7PpyjL3U1AIikAvGnTbY@vUYxteW3txk7THA4IFCXYIIAGQJuUxv1zHmAecV@kN7MOoHBQUh/a6VWEaaJQlfnlWVkHo116EQbdURT/fJ@8oKlzQV2yisM1uUjTKJkcH597aSeJOxfp8U/xxg4W0TGNY58mySKmq@Q4jSk9XttecOyldH289M69IF1sAs8JXXoccfJySCfakcdkQN6En@l6SWNiGZbZaHjrKIxTYsfnkR0nVD4nu0R@Tb01bTQc304S4gXRpEHgz6Urslh4gZcuFlpC/ZXO2/EPHzuundpkSprNRtb/nKa@F9By95immzhQRh0h906Sul7QiantskH6bNI25wVijFCLJN4lnbZNhaK3Yo3kITEmN5PX9BwKIM46ziZIZP6gIE/@Fl9O5mUp4ip57Nj2aaDFul7A75U1EdBzYPHC9sEOFUgosJlD/XLh@ZTEHS9JItsB/eRkrhuWxrtiR9AV9AVDtZsTAeAs3tAHeynkzIMwJfEMrJKDIHbgZm0u@GNaBsbBHe2nrWqbUUKNyraKjDF3i0IztwSEAmgc5UOcKBkFvZI2b89G0K1Do5Ro/2X7G/o8jsO4RU4Cl27Z97JWOekZ@CFEArCHT3CfBhrUj8JI81vEy30ReHuJFySpHYBy4J3vJan@QZJEXWmaRx5NicEePPBYdBRf10kYEw2f@Rut7enk4VS@rUaP30H2HpdLgcmRUfrp3wht5s1rYSVgfETVItv/Q1QIByy3VSBxPCvfTlPWPQODnlMDKEsqM19IBgRn/OsKcFDwC@IriujQLVB2NcmC6gVDxRyAE0Y7lXsd57JyZ2wQ1RW@BWX7nLQbLjaaTDVM2IW2rVJbQWON3FvBnUfQDMbuOMMdMtwWGK4WGUe3wrFFdgpTu0WWGENVRi21cSca1fRuMyMv66MTOF22yBcOEb8hyksv4vzzZEF9pHQdDSHmpSJmNnA/c2BzqQzczWvUjLTLauNT7BsKci99OpHu9MWOXVDTVUaleQmpuvlDs5W3XGHLV7VFwxZdbVljy2vR8pV9Lm3nU5X8Djv@VR36FVuu1BYdWzS15TW2rDPyzAmST160cML1mkLSjeLwvEWiFBKskCqZ4lQjHT5wAIaJ1pWvRcY22XvnwsYwQyozIMKVGoCyWBp22GOSxl6AUxh25nOtmKqgX24vGI4zkBwlm77l6QI55M5Wy1bhdSSYKc7Jh0yZVQo@wtDCALPoSVn/r3X929hfdRUNYBwBdv3bDG1LoFG0LnSoah3JQacpKzBaBBLS9E0YSP3v1e8C/NH5hBkOu8xrFC3kppiRwYGB5oQ9TDNn7gg4gkTJMpxDxT7mnVhHE2rACUNqPgcxM@a8iGGvIHrLElSqp73WFsBbZIGVVG0k6JUBOe5F5Z0TBgB8Qys@wqF37CjCSQYB6UUP01BzeU@d3FO1m0@uZWFZfaYoB0qtFrOvjhIzRpN9aLAeKcEoo5hivGfKhieAfwO9SiCY14eBzHB/lDiQeG4fCO0/WiBIEfZHwtdfHgktvuz5wwaEFPr/dUSkmwiY/uIaE4dRTQ7e8tJmy2pNLg4TpUiJjalZC9TUpnGY2ikbFEY3l971FKsDwkgWrQAW9QHEcUFg7qGQrnE9ly2VwggDIKvoPZQ2toNzqpktSU4BA/UcJwCfrQIVb56bXK54WDOuehqlVmPO6Og1WjqP7aWWAG1FTbJ9oWVNLGSk48slKWLlA3AZwEboOETof8OdZYK@woJxgotndB1MRkyLULJtgmRCXM8BjbYfYQdRoG6CQt5hjffvk/dnT57@hZy@ff7uydnJ6Zv3DWknNgCSxATqxfvkaRg4YP0A/uXrAmYIgM6DImtf7mlnuaxofVsYny8LSy@X8mUxsgo5Ywad7LkarQmdFLssyRGx9bJYWybWE9blRon8/RLd6P9VyH4N5EJ3X3a19f1k/IpID5hI72lE49uYqQrergWP42e2OlMhCrFStpXMInHcYzjehlGuvxL7QvfHrPszTFuOihsXDHypzcKUD9cbtcpIa@ieM7ovIYqyMWF0rYFzNtkLHs7YJkO6yuhlxojvCrPuN/NUSYv/asn7jPwrGpynF4X9wZI/4JaIqqnK3tnZLuI7Z6WRbbOG6yuFKwlXJaEqnFXrFOjEjM47NncUdZLt4@S62WNdOfPkHZVcWeD2TuFWZ4dreQo219mixehjtdHYE9s54XnN@G94iH6xo1@dRQvhhyG7lNvVkM1feSkEv580iqxhUmwaptXt9QfD0dheOjCfcEk2eMSQ1AuDO7AwukXMQZ2uPzT5zAAVkO2kKhW5Lnywvw4uMApF3c9mpjpW77nazt6dvHnZKFSqiaxUa9bRYt0Ao/fwnSFjh9dJDiopmZm4Ta0kZzG5A71Mx0/iXXqxtlPPaVSRHvFpxXV/o30FQrY759vrpWtj7QIxvz3a6Tgz2nV6anM9bZYpmuTOILSvgbAQEXKuxnuZ4CYjOCHtrV4Ixxqah4zm642fepG/uzOxDq8R65hPUt5nz/31BRBb7dor6nqfy3usWU4XDrc9Pt4VXooc/gONQ0SReGEgcrkYYVwjp2C6X7xvuYZDd@OHv1m8dejeKN63v7N0wHO/dB8@SOtBt9/DereQUO31C0Vt3caWqsAyMz0N15Ede0kY1GSmKdPB8x83tu@ldxZEbfNQ206nO32/NR6KyiJJSHphB3eK5OF1QB6Juo1CqorvHssjBYu02J@89IuXUHJMXoXnUP765JRV7@AUSY0Nf@LJ9fTsVpn1p5sz63d8unrz7M6S6nfXJNV/MO6n7@6M@T@uYf43xvy/75D733YVe5@mFzSuMWzKY8JLU5@Ss7tChAXd9tA0Dg@vC4szhuVP3jm5nZshVaS51W90t0gV8@3dimldL@XbTMq3t5bSqhMyT75BGoc@eeGHX2os3GH8/mz7abm2FOdmhd6XrPcLeb72MkzDQnW9v@hlJ3UzY15XwVbY7LgSxJ7pfj51u/O/iNEVY3T2JWx/sXfkfA@b6rnLbenPeOELRDKlZeM@rvetwCPcYihuw6tW/wgYplE6IVFnsUhoipe3FgsN5mcNtwDbH5UNXHCLj3JDMJcqSm8rwDwXIDPHnUtw9BskkG7/Ng4d6m5impDvyGvbicO6iUvjW0Kyb3ENB@ydm5ZxOS7c4JxlO@RKKM75/qbD13C30vqawVIZF5Gt7d8LmIZH7kCOg9Nvhe6Ab2bAU6a4Y6bhnOUet2CFKEIvYFqpdyp4FfoXuhPFpyNBQqbKCa0r99yKJwhO9QSBHfjg1t2sdN9rLa6sqaTyrSOUmF8Jwk3JdWmLaqaoLNm3V1fd0Ezk2UJO97p92crezY0sMS6N0l2/iN17KjLCfrh/D/qKcNNCQF3zmxNixwmNpYPF1yyKSMj3cUkYQG0qd7Nk2J2c1kTZ9yLKYK7KuN8vzWMRvtWci1hcIdrmJybG1jQN@BP3h5ofjCY/dW02S7NeTp2cAbRV6MOkh8d/tnPh0c804YjtNYVcb/stoZklxT4rO4F6Wzk8ZYiazc7H0AtujSw/3Krb09Mz4ArUE@KtwVdxiqEuIPQS/gFTUguwOfYGaDM0CJOCLEDexSU/rJkUOo7c8SKp/Qlk/XEDeZX4YQCJYblJFRKfKe4VMcWkYEeH4nnzeuNcKNS4OjqA7tAJN757mKMkSQgaTPByb7gC0qsVX6ekeCuVs0FBQoVakrohQIi984sUZAIl4WWzCJrCmBkF81dsr1E9CYd7AlNG0ExRF8En7KOQo6sVckclwf@gj5TpHQmBhDCT2xBrgH1FduEGFAmY0xA8mVKfrGJKi@BywYAODIjxvui9qh/fz/0YdygbyjnyZ4xE7swJOwjTEv26wOf@ojXJEWkS6WJAprjtp@NrvVlySdZP9aqiUxUg/weDfIKaznM7BDzEZAtX9IXkIkL9lpuSYL6OvJJdu6n8Y867oK5fx1@w87S6qtlTWD1V7ylU9nMFGc2sXQiclOgkteXLdnI71UDCmJczlEyUr72kbp/2Gd8RosvN@b/VveRxxgry41RcSKdxfMN1AXHUDJKvAkiyYvaN@T1@NhN5eGoDSuMdWngOA7NgwvhMCpfWsUW9Xy/v4YPscX7yvEC@Gv5eoXT8jBNg4Qgab9GEAVVPorMmF/XN7/MIzPkNdU47wquVMKuEoCRIn5hPLjCDQYqEBsy57IjNie2E5VWYHC9pHOK9fTyoYqkukQej/CJQdsUnuxc0V05Ok/w9e5qSq69c@SdvXpyykhKlhM4MPLe4cJHDRYscHi4WE0YgH6U1P6QQdlBJiQ9RNZQ7sCoyplHMFMtPP3iBmJ0INv/nn/9qFvOOqDKgPC/WGbxgZ1UGUBPU1dIi68khlHAJlTApJ@zHJJ3EpzTSOoZZHvor0TNnwt/BCIQwPS7DhMoLXlXvuM9@64Jiyd@9dJ7E5xucQt6yN/JejejYsV13YYse2kH780GLHLTbgg88XFA/mh5kz3wsqfmD@d0Lg@lBksIMukihbD3Qr@Pkck5MhIwPDfBOknCcNYj8@3FsYtg2BaMmK8LQK/CmFeiXFR/850QsrppSTTAeXVxQZP8hzUTqERxAKKdSn7XbbUic5Onps@cEUig8NtVlTMJO611wGlhsQPcPgfI6u/QO/UqFMScODgU5ks4mPatUelOgS2c9azKv@WWLz@7o11xi41QJuN@HlJB9tPfQLwj87vn7/3x1VhC4kA6l27JP0CJz77jZbP5srCfmN48fPLSO5lePHxx/8@Cbe8bBkfH1Xuf1z1fkjCapYyegN0g3fyVX5FUYRqgoLBrx2vf79z8yNFfkJRR7S@gqbxe4oEjo4BtTIN2BDid40T5gR7mE1ZAsoS5hAP@xGriJ7aeF8q/CQAwvsjAOiOiCq1C2LsHmx/dlM6/RwKoboA9vuif3xJtnMO/ijfUuK5cTlbCGC2ryd9J@9He9CiQnNiWSDT/YoLBqjaiDNa/oxKY5EMndOHkjjLTas8srNtJbtVnGxnv07x@QtzC9UPfe@@/t7xvkUjS@sMGXXN72Q2PXAOOJZfrPZn88JOYAb1J1G@bQGJMxfu81zLFBLPbdaoyGXWL1RB9jYBJryB@s0ZhYA97J7A/7pCt7md0@MfvyAYdY/KE/6hOrK170TCt/sAYjYorxQ/hiihFDI0cCi6Qh6fb5gzW2iCmQmGPAK@XodceEUR0AVTPvNBh1Sdfkg/tAxRKEzPFwRLqCndnvkpH42gUY3a4kCkrAr@PGoN/PQIwGIOhYgugNBVF4QK1lRHs9MxPIsoCbwYezEfjVNEA40KVpSqUNrVzpXZAupzUG6LJbF2Q1DWGzbn@Y2a9rGZmdBoZF@qK9N7Bygw/6IzmgD1JkzPtCgX3A0bcUUINxphDTGo/IUFAdjAY5QMvK1TAcGrkj9EDPliH0aUinQLOCF0pShpkJMRz1cv8wh4OcUh8UkPGGLlmvPsIVDyMUSYywQJ1dya7fG2TWMIfmiPSEt6AYI0HWBDNx05jwAkDlzj0eZw8DsJlkPh6bGfKelbk800emwhEGnMV7dXujzJFM08h7gZdmcYUOaWWebXGs/cYwN501HAqHsBo9dBsZLeNu7ik98A3uD/BiBLwkTXMMbiYfUJWsk9no93M3tYyu0CQMHnS7UklD8IfMFS0Ic@kD/WFu0F7PUHRh5rFjjsDPMssNwUm7mX1HRp4ARlZmxqFh5mZEsXvSpJC6LBG3z988@18)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 17 bytes

```
=LEN(BASE(A1,B1))
```

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AkqhtBc2XEHJnVUIy8LHmeh9tOO4?e=2NEISE)

Counting digits in base conversion beats using log by 1 byte

#### Log Method, 18 bytes

```
=INT(LOG(A1,B1))+1
```

Comment: I believe you can remove the trailing parentheses on the first one, and, if you change it to `1+` at the start, you can do the same on the second one.

Comment: I've seen answers where the trailing parentheses are removed from the byte count.  I choose to to leave them in since Excel puts them in after you hit enter and technichally the formula requires them to work.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 22 bytes

```php
fn($i)=>1+log(...$i)|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc3BCoJAGATg@z7FIHtQWtRVyxazTkGHIO8lIrZmEa6kt@rZbdXq9s8H809TNf1q01QNoWXcl7VJr1a85rO7upi2bev0cvuIENrJtmsR40iAI5@LkIEvUgY4DvzRQlcwiIEGC0YTLoP3N2@wZehrC342dkWg33kpMBl3Sao3S/WQeVGZ@I7nrb5g4akrsqgUbq2qM1kX6ixN2lkMxqkzGGg5pWSXZNvDPiJv9B8)

Or the super boring version :

#### [PHP](https://php.net/), 41 bytes

```php
fn($n,$b)=>strlen(base_convert($n,10,$b))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc3NioMwFAXgfZ7iIFlECP7V1gmOndVAFwPt3opYG5FhSMSEboZ5dps4bXeX73DumcZpef@YxonQoVoGxaji9BJWe2PnH6nYpTOy7bW6ydn6LE18HC4lIdRKYw0q1ASo060oONJdw4E4xma1IhEcwpO3fDWRcGQvy7y9FRtn@dPWrsjdu6wB/i1NSOM2Bz3Lrh8ZHuOdcRdC/LqK7EeNb6NVK1Wvr5JRG3IEZxtw0IFFUYRVTodT@3n8Kskfljs)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 42 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)for(;$a-gt$b;$i++){$a/=$b}$i+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVVdaxtBDHy2f8URlmKTdbvSfhMMgdK@NiSPpZSze25aHM49O7Tg@re7Wjexpb23FSvN7Gik2/S/u2H72K3Xs2U/dEe1mu@Pm3Zonyaq1WoxXfXD5Ea1s@87tbhRP66vp3vVvpurxYEOcDyMx7eTcUOfvp2Az1FD0HZ6jkSTddbuEshGY9Z4DqRoNTqeYgJojCyCiRICywEfvbYiCazX4EWklEEW8clrtPyKA6wiGJIGXjjSCXiVaKoHgDFE1rMIZtTAHwCZXi10cTZrqwMDhionJCIGrKovGBwGckzacm7grU78bMtbrMAltXW@oHgvuadAOmbB3cWCyyKlZRLXOZAqIRIPw@qeqmgwTDZqKYDoWMTKCpZ0q5AysRVZlqQEwy1mfZSes2iko4JB7fkNF7AybvBJFPGkiqTrSws9o@@xflDIUn7AnHTkwCGF6oWIld4xmsrajhpPT2JtNSevc1PSJAogA1KUmFzlfYihwvGktGRLGTLJl0fzSCo68SpIXbWCm3dBugUiJO34OBRZEkcGMlSRl10p4yJ3QM4yEsrW4ORyBimCQ7kjTurLJqay05AlWZfkzACYKqkMrlhYZTJRLgAqydwTK7thjMXnlxKuDIfYO9lWo@DI98U8jDsRE7CQacBEpHSU2F987qvJRWNLQ1nVYK1oTiSby5lE2r3C1T5WdnTO1MpDtYog0YRJt0WaWystmky1nxNK/0UDlf@KtE4Ykn5SeFqc0@Zv87EfPrTLx9mnxc9uuWv249HpT6hV92dDge5bM2/UV4oO3fZ5vaPTG7VqVNuoxXj0@e7h/fN21z/9z/7S3FL@6OF5uey225J4LjLrfjUvJejGXfnldjv6F9Olq1OxKwrfv0JcvaJNzhWmdOEwPhDjbT/sZv0LXeL29hXvcPwH)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 65 bytes, using `math`

```go
import."math"
func f(n,b float64)int{return int(Log(n)/Log(b)+1)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZhNblMxEMcllllxhKirRBjw57Mt1AV7FlwhrZq2osmropRNxUnYVEgcgqPAaRjPvEoez6xa__Sv7RnP1-vPX7fzy5_H3fW33e3N-rC7P67uD4_z6fzhYn84X_x-Ou_fl7-fX9lhd767WO2fjtfr_eZortb7h3l3nuL2_nh-Pt2cn07HNfy6-TLfbo7bj-3H1fad2_6gjf69fYN_287ZbJ9X33en9dz-YDWvL2FHl2o2btp-Wn89AX04vhITzGzC5eW8fVVmW03thQhMBF3sddUaz3QIjAed73QlB-NjpyMgz7WTMz73GxIRSl_glN4UAuJkl3IyITKbkcizXUjGpV5JRFG2O3mmRCKUqSTjQyckIHeMznPhQqTST8U4Zg8RoczAXH9JAlJnhzckID1pLTwD8w8RofTVG9c_IgFpS4Vo4fFIRChjqKb3Dq7NBKqJ-cYNBy9E7DcV8KzrhASEJalZ15tMQPqm5mICiwgi0uYUTGHRCGupCu1BWTwQUTwDicQ8A2vI1NnU3t6U-NMRkHk6QcD3sUBAebmYuWMWIpUt07lniCg5EB0P2IXI3PfgMdvHFwJhDV6pk-HaOAsyZ1lkQ-FwjkU2EiXzs-eFbCHKC0Ikc7uJKHZXeAh2OhFlTwh7Z9meSGRdDinz-o1A0Xk71FsiMmOsNyyA2lruFyc_ZDQRacuUCr8hArFjguhjT0NAySteIXANN5xNYu-X_PDSRLQaX4cMJKJU5FoMLzoNSN9MZRoigoiyox-zi4is3dnylkVAiTGoRp5FDhFZT-zQ2ggo3QAmB96oG5BWWzdEIgKhyyXyBkhAy8Bp7NJIlIiAFGI3RKC8CxzDey8RZccWKzzKkAhlaUHaX5KArGRQPFhIEFCmmDgNtZGIMrm5YliBQiB7ZYu9MgZjkd5xUFv5qNNASxmooo7t2BotO5qI8oa1Dkoisuq0ia53OAGhq9WxIMO1jLHoeWwT0POPVwkiSndr8zPvbkjE2SEW3oEJyJd2djybiDi7jSt9pcW1sh8MGEy3EGWS8CxwcC0qaB7Kdlarts-ZtzQC4naxNc9-OwLKfBXGHklEWgF9jjU0AnLHAl7lfiGizDrQ3rmSiMzmwI_GtcFE6TtaGqYXAnKKtoHXEALSkikMIyUCGf3QvpgLCWhfGG7oU0Tk103mLQDXykwQ7fC1REQ52Q1j6kKU14P2zms2Ee1L1g97ElGqe7FjjUUiu27xQ9dFoHxZDY4kIK1pycFrdgNKF4CPcM-_HpB0Jy__Cnh5oZ__AQ)

## [Go](https://go.dev), 69 bytes, using `strconv`

```go
import."strconv"
func f(n int64,b int)int{return len(FormatInt(n,b))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZhLahwxEIYhy1nlCINXM6AEvR8ELxPILlcYG48x9nSbSdsbk5NkYwI5RI6SnCYlVRtUqloYo4_fkqpUr_bPX7fz65_Hw_X94fZmezrcTZu70-N8Xj5eHE_Lxe-n5fgh__38xr4v5-t5er7YHJ-m6-1xN23vpiV6dVV_7-Hn5XyzPJ2n7cPNtPsyn0-H5eu07CZ1td__wM3-vX_X_rietdu_bJ4P5-1c_3wzby9hSxNKUibuP22_nYE-TG9EOTUrd3k579-USRdVemEDyoPO97qilSW6BpQFne10OTllfadDwM_V0Sib-g2RMKXNcEpvCgJ2sgkpKOeJzY3ws40LyoReiURQ1jtZomyEKUMOyrpOiIDv6I2lwpVwpY1ZGWIPEqZMwEx_SQRcp4c3RMA9qTU8A_EPEqa0xSrTPyICbkuBaKHxiIQpvSuq905bqwiqSHxjhoNXwvaLGTxrOiECZkmo1vUmI-C-KSkrRyICCbc5OJVJNMKaq1x9UBIPSATPQCIRz8AaMnVWpbc3BPp0CHieRgj4PhYQCC_nE3XMSriyZjr1DBIhB7yhAbsSnvsWPKb7-GqAWdOu1MnaWhkNMqNJZEPhMIZEdiNC5idLC9lKhBeESKZ2IxHsLvAQ5HQkwp4Q9kaTPRvhddmFROt3A4LO6qHeIuEZo60iAVTXfD8f7ZDRSLgtMWR6wwbYjgGijzwNAiGvaIVoa7jhrAJ5v2CHl0Yi1fgyZCASoSKXrGjRqYD7JuY4RAQSYUc7ZhcSXruTpi0LgRBjUI0siRwkvJ7oobUhELoBTA60UVfArdZmiMQGmC5lTxsgAikD49ilGxEiAlKI3LAB4V3gGNp7kQg71lihUdYIU-YapP0lEfBKBsWDhAQCYYrxcaiNSITJzWRFClQDvFfW2MtjMGbuHQO1lY46FdSUgSpqyI610ZKjkQhvWMqgRMKrTp3oeocjYLpSDAmytuYx5i2NbQRy_tEqgUTobnV-pt2tEXa285l2YAT8pY0ez0bCzq7jSl9p21rYDwYMoluJMElYEjhtzSpoGsp2Equ2TYm2NATsdr42z347BMJ85cYeiYRbAX2ONDQEfMcMXqV-QSLMOtDeqRIJz2ZHj25r1RKl72hhmF4Q8ClaO1pDEHBLohtGygZ49EP7Ii5EIH1hmKFPIeFfN4m2gLYWZgKvh68lJMLJZhhTVyK8HrR3WrORSF-ydtgTiVDdsx5rbCO862Y7dN0GhC-rwZEIuDU1OWjNrkDoAvARbunXQyPdyeu_Al5f8fd_)

<s>nice</s> wow builtins

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 6 bytes

```
{#y\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pWroypqOXiSos2NDAwt1YwNo1V0FfQtVMwAgoZWRpZKxiaxypAhIxBqiwtDYBiZrEIIRNjS6A+oCKIkBkAVRUSdw==)

Simple. Convert function argument `x` into base `y` with `\`, then get the length with `#`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Core Maude](http://maude.cs.illinois.edu/w/index.php/The_Maude_System), 107 bytes

```
mod B is pr NAT . op f : Nat Nat -> Nat . vars N B : NzNat . eq f(N,B)= s f(N
quo B,B). eq f(0,B)= 0 . endm
```

The answer is obtained by reducing the `f` function with \$n\$ and \$b\$.

#### Example Session

```
             \||||||||||||||||||/
           --- Welcome to Maude ---
             /||||||||||||||||||\
         Maude 3.1 built: Oct 12 2020 20:12:31
         Copyright 1997-2020 SRI International
           Thu Nov  4 21:22:07 2021
Maude> mod B is pr NAT . op f : Nat Nat -> Nat . vars N B : NzNat . eq f(N,B)= s f(N
> quo B,B). eq f(0,B)= 0 . endm
Maude> red f(1597, 16) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1709, 9) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(190, 29) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(873, 24) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1061, 27) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(289, 26) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(1575, 34) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1135, 15) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1161, 22) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(585, 23) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1412, 23) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1268, 14) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(714, 12) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(700, 29) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(1007, 35) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(292, 17) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1990, 16) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(439, 3) .  --- Expected: 6
result NzNat: 6
Maude> red f(1212, 17) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(683, 31) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(535, 25) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(1978, 32) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(153, 8) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1314, 33) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(433, 2) .  --- Expected: 9
result NzNat: 9
Maude> red f(655, 35) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(865, 19) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1947, 25) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1873, 32) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1441, 12) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(228, 30) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(947, 2) .  --- Expected: 10
result NzNat: 10
Maude> red f(1026, 11) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1172, 24) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1390, 32) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1495, 21) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1339, 10) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(1357, 9) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(1320, 27) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(602, 5) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(1462, 16) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1658, 9) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(519, 11) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(159, 3) .  --- Expected: 5
result NzNat: 5
Maude> red f(1152, 11) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1169, 33) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1298, 7) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(1686, 32) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1227, 25) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(770, 15) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1478, 20) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(401, 22) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(1097, 7) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(1017, 9) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(784, 23) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1176, 15) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1521, 7) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(1623, 23) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1552, 13) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(819, 15) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(272, 32) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(1546, 12) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1718, 4) .  --- Expected: 6
result NzNat: 6
Maude> red f(1686, 8) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(1128, 2) .  --- Expected: 11
result NzNat: 11
Maude> red f(1617, 34) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1199, 34) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(626, 23) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(991, 9) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(742, 22) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1227, 11) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1897, 12) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(348, 35) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(1107, 11) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(31, 26) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(1153, 26) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(432, 4) .  --- Expected: 5
result NzNat: 5
Maude> red f(758, 9) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(277, 21) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(472, 29) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(1935, 21) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(457, 27) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(1807, 26) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1924, 26) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(23, 27) .  --- Expected: 1
result NzNat: 1
Maude> red f(558, 30) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(203, 15) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(1633, 8) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(769, 21) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1261, 32) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(577, 7) .  --- Expected: 4
result NzNat: 4
Maude> red f(1440, 22) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1215, 35) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(1859, 23) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1702, 35) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(1580, 12) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(782, 15) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
Maude> red f(701, 32) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(177, 24) .  --- Expected: 2
result NzNat: 2
Maude> red f(1509, 28) .  --- Expected: 3
result NzNat: 3
```

#### Ungolfed

```
mod B is
    pr NAT .
    op f : Nat Nat -> Nat .
    vars N B : NzNat .
    eq f(N, B) = s f(N quo B, B) .
    eq f(0, B) = 0 .
endm
```

Maude *does* have logarithms, but only for floats and only the natural logarithm. To get the number of digits we'd need to compute \$\mathrm{ceiling}(\log(n) / \log(b))\$, which actually winds up being a few bytes longer than just doing repeated division.

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 1.5 bytes (3 nibbles)

```
,`@
```

Boring but at least short.
Input is base, then integer.

```
,       # length of
`@      # digits in given base
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 10 bytes

```
+:to_s|:+@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWq7StSvLji2ustB0gAnsKFNyiow0NzY10jExiY7mgXCMLHaPYWIiSBQsgNAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `L`, 1 byte

```
B
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

Built-in for "convert to base". The `L` flag takes the length.