# Replace 0s In a String With Their Consecutive Counts

Tags: code-golf, string, counting

## Challenge

Given a string of any length which contains only digits from `0` to `9`, replace each consecutive run of the digit `0` with its length.

### Test Cases

1. `1234500362000440` → `1234523623441`
2. `123450036200044` → `123452362344`
3. `000000000000` → `12`
4. `0123456789` → `1123456789`
5. `1234567890` → `1234567891`
6. `123456789` → `123456789`
7. `010203004050` → `11121324151`

### Note

The shortest answer in bytes wins as per [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules

Comment: What is a run of \$10\$ `0`s replaced with? `11`?

Comment: Not OP, but I think it will be replaced with `10` as no modifications to the output were also needed, as most answers suggest

Answer (score 14):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 6 bytes

```
0+
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fQJtLRU/t/39DI2MTUwMDYzMjAwMDExMDLjQBLgMkwGUAljUzt7DkgrMMEEygvIGRgTFQn4GpAQA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Unary to decimal conversion.

Comment: That `&` is neat! What does it do?

Comment: @LuisMendo It refers to the entire match, like `$0` does in Perl.

Comment: @LuisMendo Actually my original source was wrong; PCRE, PHP and Java use `$0` but Perl actually uses `$&`, as does JavaScript. (Retina actually supports both.)

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript, 31 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/0+/g,x=>x.length)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHhDkAgEADg16khJ/Evz6LlCrtVKzNvf77vdq9rvl7lGVI@kIPlZremKhZyHsUI3Rj7z26fIkzxOSX7nFomVJSjCGKf9GwWgHnVAGAM7FLyDw)

Answer (score 10):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 7 bytes

-1 byte by jezza_99 / DLosc

```
aR+X0#_
```

Wow pip is really good at regex

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJhUmAwK2AjXyIsIiIsIjEyMzQ1MDAzNjIwMDA0NDAiLCIiXQ==)

```
aR+X0#_
aR+X0     Replace all occurrences of (regexified zero with a +)
     #_   with it's length
```

Comment: @DLosc might have another method, but I got [this 7-byter](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJhUitYMCNfIiwiIiwiMTIzNDUwMDM2MjAwMDQ0MCIsIiJd)

Answer (score 9):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
r+iT Èl
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=citpVCDIbA&input=IjEyMzQ1MDAzNjIwMDA0NDAi)

```
r+iT Èl     :Implicit input of string
r           :Replace
 +i         :  "+" prepended with
   T        :    0, giving the RegEx /0+/g
     È      :  Pass each match through a function
      l     :    Length
```

Answer (score 8):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 5 bytes

```apl
0+
⍵L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/99Am@tR71af//8NjYxNTA0MjM2MDAwMTEwMuNAEuAyQAJcBWNbM3MKSC84yQDCB8gZGBsZAfQamBgA)

`0+` Replace any runs of zeros

`⍵L` with the match Length

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 7 bytes

```
ĠṠƛ0cßL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwixKDhuaDGmzBjw59MIiwiIiwiXCIwMDExMTFcIiJd)

### Explained

```
ĠṠƛ0cßL
Ġ       # Group on consecutive items
 Ṡ      # join each into a single string
  ƛ     # To each group:
   0c   #   if it contains 0:
     ßL #     push the length of the string
        # the s flag joins into a single string
```

An alternate 8 byter that uses regex match replacement

```
‛0+$⁽Løṙ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigJswKyTigb1Mw7jhuZkiLCIiLCJcIjEwMDAwMDAwMVwiIl0=)

### Explained

```
‛0+$⁽Løṙ
‛0+       # The string "0+"
   $      # pushed under the input
    ⁽L    # a function object that returns the length of its argument
      øṙ  # replace instances of runs of 0 with their length
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>91</s> 90 bytes

```python
lambda x:''.join(l>"0"and l or f'{len([*g])}'for l,g in groupby(x))
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcuxDsIgFIXh3ae46QI0xlxLdTDRF1EHmhbEAJcgJm2Mz46MOnjG/8uJS75RkEUfL8UpP4wK5gNjmzvZwN2pwUaFERxQAs1ebgr83JqreDNdi1sbsAFMomccFj4LsdKJPNg8pUzkHmB9pJTbEpMNmWvOtp3sd4hy3yFi3yOrn3/4Y/i1CuUD)

*-1 byte thanks to The Thonnu*

I use the `itertools` module's `groupby` function to group consecutively.

Comment: You can replace the `!=` with `>` to save a byte: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcuxDsIgFIXh3ae46QI0xlxLdTDRF1EHmhbEAJcgJm2Mz46MOnjG/8uJS75RkEUfL8UpP4wK5gNjmzvZwN2pwUaFERxQAs1ebgr83JqreDNdi1sbsAFMomccFj4LsdKJPNg8pUzkHmB9pJTbEpMNmWvOtp3sd4hy3yFi3yOrn3/4Y/i1CuUD "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @TheThonnu Thanks!

Comment: As this is a recursive lambda, you'll need to include the `f=` in your byte count.

Comment: @Shaggy This isn't a recursive lambda, I am not calling the function within it.

Answer (score 6):

## ><>, 55 bytes

```
i:'0'= ?v>:0(?;o
='0':i<1<\n$v?
      \+1~  /
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiaTonMCc9ID92PjowKD87b1xuPScwJzppPDE8XFxuJHY/XG4gICAgICBcXCsxfiAgL1xuICAgICAgICAgIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIxMDAxIiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJtb2RlIjoibnVtYmVycyJ9)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
0ÃηRāR:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4HDzue1BRxqDrP7/NzQyNjE1MDA2MzIwMDAxMQAA)

- -6 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

##### Explanation

```
0ÃηRāR:   # Implicit input
0Ã        # List intersection with [0]
  ηR      # Reversed prefixes
    āR    # Reversed length range
      :   # Infinite replacement
```

Previous 13 byte answer

```
.γ}εD0.åig}}J   # Implicit input
.γ}             # Group by consecutive items
   ε       }    # For each group:
    D           #  Duplicate the group
     0.åi }     #  If 0 is in the group:
         g      #   Push its length
            J   # Join everything into a single string
```

Comment: `.γ}` can be `γ`; `0.å` can be `_` and `}}` can be `]` for 8 bytes: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OZzW13iM9Njvf7/NzQyNjE1MDA2MzIwMDAxMQAA). Although `0ÃηRāR:` is 1 byte shorter: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4HDzue1BRxqDrP7/NzQyNjE1MDA2MzIwMDAxMQAA).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>64</s> <s>58</s> 57 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to [@Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)*.

```
\(x){regmatches(x,t)=Map(attr,t<-gregexpr("0+",x),"m")
x}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ddBLCsIwFAVQnLqKEAdJMMLLp7aCXYI7cFKkrROx1BQC4kqcVMFF6WqMTf23bxLCPQk3OZ7K-pzFl8pkk-g6W1LL9mWabxKzWqc7arlh8SIpaGJMyc18krswtUVJMYwxt4zjDWZDe_AX3AZhRomQSgcAaioBQGsgbIS2lSkqg2LkU-lCpbUgw39PUK9vOHwMQW5-uEfNsWkYzRryi97pq8BjB534mYpv3Noe3LYACco9CoKuqq6GUFKLQBD_f3Xt1zs)

`R` has some weird string manipulation functions...

Comment: Can't you swap the ```<-``` for simply ```=``` in the 2-liner to save a byte?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen, well, to my surprise, I can. Thanks! I thought that `...<-` functions need the actual `<-`, but after a while of thought `[<-` works well with `=`, so why not other functions like that?

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 18 bytes

```
{S:g[0+]=$/.chars}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OtgqPdpAO9ZWRV8vOSOxqLj2f3FipYKSSryCrZ1CdZqCSnytkkJafpGCjaGRsYmpgYGxmZGBgYGJiYECmoCCARJQMADLmplbWCrAWQYIJlDewMjAGKjPwNTA7j8A)

Comment: still annoyed this can't be `.=chars`

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 16 bytes

```perl
s/0+/length$&/eg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdAv@F@sbaOvnpOall2SoqOmnpv//b2BoYGRgbGBgYmBqAAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vim](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 28 bytes

`:s/0\+/\=len(submatch(0))/g`
<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/36pY3yBGWz/GNic1T6O4NCk3sSQ5Q8NAU1M/nev/f0MjYxNTAwNjMyMDAwMTEwMkAAA)

We cannot use `0*` because it matches the empty string between digits.

Comment: Here's a [TIO link](https://tio.run/##K/v/36pY3yBGWz/GNic1T6O4NCk3sSQ5Q8NAU1M/nev/f0MjYxNTAwNjMyMDAwMTEwMkAAA) for you. The `%` isn't necessary because the input "contains only digits from 0 to 9" and therefore contains no newlines. However, if your language is Vim and not V, I think you have to count the Enter keypress after the replace command (otherwise, the replacement doesn't happen), so that makes it 28 bytes. If you want to call it V instead of Vim, you can skip the newline and claim 27 bytes.

Comment: Thanks @DLosc, edited.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 8 bytes

```
(0+)
$.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fw0Bbk0tFz/D/fwNDAyMDYwMDEwNTAwA)

#### How it works

Match runs of zeros (`0+`), capture each match in a group (`( )`), replace it with the length of the most recent capture (`$.1`).

Comment: Oh, I see you had already posted your answer while I was writing mine. Sorry to outgolf you like that.

Comment: @Neil No problem at all, and great answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 28 bytes

```
0i:"0"=?v{:?n}ol?!
~1+00.  >
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yDTSslAyda@rNrKPq82P8dekavOUNvAQE9Bwe7/f0MjYxNTAwNjMyMDAwMTEwMA)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 70 bytes

```c
n;f(char*a){*a-48?n=!printf(n?"%d":"%c",n?:*a++),*a&&f(a):f(a+!!++n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcnBCsIwDADQb2lgI2k2iFsV6ZB@S4hUdzCM4W347VUv7/JsfJi15ktFe@oelY6oY7oWv4VtX/1d0Qt0d8jQGQxeclRmGqL2fUWl/INDYHZaPu2lqyMdFeE0zeksMl8mEUlJ4N9f)

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 62 bytes by c--

```c
n;f(int*a){*a-48?n=!printf(n?"%d":a++,n),*a&&f(a):f(a+!!++n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/POk0jM69EK1GzWitR18TCPs9WsaAIKJKmkWevpJqiZJWora2Tp6mjlaimlqaRqGkFJLQVFbW18zSta//nJmbmaWhWp2n4KBkaGZuYGhgYmxkZGBiYmBgogeQB)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 16 bytes

```ruby
gsub /0+/,&:size
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6BUuyCpaUlaboWG9KLS5MU9A209XXUrIozq1IhwlDZBXsNjYxNTA0MjM2MDAwMTEwMuAwMDYwMjIFsA1MDiCIA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>62</s> 57 bytes

```python
lambda n:re.sub("0+",lambda s:str(len(s[0])),n)
import re
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3LXMSc5NSEhXyrIpS9YpLkzSUDLSVdKCCxVbFJUUaOal5GsXRBrGamjp5mlyZuQX5RSUKRakQA24x8hYUZeaVaKRpqBsaGZuYGhgYmxkZGBiYmBioa9raQgSNgGLGJiaG6ppcuFRjKEZWa4AEoApRpMH6zMwtLCGSSFw0-0CCSO4CcTEdhTAImzkGhgZGBsZAJxuYQk0C2mdobGRiaAo0ChIqCxZAaAA)

-5 bytes thanks to @xnor

Regex solution, port of [@mathcat's Pip answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/255826/110555)

Comment: I think you can do `s[0]` in place of `s.group()`

Answer (score 3):

## Excel VBA, <s>100</s> 77 bytes

<sup>Saved 23 bytes thanks to a translation by [Taylor Raine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255822/replace-0s-in-a-string-with-their-consecutive-counts/255867?noredirect=1#comment572654_255867)</sup>

```vb
For i=2^15-1To 1Step-1:[B1]=i:[A1]=[Substitute(A1,Rept(0,B1),B1)]:Next:[B1]="
```

Input is in the cell `A1` of the active sheet. Output is in the same cell. The code is run from the immediate window in VBA. The only clever bit is that Excel only allows 32,767 characters in a cell and counting down from there is less bytes than counting down from the length of the input.

Comment: You could make this into an immediate window function something like `For i=2^15-1To 1Step-1:[B1]=i:[A1]=[Substitute(A1,Rept(0,B1),B1)]:Next:[B1]="` for a pretty significant drop in bytes. (Also reminder that using `^` with no leading space makes this a 32-bit only solution as `^` is the `Longlong` type literal in 64-bit installs of excel)

Answer (score 3):

## Bash - <s>181</s> 158 chars

*Edit 1: I used [this trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25802/116162) for the `for` loop, remove whitespace, condence an `if` statement*

```bash
n=0;for ((i=0;i<${#1};i++));{ c="${1:$i:1}";if [ $c = '0' ]; then ((n++)); else [ $n -ne 0 ] && { echo -n $n;n=0;};echo -n $c;fi;};[ $n -ne 0 ] && echo -n $n
```

### Explanation

```bash
# a counter of how far into a sequence of zeros we are
# this is zero if we're not in a 'zero-sequence'
n=0

# iterate over all the characters
# $1 is the first function argument ($0 would be the script name)
for (( i=0; i<${#1}; i++ )); do
    # get the current char
    c="${1:$i:1}"

    # if it is a zero, then increment the counter
    if [ $c = '0' ]; then
        ((n++));
    # if it is NOT a zero
    else
        # if a zero sequence is over (given that the counter is
        # not equal to zero and the current char isn't zero)
        if [ $n -ne 0 ]; then
            # print the number of zeros in the sequence,
            # and reset the counter to zero
            echo -n $n;
            n=0;
        fi;
    echo -n $c;
    fi
done
# check if there was a zero sequence terminating the string,
# as we wouldn't otherwise check as there wouldn't be a non-zero
# char initiating the check
if [ $n -ne 0 ]; then echo -n $n; fi
```

I referred to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10552175/20827475) for how to iterate over a string in Bash and [this AU answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/385532/1659062) for a short way to increment a variable

Comment: Hi there, welcome to CodeGolf! There are many more optimisations to be made, [here's an example for 81 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZYzLCoMwFET3fkWgIeQSCjeJ2tZH@y1tMJhNFLWr4LenUWgROquZw2Fez7mPlkPI3n7uFuKIj3aYOK@dEA0NJ7nWAIGYlgZZubOsEuDcNPLhhQDY@h0BGBsn5xdLqKeGMd/Wa/YjsTP9kEBmiVQ6LxB1qRAxz/EfJYKHbHM3ysv19rW3jsexW6hQpwcsMH4A) based on your code.

Comment: PS: Here are some [tips for golfing in Bash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash). Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 25 bytes

```
{,/$(.'x)|#'x:(&~=':x)_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxtkN1OgzAYhs97Fc1chCV2LQXmhHjkLXi2LI7UAs0QJu20y3SHXoCX6JVYfuRnjqN+7/f0LXni4HiDp/bc0rOPK0sH9vXp3gr07El/AqCC43R1OJVBDCHU4abYhvYmjkQW6vAQlrN1xawmDnU9nxB3QQkhnkcmYRNRk7ie50zWF6gzqGHI4KuBNq7Jxe3yrgr7oe+txu7danDOlsPdXymhxDW/Qvz6pul1XOo5fnUVAAxSpXYywJgVzzwpsnguVcS2XLM0yhM+Z8ULft1zqUSRS0x9f0kpLvkuixhHRCKRowhJVYo8Qe9CpUilXJSIGZqzvRJv3Jz3uZIAPJoW+BBJbs7GNDwXCn++vuFI6SXsH1VDQ6Ut0eSdjibtxr66ltq31lrH2/Gy7e21ts2dWAB+AUx2mz8=)

- `x:(&~=':x)_x` split the input where it changes, and reassign to `x`
- `(.'x)|#'x` take the maximum of the chunk of input (converted to its corresponding integer) and its count
- `,/$` convert to strings and flatten (and implicitly return)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 27 bytes

```julia
!x=replace(x,r"0+"=>length)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9fa4MwFMXf8ymuMoiybtz80W4D@7ZPMcaINesyQioawYd@dxfr7Cptd8lDOOf8Lud@d9Yo1g9D1BeNrq3a6qRfNTHex8XGarfzX@nwuW/AgHHQaFVZ43SbpATCfKx@n5o/JRTQ1tb4xEwRFQT1xl@0qx7Y@1EaM@VSqhvjvHWJKjaRmsAokCEHh8PJjV/7Wm@9ruCujFMS@IE9QuuDvQs7KeNCZogi54goJVLYd77u/MnjwRJSMkr4PxyFGxwl4hzDs6Fj5QVGiVyEj4vy9dPzFF2E/zySXRQbdbwCzV64Jr8Kzcw1iJL1sh1yFOF4zC5PCfWY4JJljP4A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Œgċ”0ȯƊ€
```

A full program that accepts a string of digit characters and prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opPQj3Y8a5hqcWH@s61HTmv///6sbGhmbmBoYGJsZGcCBiYk6AA)**

#### How?

```
Œgċ”0ȯƊ€ - Main Link: list of characters, S
Œg       - group runs
       € - for each group:
      Ɗ  -   last three links as a monad - f(group):
   ”0    -     literal '0' character
  ċ      -     count occurrences
     ȯ   -     logical OR (group)
         - implicit, smashing print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
ṁ?IosLig
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f/DnY32nvnFPpnp////j1YyNDI2MTUwMDYzMjAwMDExUNJBFwKKGCABEBeswszcwhKmGsQ2QOaAVRkYGRgDTTAwNVCKBQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 42 bytes

```factor
[ R/ 0+/ [ length >dec ] re-replace-with ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDdSsNAEIXv8xRjbzXJmKTVRCj0RilILyxelRLiZrIpJLvrZkoVEXwIn9AXidv4QxDP3XyccxhOVQjWtr9fL1c3GViS9GSgo8c9KUEdtAXXgSlsRxaMJeZnY3eK4QqWqwykbipvcbtcrDOYlyRA7dsHsvOOnUkCnMD1UA8YpCl8vL27ZoKa2XRZGJZadEE1GIQuKdBWhkIrJsXhQdvSz3PJee56z0ZvBDW3jffigdPkPIqTKWI8ixAxSXDyL/6mONIPGpyzi8t0nDze@Bf8JjDC2LXi1Fle@w3chYCnIWygISW5/hpi66b0LZmmEOQfdg5v@7YwEPSf)

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/) `--extendedglob`, 24 bytes

```zsh
<<<${1//(#m)0##/$#MATCH}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWpJfUKKQWlGSmpeSmpKek5/ElaahWf3fxsZGpdpQX19DOVfTQFlZX0XZ1zHE2aP2fy0XV5qCoZGxiamBgbGZkYGBgYmJAaYQUMQACYC4YBVm5haWMNUgtgEyB6zKwMjAGGiCganBfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
ḅ{ị0&lṫ|}ᵐc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO1uqHu7sN1HIe7lxdU/tw64Tk//@VDI2MTUwNDIzNjAwMDExMDOBA6X8EAA)

#### Explanation

I was hoping for some automatic number -> string conversion, but no dice.

```
ḅ{ị0&lṫ|}ᵐc
ḅ            Break the input string into blocks of identical characters
 {      }ᵐ   Map this predicate to each block:
  ị            Convert to integer
   0           Assert that the result is zero
    &l         If so, get the length of the block
      ṫ        and convert to string
       |       If that failed (because the number wasn't zero), return the block unchanged
          c  Concatenate the results together into a single string
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 88 bytes

```java
s->java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("0+").matcher(s).replaceAll(r->r.group().length()+"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BTsMwDIbP9CminBJNjbK141KoxAMgkCZOiEPI0i4lTSLHnaimPXsJbBLigm/2/9n@BnVU5bD/WOwYAyAZci8mtE50k9dogxcvXsH8FA0oDNAUcXp3VhPtVErkUVlPTgXJlVBhnv@h73YI1vct6e6XVLa/x8H05lM8K0QDXugwRusMo3JFuRgV6oMBlnjGolPaPDjHoGxB9BCmyLhwxvd4YHxFKV@an/dXravFMdg9GbMcuxi8vhEFfeKn4mY3JzSjCBOKmCN0nnVCxehmRtebqt5KWd1upJR1LSnnzf8bci03ssqw3F7ob5dzcV6@AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>23</s> 18 bytes

```
\&l:?n&o]
\i:'0'-?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P0Ytx8o@Ty0/lism00rdQF3X/v9/QyNjE1MDA2MzIwMDAxMTAwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>110</s> <s>96</s> <s>94</s> 86 bytes

```php
try{for(;;)if(!~~$c=fgetc(STDIN))$x++;else{echo$x?:"",$c;$x=0;}}finally{echo$x?$x:"";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkS4oqq9PyizSsrTUz0zQU6@pUkm3T0lNLkjWCQ1w8/TQ1VSq0ta1Tc4pTq1OTM/JVKuytlJR0VJKtVSpsDaxra9My8xJzciphkioVQGnr2v//DY2MTUwNDIzNjAwMDExMTICkAQA)

Takes input via STDIN, outputs via STDOUT.

Comment: if the string ends in 0s, it just removes them: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxCsIwFEX/pTxoQkGebXRJHy4uLi66SwmJKRQa8jIESr89Rl0O3MPlBB/KeAmVwOTeNrF4PK@3u9SQCTVEahrt1mgn4wWn@OKwzEkAy4nByNkJMEQttnKD3HV6twvb7atzNfFAkP@l/TdMPRi/QtSlHPtBnRCHc4@ISuEH "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: here's 59 based on what you curerntly have though, to give you a good base: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKytNTPTNBTr6lSSbdPSU0uSNYJDXDz9NDVVKrS1rVNzilOrU5Mz8lUq7K2UlHRUkq1VKmwNrGv//zc0MjYxNTAwNjMyMDAwMTEBAA "PHP – Try It Online")

Comment: no it doesn't fix it, i just golfed your current code down. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKytNTPTNBTr6lSSbdPSU0uSNYJDXDz9NDVVKrS1rVNzilOrU5Mz8lUq7K2UlHRUkq1VKmwNrGv//zc0MjYxNTAwNjMyMDAwMTEBkgYA "PHP – Try It Online") that should end in a 3

Comment: @Steffan fixed, thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Java 19, 156 <s>161</s> <s>162</s> bytes

```java
interface A{static void main(String[] a){var i=0;var s="";for(var c:a[0].toCharArray())if(c==48)i++;else{s+=i>0?i+""+c:c;i=0;}System.out.print(i>0?s+i:s);}}
```

### Without Java's golfing tax, 113 bytes

```java
var i=0;var s="";for(var c:a[0].toCharArray())if(c==48)i++;else{s+=i>0?i+""+c:c;i=0;}System.out.print(i>0?s+i:s);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzRCoIwFEB/Zfi0IclNLcJhIX2Cj@LDZc26pi7mEkT89pXU04Fz4LQ44a69Pb2nwWnboNKsWEaHjhSbDN1YjzTw0lka7lXNUCwTWkY5yI0mL@fR6T4ybycbYxnfrMqwgjpy5vpAW1iLMxeCGq7yPD0JCkOpu1EvJnp9r47TGS4UBkGoMiXktl7/qRt@MQsCIdfVe7@Pk/QAkBxjAEhT@AA)

Edit: replaced `'0'` with `48` as suggested in the comments. Thanks!

Edit: String concatentation is shorter than doing `var o=System.out;`

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 86 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
R	I ARB . L SPAN(0) . X REM . I	:F(O)
	O =O L SIZE(X)	:(R)
O	OUTPUT =O I
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NTwdbTLyA0hCsIyHQMclLQU/BRCA5w9NMw0ASyIxSCXH2BtCenlZuGvyYXp7@CrT9IhWeUq0aEJqeVRpAmlz@nf2gI0AyQlCeXq5/L//8GhgZGBsYGBiYGpgaGAA)

```
	I =INPUT				;* read input
R	I 					;* Match in I:
	  ARB . L				;*	ARBitrary characters (save as Left part of string) up to
		  SPAN(0) . X			;*	1 or more 0s (save as X)
			      REM . I		;*	REMaining characters (save as I)
					:F(O)	;* On no match, goto O
	O =O L SIZE(X)	:(R)			;* Append L and # of 0s to O and goto R
O	OUTPUT =O I				;* Output O and any remaining characters of I that didn't match
END
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
⭆⪪⁻⪫⪪ＳＩ⁰_0_×_²_∨№ι0ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc3BCsIwEATQXyk57UKFterJY08KRaHeQyiiCzEJycbfX1PqaYbHwCxvl5fovOo9cxCYpcVrcgnm5Flg4lALXCOHP1xCqrKtAPtudEWAsDVjyZqWD/48Cxhr@m7YfNVbhjHWdsBNaBVGxLMq7WmgA9GRTqS7r/8B) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
     Ｓ                  Input string
    ⪪                   Split on
       ⁰                Literal integer `0`
      Ｉ                 Cast to string
   ⪫                    Join with
        _0_             Literal string `_0_`
  ⁻                     Remove matching substrings
            _           Literal string `_`
           ×            Repeated
             ²          Twice
 ⪪                      Split on
              _         Literal string `_`
⭆                       Map over pieces and join
                №       Count of
                  0     Literal string `0`
                 ι      In current piece
               ∨        Logical Or
                   ι    Current piece
```

String separators are only needed between consecutive strings so the code has been tweaked to avoid them to reduce the byte count. `⭆Ｓ∨Ｉι_0_` also works instead of `⪫⪪ＳＩ⁰_0_` for the same byte count.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dart (2.18.4)](https://dart.dev/), 63 bytes

```dart
r(s)=>s.replaceAllMapped(RegExp('0+'),(m)=>'${m.end-m.start}');
```

```dart
String replaceZerosWithTheirConsecutiveCounts(String src) {
  return src.replaceAllMapped(
    RegExp('0+'),
    (Match match) => '${match.end - match.start}',
  );
}
```

- [Try it online](https://tio.run/##fY/dCoIwGIbPu4odBNuo5NuPVoRBBx120h2MNkJQG1MiEK/dppGYVjt8eN733aeVK5vGkYLG@yJwxqbqYg5pelLWGk3O5np8WIJhgemSZF7C8yoLTK5XWVCUPlxjumvut0SjTCU5oaiaIWRdkpfEEcy4kCGAiDgASAmYojhGL8w9FVIyX/An8iUxCsDg9fbY6fLRerN9GwMwnW/5x19bwH6ZY3GyDRyEvwXCvtPPM8ElC7vSunkC).
- [Full source](https://github.com/alexrintt/algorithms/tree/master/codegolf/replace-0s-in-a-string-with-their-consecutive-counts/dart-2.18).

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 16 bytes

```
'0+'":@#rxapply]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8EuJT0F9TQFWysFdQUdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrsUHdQFtdycpBuagisaAgpzIWInxztiZXanJGvkKagrqhkbGJqYGBsZmRgYGBiYmBOi4ZhIQBEkASBas3M7ewRDMCJIRuLKoyA0MDIwNjoCUGpgbqECcuWAChAQ)

Fairly simple regex solution:

```
'0+' ":@#rxapply ]
'0+'     rxapply ]    apply to all relevant patterns in the input
        #             length
     ":@              casted to string
```

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 47 bytes

```
' '-.~[:,(1,2~:/\'0'&=)([`(":@#)@.('0'&e.));.1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8EuJT0F9TQFWysFdQUdBQMFKyDW1VNwDvJxW1pakqZrcVNfXUFdV68u2kpHw1DHqM5KP0bdQF3NVlMjOkFDycpBWdNBTwMkkqqnqWmtZxgL1TZbkys1OSNfIU1B3dDI2MTUwMDYzMjAwMDExEAdlwxCwgAJIImC1ZuZW1iiGQESQjcWVZmBoYGRgTHQEgNTA3WIExcsgNAA)

Horrendously long non-regex solution. This is the only way I could really think of approaching this, since, afaik, J doesn't have a builtin for grouping according to a boolean matrix or similar.

Comment: +1 for rxapply.  re: non-regex, yeah, J performs badly here, I got a 40: ``[:;]<`(<@":@#)@.('0'&e.);.1~1,2~:/\'0'&=``

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) `--extglob`, 57 bytes

```bash
j=$1;for w in ${1//[1-9]/ };{ j=${j/+(0)/${#w}};}
echo $j
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzdCoIwHMXv9xR/aBdKyM7mtER6kugiQ7MhLZpgMPbsS4VA6Fydjx@nubo@ut6@RsoctZ/xPtiGdUnqozlxWXf2TRM9nsS9FOIss@oiKNSe5tUbsU@QCu53Uwh1YO2tt8RNDIx1JFWuCyAvFQCt8V/NDTZa4kqUh2P1oxePbVgpKOTzAwrELw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
sm`|vedhdr8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzg3oaYsNSUjpcji/391A0MDIwNjAwMTA1MDOFAHAA)

#### Explanation

```
sm`|vedhdr8Q    # implicitly add Q to the end
                # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
         r8Q    # length encode Q
s               # concatenate together
 m              # map over lambda d
  `             # convert to string
   |            # short circuiting or
    ved         # evaluate the second element of d
       hd       # or take the first element of d
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua 68 bytes

```
s=io.read("*a")for i=#s,1,-1 do s=s:gsub(("0"):rep(i),i)end print(s)
```

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQu6yfjWIstT66jaGEIBpLz7/eqzOavVraQCydNceEdD3fvBFkha32mEDzmNoWZgYiMtudD4eIP52IhCA/)

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ0NPT0/TKr24NElDyUBbSScnPzFFqSi1pLQoTxkopaSpqfn//39DI2MTUwMDYzMjAwMDExMDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)), <s>120</s> 119 bytes

```python
def f(s):
    c=0;r=''
    for d in s:
        if d=='0':c+=1
        else:r+=f'{c if c!=0 else""}'+d;c=0
    return r+f'{c if c!=0 else""}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxNDoIwEAXgdTnFyKaQuhgoIEJ6mv5EElPIgAtjPHstRg1RZzffvHnTdTmNXrYThWCsA5fNeZcwrbAnxXnC3EhgYPAwR2aDA6MUR95poYoI9jzbjoRy/KYhXvVOIayYpncuTB@LEkZ2uZAHEn9TYaLBL5nLeFHKqkaUTYmIVYU838MvvxQ386Znsjm0x@3nuuM3fD6wRBlbsY6RPDwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 55 bytes

```arturo
$=>[chunk&=>[&]|map'g->(`0`=g\0)?->size g->join g|join]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?9OBLqW)

```
$=>[                   ; a function, assign input to &
    chunk&=>[&]        ; split input into blocks of equal, contiguous chars
    |                  ; then
    map'g->            ; map over each block and assign current elt to g
        (`0`=g\0)?     ; is the first element of g the character `0`?
        ->size g       ; then map g to the length of g
        ->join g       ; otherwise, map g to its joined string
    |                  ; then
    join               ; join the block of strings and numbers to a string
]                      ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 94 bytes

```powershell
$r='';$_|sls '0+|[1-9]+'-a|% m*|%{$v=$_.value;('$r+=$v','$r+=$_.length')[$v-match"0+"]|iex};$r
```

**Ungolfed**

```powershell
$args|%{
    
    # empty string to append to
    $r=''
    
    # '0+|[1-9]+' will match full string but split by zeroes and non-zeroes
    $_ | sls '0+|[1-9]+' -a | % m*| %{
        
        # value is the matched string 
        $v=$_.value

        # true = 1; false = 0; shorter than an if statement
        # iex will execute the command in quotes
        ('$r+=$v','$r+=$_.length')[$v-match"0+"] | iex
    }
    
    # prints the results
    $r
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYztCoJAFERfReTKrTbl@lkiPomISCwZrBW7tgWtz76pEUjza@ZwmPvtyaXquBAWWnlWxntbkCViAY1RQjlIzFShn9cM/dZ4Tr@bFNAlNIFuxYMXGwTJStC4/5YmEPx6HjrcVqD9vh1OnUvMrc2Fv8YCpB2txTCKk5QoziIiShJC5x9NhFaZ52Jkh2P@s@dO67FYFFE8PVBK@AE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>7</s> 6 bytes (12 nibbles)

```
+.`=$$?`r$@,
```

```
  `=$           # chunk the input by
     $          # itself,
 .              # now map over each chunk:
      ?         #   if
       `r$      #   its value as an integer is nonzero
          @     #     return itself
                #   otherwise
           ,    #     return its length
+               # finally, join it all together
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Mathematica (13.1)](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) 54 bytes

```
StringReplace[string,x:"0"..:>ToString@StringLength@x]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 76 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
r s=concat[case t!!0 of '0'->show$length t;_->t|t<-group s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYvNCoJAGEX3PcWnCK6Mm38VpauWvUFEDGY6pDPDzBduevdJWlR0V4d7OL1w93YYvJej0ZbpIFgsj9LxwpKrGq0awadGuJY4CED6RjHipHa9nqKhVR33xLtLUvOT90ln9cOQO/tRSFUZKxVHozBko0nbqwtXaZYXQFamAPIc9HcQfkZ423K92dKH8MXZI0U2dygQ@hc)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 71 bytes

Solution without using regexp

```javascript
s=>s.split(0).map(c=>c?(a?a:"")+(a=1,c):(++a,""),a=0).join``+(--a?a:"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDZDoIwEEXf/YqGpzYsThdcSKq/QlOrwSAllhj/HquiElnmsXPOzZ2e1U05fS3qJq7swbRH2Tq5c4mry6LBQJKLqrGWO73Haq@yICAhVpJGmmQ4DFXkHyIlPXe2RZXnIY7jjmu1rZwtTVLaEz7igDIuUgC@YgAgBASEIISWS2TutdGNOaAMvRjmES4EXcwHvP2ZgH8fetPJI/7AekWu1pvtzxlYX2a083MBM/aHoZN2X56yh8WBAfc/Ben0ub455UzQlLYP)