# Shortest way to convert the result of a test to a string output (e.g. true or false) in bash

Tags: tips, bash

I'm trying to shorten a bash solution to a Code Golf challenge, which requires an output of `true` or `false`. I've managed to condense the key piece of the code down to a substring check, to determine if the provided argument, `$1`, is a substring of a particular hard-coded fixed string, of the form:

```
[[ FIXEDSTRING = *$1* ]]&&echo true||echo false

# And a minor improvement to shave a character on the test:
[[ FIXEDSTRING =~ $1 ]]&&echo true||echo false
```

**My question is, is there some clever way to shorten this, either in general, or for the specific case of converting success to `true` and failure to `false`?**

In a language like Python, I'd use:

```python
# Shortest solution without imports I know of
str(sys.argv[1]in"FIXEDSTRING").lower()  # Also feels a little long, kinda
                                         # curious if there is a better way

# Shorter when json is already imported for some other purpose, saves a character (more if
# json aliased or dumps denamespaced via from json import*):
json.dumps(sys.argv[1]in"FIXEDSTRING")
```

for the specific case of "success is `true`, failure is `false`", and one of:

```python
# When string lengths close enough for stepped slicing to work, only 3 characters longer
# than the true/false specific solution
"ftarlusee"[sys.argv[1]in"FIXEDSTRING"::2]

# When string lengths aren't compatible for stepped slicing, 
("false","true")[sys.argv[1]in"FIXEDSTRING"]
```

when I need to select between arbitrary strings, not just `true`/`false`.

But AFAICT:

1. `bash` has no concept of converting from success/failure to a specific string (without relying on `if`/`then`/`fi`,`case`/`esac` or `&&`/`||` and manually running `echo` with a literal string for each string option)
2. `bash` arrays can't be used "anonymously", and the array indexing and slicing syntax is so verbose you can't save any characters this way (e.g. `a=(true false);[[ FIXEDSTRING = *$1* ]];echo ${a[$?]}` is six characters longer than my current approach; useful if I needed to convert exit status to true/false in multiple places, but not for a one-off use)
3. Stepped slicing of a string isn't a thing.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a slightly shorter method in pure Bash. It doesn't beat the `expr` based method, but it doesn't use any utils.

```bash
false
[[ FIXEDSTRING =~ $1 ]]&&true
echo $_
```

Comment: Nice! Splits the difference between my naive solution and the `expr` one (this one is three character shorter, `expr` is six characters shorter), and as you say, is pure Bash so it definitely works on any setup, even weirdly limited ones without access to coreutils. I'd read [the tip to use `$_`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237192/70305), but hadn't realized how it could help here. Limited to the `true`/`false` case for direct use, but combined with `:` you could make it handle any string for two characters more apiece (though if you need it for both, the naive solution wins again).

Comment: I see that this works, but am curious why `true; echo $_` eg returns true?  we invoked `true` with no arguments, after all...

Comment: @Jonah: `$_` is the last argument to the prior command. `argv`-style, the name of the program is the first argument (it's `$0` for `bash` too), so if you give it no arguments, then the program name itself is also the last argument.

Answer (score 5):

This one is the **same size** as the `expr` method while still being **pure Bash**. It takes advantage of `$_` and the fact that `true`/`false` are builtins that simply returns the status you would expect.

```bash
FIXEDSTRING
${_/*$1*}true||false
echo $_
```

###### Explanation:

- "FIXEDSTRING" gets stored into `$_` by attempting to execute it with no args.
- If $1 is a substring of "FIXEDSTRING", then it will be removed in the pattern replacement and allows Bash to execute the `true` builtin.
- Otherwise, the pattern replacement will result in no change to "FIXEDSTRING" if it's not a substring, thus executing `FIXEDSTRINGtrue`, which is not a valid command and fails through to executing `false`. Thus putting either "true" or "false" into `$_` based on the pattern replacement result.
- `$_` is then echoed out.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice tip!

Comment: Nice. Sadly won't work for my specific Code Golf evaluator (it checks *all* text output, including the `stderr` output you'd get for running the non-existent `FIXEDSTRING` command and the weird prefixed version of `true`), but it's likely helpful to other Code Golf evaluation setups. Up-voted!

Answer (score 3):

I found one way to improve on this using [the `expr` command](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expr.1.html); not `bash` itself, but at least a GNU coreutil so it exists pretty universally (and more importantly, on the Code Golf test bed):

```
expr true \& FIXEDSTRING : .*$1 \| false
```

`FIXEDSTRING : .*$1` is a regex pattern match; it's implicitly anchored with a leading `^`, thus the need for the `.*` in front of `$1` (probably would need to be `.\*$1` if there was a possibility of a file with a name matching the pattern). `true \&` will evaluate to the string `true` if the pattern match succeeds, and `0` otherwise, which, when paired with `\| false`, will replace all cases where it evaluated to `0` with the string `false`. Shaves off seven characters from my original approach (and six characters relative to the slightly shorter version I updated the question with, using `=~` to avoid a pair of `*`s).

If anyone can come close to that with pure `bash`, or beat it using near-universally available tools like `expr`, let me know; I'll happily accept such an answer.

Comment: This seems to return true for any subsring of FIXEDSTRING. eg, `set FIXED; expr true \& FIXEDSTRING : .*$1 \| false` returns true.

Comment: @Jonah: Yes, that's the goal. The original test is a substring test, the `expr` one is too.

Comment: Ah. It's never actually stated in the question. Even though I could have figured it out if I'd read the python examples, the actual goal should probably be stated up front.

Comment: @Jonah: I said it in the first paragraph, but I admittedly wasn't clear on which *direction* the substring checking was going (checking for `$1` in `FIXEDSTRING` or `FIXEDSTRING` in `$1`). I've edited to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option that abuses the filesystem for 41 bytes:

```bash
echo true>FIXEDSTRING
dd<*$1*||echo false
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8GCpaUlaboWNzVTkzPyFUqKSlPt3DwjXF2CQ4I8_dy5UlJstFQMtWpqwNJpiTnFqRANUH0ropVAqpVioXwA)

This requires that your fixed string is not empty, `.`, `..`, nor contains `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a `sed`-based solution that beats `expr` significantly. Obviously not a `bash` built-in, but it's using solely portable `sed` features AFAICT so it should be near universally available:

```bash
sed "/$1/ctrue
cfalse"<<<FIXEDSTRING
```

`/$1/ctrue` selects "lines" (there's only one line) which match the regex from `$1`, and `ctrue` short-circuits for that line, emitting `true` and discarding the line. If it wasn't short-circuited, `cfalse` with no selector handles everything else by echoing `false` and discarding the line.

Shaves four characters off the `expr` solution: Ignoring length of the fixed string, which appears once in each, it's 25 characters, vs. 29 for `expr`. It also has similar flexibility (it's not just `true` or `false`, you can use *mostly* arbitrary string outputs).