# Sum the means of the two integers

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory

There are quite a few means in mathematics, such as the arithmetic mean, the geometric mean, and many others...

### Definitions and Task

Note that these are the definitions for *two positive integers**:

- The **root mean square** is the square root of the sum of their squares halved ([image]).
- The **arithmetic mean** is their sum, halved ([image]).
- The **geometric mean** is the square root of their product ([image]).
- The **harmonic mean** is **2** divided by the sum of their inverses ([image] = [image]).

Given two integers **a** and **b**  such that **a, b ∈ [1, +∞)**, sum the means mentioned above of **a** and **b**. Your answers must be accurate to at least 3 decimal places, but you do not have to worry about rounding or floating-point precision errors.

## Test Cases

```
a, b -> Output

7, 6 -> 25.961481565148972
10, 10 -> 40
23, 1 -> 34.99131878607909
2, 4 -> 11.657371451581236
345, 192 -> 1051.7606599443843
```

You can see the correct results for more test cases using **[this program](https://tio.run/##Zcwxr4IwFAXgvb/ixqlFIlJ00MTBSWdXdbjVaklsS0oZ/PV4gfdCxOmk53y31Tsa74q2NbCDF1p1R8BUbSVkwPMMYQ55pgTD75njXAkikj2nQ0JDksBizcJkoi2R9KGi6I//YGsJli7y0lVN5EIwNy2Y1ehqas@G29SJ9DkEDhH6uDJWhe5sdvI@QneynaV91ufiKv7XfSijsTqWt4mRozloTyL8kHwkRwzWux@xHMXFnXTdvCLwurHgHxCNHpToPJV8eIm2WK1ZvpEf)**. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest valid submissions that follows the standard rules wins.

<sub>* There are many other means, but for the purposes of this challenge we'll use the ones mentioned in the "Definitions" section.</sub>

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37217/8478)

Comment: Must've asked to output the mean of means. -1 (not).

Comment: At least there is no Mathematica builtin for that. Right?

Comment: @NieDzejkob I don't think so :-)

Comment: @NieDzejkob Although I suspect there are builtins for each one of the means.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It's not the same

Comment: Can we take inputs as `7.0, 6.0`?

Comment: @icrieverytim yes, you can.

Answer (score 13):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 48 bytes

```hs
a%b=sum[((a**p+b**p)/2)**(1/p)|p<-[2,1,-1,1e-9]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcRLCoAgEADQq7hoQG2kZvoR1EnEhUFQVCJ9dt3deou3@Gub9z0lD9N4PYeV0msd8@lPFay0llRE9cbBWEZCQ0iz6Z1Lh1@DGEU813CLTNgOWqQSqESugJChxqpugHp26QM)

This uses the fact that the root-square, arithmetic, harmonic, and geometric means are all special cases of the [generalized mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) `((a**p+b**p)/2)**(1/p)` for `p=2,1,-1,0`. The geometric mean uses the limit `p->0+`, approximated as `p=1e-9` which suffices for precision.

Answer (score 9):

## [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/), 37 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Martin Ender. -6 bytes thanks to Jenny_mathy and function reusability thanks to JungHwan Min.*

```
(t=1##)^.5+(2(s=+##/2)^2-t)^.5+s+t/s&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxNCsMgEEb3OcWAUBRtjZOf0oXgEXqCgJSEZpEuOrMTz26Mq@/xeHxH5O96RN4/sWzgoUj2Tgi1PCYtUZLXQlhUC965OdJs6VZ4Jaaap/Q0MGcDyfUGXH8RDpUaGBivHcapmhfm3HXv//5jsAHkBiEEaEeqnA)

## [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/), 55 bytes

```
RootMeanSquare@#+Mean@#+GeometricMean@#+HarmonicMean@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@z8oP7/ENzUxL7iwNLEo1UFZG8QBUu6p@bmpJUWZyVC@R2JRbn4ejKv2vyS1uKRYwVahutpcT0fBTK9WR6Ha0ADIBBIgtpExiA1hAlkmYJaxiSlI1NJIr7aWiyugKDOvREHfQSENRIAN/A8A)

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I am pretty sure the chain of built-ins is way more verbose than applying the formulas (for some).

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Oh maybe but I thought it'd be more fun to ridicule Mathematica's built-ins! Anyways, here you go, a much less readable golfy version. :3

Comment: An alternative: `((#^2+#2^2)/2)^.5+(#+#2)/2+(#1#2)^.5+2#*#2/(#+#2)&`

Comment: 2 bytes off: `((#^2+#2^2)/2)^.5+(+##)/2+(1##)^.5+2/(1/#+1/#2)&`

Comment: @MartinEnder Does... Does Mathematica turn prefix when you want it to? Oh wait, it changes the head of the list or something..? Thanks! (Also, do you happen to know if I can remove the `N@` from the second solution?)

Comment: I've explained how those `##` tricks work [in this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45188/8478). And no you can't remove the `N@` unless the OP allows exact symbolic solutions, or lets you take the input as a floating-point type.

Comment: 42 bytes:  `(((s=+##)^2-2##)/2)^.5+s/2+(1##)^.5+2##/s&`

Comment: 37 bytes:  `(2(s=+##/2)^2-t)^.5+s+(t=1##)^.5+t/s&`

Comment: A slight fix to @Jenny_mathy's version (same byte count): `(t=1##)^.5+(2(s=+##/2)^2-t)^.5+s+t/s&`. Just to make it easier to reuse the function (without having to run `Clear@t` before each iteration).

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 57 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:(a+b+(a*a+b*b<<1)**.5)/2+(a*b)**.5+2*a*b/(a+b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8lKI1E7SVsjUQtIaSXZ2BhqamnpmWrqG4HEksAcbSMtIFMfpFDzf0FRZl6JRpoGiMzMKygt0dDU1EHmaGr@NzYx5TK0NAIA)

Comment: The `<<1` is going to incorrectly truncate to an integer when `a` and `b` are opposite parities.

Comment: @xnor No it's not :) You're thinking of `>>1`.

Comment: Oh, my mistake! I see now there's a `/2` outside that this is compensating for. Nice trick.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 52 bytes

```r
function(a,b,m=(a+b)/2,p=a*b)m+p^.5+(m^2*2-p)^.5+p/m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jUSdJJ9dWI1E7SVPfSKfANlErSTNXuyBOz1RbIzfOSMtIt0ATxCnQz/2fpmGuY6b5HwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>44</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```matlab
@(n)(q=mean(n))+rms(n)+(z=prod(n))^.5+z/q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/V@UW2zroJGnWVxYVKJRXJqrkacXZ6Spn5Oal16SARTXtOZKs9XT0/sPUqRRaJubmpgHEtYGagTS2hpVtgVF@SkgoTg9U@0q/cL/aRrR5jpmsZr/AQ)

Note that TIO does not have the signal package installed, so I defined `rms()` in the header. On [Octave Online](http://octave-online.net/), you can try it if you `pkg load nan`. I'm not sure if there are any online interpreters that load it by default, but most systems would have this package loaded by default.

Thanks to Tom Carpenter for spotting a small mistake of 2 bytes.

This defines an anonymous function, taking the input as a vector `n=[a,b]`. We then use inline assignment to reduce the calculation of the HM to just `z/q`.

Comment: You don't need to include the `f=` in the code, so that makes it 42 bytes. (which of course leads to the "crossed out 44 looks like 44") - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/V@UW2zroJGnWVxYVKJRXJqrkacXZ6Spn5Oal16SARTXtOZKs9XT0/sPUqRRaJubmpgHEtYGagTS2mB9VbYFRfkpYOEq/cL/aRrR5jpmsZr/AQ "Octave – Try It Online")

Comment: Oh oops, that's an artifact from copying it from Octave-Online! Thanks.

Comment: TIO loads installed packages by default, it just doesn't have the Signal package installed

Comment: @LuisMendo Exactly, I think te de facto standard of MATLAB and Octave is to assume that all packages are installed and loaded.

Comment: `^.5` [saves a byte](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/V@UW2zroJGnWVxYVKJRXJqrkacXZ6Spn5Oal16SARTXtOZKs9XT0/sPUqRRaJubmpgHEtYGagTS2hpVtgVF@SkgoTg9U@0q/cL/aRrR5jpmsZr/AQ) over `sqrt`. Also, remove `f=` from the code part in the link

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 48 bytes

```hs
a?b|s<-a+b,p<-a*b=s/2+sqrt(s^2/2-p)+sqrt p+2*p/s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcdBCoNADADAr@RY3ci60VoKlbzAF4iVLAiVqqTGY/@@LZ6GeYm9p2VJSTh@7VGIi6h/8tiaJ2ef/bjYkzwVmp0DdZSrt7TKvEELq2g3gu7zdkB/4wZDyaFEqjggcY1VfeVwpyH9AA)

#### Explanation:

`s/2 = (a+b)/2`: The arithmetic mean.

`sqrt(s^2/2-p) = sqrt((a^2+2*a*b+b^2)/2-a*b) = sqrt((a^2+b^2)/2)`: The root mean square.

`sqrt p = sqrt(a*b)`. The geometric mean.

`2*p/s = 2*a*b/(a+b)`. The harmonic mean.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
²Æm,P½S
PḤ÷S+Ç+Æm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QpsNtuToBh/YGcwU83LHk8PZg7cPt2kCx////R5vrKJjFAgA)

Comment: Nice combination of links. The best I could do in one line is `PḤ÷S,µ³²Æm,P½,µÆmFS` (19 bytes) - I though it's worth mentioning, maybe it's a source of inspiration. **EDIT:** >_> I now realise I can just use `+` instead of `,`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I had an 18-byte version at first (not in revision history) but then thought to put the ones subject to `½` together, and it saved a byte.

Comment: Another possible source of inspiration: `PḤ÷S` can be replaced by: `İSHİ`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder thought of that too

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>21</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
UYmGphX^GYmGpy/vs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzQy170gIyLOHURX6pcV//8fbaZgHgsA)

-3 bytes thanks to Luis Mendo.

#### Explanation

```
UYm               % Mean of squares, 
                  % Stack: { (a^2+b^2)/2 }
   Gp             % Product of input, a*b
                  % Stack: { (a^2+b^2)/2, a*b }
     hX^          % Concatenate into array, take square root of each element.
                  % Stack: { [RMS, HM] } 
        GYm       % Arithmetic mean of input.
                  % Stack: { [RMS,GM], AM }
           Gpy    % Product of input, duplicate AM from below.
                  % Stack: { [RMS,GM], AM, a*b, AM
              /   % Divide to get HM
                  % Stack { [RMS,GM], AM, HM}
               vs % Concatenate all to get [RMS,GM,AM,HM], sum.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Erik the Outgolfer

```
nO;t¹O;¹Pt2¹zO/O
```

Explanation:

```
nO;t                Root mean square
n                    Raise [a, b] to [a ** 2, b ** 2]
 O                   Sum
  ;                  Half
   t                 Square root
    ¹O;             Arithmetic mean
    ¹                Retrieve stored [a, b]
     O               Sum
      ;              Half
       ¹Pt          Geometric mean
       ¹             Retrieve stored [a, b]
        P            Product
         t           Square root
          2¹zO/     Harmonic mean
           ¹         Retrieved stored [a, b]
            z        Vectorised inverse to [1 / a, 1 / b]
             O       Sum
          2   /      Get 2 divided by the sum
               O    Sum of all elements in stack
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOsQyvz/K1LDq3ztz60LqDE6NC6Kn99////zbnMAA)

Comment: `nO;t¹O;¹Pt2¹zO/O`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I don't think that works.

Comment: Take input as a list `[a, b]`.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Of course! Why didn't I think of that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 19 bytes

```
ṁëȯ√½ṁ□o½Σo√Π§/ΣoDΠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxsOrT6x/1DHr0F4g@9G0hfmH9p5bnA8UOLfg0HJ9INPl3IL///9Hm@uYxQIA)

-1 thanks to [H.PWiz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71256/h-pwiz).

Comment: `ö√½Σm□` can be `ȯ√½ṁ□`

Comment: @H.PWiz >_> I knew I'd forget something

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOxsOrT6x/1DHr0F4g@9G0hfmH9p5bnA8UOLfgxHqXGKBgzP///6PNdcxiAQ)

Comment: @H.PWiz still learning! :p

Comment: you can change `o½Σ`    →  `Y`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 16 bytes

```
²Σ½¬³Π¬³Σ½D³Πs/Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//9Cmc4sP7T205tDmcwvAJJDnAuIU659b/P9/tLmOglksAA)

### Explanation

```
square sum halve sqrt input product sqrt input sum halve dupe input product swap div sum
```

...if Ohm had a verbose mode of sorts. :P

```
²Σ½¬³Π¬³Σ½D³Πs/Σ

                  implicit input       [[7, 6]]
²Σ½¬              root mean square
²                  square              [[49, 36]]
 Σ                 sum                 [85]
  ½                halve               [42.5]
   ¬               square root         [6.519]
    ³Π¬           geometric mean
    ³              push first input    [6.519, [7, 6]]
     Π             product             [6.519, 42]
      ¬            square root         [6.519, 6.481]
       ³Σ½        arithmetic mean
       ³           push first input    [6.519, 6.481, [7, 6]]
        Σ          sum                 [6.519, 6.481, 13]
         ½         halve               [6.519, 6.481, 6.500]
          D³Πs/   harmonic mean
          D        duplicate           [6.519, 6.481, 6.500, 6.500]
           ³       push first input    [6.519, 6.481, 6.500, 6.500, [7, 6]]
            Π      product             [6.519, 6.481, 6.500, 6.500, 42]
             s     swap                [6.519, 6.481, 6.500, 42, 6.500]
              /    divide              [6.519, 6.481, 6.500, 6.461]
               Σ  sum                  [25.961]
                  implicit output      [25.961]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I added a built-in for arithmetic mean a little while ago, but it wouldn't save you any bytes here.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
√(sum(Ans2)/2)+mean(Ans)+2prod(Ans)/sum(Ans)+√(prod(Ans
```

-2 bytes from [Scrooble](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73884/scrooble)

Takes a list of two numbers in `Ans`, and implicitly returns the sum of the four means; e.g. run with `{7,6}:prgmNAME` to get `25.96148157`.

Explanation:

`√(sum(Ans2)/2)`: 8 bytes: root mean square

`mean(Ans)`: <s>5</s> 3 bytes: arithmetic mean (old: `sum(Ans)/2`)

`2prod(Ans)/sum(Ans)`: 8 bytes: harmonic mean

`√(prod(Ans`: 3 bytes: geometric mean

+3 bytes for 3 `+`es

Comment: I think you have an extra unmatched closing parenthesis here after the 2 in `sum(Ans)/2)`.

Comment: @kamoroso94 Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Save two bytes with the `mean(` builtin.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
+:A½.².²+½√..*:√;«a/¹∑
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=KyUzQUElQkQuJUIyLiVCMislQkQldTIyMUEuLiolM0EldTIyMUElM0IlQUJhLyVCOSV1MjIxMQ__,inputs=MzQ1JTBBMTky)

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 44 bytes

```apl
{+/(2×o÷k),(.5×k←⍺+⍵),.5*⍨(o←⍺×⍵),.5×+/⍺⍵*2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqbX0No8PT8w9vz9bU0dAzPTw9Gyj6qHeX9qPerZo6eqZaj3pXaORDxA5Phwoenq6tD@QDeVpGtf//myukKZhxGRoAKUMDLiNjEM1lBCRNuIxNTEE8SyMA)

Dyadic dfns with `a` on the left and `b` on the right.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 76 bytes

+13 bytes for `using System;`

```cs
a=>b=>Math.Sqrt((a*a+b*b)/2)+(a+b)/2+Math.Sqrt(a*b)+2/(1/a+1/b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY4/D4IwFMT3fgrGlioNDDogXUicZGJwfv0TbYIt0mJiCJ8dm0B0cXr37nfJnfR76Qa9jN7YW9K@fdCPEvWj6IxMZAfeJ/WEfIAQ/xVn59HKk3Ixo3d/rPVw3lcLVFxUvIFwz9rnEDCGFKhIBWEFoTjKKOgPQyS0YDhnQHMmyPJdsg14OaOSBozFBE1bde2sd53OroMJ@mKsxj0@KoIPipASzWhePg)

Comment: You can save a byte by `using System;` and removing both `System.`. PS: If you want a less boring way (with the exact same byte-count of 76): [`using System;a=>b=>(a+b+Math.Sqrt(a*a+b*b<<1))/2+Math.Sqrt(a*b)+2d*a*b/(a+b)`](https://tio.run/##XY49D4IwFEX3/oo3tqAQGXTgYzFx0sSEwbktVZpgi/RhQgi/HWvEQaebk/dO7pVuLW2n5t5pc4NycKjuKQDEMZx5h2CvgLUCMaDyj71BQtpeNFqCbLhzsB@JQ46eP2506I3MtMHVP1fWe6oo2nzmeSHygvJQhCeOdVQ@OqQ88ByILNswFic/B8HCpAp8xm@Hzel3w1L9tLqCE9eGMjIuvXtrnG1UdOk0qqM2irZ0x@iWsZRMZJpf). ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```julia
a$b=(x=a+b)/2+((a^2+b^2)/2)^.5+(y=a*b)^.5+2*y/x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcdBCoAgEADAe@/Yw6qQuWXRwa8I680QiSiw11sEUbeZ5UiRx1oZgsPiWAWhSSGyJxU83RG@tQpPxzI8JHnqUtct5j1lHGESzRvTgem@Ug/mNxi@9IMFM5OoFw)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 47 bytes

```
a=>b=>(c=a+b)/2+(c*c/2-(d=a*b))**.5+d**.5+2*d/c
```

quite trivial

```js
f =

a=>b=>(c=a+b)/2+(c*c/2-(d=a*b))**.5+d**.5+2*d/c
```

```html
<div oninput="r.value = f(+a.value)(+b.value)">
<p><label>a = <input id="a" type="number" step="any" value="1" /></label></p>
<p><label>b = <input id="b" type="number" step="any" value="1" /></label></p>
</div>
<p>result = <output id="r">4</output></label></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), <s>49</s> 45 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder*

```lua
((a^2+b^2)/2)^.5+(a+b)/2+(a*b)^.5+2*a*b/(a+b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/19DIzHOSDspzkhT30gzTs9UWyNROwnIBtJaSWABIy0gSx8s/P//f/P/ZgA)

Comment: **[45 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/19DIzHOSDspzkhT30gzTs9UWyNROwnIBtJaSWABIy0gSx8s/P//f/P/ZgA)**

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 63 bytes

```java
a->b->Math.sqrt((a*a+b*b)/2)+(a+b)/2+Math.sqrt(a*b)+2/(1/a+1/b)
```

Takes both parameters as `Double` and outputs as `Double`.
[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jY8xT8MwEIX3/gqPdk0ckhYQKmRCbJ06IoazE8DBtU19qVRV/e3hClEzNrfck973Tu9a2EMWYuPb@rs3DlJia7D@OGMsIaA1rCVCdWid@ui8QRu8eh3E00votGtuJjH/u6qYYc89ZJXOqjXgl0o/O@Qc5iD1XIu8FJKTJCFHG8iRZc6LHGSRa9GvqN95aEU6SzWHtvtga7alD/gGd9Z/vr0zEMc/enNI2GxV6FBFstB5bhTE6A78oRaDuq@FWF3Di9sLf5bXA@ViDEziL/hyCr5Y3o33H8shcpqd@l8)

Or (also **63 bytes**):

```java
a->b->(a+b+Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b<<1))/2+Math.sqrt(a*b)+2d*a*b/(a+b)
```

Takes both parameters as `Integer` and outputs as `Double`.
[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jY8/T8MwEMX3fgqPdkLcNv2DUEMmhMTQqSNiODumOLi2G18qVVU/e3AhFDE1t9w73e@e3tVwgMx5Zevqs5MGQiBr0PY0IiQgoJakjgRvURv@3lqJ2ln@3IvixaLaquZuGPTkWmFUWRJJHjvISpGVFFKRrgE/eNg3SCGJcyKKYsrYOP@3ECzNqyT28eWGdauY8FKx@Wgbg/Z5D05XZBd/oBtstN2@vhFgp296cwyodty1yH1cobFUcvDeHOk968WSsdUteDphf@o2ns@u@BD6F54PgGfzxdX7If85OI/O3Rc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 58 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:((a*a+b*b)/2)**.5+(a+b)/2+(a*b)**.5+2*a*b/(a+b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tck7CoAwDIDh3VM4tmmJGl8oeBOXFCkKvhAXT1@DIDqE5P@yX@e4rRR814eZFzdwzNa1SjGwceB0QhoAS6MkJWQLPkIgZ/J42I9pPWOvarQV6ujNLEUr8wHlAv9GW/wyL0r5N4Q63A)

Takes input as floats

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 15 bytes

```
æßπ√+ßΣßπτ/+ßµ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8///wssPzzzc86pilfXj@ucUg9vkWfSD70Fbt//@jjU1MdRQMLY1iAQ)

Yay Actually has a built-in for Root Square Mean!

```
æßπ√+ßΣßπτ/+ßµ+  ~ Full program.

æ                ~ Arithmetic mean.
 ßπ√             ~ Product, Square root (computes geometric mean).
    +            ~ Addition.
     ßΣ          ~ Push the sum of the input.
       ßπτ       ~ Push the product of the input doubled.
          /      ~ Divide.
           +     ~ Addition.
            ßµ   ~ Push Root Square Mean.
              +  ~ Addition.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy, 54 bytes

```
{a,b->c=a+b;((a*a+b*b)/2)**0.5+c/2+(a*b)**0.5+2*a*b/c}
```

-2 thanks to Mr. Xcoder for an edit that made me feel dumb.

Comment: I think you can replace `a**2` with `a*a` and `b**2` with `b*b`

Answer (score 0):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 76 bytes

```
[pow((map(pow(.;2))|add)/2;.5),add/2,pow(.[0]*.[1];.5),2/(map(1/.)|add)]|add
```

Expanded

```
[
  pow((map(pow(.;2))|add)/2;.5)  # root mean square
, add/2                          # arithmetic mean
, pow(.[0]*.[1];.5)              # geometric mean
, 2/(map(1/.)|add)               # harmonic mean
]
| add                            # that just about sums it up for mean
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxNbsMgEIX3PgVSN3YFmBkYYBSpF0EsLGWTKrWd1lY2OXsIpl10FvPz5nvv81ZSkMJnKWq9CfUhkDR7cBHIUx0csEtgpABzQA1xpktoq9RsTbJOM4OFGKI3gQ1XQgr3LxdAewo2gCOgCGh9l6yjmsKY/xBDoIM3npids9HZ7lHSutz7/mta@2PRJxyGx3Q@DyOeNA2yriPK9komv@sEuek4Ng@M@hfPRy/luazbZZl/ilLzfr2qy7zuWz2@p7ta9q0eLw)