# Parallel resistance in electric circuits

Tags: code-golf, math, physics, electrical-engineering

#### Introduction:

Two resistors, `R1` and `R2`,  in parallel (denoted `R1 || R2`) have a combined resistance `Rp` given as:

$$R_{P_2} = \frac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}$$
or as suggested in comments:

$$R_{P_2} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}}$$

Three resistors, `R1`, `R2` and `R3` in parallel (`R1 || R2 || R3`) have a combined resistance `(R1 || R2) || R3 = Rp || R3` :

$$R_{P_3} = \frac{\frac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}\cdot R_3}{\frac{R_1\cdot R_2}{R_1+R_2}+R_3}$$

or, again as suggested in comments:

$$R_{P_3} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}+ \frac{1}{R_3}}$$

These formulas can of course be extended to an indefinite number of resistors.

---

#### Challenge:

Take a list of positive resistor values as input, and output the combined resistance if they were placed in parallel in an electric circuit. You may not assume a maximum number of resistors (except that your computer can handle it of course).

#### Test cases:

```
1, 1
0.5

1, 1, 1
0.3333333

4, 6, 3
1.3333333

20, 14, 18, 8, 2, 12
1.1295

10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90
2.6117
```

---

**Shortest code in each language wins. Explanations are highly encouraged.**

Comment: There are a few other challenges that refer to the harmonic mean ([1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/182460/31625) [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/145351/31625) [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37217/31625)) but I don't think there is a duplicate. In line with what flawr suggested, I think this challenge body should have that phrase listed somewhere so we can close a future dupe more easily.

Answer (score 13):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>5</s> 3 bytes

```
zOz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/yr/q//9oQwMdBRA2AmJjIDYBYlMgNgNicyC2AGJLg1gA)

---

#### Explanation

```
z                     # compute 1/x for each x in input 
 O                    # sum input 
  z                   # compute 1/sum
```

Comment: Excepting built-ins, this is probably as low as we can go!

Answer (score 11):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```hs
(1/).sum.map(1/)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX8NQX1OvuDRXLzexAMT@n5uYmadgq1BQlJlXoqCikKYQbaKjYKajYBz7/19yWk5ievF/3QjngAAA)

Comment: It looks beautiful.

Comment: Solution along the OP's recursive lines would be 22 chars: `foldr1(\r s->r*s/(r+s))`.

Answer (score 10):

## [MATLAB](https://ch.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html), 14 bytes

In MATLAB `norm(...,p)` computes the `p`-norm of a vector. This is usually defined for \$p \geqslant 1\$ as

$$\Vert v \Vert_p = \left( \sum_i \vert v_i \vert^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}.$$

But luckily for us, it also happens to work for \$p=-1\$. (Note that it does not work in Octave.)

```matlab
@(x)norm(x,-1)
```

[Don't try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCMy@/KFejQkfXUPN/Yl6xRrShjpGOcazmfwA)

Comment: This is horrible and beautiful simultaneously!

Comment: Thanks, these are the best compliments:)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>5</s>  3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
İSİ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///IhuAjG/7//x9taKCjAMJGQGwMxCZAbArEZkBsDsQWQGxpEAsA)**

#### How?

Initially I forgot this form from my electronic engineering days ...how easily we forget.

```
İSİ - Link: list of numbers, R   e.g. [r1, r2, ..., rn]
İ   - inverse (vectorises)            [1/r1, 1/r2, ..., 1/rn]
 S  - sum                             1/r1 + 1/r2 + ... + 1/rn
  İ - inverse                         1/(1/r1 + 1/r2 + ... + 1/rn)
```

Comment: I'm assuming `İ` is pronounced the same way `i` is pronounced in `list`. Is this a way of saying the challenge was easy?

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 15 bytes

```matlab
@(x)1/sum(1./x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330GjQtNQv7g0V8NQT79C83@aRrShgmGsJheIYaCjAMJGQGwMxCZAbArEZkBsDsQWQGxpEKv5HwA)

Harmonic mean, divided by `n`. Easy peasy.

Comment: @tsh you know, I don't think I ever noticed that. I guess it's *almost* the harmonic mean...

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 22 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{$y+=1/$_};1/$y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BDoJADETv@xUbUgXiJHYXxFVCwp@gB9ADiQYOSnC/fa0kag/NvGknc7892mG8tn0fqKvmQOfhMr5WM02bymyp8aXsKXil6KkrXSeJgUmhtMxH/iFHgewLlmFyGAcHC2N/AbEZcswYOWPHKBh7hmMcOE2lQ6qX14ia0zFa5Jo6XTdlHCsf3g)

Takes input via splatting and uses the same 1/sum of inverse trick as many of the others are doing

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
÷1⊥÷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/////B2w0ddSw9v/5/2qG3Co94@o0ddzY/6pgYHOQPJEA/PYC4gDZRKUzA0ACEjAwVjAwUTAwVTAwUzAwVzAwULAwVLg/8A)

-1 thanks to [Adám](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/43319/ad%c3%a1m).

Comment: APL is the original golfing language!

Comment: @YiminRong It's not a golfing language... :P

Comment: I know, but its byte count is on par with modern golfing languages!

Comment: -1 byte: `÷1⊥÷` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/////B2w0ddSw9v/5/2qG3Co94@o0ddzY/6pgYHOQPJEA/PYC4gDZRKUzA0ACEjAwVjAwUTAwVTAwUzAwVzAwULAwVLg/8A "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám Oh duh of course `1∘⊥` is the same as `+/` for vectors...

Comment: Heh, it is even [on APLcart](https://aplcart.info/?q=resistors#).

Comment: @Adám Hm... somewhat obscure entry... :P

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 15 bytes

```r
1/sum(1/scan())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/31C/uDRXA0gmJ@ZpaGr@NzTgAiIjAy5jAy4TAy5TAy4zAy5zAy4LAy5Lg/8A)

Follows the same Harmonic Mean principle seen in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 28 bytes

```
a=>a.map(y=>x+=1/y,x=0)&&1/x
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##DcJRDoIwFATA25A2LLBVQfx4XMT48YJAIEgJGFJOX53MpIfu7Tau32zx7y72ElUazT@6mlOakIorTgShTRJXhNj6Zfdzl89@ML15OuL/QlyJG1ESFXEnauLBl7XxBw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 14 bytes

```
1/*.sum o 1/**
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBDoIwFIThq/whxAUx@l6ppUbpVQgLu5JgICwI8ey1wmq@zMznNb1dGlZOkTbptbrMy8BIVpUezP1KUXa0gS1Sdt@COE48FQ3nPQ5YHPUfRlCLejwGNfspV0IeasEKN8EJjeCFu4T0Aw)

`1 / **` is an anonymous function that returns a list of the reciprocals of its arguments.  `1 / *.sum` is another anonymous function that returns the reciprocal of the sum of the elements of its list argument.  The `o` operator composes those two functions.

Comment: Very nice. I don't see HyperWhatevers used often enough in golfing since they can't be used in more complex expressions. If they were closer to normal Whatevers, I'd expect sumething like [this](https://tio.run/##JYpBDoIwFAWvMiHEKDHyf6mlRulViAu7gkAgLojh7BVxNZN5b3xNnUv9wiHSJC2PWhbF6TK/@3Rnfi5keUsT@ETyds2Iw8RD0XDe8ReLo/qJEdSiHo9BzX7akrANlWCFq@CEWvDCTUL6Ag) to work, but alas...

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the first time I've even thought about using one for golfing, and I was disappointed to discover its limitations.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pa -MList::Util=reduce`, 26 bytes

```perl
$_=reduce{$a*$b/($a+$b)}@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rYoNaU0ObVaJVFLJUlfQyVRWyVJs9bB7f9/QwVDLiAGkiYKZgrGXEYGCoYmCoYWChYKRgqGRlyGQL6BAlDU2EDBxEDB1EDBzEDB3EDBwkDB0uBffkFJZn5e8X9dX5/M4hIrq9CSzByoXf91E3MKAA)

Comment: [20 bytes](https://tio.run/##DY0xDoMwEAR7v2ILWsSdMeAgIaVKlZSpEQWFJRMsbCqUr@dyxY4002xaj9iJVPPETT43bEu6uKnm7/0hwmCjUzr0aI0lsAN7eFiwNaxO0NoSHKEj9ISB4Ak3@u2phP2TpX49Qy7j@C4hTvoh9RLTHw)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul [17 bytes, no -M](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/192679/6484)

Answer (score 3):

## bash + coreutils, 25 bytes

```
bc -l<<<"1/(0${@/#/+1/})"
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##DYhBCsIwFAX3OcWjdqGI5P001kiz8B6li9YEKgQLVnBhPXvMYgZmpnGd82d@pIhXHAPStvU96oRh6BAWrPFdqsvTHafkva9E71l/b3qnj6J/hyqH5RmzQFSh2KJFowwhFuLgYCBGSWmi3IawxJloiQvhiCv/)

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 10 bytes

```
1/Tr[1/#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYoxDoMwFEN3roHE5Cr@IdAwFHEEBjbUIUJFZaBDlA3l7GmAyc/P3l34fnYXtsWl9ZVETX4WVb6rNPrtF@by0a9Drmo4ikMgEVfcYNCiPkETYiAWFhqir1NWRB5qwhAN0RJPwhIdYxHTHw)

Comment: Is there no harmonic mean builtin, or is it longer to type?

Comment: @Eric AFAIK it's intuitively named `HarmonicMean` and is longer.

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
∩Σ∩
```

The same as other answers, using the builtins `∩` (\$\frac{1}{n}\$) and `Σ` (sum):
$$M(x_1,...,x_n)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{x_2} + ... + \frac{1}{x_n}}$$

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7//9Rx8pzi4HE///RhjqGsVwgEkyb6JjpGANpIwMdQxMdQwsdCx0jHUMjkAqgiIEOUNzYQMfEQMfUQMfMQMfcQMfCQMfSIBYA)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 24 bytes

```java
a->1/a.map(d->1/d).sum()
```

I noticed there wasn't a Java answer yet, so figured I'd add one.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hVDLTsMwELz3K1Y9Oep2sdNQgiqQkLjSS4@Ig0lclJA4UexUqlCvfACfyI@EzUOiFQculnd3ZnZ2cn3Qyzx975JCOwdPOrMfM4DMetPsdWJg25cAadW@FgYSkTOBWp8V5HxjdEmPw2Q3FKCDDcNPM36c1z5LYAsW7qDTy3t1panUtUj7bxqQa0sRdJseW7MEYyfKocpSKNmJYNXMvj2/sO5owxvnhUI1rPktLxsRrnF13gglqghVjDGGqMILMo8kMmAlMZJ4LXEt8UZiLPFW/jlmcDbwxjyIiKOqWz/Z2x2dNyVVraeanfvCnuX10DT66MhX41ViJC7m8P35BfOFpX/CpWo/cYLJ2Kn7AQ)

**Explanation:**

Uses the same Harmonic Mean approach as other answers:

$$M(x_1,...,x_n)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x_1} + \frac{1}{x_2} + ... + \frac{1}{x_n}}$$

```java
a->                       // Method with DoubleStream parameter and double return-type
     a.map(d->1/d)        //  Calculate 1/d for each value `d` in the input-stream
                  .sum()  //  Then take the sum of the mapped list
   1/                     //  And return 1/sum as result
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 29 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.reduce((p,c)=>p*c/(p+c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc@9DoIwEMDx3ae4sdVa2vI9wOhLGIemFIMhtAE0vn09ViFBL/0nnX65e@iXnszY@fk8uMaGtgq6qjUfbfM0lhDPDK1qfzQR8SdDaTBumFxvee/upCVXyUDC7twon92le9uGJJRCFIHg6WGD2te2qBjnW0sYZAzivzW5qSmBmyEpCwb4FP7Ub5pU5frSRcMWNcYSLMUyLMcKrBRrTfFMyjx8AA)

or:

```javascript
a=>1/a.reduce((p,c)=>p+1/c,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc@9DoMgEMDxvU/BCCkFDr8HHfsSTQeC2GiMGLVN356eazWxvfBPmH6568zLzHZqx@Uy@NqFpgymrEAaMbn6aR2lI7esrMYzSMsVC9YPs@@d6P2DNvQGnAA5nDsTi7@2b1fTmDEiJVEiOe1Qx9oeFeF8azEnKSfR3xrsalrhZkhCzgk@jT/9mwa62F66atiqRliMJViKZViOFWqraZECZOED)

But with this approach, using `map()` (as [Shaggy did](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/192651/58563)) is 1 byte shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
,1w/s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X8ewXL/4//9oIwMdBUMTILbQUQAiIyDLKBYA)

I'm not sure if "do twice" (`,`) counts as a loop, but this is just the harmonic mean, divided by `n`.

Alternately, `,-1^s` is five bytes as well.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 51 bytes

Reciprocal of sum of reciprocals. Input is `$a`.

```php
1/array_reduce($a,function($c,$i){return$c+1/$i;});
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxDsIgEADQX2G4ASJJQa2tQeOnGHLSwALkUgbT9Nvx7PDGV2Ptj1eNVYB/eiL/ldZo8XdmF3ZlI7uxic3sbpQTAWPpdjjWm8KnYZDg9dIyrqlkCaghqY3C2igDnuwAye3K9f4D)

Comment: With PHP7.4, I think you can do this: `1/array_reduce($a,fn($c,$i)=>$c+1/$i);` (38 bytes). Read more in https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions

Comment: I think you're right! But nowhere to demo?

Comment: You have to download it yourself. However, since PHP 7.4.0RC1 was released on the 5th of this month (https://www.php.net/archive/2019.php#2019-09-05-1), you probably are safe using it. If you have doubts, you can ask in the meta.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 30 bytes

```python
lambda r:1/sum(1/v for v in r)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7LCoMwEEX3fsXsTGBAY6y1gl9SXVhUKtQoMRX69emN0EfIYc7NzEDWl7svRvuxbvyjm299R7ZSyfachUp2GhdLO02GrPTB3bC5EEVEOFfFpFr@@V/MmQom/YlZih7eVMmEm8Gy72bogTCjQQ5OoABnUIJL2kayOuZXOxknwk@YxqNKpm1Y67gxMdNg@mBw6d8)**

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (-p), 17 bytes

```perl
$a+=1/$_}{$_=1/$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lUdvWUF8lvrZaJR7ESPz/39CAC4iMDLiMDbhMDLhMDbjMDLjMDbgsDLgsDf7lF5Rk5ucV/9ctAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## x86-64 Machine code - <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
0F 57 C0             xorps       xmm0,xmm0  
loopHead
F3 0F 53 4C 8A FC    rcpss       xmm1,dword ptr [rdx+rcx*4-4]
0F 58 C1             addps       xmm0,xmm1  
E2 F6                loop        loopHead
0F 53 C0             rcpps       xmm0,xmm0  
C3                   ret
```

Input - Windows calling convention. First parameter is the number of resistors in `RCX`. A pointer to the resistors is in `RDX`. `*ps` instructions are used since they are one byte smaller. Technically, you can only have around 2^61 resistors but you will be out of RAM long before then. The precision isn't great either, since we are using `rcpps`.

Comment: “Only 2⁶¹ resistors” would probably fill the observable universe (many times over)!

Comment: Actually, 2^61 is only 2.305843e+18 and the observable universe is 8.8 × 10^26 m in diameter.

Comment: Yeah, serious overestimation! Actual magnitude would be around the size and mass of Deimos, smaller moon of Mars.

Answer (score 2):

## Intel 8087 FPU machine code, 19 bytes

```
 D9 E8      FLD1                    ; push 1 for top numerator on stack
 D9 EE      FLDZ                    ; push 0 for running sum 
        R_LOOP: 
 D9 E8      FLD1                    ; push 1 numerator for resistor
 DF 04      FILD WORD PTR[SI]       ; push resistor value onto stack 
 DE F9      FDIV                    ; divide 1 / value 
 DE C1      FADD                    ; add to running sum 
 AD         LODSW                   ; increment SI by 2 bytes 
 E2 F4      LOOP R_LOOP             ; keep looping 
 DE F9      FDIV                    ; divide 1 / result                  
 D9 1D      FSTP WORD PTR[DI]       ; store result as float in [DI]
```

This uses the stack-based floating point instructions in the original IBM PC's 8087 FPU.

Input is pointer to resistor values in `[SI]`, number of resistors in `CX`.  Output is to a single precision (DD) value at `[DI]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 24 bytes

```
|>II^[=1+#g`e_1P+~s]`e_1
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7C%3EII%5E%5B%3D1%2B%23g%60e_1P%2B%7Es%5D%60e_1&inputs=10%2C%2010%2C%2020%2C%2030%2C%2040%2C%2050%2C%2060%2C%2070%2C%2080%2C%2090)

This answer can probably be golfed more (can anyone outgolf me in my own language?)

## Explanation

```
|                 take input, parse automatically (Rattle's input parsing is powerful 
                   enough to recognise "1,2,3" etc. as a list)
 >                move pointer to the right (to slot 1)
  I               flatten input list and insert into consecutive memory slots
   I^             get length of this list (which is still on top of the stack)
     [ ... ]`     loop structure: loop as many times as the length of the list

=1                set top of stack to 1
  +#              increment top of stack by list's iterator 
                   (the number of times the loop has run)
    g`            get the value in storage at the calculated index (iterator + 1)
      e_1         get 1/x of this value
         P        set the pointer to slot 0
          +~      increment the current value by the stored value in slot 0
            s     save the result to slot 0
e_1                get 1/x of this value
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
Ｉ∕¹Σ∕¹Ａ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwyWzLDMlVcNQRyG4NBeJ55lXUFqioQkG1v//R0cbGegoGJoAsYWOAhAZAVlGsbH/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Works by calculating the current drawn by each resistor when 1V is applied, taking the total, and calculating the resistance that would draw that current when 1V is applied. Explanation:

```
      Ａ Input array
    ∕¹  Reciprocal (vectorised)
   Σ    Sum
 ∕¹     Reciprocal
Ｉ       Cast to string for implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 42 bytes

```
f(List<num>a)=>a.reduce((p,e)=>p*e/(p+e));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxBDsIgFET3noLlRyf6oVgxak/gDYwLYmnCooRUujKeHYk7a2Y1702md1MuZaBreOZznMfOyUvntpPv54cnSvC1p7XfUdp4KU9ldCGSfK2ESFOImQa6KQh1r@6X1SyhQYtmCTVDGSgLCw2l/46qZtRRwzCMPaNlHBiWceTv@F0@)

Having to explicitly specify the `num` type is kinda sucky, prevents type infering, because it would infer to `(dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic` which can't yield doubles for some reason

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 40 bytes

```php
for(;$n=$argv[++$i];$r+=1/$n);echo 1/$r;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxV8mxVEovSy6K1tVUyY61VirRtDfVV8jStU5Mz8hWAzCLr////GxqAkJHBf2OD/yYG/00N/psZ/Dc3@G9h8N/SAAA)

Tests: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/baoQwEIbv8xSDBDZiUKO77iGVvkNvrZSwpKvFjZJooZQ@u501le0O@WEO3/xDhmaYn56HZiCEjtqNDkqoCGBUgoOoOSQJpPHu3vrXzX342ZZDwSH3M/E4y1LcQkAcOODLMMtWUGTH1f1GoW50jtqidqgCtUcdUMfU72VxIcSe1JKQ995qdW6A/X1AOViyEL4XX6rs5RO/paxVX29XbS@aVWbqOnTyoFw4fW56CF60m7oR0BSqAGL46FvDNhw2K4y9oIbWnSCQM2JMUlMuN6ooom0tqY1KkVATysURUyvn@4FXG/h7k3F6ZLQNH0qL5c/8Cw)

Similar to [Yimin Rong's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/192652/81663) but without built-ins and all program bytes are included in the bytes count.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>58</s> 44 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,y=0,*i:f(x*y/(x+y),*i)if y else x
```

A recursive function. Requires arguments to be passed unpacked, like so:

```python
i=[10, 10, 20]
f(*i)
```

or

```python
f(10, 10, 20)
```

**Explanation:**

```python
# lambda function with three arguments. *i will take any unpacked arguments past x and y,
# so a call like f(10, 20) is also valid and i will be an empty tuple
# since y has a default value, f(10) is also valid
f=lambda x,y=0,*i: \

# a if case else b
# determine parallel resistance of x and y and use it as variable x
# since i is passed unpacked, the first item in the remaining list will be y and
# the rest of the items will be stored in i
# in the case where there were no items in the list, y will have the default value of 0
f(x*y/(x+y),*i) \

# if y does not exist or is zero, return x
if y else x
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 6 bytes

```
1%1#.%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYsxCoNAFER7T/GIiAR0mb@uugqpAqlS5QpBCWm8f7WaIirMg3kM800XV87cRkoqxLhRO@6v5yNZYbkr0jUjm96fhRnDTvWQQEfzFy8sYJGIx/x@0C/b2IggWtGJXkQxKK0)

Comment: it's a pity "sum under reciprocal" is the same number of bytes: `+/&.:%`

Comment: @ngn Yes, but your solution looks more idiomatic to J.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>26</s> 22 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to @ValueInk.

```ruby
->x{1/x.sum{|i|1.0/i}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166i2lC/Qq@4NLe6JrPGUM9AP7O29n9BaUmxQppecmJOjka0YawmF6qAjgKGmJEBUNAEiC10FIDICMgywtAHUgPEILXGQGwCxKZAbAbE5kBsAcSWBrGa/wE)

Comment: [`x.sum{...}` is equivalent to `x.map{...}.sum`](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166i2lC/Qq@4NLe6JrPGUM9AP7O29n9BaUmxQppecmJOjka0YawmF6qAjgKGmJEBUNAEiC10FIDICMgywtAHUgPEILXGQGwCxKZAbAbE5kBsAcSWBrGa/wE "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: @ValueInk: Doh! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

## [MATLAB], 15 bytes

One more byte than *flawr* excellent answer, but I had to use other functions so here goes:

```
@(x)1/sum(1./x)
```

It's rather explicit, it sums the inverse of the resistances, then invert the sum to output the equivalent parallel resistance.

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 49 bytes

```forth
: f 0e 0 do dup i cells + @ s>f 1/f f+ loop 1/f ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY9BTsMwEEX3PcVnxaJTGCdpmlIJISFxCcrCJA6JSOPKdoCevkxiEJVQVS9iR/7v/XFtXWgWb/W4HY93qMEGjMqiGvZoUZqu85jjAf6@hrqtUc/RWbufzhshvmI8DOX7Sf4qhionnw228I00lENAsPDBOoNKB422x87srDsQfNuXBk/jIOIzvr8OaPSHwevQdmEhSe2cPviZgsJeV0ikelxbPDqjg4n3@GxF8KxIvcxiSka@QelmExjRdELPgb9o@odmyOX3AppRTuk/NGGoDKpAIbOoZJLk5yUJk8pIFVRQQiqJuvzkEaJjiDRlZIwlI2esGAVjzZNcrs@/TuxM0pEyZUxLppxpxVQwrTl2Cf5TdvwG)

Input is a memory address and array length (used as an impromptu array, since Forth doesn't have a built-in array construct)

Uses the sum-of-inverse method as most other answers are

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f           \ start a new word definition
  0e          \ stick an accumulator on the floating point stack
  0 do        \ start a loop from 0 to array-length -1
    dup       \ copy the array address
    i cells + \ get the address of the current array value
    @ s>f     \ get the value and convert it to a float
    1/f f+    \ invert and add to accumulator
  loop        \ end the loop definition
  1/f         \ invert the resulting sum
;             \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 16 bytes

```
1/l.Sum(n=>1f/n)
```

### [Try It](https://tio.run/##LY0xC8IwEEZ3f8WNyWBK59CCuCoIFRzE4YinBNJEc1ehlP72GEHe8vH44DneOnZlYh@fMMwsNJqDj2/rAjLDa2FB8Q4@yd/hiD4qlly/1xugXnyUOgJ0gGagQE4UQ9dD9eaEmUmx1uacdjnjrLTd/Av7FDkFMpfshWqOVGmbYIZpVLHr20cTddF2XUtpf3wB)

Comment: Since the `Sum()` function can also accept a selector, you can cut 9 bytes by ommiting the `.Select()` part, [like so](https://tio.run/##LY0xC8IwEEZ3f8WNyWBq5tKCuCoIFRzEIcRDAulFc1ehlP72GEHe8vH44HneevZl4kBPGGYWHM0x0Lv10THDa2FxEjx8UnjAyQVSLLl@b3dwegkkdUTowJkBI3pRDF0P1Zuzy4yKtTaXtM/ZzUq3m3/hkIhTRHPNQbDmUBXbRDNMo6Kut2bXkC66XddS7I8v)

Comment: Just realized, one more byte can be saved by writing `1f/n` instead of `1.0/n` as both methods will avoid integer division.

Comment: nice catch mate!

Answer (score 1):

## expl3 (LaTeX3 programming layer), 65 bytes

The following defines a function that prints the result to the terminal (unfortunately `expl3` has very verbose function names):

```latex
\def\1#1{\fp_show:n{1/(\clist_map_function:nN{#1}\2)}}\def\2{+1/}
```

A complete script which can be run from the terminal including all the test cases as well as the setup to enter `expl3`:

```latex
\RequirePackage{expl3}\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\1#1{\fp_show:n{1/(\clist_map_function:nN{#1}\2)}}\def\2{+1/}
\1{1, 1}
\1{1, 1, 1}
\1{4, 6, 3}
\1{20, 14, 18, 8, 2, 12}
\1{10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90}
\stop
```

If run with `pdflatex <filename>` the following is the console output:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./cg_resistance.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unravel/unravel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def))
 (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gtl/gtl.sty))
> 1/(\clist_map_function:nN {1,1}\2)=0.5.
<recently read> }

l.3 \1{1, 1}

?
> 1/(\clist_map_function:nN {1,1,1}\2)=0.3333333333333333.
<recently read> }

l.4 \1{1, 1, 1}

?
> 1/(\clist_map_function:nN {4,6,3}\2)=1.333333333333333.
<recently read> }

l.5 \1{4, 6, 3}

?
> 1/(\clist_map_function:nN {20,14,18,8,2,12}\2)=1.129538323621694.
<recently read> }

l.6 \1{20, 14, 18, 8, 2, 12}

?
> 1/(\clist_map_function:nN
{10,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90}\2)=2.611669603067675.
<recently read> }

l.7 \1{10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90}

?
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on cg_resistance.log.
```

### Explanation

`\fp_show:n`
: evaluates its argument as a floating point expression and prints the result on the terminal, every expandable macro is expanded during that process.

`\clist_map_function:nN`
: takes two arguments, a comma separated list and a function/macro, if called like `\clist_map_function:nN { l1, l2, l3 } \foo` it expands to something like `\foo{l1}\foo{l2}\foo{l3}`. In our case instead of `\foo` the macro `\2` is used, which expands to `+1/` so that the expression expands to `+1/{l1}+1/{l2}+1/{l3}`

Answer (score 1):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate), 72 bytes

Okay, this was VERY hard!
Specifically with a language that has VERY poor math support.

```
{@fnx A,S}{@eachA}{@set/_ 1 _}{@set+S S,_}{@/}{@set/S 1 S}{@returnS}{@/}
```

Creates a function `x` that *must* be called by passing an array as the first and only argument.

**Ungolfed**:

```
{@fn calc values, sum}
    {@each values as value}
        {@set/ value 1 value}
        {@set+ sum sum, value}
    {@/}
    {@set/ sum 1 sum}
    {@return sum}
{@/}
```

**Explanation**:

- `{@fn calc values, sum}` - Creates the function `calc`, which has 2 variables (`values` and `sum`) taking the values of the first arguments (defaults to `null`)
- `{@each values as value}` - Loops over each `value` in `values`
- `{@set/ value 1 value}` - Divides `1` by `value`, storing it into `value`
- `{@set+ sum sum, value}` - Adds `sum` to `value`, storing it into `sum`
- `{@/}` - Closes the `{@each}` (usually optional)
- `{@set/ sum 1 sum}` - Divides `1` by `sum`, storing it into `sum`
- `{@return sum}` - Returns `sum` (duh)
- `{@/}` - Closes the `{@fn}` (usually optional, even if it shouldn't be for functions)

To use the function, you can use this code:

```
{@set values 10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90} {@//array of values}
{@call calc into result values}
{@echo result} {@//2.6116696030677}
```

---

---

If you are curious, the ungolfed example compiles to this PHP code:

```php
// {@fn calc values, sum}
$DATA['calc'] = function()use(&$FN, &$_){
    $DATA = array(
        'argv' => func_get_args(),
        'argc' => func_num_args(),
        'VERSION' => '0.62',
        'EOL' => PHP_EOL,
        'PARENT' => &$_
    );
    $_ = &$DATA;
    $DATA["values"] = &$DATA["argv"][0];
    $DATA["sum"] = &$DATA["argv"][1];


    // {@each values as value}
    // loop variables
    $tmp_1_val = isset($DATA['values']) ? $tmp_1_val = &$DATA['values'] : null;
    $tmp_1_keys = gettype($DATA['values']) == 'array'
        ? array_keys($DATA['values'])
        : array_keys(range(0, strlen($tmp_1_val = $tmp_1_val . '') - 1));
    $tmp_1_key_last = end($tmp_1_keys);
    
    // loop
    foreach($tmp_1_keys as $tmp_1_index => $tmp_1_key){
        $DATA['loop'] = array(
            'index' => $tmp_1_index,
            'i' => $tmp_1_index,
            'key' => $tmp_1_key,
            'k' => $tmp_1_key,
            'value' => $tmp_1_val[$tmp_1_key],
            'v' => $tmp_1_val[$tmp_1_key],
            'first' => $tmp_1_key === $tmp_1_keys[0],
            'last' => $tmp_1_key === $tmp_1_key_last,
        );
        $DATA['__'] = $tmp_1_key;
        $DATA['value'] = $tmp_1_val[$tmp_1_key];

        // {@set/ value 1 value}
        $DATA['value'] = array_map(function($value)use(&$DATA){return (1 / $value);}, $FN['array_flat']((isset($DATA['value'])?$DATA['value']:null)));

        // {@set+ sum sum, value}
        $DATA['sum'] = array_sum($FN['array_flat'](array((isset($DATA['sum'])?$DATA['sum']:null),(isset($DATA['value'])?$DATA['value']:null))));

    // {@/}
    };

    // {@set/ sum 1 sum}
    $DATA['sum'] = array_map(function($value)use(&$DATA){return (1 / $value);}, $FN['array_flat']((isset($DATA['sum'])?$DATA['sum']:null)));

    // {@return sum}
    return (isset($DATA['sum'])?$DATA['sum']:null);

// {@/}
};

// {@set values 10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90}
$DATA['values'] = array(10,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90);

// {@call calc into result values}
$DATA['result'] = call_user_func_array(isset($DATA['calc']) && is_callable($DATA['calc'])? $DATA['calc']: (isset($FN["calc"])? $FN["calc"]: "calc"), array((isset($DATA['values'])?$DATA['values']:null)));

// {@echo result}
echo implode('', $FN['array_flat']((isset($DATA['result'])?$DATA['result']:null)));
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `d`, 3 bytes

```
Ė∑Ė
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=d&code=%C4%96%E2%88%91%C4%96&inputs=%5B1%2C1%5D&header=&footer=)

Reciprocal, sum, reciprocal.

You can remove `d` if you're fine with the result being double-wrapped in a list for some reason.

Comment: am I crazy or is that [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7//8i0Rx0Tj0z7/x8A), not 3? (the TIO link is just for the byte count)

Comment: @DanielH. Vyxal scores bytes using a SBCS, or Single Byte Character Set [here](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/blob/master/docs/codepage.txt).

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
c1scL1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P9mwONnH8P9/IwMdBUMTILbQUQAiIyDLCAA)

Uses the modified formula \$\frac{1}{R_P}=\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}\$.

```
c1      # 1/
  s     #   sum(                     )
   cL1  #       map(lambda x: 1/x, Q)  # Q (=input) is implicit
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
1÷Ux!÷1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=MfdVeCH3MQ&input=WzEwLCAxMCwgMjAsIDMwLCA0MCwgNTAsIDYwLCA3MCwgODAsIDkwXQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [OCaml](https://ocaml.org), 50 bytes

```
fun l->1./.(List.fold_left(fun a e->a+.1./.e)0. l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc1dCsIwDAfwd0@RxxZZ3PwWcSfwBiKluFQKsR1bPX/NYh5@kIR/kl/@w5WpwOgnuNXwTcBN3@EGzT3OBUPmwTGFYpaVB2p6v8ZlT7ZFYFujJCQvab3x6GR8hb9bdafu1YN6VE/qWb20@FyBlJwbp5iKozRwTARmLtK/XQ4ucPbyydYf)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 bytes

```
{u+Fu
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7Bu%2BFu&i=[1+1]%0A[1+1+1]%0A[4+6+3]%0A[20+14+18+8+1+12]%0A[10+10+20+30+40+50+60+70+80+90]&a=1&m=2)

```
{  F     For each:
 u         Invert
  +        Add to running total
    u    Invert
         Implicit print as fraction
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 15 bytes

```scala
1/_.map(1/).sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzBCoJAEIbvPsUcd2ExV81MMAi6dpJOIrGairGupmsQ4bNvIx0V5oOf@b@ZsRBSmC5/loWGq2gUfK1HWUGLkYihHiM4D4P4pIkeGlVnNIKbajTE6L2FhCoiSflKL92UyzKLT/9AY8N3d7sVPeE7ao9Ta3o811KRavEJZ8AppdZ6u1n4DAIG3rpwHfSx5SEDHBeTu/F3sZDF9hAf2SMBckBC5Ogsd/Nsfg)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org/), 30 bytes

```
lambda v:1/sum(1/x for x in v)
```

-2, thanks @JoKing

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Unfortunately, submissions should either be a full program (preface with `v=input();print `) or a function (preface with `lambda v:`) to be valid. A snippet which presumes pre-defined variables isn't allowed.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a snippet, which means that you don't output or input according to our [Input/Output rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). You can correct this by wrapping the statement in `print(...)` and by taking `v` as input, either in a lambda or by using `input`.

Comment: That's unfortunate, thanks for pointing me to the IO conventions. I have updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 16 characters

```
1/(map(1/.)|add)
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ jq '1/(map(1/.)|add)' <<< '[10, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]'
2.611669603067675
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/99QXyM3sUDDUF9PsyYxJUXz//9oQx0Fw1guMAVhmegomOkoGANZRgZAESDX0EJHAYiMgCwjkFKQMBCDpI2B2ASITYHYDIjNgdgCiC0NYgE)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>65</s> 62 bytes

Thanks to ceilingcat for -3 bytes.

```c
float a(b,c)int*b;{float d=0;for(;c--;)d+=1./b[c];return 1/d;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdBba4MwGAbg@/6Kj46BWWM1B11H5v5I5oUmugqdirU3E3@7@2x3CIiFvJATzxti/A9jpqk8NVkPmZdTQ6q6f8rVcNuySajKpvOU8X1F7C5h@yDXJlVd0V@6Glhg1Tg9VLU5XWwBr@feVs3@@LZBBT6zqvbIsAGYV1nbMs1TSGBgFNiocL/t8KT0to/le72l@ID5Ej1XX0VTXuckcBY6TAkh6t/jWvx590jukNwl@YIUP6SkEFMQq6RwSOGSYkFKHV9JHuIb0WUHCjg4zviqLx1fur5c@JFm4e0b5gLMXCQwEhNhYswz5oB5CVcrI6cyciuj38px@gY)

Comment: if you change it to clang on TIO, you can do `float a(*b,c)` instead of `float a(b,c)int*b;`

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 78 bytes

```cpp
#import<list>
void f(std::list<int>r,double&s){s=0;for(int p:r)s+=1./p;s=1/s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY/faoMwFIevzVMECkPZ2Wqsa52JvovTWAJqQk7cjfjs7khH2S5LIR@cP/l9Ia1zb@3QTNftYKZ2mDvNlbEYvG7Gmmajsz6owWCo2bc1He9jDF1Z7hNlplB76Oz8NegXTBasUtlbH9Ocu9In@FqJ96OTWIkjynVj@2JszBQnbGHRfxH3Gqm2HvkiQKySRTczRyr7@L4GTORvuLVzUArp7J2eukEyxqL71Wo33VwPCP7mczjD6Yl8loLIQRRQQAYiW5/5Sgp8h5T8ROTEB3EmLkRBfKaPvbBuPw)

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##pY/baoQwEIavzVMECkXpbNe4dtca9V3EQwnEJGSyvRGf3U7KsrR3LQv5YA75v5DBucOge/OxPykz6Os48UZZDH7ql45mi7M@NFph6NinVSOfUwxjXcdJo0zoPMza9uEZsxXbXM7WpzTmrvYZvrTi9egktuKIcttZXCy9MmnGVpb89nA/IdXWI18FiE2y5FvMMVbpfQuYyVt2sNfQNEgndpMZtWSMJferbRTdVH8X/MyXcIbTA/kiB1GCqKCCAkSxPfKVHHiElPxElMQbcSYuREW85/97Ydu/AA "C++ (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 bytes

```
⅟Ʃ⅟
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//Uev8YyuBxP//0YYGOgogbATExkBsAsSmQGwGxOZAbAHElgaxAA)

```
⅟        implicit input; take reciprocal
 Ʃ       sum
  ⅟      take reciprocal; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 3 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 2.47 bytes

```
oSo
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaL84PzISyowIKbGtGGBjoKIGwExMZAbALEpkBsBsTmQGwBxJYGsRANAA)

##### Explanation

```python
oSo  # Implicit input
o    # Inverse: 1 / input
 S   # Sum this list
  o  # Inverse: 1 / sum
     # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 27 bytes

```javascript
a=>1/eval('1/'+a.join`+1/`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcJRCoMwEAXA45iQ1byorfZDL1IEF41FCVmpkuunHebgxNfy3c@7jLL6vA2Zh9FZnziowtnCcHXIHmfj7KzzIvGS4KsgH7WptwP916AG1IIeoCeoA/WgFyat8w8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ỊSỊ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCQiU4QVMlRTElQkIlOEEmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lNUIxMCUyQyUyMDEwJTJDJTIwMjAlMkMlMjAzMCUyQyUyMDQwJTJDJTIwNTAlMkMlMjA2MCUyQyUyMDcwJTJDJTIwODAlMkMlMjA5MCU1RCZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
ỊSỊ  # Implicit input
Ị    # Reciprocal
 S   # Sum
  Ị  # Reciprocal
     # Implicit output
```